# One 1, Two 1's, One 2 One 1

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

### Challenge:

Create a program that takes input of a positive non-zero integer and outputs the 4 next numbers in the sequence described below.

*Note: Checking if the input is actually a positive non-zero integer is not necessary*

### Sequence:

Every number in this sequence (apart from the first, which is the input) shall be composed of n digits, where n is an even number. If we split the number to n/2 pairs, for each pair, the first digit should be the amount of times the second digit appeared in the previous number

**Visual explanation**:
Consider this example "sequence starter" or input `6577`
The next number in the sequence should look like this `161527`
Because the input has 1 "6", 1 "5" and 2 "7"s.

If input has too many digits (more than 9 of a single digit) you wouldnt be able to get a correct output
Example: `111111111111` (12 1's)
Next number in sequence has to describe 12 1's. Thus we split it into 9 1's and 3 1's (sum 9+3 = 12)
Next number: `9131`

*You should iterate 4 times for the input, and output it (either return a list/array of 4 integers, or output it by seperating them with a space, newlines are also acceptable)*

**"The number can be written in a lot of ways, how do I write it?"**:
If you think about it, the example input `6577` can also be written as 271516 (two 7's, one 5, one six). However this is non-valid output. You should iterate the number left to right. Thus 161527. If it was `7657` you would iterate the amount of 7's, then amount of 6's then amount of 5's, thus valid output would be `271615`

### Example I/O:

Input:`75`
Output:`1715 211715 12311715 4112131715`

Input:`1`
Output:`11 21 1211 3112`

Input:`111111111111` (12 1's)
Output:`9131 192113 31191213 23411912`

---

This is unlike the "Say what you see" question, because the sequences are different: https://oeis.org/A005150 <- This one returns numbers like this:
Input: 1211 Output: 111221
While the sequence I'm asking for would do
Input: 1211 Output: 3112

The two sequences are different and require different algorithms.
My asked sequence: https://oeis.org/A063850
"Possible duplicate" sequence: https://oeis.org/A005150

---

**Important specification:**

Since it wasnt clear enough for some people who tried to answer this question, the correct output for k chars where k > 9 is not "kc" (where c is char) but 9c(k-9)c etc. Thus correct output for 12 1's isn't `121` (12 1) but `9131`(9 1's, (12-9) 1's and so on)

If in doubt, your code is wrong if it ever outputs a number with an odd amount of digits (like 121), it should have output of even digit numbers due to the nature of the sequence.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) thus code with least bytes wins.

Comment: Proposed testcase: `1111111111111111111` (19 *1's*)

Comment: [More closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90119/42545) (still not dupe though).

Comment: Can we output as a comma-separated list of integers? Can the output start with the input integer (and thus have length 5)?

Comment: In your last test case, shouldn't the last number be `23411912` instead of `23411219`?

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed. Thanks for pointing out. But no, you are not allowed to return a list of integers or output integers seperated with anything apart from newlines or spaces. And no, you shouldnt output the input

Comment: Input `1111112111111` do we output `913112` or `911231` (since the three `1`s all appear after the `2`)?

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>111</s> 104 bytes

```powershell
$z=$args;1..4|%{($z=-join($z-split'\B'|group|%{for($c,$n=$_.Count,$_.Name;$c-gt9;$c-=9){"9$n"}"$c$n"}))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@69SZauSWJRebG2op2dSo1qtARTQzcrPzAMydIsLcjJL1GOc1GvSi/JLC4DSaflFGirJOip5tirxes75pXklOkCGX2JuqrVKsm56iSWIsrXUrFayVMlTqlVSSQZRmpq1////N0QCAA)

Comment: Since you don't use `$i` in your loop, why not just [loop directly](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15352/42963) like `$z=$args;0..3|%{...`

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I thought about it but felt it would be longer after having to assign `$args` (and I originally thought I would use `$i`). I was going to measure it but then the question got closed.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork ...aaaand edited (thanks)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 116 bytes

```python
x=input()
exec"x=''.join(x.count(n)/9*(`9`+n)+`x.count(n)%9`+n for i,n in enumerate(x)if n not in x[:i]);print x;"*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TchBCoMwEAXQfU8xCJIZLZZCNyqeRAopEmEK/ZGQwNw@xVX7lq/aojhKZrkEC1tji3PDOyrYhi0WZIbcxo796HtI73/bnkN7TKRXkIICyiekVw5sojuBEPP5tk76lPlIikw2N92jVnf/474)

Comment: Output for 19 ones `1111111111111111111` is incorrect. Should be `919111` but gives `919121`

Comment: Output wrong for many values. Example: http://image.prntscr.com/image/ed4c523b105b41169e8aa8c46a95f963.png , With input `11` output should be `21 1211 3112 132112`, I dont understand why it outputs `111` as the first iteration which causes the whole chain to go badly

Comment: @P.Ktinos the input format was wrong, it need to be a string (it must be the leftover of the tests that i was doing). Fixed the link

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
4F©Ùv9y«®y¢9‰`U×XyJ}=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/idmjl4ZlllpWHVh9aV3lokeWjhg0JoYenR1R61dr@/2@ICQA)

**Explanation**

```
4F                     # 4 times do:
  ©                    # store a copy of the current number in register
   Ùv                  # for each unique digit y in the number
     9y«               # concatenate 9 with y
        ®y¢            # count occurrences of y in current number
           9‰          # divmod by 9
             `U        # store the result of modulus in X
               ×       # repeat the number "9y" result_of_div times
                X      # push result of modulus
                 y     # push y
                  J    # join everything to one number
                   }   # end inner loop
                    =  # print the current number without popping
```

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: That won't work for number with more than 9 repetitions of a digit, like the example in my TIO link for example.

Comment: Ohhh... I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 117 bytes

```
Grid@{Rest@NestList[FromDigits[Join@@(Reverse/@Tally@IntegerDigits@#//.{a_,b_}/;a>9->{9,b}~Sequence~{a-9,b})]&,#,4]}&
```

Seems like it shouldn't need to be this long.

Answer (score 1):

## C# 246 bytes

```
namespace System{using Linq;using f=String;class p{static void Main(f[] s){f p=s[0];for(int i=0,n;i++<4;Console.Write(p+" "))p=f.Concat(p.GroupBy(c=>c).SelectMany(g=>new int[(n=g.Count())/9].Select(_ =>"9"+g.Key).Concat(new[]{n%9+""+g.Key})));}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
namespace System
{
    using Linq;
    using f = String;
    class p
    {
        static void Main(f[] s)
        {
            f p = s[0];
            for (int i = 0, n; i++ < 4; Console.Write(p + " "))

                p = f.Concat(p.GroupBy(c => c).SelectMany(g =>
                    new int[(n = g.Count()) / 9].Select(_ => "9" + g.Key).Concat(new[] { n % 9 + "" + g.Key }
                )));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rxarw) (Type input into bottom frame once its compiled and hit ENTER)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
L,Ḣ
D©®i$ÞŒgs9$€Ç€€FḌµ4µÐ¡Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@@j83DHIi6XQysPrctUOTzv6KT0YkuVR01rDrcDCSBye7ij59BWk0NbD084tPDhjq7///8bIgEA)

The successive `€`s cannot be nested because chains cannot be nested.

[Nesting with separate link: 27 bytes.](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19seWirj87DHYsObX3UtIbL5dDKQ@syVQ7POzop/XA7UMTt4Y6ehztbDm01ObQQqKRx2////w2RAAA)

[Print instead of cumulation: 27 bytes.](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19seWirj87DHYsObX3UtIbL5dDKQ@syVQ7POzop/XA7UMTt4Y6ehztbDm01ObQQqKRx2////w2RAAA)

**Explanation**

```
L,Ḣ                     - helper function, does the look-and-say. Input is a list of digits
 ,                      - return 2-tuple of:
L                       -   length of input
  Ḣ                     -   first element of input

D©®i$ÞŒgs9$€Ç€€FḌµ4µÐ¡Ḋ - main link, takes input as integer
                 µ4µÐ¡  - repeat 4 times, saving the results of each iteration:
D                       -   convert integer to list of digits
 ©                      -   save into register, for later use
  ®i$Þ                  -   sort list's elements by first occurrence in list
      Œg                -   group runs of equal elements
        s9$€            -   split each run into sets which are at most 9 elements long
            Ç€€         -   do the look-and-say with helper function
               FḌ       -   flatten and convert back into integer for next iteration
                      Ḋ - remove the first element from the list since it includes the
                           initial element
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 141 Bytes

```php
for($a=$argn;$i++<4;$a=$o,print$a._,$o="")foreach(array_count_values(str_split($a))as$n=>$c)$o.=str_repeat("9$n",$c/9^0).($c%9?($c%9).$n:"");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HY1BCsMgFET3PYb8ghKxXbSUxNjcpPIR2wSCytcUenprshmYecPMOKU5nQDpEwx73Jmu70gc0ByRhqXrxpvefZSJllAAlZUQDWOiNT26mSMR/qyLWyj2i@vmM8@FbE7rUtqUEJghmCc4AVGZHZFPHgtnPQQmwV3611UoDu7cT4cKBWFoD7rWPw)