# Sort by what the digit pairs describe

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, sorting

Given a positive integer, we can form a new number that's described by its digits taken pairwise (with a leading 0 added for numbers with odd number of digits).

For eg.:

- 1234 can be read as one 2, three 4s - so, the output for 1234 is 2444.
- 643 has an odd number of digits, so a leading zero is added to make it even. Then, 0643 can be read as: zero 6s, four 3s, hence the output would be 3333.

(This is [OEIS A056967](http://oeis.org/A056967)).

**Task:** Given an array of positive integers, sort them by their digit-pair-described value, in ascending order. Order does not matter between input numbers that lead to the same value.

**Input**: an array/list/set of positive integers. Leading zeros in the input are **not** allowed, and input as strings/lists of digits/etc. are not allowed - the inputs should be as close to an integer/numeric type as your language is capable of using.

**Output**: the array sorted in the above-mentioned way, returned in any of the usual ways (function return value/STDOUT/shouting into the void/etc.) You can print them individually, return them as numbers, strings, or lists of digits.

#### Test cases

```
Input 
Output

[19, 91, 2345, 2023]
[19, 2023, 2345, 91]

[25257, 725, 91, 5219, 146125, 14620512]
[725, 5219, 14620512, 91, 146125, 25257]

[123130415 3335 91 111111111 528 88]
[528, 111111111, 123130415, 3335, 88, 91]

[1 21 33 4 5]
[1 4 5 21 33]

[3725, 10, 2537, 1, 1225, 2512]
[10, 1, 1225, 2512, 2537, 3725]

[125, 26, 1115, 1024] 
[1115, 1024, 125, 26]
```

(In the 4th test case, 1, 4, and 5 all evaluate to 0, and so can be sorted among themselves in any order. Similarly in the fifth test case, 10 and 1 both evaluate to 0s, and so can be sorted in either order.)

(Related: [Say what you see](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70837/say-what-you-see), [One 1, Two 1's, One 2 One 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108831/one-1-two-1s-one-2-one-1)

*Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for help clarifying the question in the Sandbox.*

Comment: Can we take a list of lists of digits as input? Can we output a list of lists of digits?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Input should be as a list of integers, not lists of digits. Output can be a list of lists of digits though, if that's somehow more convenient.

Comment: as pointed out by @mnel, [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170806/80010) won't work for numbers above 10 digits. is it legit to keep it as is, or should I modify it at the cost of 32 bytes.

Comment: @JayCe If I understand correctly, the limitation is because that's the limit of the integer type in R -  because `strtoi` returns an integer - correct? If so, that's fine, it's legal as it is.

Comment: you are correct! will keep it as is.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

Thanks ngn for saving 1 byte :)

```
{⍵[⍋⌽↑,⍨⌿⍴⌿0 10⊤⍵⊤⍨⍴⍨100]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9DcJADIV7pvAAIPnnnLvMgigiodBEghYh2hSQk2AHigwAJWIXLxJ8keLC9vP7/JpTt9mfm@54mKbW@sfF8mdr@W7D1/rn2vJow8/y2zsCod1eDsx9LNc8EuLu6r9ANdQELEGBkWXVAitrhMhaDGUHKFTk0gejEjtDLCQYSEFEZpCW8pcEKRUImNyHAOpKSiKhx0t0i9glL2m@ViWiEBz@)

Inspiration take from [dzaima & ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170779/71256)

Comment: `100⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵` -> `⍵⊤⍨⍵/100` works for 26.

Comment: I don't really want WSFULLs on the given test cases

Comment: 26 is possible with MAXWS=1M

Comment: `100⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵` -> `⍵⊤⍨⍴⍨100`

Comment: @ngn Nice. I see no reason why `100⍴100` isn't enough

Comment: @H.PWiz right, even with `⎕FR←1287` the precision is only ~34 decimal digits

Comment: @H.PWiz and here's a different solution for 26 bytes: `{⍵[⍋⌽↑,⍨⌿⍴⌿⊃⊥⍣¯1/10 100⍵]}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṚẋƝm2ṚFḌµÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlkPd3Ufm5trBGS5PdzRc2jr4Xn///@PNjI1MjXXUTA3MtVRsDTUUTA1MrTUUTA0MTMEiQBpIwNTQ6NYAA)

[Check out a test suite!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlkPd3Ufm5trBGS5PdzRc2jr4Xn/D7c/alrj/v9/dLShpY6CpaGOgpGxiSmQNDAyjtVRiDYyNTI111EwNzKFyJoagdQZmpgZgkSAtJGBqaERSKWhkbGhsYGJIVDY2NgYqtwQBkA6LXQULCzASoHmG4KU6SiYACViYwE)

#### How it works

```
ṚẋƝm2ṚFḌµÞ    Monadic link / Full program.                            | Example: [25257, 725, 91, 5219, 146125, 14620512]
        µÞ    Sort the input list by the result of the monadic link:  | Example: 725
Ṛ             Promote N to its digit array and reverse it.            | [5, 2, 7]
 ẋƝ           For each two consecutive digits x, y, repeat x y times. | [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
   m2         Modular 2. Take every other element of this array.      | [[5, 5]]
     Ṛ        Reverse.                                                | [[5, 5]]
      F       Flatten.                                                | [5, 5]
       Ḍ      Convert from decimal to integer.                        | 55
```

Comment: It definitely is a coincidence: `2537` and `3725` don't represent the same number.

Comment: Could you give me a test case that would catch that, and I'll add that to the question?

Comment: @sundar As Erik said, `[2537, 3725]`. I never doubted that this is a coincidence, hence I included that note to the answer

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Testcase added, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 141 bytes

```r
(s<-scan(,""))[order(strtoi(sapply(s,function(x)paste(strrep((m=matrix(c(if(nchar(x)%%2)0,el(strsplit(x,""))),2))[2,],m[1,]),collapse=""))))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9LasMwEN3nFCIhIMEEPCMrH2gO0FUPELQwrkMNji0kBdLTuzPKp7Te@Pn9/CbOq/cxXLNarD6umcFisTrhQR1Qka2dooqsLxQUDIUG1r04yZHbqR05CTjiINZb5E9@UeWQJMsyFBFetBTAw8uV0lL6kCzaqkanrLWlFJ8PN@zVfi@FjOBXYPhMQYkB214L@Q5kVtXKlTsE3Kki2zIOKxlhd4yk7b7pPl6kP@TTKcnHZi7cyh4@u6LaKyERSy/VkpXo1s86vW1S24walktjTlP87KJOOeap16kJYfjWCc7Xsc39NOqbCU3KnRhiF7S@HC9Njv1Nt7o/67H9aiJ71msyFXSD2FIY@qxvpd0A8S8IPFxOCN5AOw1DE1J3LKrx8//d8w8)

Rather laborious answer - but it works on all test cases.
Builds the digit-pair output and sorts the input according to this.

Comment: I posted my approach on another answer since I was working on it on this afternoon but I was interrupted. Just to assure you I didn't get inspiration from yours without credits ;)

Comment: @digEmAll no worries :) - Actually I think I took the name `v` for the variable from your other answers - I never used `v` before. And nice use of  `intToUtf8`!

Comment: ahah I'm really jealous of my single letter variables names ! No, seriously... coming from StackOverflow everytime I post a "similar" alternative it feels like stealing ;)

Comment: strtoi will return NA for integers above 10 digits, (as.numeric won't )

Comment: @mnel thanks for pointing out ! I checked with sundar and since it's a limitation of the integer type I can leave it as is :)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 120 bytes

```r
(v=scan())[order(sapply(v,function(n,e=nchar(n))sum((a=rep((x=n%/%10^(0:(e-1-e%%2))%%10)[!0:1],x[!1:0]))*10^seq(a=a))))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLToNAFN3zFbdpiDNmWucBLW3CB7hy445ggjgoSTtUXrYxfjveC33oLODe8@IM9TCHL3tXW7D7bpe1pXuHJs8clK6tIIOic3lbVg6KqobWNi3kWWMhr1xvXWldbgHJ58cnYE22t/B6aontXNtwr4gvdtbzb4q9AcvlkvcD62OCGedJVb/ZGkMOh92J9eIqdMLGLv/IauY4b7o9Y1lc2wNjx9j5D76SL0xumV2ohfV9zbmPEE9mcqtScUxmaitTzu9R1thPtGYcTzr8eF7BcqY2YqOENkEotNSGc2@eIAa04JNw2Kh0EutQh2ux1iF5Qo06FawUrvjSMlR6tBMPIwsXnDLGjcQwxpwjlTbKyECFwhgz5qrLwS9EIorGTBrhxsDNBqMPouhPT7yQwjwRiHC6EE0TdlaYsaSSVMascaLIqdv5FsT9Qy9Ssl7LY@qKGuMvkDqYjLQBreQm8yr1hl8)

- -11 bytes thanks to @sundar "arithmetical" suggestion !

**Ungolfed code with explanation :**

```r
# define a function G which takes a number 'n' and uncompress it multiplied by 10
# e.g. 2735 -> 775550, 61345 -> 355550 etc.
G=function(n){
  e = nchar(n)                   # get the n.of digits in the compressed number

  x = n%/%10^(0:(e-1-e%%2))%%10  # split 'n' into vector of digits reversed adding 
                                 # trailing zero if 'e' is odd (e.g. 123 -> c(0,3,2,1))

  even = x[!0:1]                 # take only the odd elements of 'x' (= even digits)
  odd  = x[!1:0]                 # take only the even elements of 'x' (= odd digits)
                                 # N.B. :
                                 # these tricks work because !0:1 is c(TRUE,FALSE)
                                 # and V[c(TRUE,FALSE)] exploits the fact that R 
                                 # automatically recycles the logical indexes up to the
                                 # length of the vector V

  a = rep(even,odd)              # repeat each value in 'even' 'odd' times obtaining the
                                 # uncompressed number as digits vector. Note that in
                                 #  case of single digit 'n', 'a' will be an empty vector

  sum(a*10^seq(a=a))             # multiplies 'a' * 10^(1:length(a)) and sum 
                                 # obtaining the uncompressed number multiplied by 10
                                 # N.B. in case of empty 'a', we get 0
}

v = scan()                       # take vector v from stdin

w = sapply(v,G(n))               # apply G to all numbers of 'v'

v[order(w)]                      # use the uncompressed values as weights to sort 'v'
```

Comment: The `[!1:0]` trick is real nice - never seen it before.

Comment: @sundar: explanation added ;)

Comment: Nice. I knew those `[!1:0]` fellas were hiding something neat. I was playing around with this and the tips on R golfing, trying to get the number from the digits arithmetically (without `as.double`), but only came up with a 132 byte version: [TIO](https://tio.run/##RYzBaoRAEETvfkUvi6Q7zBpHsnsQ/ICccslNDEyGdiNoKzOj2SXJt5txIUkfGqrqVbl1Dx985xh4mHsTOjmDt0agkzCCgXYWG7pRoB0dBPYBrPEMdpSFpWOxDDF8eXoG9GZgeLuGLZ0leEra6reOC31us/9GlmW0rLhUm41EtR9dyPrOhzg0Tf0VF/UHi@JK7LtxKER@HjD2HE@Il0rSh1Tnr4h80AdO04LKnNJoUb3TZd6oS73LS90Q3d@wrb18aTroDYzXrN9J0qJFXRxVcVJa66PSefFIlOzrm4JNxh8BKE5Nsv4A)

Comment: @sundar: I didn't think to the arithmetical approach... I saved 11 bytes, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes

```
oir9c.[Z2jNT2T
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=oir9c.%5BZ2jNT2T&input=%5B25257%2C+725%2C+91%2C+5219%2C+146125%2C+14620512%5D&debug=0) | [Test suite!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=oir9c.%5BZ2jNT2T&input=%5B25257%2C+725%2C+91%2C+5219%2C+146125%2C+14620512%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B25257%2C+725%2C+91%2C+5219%2C+146125%2C+14620512%5D%0A%5B19%2C+91%2C+2345%2C+2023%5D%0A%5B123130415%2C+3335%2C+91%2C+111111111%2C+528%2C+88%5D%0A%5B1%2C+21%2C+33%2C+4%2C+5%5D&debug=0) | [12 bytes with list of digits I/O](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=oir9c.%5BZ2N2T&input=%5B25257%2C+725%2C+91%2C+5219%2C+146125%2C+14620512%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B2%2C+5%2C+2%2C+5%2C+7%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+2%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B5%2C+2%2C+1%2C+9%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+4%2C+6%2C+1%2C+2%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+4%2C+6%2C+2%2C+0%2C+5%2C+1%2C+2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+9%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+0%2C+2%2C+3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+1%2C+3%2C+0%2C+4%2C+1%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B5%2C+2%2C+8%5D%2C+%5B8%2C+8%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+3%5D%2C+%5B4%5D%2C+%5B5%5D%5D&debug=0)**

#### How it works?

```
oir9c.[Z2jNT2T – Full program.
o              – Sort the input list by the results of the following code (variable: N).
         jNT   – Cast the current element to a list of digits.
     .[Z2      – Pad it on the left with 0s to the nearest multiple of 2.
    c       2  – Split in pieces of length 2.
  r9           – Run length decode.
 i           T – Cast the list of digits to a base 10 integer.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, <s>41</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```apl
f←⊂⌷¨⍨∘⍋{10⊥∊⍴⌿0 10⊤100⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵}¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw7CsJAEIZ7TzEXEHZmdvI4TkBiE9BWxMZCwpoFS2sfkM5GsRRylLlInA1kmp1//2@@atssV7uq2azHsdbTRcNRu@/Qa@y1vWo879FpeGobNL61@zlI@YFu@o334YUabho/h6E3A2AJJQKxFyBHvKiBhCSHnCQVQgagz9CiPeQEyRgkRnYeBZh5AnEeOymgKBIEhNaDB7HEyYjO9JxbhWSRZputWVIkgvwf)

-2 thanks to [Cows quack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/cows-quack)
-4 (plus -4 for the base conversion idea) thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)
-2 thanks so [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)

Comment: `⊃,/` can become `∊`

Comment: @Cowsquack I knew I was forgetting a built-in :p

Comment: `{⍺⍴⍨⍎⍵}` -> `⍴⍨∘⍎`

Comment: @ngn of course, I can never remember all the jot/train things

Comment: here's another trick for -1 byte - trainify `{⍵[⍋F ⍵]}` as `⊂⌷¨⍨∘⍋F`

Comment: Can `⍴/⍉` be `⍴⌿`?

Comment: You should also be able to use `0 10⊤`

Comment: 27 bytes: `{⍵[⍋⌽↑,⍨⌿⍴⌿0 10⊤100⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵]}`

Comment: @H.PWiz submit that as another answer, it contains pretty much nothing that I thought of :p

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (32bit systems), <strike>188</strike> <strike>177</strike> 176 bytes

```c
char*p,*q,c[99],b[99]="0";i;d(x){for(p=b+!(sprintf(b+1,"%d",x)&1),q=c;i=*p++;++p)for(i-=48;i--;*q++=*p);*q=0;atoi(c);}m(int*a,int*b){return d(*a)-d(*b);}s(l,c){qsort(l,c,4,m);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHfasIwFMbvfYqs4EiaU2j@OSXrk4gXbTpdYNXa1jEovvq6k1k3L8QxMBcnh5Pf930hccnGuWFwr3kT1xDvwS0XixUUoWZRGllvS/rB@vWuoXVW8Afa1o3fdmtacAHRtIzggz0KBvvMWZ/FNeeW85oF3ieZnlufJDbec45nDJsstXm389Qxe6woOsU5hFqwvnnpDs2WlDTOWYK1QKSlb@BYv293TRda0FDheEAJqXK/pe87X7JJPyG4wrATyxXJSC8WQBYCiFTaYE2lOtpfSJ4gaaR5AvIkzQk2MsiEnokwwV2mRshLoRrdpRIq1QIppdSoFucVjOZA5vNLpR6VeBkRVEA0cpeEORF/3@Zb0tIOGc1OBuOnREsSjZPvH0Bbj56pxe2ZaEs49@wHnpYkgvBifnW2OXQtjVbB4xwigcz@EzK7HiJvhqj7hKibIeG9/xNirofomyHmPiHmashxMny69Vu@aYekUvIL)

on `amd64` add flag `-m32` for compiling.

**Usage**: `s(x,n);` where `x` points to an array of integers to sort and `n` is the length of that array.

Second test case gives wrong result because converting `25257` gives `2222277777` which overflows a 32bit integer -- added a 5th test case without that number.

#### Explanation:

```c
char*p,                                     // d(): input pointer
    *q,                                     // d(): output pointer
    c[99],                                  // d(): output buffer
    b[99]="0";                              // d(): input buffer
                                            //      (fixed first char 0)
i;                                          // d(): repeat counter

d(x){                                       // conversion function
    for(
            p=b+!(sprintf(b+1,"%d",x)&1),   // print number in decimal to
                                            // input buffer, starting at second
                                            // character, initialize input
                                            // pointer to first or second char
                                            // depending on the length of the
                                            // number
            q=c;                            // initialize output pointer
            i=*p++;                         // set repeat counter to digit and
                                            // point to next digit, stop when
                                            // NUL character is found
            ++p)                            // point to next digit after loop
        for(i-=48;i--;*q++=*p);             // inner loop, append current digit
                                            // i-48 ('0') times to output buffer
    *q=0;                                   // terminate output with NUL
    atoi(c);                                // convert to number, 'return' not
                                            // needed as atoi() leaves result
                                            // on the stack
}

m(int*a,int*b){                             // comparison function for qsort
    return d(*a)-d(*b);                     // return difference of converted
}                                           // values

s(l,c){                                     // sorting function
    qsort(l,c,4,m);                         // only "wrap" qsort, assuming
}                                           // sizeof(int) is 4
```

Comment: Your function `d()` is long because of strings and functions related to them, you can save many bytes just by reading the last 2 digits and building the output like this : `o;u;i;d(x){for(u=1,o=0;x;x/=100)for(i=0;i++<x%100/10;o+=x%10*u,u*=10);x=o;}m(int*a,int*b){u=d(*a)-d(*b);}s(l,c){qsort(l,c,4,m);}` you will also save bytes by avoiding declaring and initializing `char`s.

Comment: Nice idea -- I think working on the integer values makes this a completely different approach, so you should consider posting an answer? :)

Comment: Suggest `b-~sprintf(b+1,"%d",x)%2` instead of `b+!(sprintf(b+1,"%d",x)&1)`

Comment: @Annyo suggest `x/10%10` instead of `x%100/10`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 53 bytes

```perl6
*.sort(+*.flip.comb.rotor(2).map({[x] $_}).join.flip)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvdCoJAEIXve4q5iNg1WZxZxx@sXkQkLBIMbWX1IomefVuLai7OwDnfN1xsl7h@hk0Dexeo0dhJbAPVdO2gzqY/KWsmYwVJ1deDeJT3CtbHp1RX097elHTFaqxnaESJeQg5hkA6Zp8R6Ur@RmLiNISU@AMxLTjGCS6N/xQx0l/YIWnUUYwMWmv2DuD3vJxBlh1k4V4)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that takes a list of values and sorts it by what the pairs of numbers describe.

In this case, I'm reversing the number, then `rotor`ing the list by two to get each pair of numbers. This will exclude the first digit for numbers of odd length, but since that translates to `0` times that number, it's okay. Plus, it lines up the values to use `[x]` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>89</s> 88 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to ovs*

```hs
import Data.List
(%)=mod
m?n|n<1=0|n%100<10=m?div n 100|w<-n-10=m*10?w+m*n%10
sortOn(1?)
```

The last line defines an anonymous function that can be used like so:

```hs
> sortOn(1?)[19, 91, 2345, 2023]
[19,2023,2345,91]
```

The core functionality is provided by the infix operator `(?)` which keeps track of a multiplier, `m`, and the remaining RLE input `n`. `(?)` continually subtracts 10 from `n` whilst there is a tens digit to subtract from, and as it does so it pushes another copy of the final digit to the front of the output (via the multiplier `m`, which is increased by 10 each time). When the tens place is exhausted, the final two digits are discarded and the process repeats until the number is reduced to 0. Finally, we use the operator (with an initial multiplier of 1) as a sort key.

Comment: `m?n|n<1=0|n%100<10=m?div n 100|w<-n-10=m*10?w+m*n%10` is a byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```python
def g(l):l.sort(key=f)
f=lambda n:+(n>9)and int(`f(n/100)`+n/10%10*`n%10`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDdasMwDIXv@xS6Gdir6SzJbpNA9yKlkIzU25jrlCw3ffpM8n5gvpDko09H2Lf78jYVWtfxkuDVZNvl3ec0L@bjcj8mu0nHPFxfxgFKtzXlubVDGeG9LKZPpjyh97bfan5A/9gXib1d0zRDFghO2Dpo0QFxiBI98dnBiSLFg4MDxe9uJOUw7FEVyeQjkpJIjOwDiszMPzj@Hp1sHDRNRcUfFXMQpKES1w3opRNZFuosqUR/9nrZV8tKUjh3G4DbLC@ELJX@yD@hVusX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
ÖödṁΓ*C_2d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7///C0w9tSHu5sPDdZyzneKOX////RpiY6hkY6RsY6xkbGhrEA)

## Explanation

```
ÖödṁΓ*C_2d    Full function
Ö             Sort the input list by the result of...
 ö            The composition of these four functions:
         d      Convert to a list of digits
      C_2       Split into length-2 sublists starting at the end
   ṁ            Map the following function and concatenate the results:
    Γ*            Repeat the list tail X times, where X is the list head
  d             Convert back to an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>97</s> 101 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,key=lambda x:int(''.join(v*int(c)for c,v in zip(*[iter(`x`[len(`x`)%2:])]*2))or 0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/vasMgEP@@pzgYpRpk5E5dTaBPkgnt2oS5pSZkobR7@UxNU8rmB@/u90@vv44fnaep2b5N7f70ftxDW353w1gfWSu@6uv2hl5K50e2Xr98ds6zcxanA2@6AQ7iDM7Dj@tZVrmxHtjusqva2sfKV1RabjPiPEhzzqd@CFZoWIWFgAIFkFQ63DlJy58hwXFYiALt091DmvRGwIb07NUU5aheMSKhUq6RUk7S3PmEz55FnbIespEkylxhoKSUtwdwOTHLCDAmhaf@gfvnNebPz@OiGFkBKmTNq4ICHeCA2ukX)

Comment: @sundar No worries, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 13 bytes

```
ñ_ì_ò2n)®rçÃ¬
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8V/sX/IybimucufDrA==&input=WzE5LDkxLDIzNDUsMjAyM10KLVE=) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8V/sX/IybimucufDrA==&input=WwpbMTksOTEsMjM0NSwyMDIzXQpbMjUyNTcsNzI1LDkxLDUyMTksMTQ2MTI1LDE0NjIwNTEyXQpbMTIzMTMwNDE1LDMzMzUsOTEsMTExMTExMTExLDUyOCw4OF0KWzEsMjEsMzMsNCw1XQpdLW1S)

---

### Explanation

```
ñ_                :Sort by passing each integer through a function
  ì_              :  Split to an array of digits, pass it through the following function and implicitly convert back to an integer
    ò2n)          :    Starting from the end of the array, split at every second element
        ®         :    Map
         rç       :      Reduce X & Y by repeating X Y times
           Ã      :    End mapping
            ¬     :    Join
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
{↔ġ₂ẹ{Ċj₎|Ȯt}ˢ↔c}ᵒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pR25QjCx81NT3ctbP6SFfWo6a@mhPrSmpPLwJKJNc@3Drp//9oQyNjQ2MDE0NTHQVjY2MgaWmoo2AIAzoKpkYWOgoWFrH/owA)

#### Explanation

Loads of small stuff needed to account for the three different cases: odd number of digits, pair of 0 times a number, and normal pairs.

```
{               }ᵒ     Order the Input according to the output of this predicate
 ↔                       Reverse the number
  ġ₂                     Group into pairs; the last digit is alone if there are
                           an odd number of them
    ẹ{      }ˢ           For each group:
      Ċ                    If there are two elements
       j₎                  Juxtapose the first one as many times as the second
                             element (won't work if the second element is 0)
         |                 Else
          Ȯ                If there is one element (odd number of digits)
           t               just take that element
                           (Else don't select anything, i.e. 0 repetitions)
              ↔c         Reverse and concatenate back into an integer
```

Comment: I think the `|Ȯt` is unnecessary, and in fact makes it sort wrong: it's equivalent to padding with a 1 instead of a 0, so given [125, 26, 1], sorts it as [1, 26, 125] instead of [1, 125, 26].

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 76 bytes

A function instead of a one-liner for once.

Quite straight forward: `g` sorts the inputs numerically, using `h` to convert the numbers. `h` does this by using the regex `s/(.)(.)/$2x$1/gre` (which is probably readable enough). And the `0` left-padding is done with `0 x("@_"=~y///c%2)."@_"` (where `y///c` is a shorted way of writing `length`, `x` is the repetition operator and `.` the concatenation).

```perl
sub h{(0 x("@_"=~y///c%2)."@_")=~s/(.)(.)/$2x$1/gre}sub g{sort{h($a)-h$b}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY79aoMwFMX/9ykuwUECWeO9MaulOHyPTmQdnTo2FbXQIvbV3c10IeTj/M7JSXfpv92yDNczVJOM4CZFVoj0cTfGfDyR2vmrSh@DkTvF04R0C9GU/WX2mXIa2n6cKhm@q@cqPM9ZMS8/d8jqpruOA6QgIQA44UHDATWQjR2vEdlce50cub2GPbmVO/JOjF/QK7xT5JBWL5JFG8XIwFq7BfB/@GyiIUk2M7egN2qIGa2i/evBiJmzXOvz5CXyJYE6Bp9tD3L7vIKJQ11fNyOIUxYWOQCkafrKLwkNX23dgAA@lZKh0iDyt0Ycg3n5BQ)

I'm expecting to see some shorter Perl answers though!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΣDgÉi¦}2ôε`sиJ}J0ìï
```

Bug-fixed for +1 byte, and then golfed by -2 bytes thanks to *@sundar*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3GKX9MOdmYeW1Rod3nJua0LxhR1etV4Gh9ccXv//f7SRqZGpuY6CuZGpjoKloY6CqZGhpY6CoYmZIUgESBsZmBoa6SiYxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##TYw9CsJQEIR7TxFSb/F29m1@KpsgmCuEgAoiqSxSpxVsvYJgJdgoWJs@eAYvEvcJAbfZnZ1vZt@uN812TBfLYh5Hn8MpiufjcC52/bF5XTr09@Gxat/Psitdf@1vY0djxTnlTBCvBAepZxUUmlIKDYbCAPYJm7QFpwxjGMLiPCuJyA/kaSySUZYFiMDmkyc1JaGRHUElJeNhElObnUmoCAT836v@Ag).

Can definitely be golfed.. Not too happy about it tbh..

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ                    # Sort by:
 Dg                  #  Duplicate the current number, and take it's length
                     #   i.e. 25257 → 5
                     #   i.e. 4 → 1
   Éi }              #  If this length is odd:
     ¦               #   Remove the first digit
                     #    i.e. 25257 → '5257'
                     #    i.e. 4 → ''
       2ô            #  Then split the number in pieces of 2
                     #   i.e. '5257' → ['52','57']
                     #   i.e. '' → []
         ε    }      #  And map each to:
          `          #   Push both digits to the stack
                     #    i.e. '52' → '5' and '2'
           s         #   Swap them
            и        #   Repeat the first digit the second digit amount of times
                     #    i.e. '2' and '5' → ['2','2','2','2','2']
             J       #   Join the list of digits together
                     #    i.e. ['2','2','2','2','2'] → '22222'
               J     #  Join all numbers back together again
                     #   i.e. ['','22222','77777'] → '2222277777'
                     #   i.e. [] → ''
                0ì   #  Prepend a 0 (because `Σ` will put all '' at the back)
                     #   i.e. 2222277777 → '02222277777'
                     #   i.e. '' → '0'
                  ï  #  Cast it to an integer, because sorting is done string-wise by
                     #  default despite 05AB1E's interchangeability of strings and numbers;
                     #  and it's also to remove all leading zeros
                     #   i.e. '02222277777' → 2222277777
                     #   i.e. '0' → 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 44 bytes

```
^.?((..)*)$
$1 $&
%)`\G(\d)(.)
$1*$2
N`
.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P07PXkNDT09TS1OFS8VQQUWNS1UzIcZdIyZFU0NPEyikpWLE5ZfApaetwPX/v5Gpkak5l7mRKZelIZepkaEll6GJmSGQC6SMDEwNjQA) Generating the sort key at the start of the line is harder but the short sort stage results in an overall 3 byte saving. Explanation:

```
%)`
```

Apply the first two stages on each line individually.

```
^.?((..)*)$
$1 $&
```

Match and copy an even number of trailing digits.

```
\G(\d)(.)
$1*$2
```

Replace each digit pair with their described value. The `\G\d` causes the match to stop at the space.

```
N`
```

Sort numerically.

```
.+
```

Delete the sort keys.

Comment: That's a clever trick to sort by a key. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>(g=n=>n&&g(n/100|0)+''.padEnd(n/10%10,n%10))(a)-g(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BbsIwDIbve4pcBrEIXWwnUA7pbU8x7RAoVCCUIIo48e7FKdtl6nJwJOf77D@neI/97nq83JYpt/vhEIYYmlj1@XrTOpothEZ3IYUmzWadTh9o7cPCYj6vLrH9TO3YekdrkhQAHWHZ6S3AsMupz@d9dc6dPugv3Bi1QaOInZdqib8B3v5A5MmvjVqTf8GeioZuhaUjN1mPNCEiMbJ1KBQz/9j4e8qg2qi6njIlDBbLKCfcBMFjHPmhIs@Srkym0qL/spS31bh/FMkJNTwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 50 bytes

```
SortBy!N@Flip##~`&&>PadRight&0&2=>Chop&2@Flip@List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwEIb3PkVEyZQhd5doFRRRcBIRdSsBS422IFpMFhdfvSbVCt6QwP99d3/ufV6UtjmzybTZ3x9@8ext5qtrVff7ryPns21@2lWX0nPJcTpblveaY8vn68r5ZmPtyWWDui4uJkm2j@rmD9b5Ze6sy86CZQkLk8FYsDEIhqR0eCWSER@CGvVIsBHqj6ExuqCGEJPwo9SAnQ1IQFJBQET0XYFu4nYqWJr@9NAFURVMBdjF1LaBDFRTKI83MEb4VxWDYXu@tVGZxJjmDQ)

### Explanation

```
SortBy!N@Flip##~`&&>PadRight&0&2=>Chop&2@Flip@List      anonymous function, argument: [a1..aN]
SortBy!                                                 sort the given array by grading f[ai]
                                                        e.g. 42513
                                              List      digits of ai
                                                        e.g. [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
                                         Flip@          flip the digits around
                                                        e.g. [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
                                  Chop&2@               chop into groups of 2
                                                        e.g. [[3, 1], [5, 2], [4]]
                    PadRight&0&2=>                      pad each group to size 2 with 0's
                                                        e.g. [[3, 1], [5, 2], [0, 4]]
                  &>                                    using each sub array as arguments...
               ~`&                                      ...repeat the 2nd the 1st amount of times
                                                        e.g. [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], []]
             ##                                         then:
         Flip                                           reverse the groups
                                                        e.g. [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1]]
       N@                                               then convert it to an number
                                                        e.g. 22222111
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
DŻLḂ$¡ẋ@2/ẎḌµÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6G6fhzuaVA4tfLir28FI/@Guvoc7eg5tPTzv////0UamRqbmOgrmRqY6CpaGOgqmRoaWOgqGJmaGIBEgbWRgamgUCwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, <s>204</s> 189 bytes

```java
L->{L.sort((a,b)->Long.compare(s(a+""),s(b+"")));}long s(String s){var r="";for(int l=s.length(),i=l%2;i<l;)r+=s.split("")[++i].repeat(s.charAt(i++-1)-48);return r.isEmpty()?0:new Long(r);}
```

Takes a List of Longs as parameter and sorts this input-List (without returning a new List).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fVPLbtswELz7KxYGipKwzJiUlThVnCIFcmihpof05uZAK0zMVA@DXDkwAn@7u5TkJm6LCgJJcWd3h8PRk97o8dP9z31eaO/hq7bVywDAVmjcg84N3IRPgE1t7yFnTwQXDdpCXDmnt5n1eJHV1eMlZDwl4G5Aww1UMId9Nr58yYSvHTKmoyUfXwakyOtyrZ1hnunRcMgjz5Zh5jzdDVI4OYGbGoEQCPUD4MrAcotmnNdNhYOCCoBnt@hsWPCXjXbg5sNh@lA7RqShmHtRmOoRV4xHdl68U6m9KFLuRnNn1kYj88KvC4uMei5GI3sXeZGvtLtCZkejseTj6YynzmDjKnDC@utyjVvGP04@VOYZwhGYI657gHWzLGwOHjXS1CpUkn49vcUdaN6Jh8Yjk@dZdC6zSMXThMaJijvJ@rBKVHKWRWcq6WCJCglyeirDDs1qkkh1lCJVLOPJVFI8juM@Tx6eUGKWRbPZcQ61lgGfRVNCHMXitrmcECSJiUuopsKW@rtz2D1tu7Upavrm/t8K0sLbexfitx7/cREZJ8j8D8Sf3vNC@3Zf855aSAwGZlxUImcHxrdbj6YUdYNiTReDRcUOZAHoJctdl02hsSYvdR7pbjAiMAdyVmvDL9QepIQuJnpkgESwNLluvIHvn7/BfW189R5hpTevSVuDAtgncjK0TqZGwSq@rex1aQR/Fa639xEXirnAB3QZ8nshe5uGg3cwFpbBzosOd8cD0YJ@ZDb8MRlGVKU/@m7/Cw) (NOTE: `String.repeat(int)` is emulated as `repeat(String,int)` because Java 11 isn't on TIO yet. The byte-count remains the same.)

**Explanation:**

```java
L->{                     // Method with ArrayList<Long> parameter and no return-type
  L.sort(                //  Sort the list by:
   (a,b)->Long.compare(  //   Using a builtin Long-comparator with:
     s(a+""),s(b+"")));} //   The correctly formatted values as described in the challenge

long s(String s){        // Separated method with String parameter and long return-type
  var r="";              //  Temp-String, starting empty
  for(int l=s.length(),  //  The length of the input-String
      i=l%2;i<l;)        //   If the length is even:
                         //    Loop `i` in the range [0,`l`) (in steps of 2)
                         //   Else (the length is odd):
                         //    Loop `i` in the range [1,`l`) (in steps of 2) instead
    r+=                  //   Append the result-String with:
      s.split("")[++i].  //    The digit at index `i+1`
      .repeat(s.charAt(i++-1)-48);
                         //    Repeated the digit at index `i` amount of times
  return r.isEmpty()?    //  If the temp-String is empty:
          0              //   Return 0
         :               //  Else:
          new Long(r);}  //   Convert the temp-String to a long and return it
```

Comment: Hi, the challenge explicitly disallows string input, sorry! (I'm tempted to allow it for Java, but it wouldn't be fair on the other answers.)

Comment: @sundar Ah, missed that requirement; my bad.. Luckily it's an easy fix of just adding to 2x `+""` to convert the number to String. Should be fixed now. :)

Comment: Nice. I did not expect that from Java. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 71 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sort_by{|a|s='';s,a=[a%10]*(a/10%10)*''+s,a/100while a>0;s.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1NjsIwDIX3nMIbVGBCie0EilC5SBShIIEGaUYgymiK2p692OXHizh@7/Pz9W9/749lP9@mJuXV@Xrb7e9Nm9qqzLJNZVIZ0hhtnE3SAq38prMs@xJdJvv/ffo5QNraTZXfzrtT1/Uh4NrAGg0QOy@vJY4GAnnyKwMr8k/Xk3LolqiKdLIeSUkkRrYORWbmF47v0s3CQFEMqOSjYgacGCrxcAGtOJ7loO6SSvSJ12E5RA4kuRjz33Rp2rodXSDUBo6hjrHrHw)