# Find the k-th order summary of a number

Tags: code-golf, math, number

#### Background

The summary of a non-negative integer \$n\$ is the concatenation of all digits that appear in \$n\$ in increasing order, with each digit being preceded by the number of times it appears in \$n\$.

Some Examples:

```
n            -> summary(n)
1221         -> 2122 (2 ones, 2 twos)
1212         -> 2122 (2 ones, 2 twos)
912334       -> 1112231419 (1 one, 1 two, 2 threes, 1 four, 1 nine)
888888888888 -> 128 (12 eights)
```

The \$k\$-th order summary is result repeatedly applying the summary operation on a number \$k\$ times (i.e. \$2\$nd order summary of \$n\$ is `summary(summary(n))`, \$3\$rd order summary of \$n\$ is `summary(summary(summary(n)))`, etc.).

**Note:** The \$0\$th order summary of a number is itself

#### Task

Write a program/function that outputs the \$k\$-th order summary of a non-negative integer \$n\$.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins

#### Sample Testcases

```
n, k             -> answer
0, 1             -> 10
1, 10            -> 41122314
1221, 0          -> 1221
1221, 1          -> 2122
1212, 1          -> 2122
912334, 1        -> 1112231419
912334, 3        -> 412213141519
21322314, 1      -> 21322314
21322314, 123    -> 21322314
21322314, 2222   -> 21322314
888888888888, 1  -> 128
888888888888, 2  -> 111218
1888888888888, 1 -> 11128
```

---

*Inspired by [A005151](https://oeis.org/A005151)*

Comment: Similar question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70837/say-what-you-see

Comment: Please add `1888888888888, 1` as a test case (outputs `11128`) as my program failed for it (as will any method that concatenates by converting from base 10)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for pointing that out, added the testcase

Comment: Suggested test case: `21322314, anything -> 21322314` (a stable input).

Comment: Another interesting input is `9009` with a run of [21 distinct values](https://tio.run/##XY9LDgIxDEMvNEiN0@9ZEIvRwAIWgABxfUhCOhS6qf3iuOppfs735Xa8Pjbny/7wktNCaBMC2kQBILvIBRN3IYhNRlEubcwUzSSJ8GigJpnNWigWyae@lygbKB5HB3lMFEN1rURH5TdVDbbv0xkd1r8kPhBrkgo0udXSOETR9/UDGEp3bw) before it starts repeating.

Comment: Should the summary of `0` be `10` or `0` (empty)?

Comment: @att the summary of `0` is `10`

Comment: The series mentioned starts at 1, not 0

Comment: Are we allowed to output the result as digit-list instead of integer?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, digit-lists are allowed.

Comment: @AZTECCO according to the definition i use in the background, `0` (which clearly has a digit) gets converted to `10`

Answer (score 5):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 67 bytes

```
f=(n,k)=>k?f("".join(str(n.count(x))+x for x:sorted(set(n))),k-1):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctBCoAwDAXRq5Su8rEKuhJBPYxa0EIiaYTevrp01m9uFROuNc7EIWFe0hrJ@@6SkymbEnebPGxUgKa4KOrKlEXt2CkfRgwgpLbHxPXW84PfPv7ywQ1AfQE)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:k and f("".join(str(n.count(x))+x for x in sorted({*n})),k-1)or n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BboMwDAbgO09h9dJkC6gOTKKV6LuwUbQM6kQklUDTnp05iFW0mi@J/P1x7KbwaSmf57bq6@t7UwOp7tRBTQ20YrfLvqwh4cMgKPuwNwpilPJ1hNYOMIIh8HYIl0Z8v9CPlKpLUbLQbK6OAfzkkxjtDV2W9OQzHxpDpwS4DDkF9hagWhKZd70JYp@e93JxUtCxceyP1CpuMLxLKzgRL52UUFVxFI8fjBNSzqgAD7Cp9AwFotY5Fgkf7IcHjL0V8AE0NxlQ/wtH1HlebCiOWv/B453zhzX4l8hvHCg3tUxZVimf@vo@F8sEn9@sVP4C)

-7 bytes thanks to Mukundan314

Comment: [-7 byte](https://tio.run/##bc7BboMwDAbgO09h9dJEC6gOVKKV6LuwAVoGdSKSSvD0zEGsotV8SeTvj2M3h29L@bJ01VDfP5saSPXXHmpqoBOHQ/ZjDQkfRkHZl31QEJOUHxN0doQJDIG3Y2gb4dsgSEqp@hQlGy3m7pjAzz6J4cFQu@Znn/nQGLomwGXIKbCPANWayLwbTBDH9HaUq5OCno1jf6Q2caPhbTrBiXjppYSqiqN4/GickHJBBXiCXaU3KBC1zrFI@GA/vWDsbYAvoLnJgPpfuKDO82JHcdT2D16enL@swb9EPnOg3NU6ZV2lfOvr51wsE3x/s1H5Cw) for the python solution

Comment: @Mukundan314 Ah, nice! Thanks

Comment: Do you really need the `str` in the Proton function? Seems to work fine without it

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṢŒrUFVµ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkVHJxWFuoUd2npo4f///w0tkMB/QwA)

Credit to hyper-neutrino for the `µ` trick, and for telling me [I was wrong](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59537861#59537861) :P

Full program. Takes `n` then `k` on the command line

### How it works

```
ṢŒrUFVµ¡ - Main link. Takes n on the left, k on the right
      µ  - Last links as a monadic chain f(n):
Ṣ        -   Sort the digits of n
 Œr      -   Run length encode
   UF    -   Reverse each and flatten
     V   -   Eval as a single number
       ¡ - Iterate f(n) k times
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
(søeRf∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%28s%C3%B8eRf%E2%88%91&inputs=10%0A%271%27&header=&footer=)

```
(       # k times...
 s      # Sort 
  øe    # Run length encode
    R   # Reverse each
     f  # Flatten
      ∑ # Sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
ToString@#2<>#&@@@Sort@Tally@Characters@#<>""&~Nest~##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQ/uKQoMy/dQdnIxk5ZzcHBITi/qMQhJDEnp9LBOSOxKDG5JLWo2EHZxk5JSa3OL7W4pE5ZWe1/AFBTSbSyrl2ag4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V7WSoZKOoUGtDohlZATkILMNoWxDIxjb0tDI2NgEnWcM5lkgAZgKVDEjiHnoCrlq/wMA)

Input `["n", k]`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

Expects `(k)(n)`, where `n` is given as a string. Returns a string.

```javascript
k=>g=n=>k--?g([...n].sort().join``.replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>s.length+s[0])):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BTsMwEEX3OcWom9g0ceKkSGmR0xVcoMu2UqPESdMEO8QGgRA3QGLDEu7BeXoBjhCcUpW2Yha29N//f2aTPCQqbctGu0JmvMtZV7G4YILFletOCzQnhIglUbLVCJONLMVqRVre1EnKkYcIXtALr3AUixWpuSj0eqjm/hLjiehafndfthzZubKxCSXZTVnz2ZNIkY@JljPdlqIwtaqpS40GCzHAJJftdZKukQIWw7MFUHMNcxAOVA7wx4anmmewBAaK3CbaOL1FNvQK7BhvPy03UcjRsMJI4CvLyKkUStac1LJABju/HvZXNwX7@@tt@/FuXhsmYG8/X22TfcEddYD6cDRuDCNKgyCkI8t8hvsnsNf2gJ6AwIgG0OBfMKZBGI6OUF@130PHBxyenGG29PjSGKKj2bXsTonO9ODQSyOLnmf2KPoB)

#### Commented

```javascript
k =>                 // outer function taking k
g = n =>             // inner recursive function taking n as a string
  k-- ?              // decrement k; if it was not 0:
    g(               //   do a recursive call:
      [...n]         //     split n into a list of digits
      .sort()        //     sort this list in ascending order
      .join``        //     join the digits again
      .replace(      //     replace ...
        /(.)\1*/g,   //       ... runs of consecutive identical digits ...
        s =>         //       ... with:
          s.length + //         the number of occurrences
          s[0]       //         followed by the digit
      )              //     end of replace()
    )                //   end of recursive call
  :                  // else:
    n                //   we're done: return n
```

Comment: Love it.  I've never considered using ` join`` ` in place of `join('')` before.  I'm going to have to start doing that in my own code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
d!¡oṁoṁd§eL←kDd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P0Xx0ML8hzsbQTjl0PJUn0dtE7JdUv7//29ogQT@GwEA)

Order is taken 1-indexed.

### Explanation

```
d!¡oṁoṁd§eL←kDd
              d digits
  ¡             apply the following repeatedly and collect results:
            kD   group digits into lists
    ṁ            map each list and join:
        §e        two element list with:
          L        length
           ←       first element
     oṁd          convert each to individual digits 
 !              index into that using order
d               convert back to integer.
```

Comment: You program fails for `n = 1888888888888, k = 1 (2 if 1 indexed)`

Comment: fixed it. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 94 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 87 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(n,k){while(k<-k-1)n=Reduce(paste0,c(rbind(r<-table(el(strsplit(n,""))),names(r))));n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7dCoIwFAfw@55C1s1GG3g2AyXtIXoDPyaJtmROuoie3TYTNJPO1YH/73zooUyGsle5qe4KK1qT5@NaNRLXMasZEJVcZNHnErdpZ6RPc6yzShVYx8ykmXWywZ3RXdtUxo4jRAihKr3JDmvbkpN6DSVGAJwjKsjO9Yh64B@A7L1FsbMXOCUgGBHnzq2YRS5YAPgB3CYfAPwviIALEayJOzH9AdEXEysWuBccO35guKh56/hyuJHzObf3YCSwuWMi4fAG)

Expects `n` as a string and `k` 1-indexed. Outputs a string.

Creates `table` of digits and interleaves resulting values (counts) with their names (digits) using [this trick from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961969/6713210).

The rest is just string manipulation which is quite cumbersome in R.

---

Recursive approach results in the same byte-count:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 94 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 87 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
f=function(n,k)"if"(k,f(Reduce(paste0,c(rbind(r<-table(el(strsplit(n,""))),names(r)))),k-1),n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7bCoMwDIbv9xTS3aRQwUQHCtseYm/goQXRddLW53etB9Ahy1XI9yV/zDSphxp17dqPBi06zlrFoBMKXrIZawlDaZ1MRA2manUD5h67suolyB6sM3boW@f3GOOcC12@pQXDQ9/F6Ad8UsAQiZggfgk9ExEm/BrtKn5GWXBSzGaFKFgHySthvMP4g8nPF4z0BxdIaZodhXB8zcfiIKUHKQvRQbotWr6r7eL8aH5CaaM@CWcBT/ZXIZ@@)

Here `k` is 0-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 25 bytes

```
1A`
"$+"{O`.
(.)\1*
$.&$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/39AxgUtJRVup2j9Bj0tDTzPGUItLRU9NBShlzGVpaGRsbAIA) Takes input in the order `k, n`. No test suite due to the program's use of history. Explanation:

```
1A`
```

Delete `k` from the input.

```
"$+"{`
```

Retrieve `k` from the history and repeat the rest of the program `k` times.

```
O`.
```

Sort the digits in ascending order.

```
(.)\1*
$.&$1
```

Precede each distinct digit by its count.

The best I could do in # [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) is 45 bytes:

```
,\d+
$*_
{O`.(?=.*_)
(\d)\1*(?=.*_)
$.&$1
_$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wXycmRZtLRSueq9o/QU/D3lZPK16TSyMmRTPGUAvGVdFTUzHkilfh@v/fUMfQgMvQyMhQB0oZAilDIyBlaWhkbGyCYBhzWSABoDgK14jLEFUaAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
,\d+
$*_
```

Convert `k` to unary, using `_` because they sort after digits, saving a byte.

```
{`
```

Repeat (until `k` is zero, at which point the loop converges).

```
O`.(?=.*_)
```

If `k` is not zero, sort the digits in ascending order. (If `k>1`, `k` is also sorted, but it always sorts after digits.)

```
(\d)\1*(?=.*_)
$.&$1
```

If `k` is not zero, precede each distinct digit by its count.

```
_$
```

If `k` is not zero, then decrement `k`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>74</s> 66 bytes

```ruby
->n,k{k.times{a=n.chars
n=(a|a).sort.map{|d|[a.count(d),d]}*''}
n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBdT4MwFIbv@yuO7IKhXbcCJsykeOWtej8XUqHLCK4QWhIN9LdjmWyBxXPRk7zP6Xs@6ubzpz@wfhVLXLQF0flJqJYzSdIjrxWSbMk77hFV1pqceNV2WbfjJC0bqZeZh7O9uXddg6TptVA6UU2ugYFDMdANTGIVQ0ip7wc0RDZZvpnBQRsBnQHfihZQ/1@wpX4QhBM0WI196PaKg9kYtsuAH21BNImzy3mU6Eb3r740QvT2z4gihwieHpOvXIq2G94Ogb0qFt@VSLXIGAwiUSmXy/VH9rD2ENRC2XMddiABgz1/meSwRxU4i1YaDIu2MMBim22h@UvAGFws4RncsnDhCdzXt/eXO9c4CBnUT3f8BQ)

- Thanks to @ovs for actually golfing  thus saving 8 Bytes!
  .uniq => a|a and join by *'' instead of appending values
- takes *n* as string, *k* as int
- reconstruct *n* by appending each (count,digit) *k* times
- uses a=n.split n='' instead of a,n=n.chars,'' which is the same byte count

Comment: `(a|a)` is a byte shorter than `a.uniq` and building `n` by joining a nested array saves a few more bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBdT4MwFIbv@yuO7IKhXbcCJsykeOWtej8XUqHLCK4QWhIN9LdjmWyBxXPRk7zP6Xs@6ubzpz@wfhVLXLQF0flJqJYzSdIjrxWSbMk77hFV1pqceNV2WbfjJC0bqZeZh7O9uXddg6TptVA6UU2ugYFDMdANTGIVQ0ip7wc0RDZZvpnBQRsBnQHfihZQ/1@wpX4QhBM0WI196PaKg9kYtsuAH21BNImzy3mU6Eb3r740QvT2z4gihwieHpOvXIq2G94Ogb0qFt@VSLXIGAwiUSmXy/VH9rD2ENRC2XMddiABgz1/meSwRxU4i1YaDIu2MMBim22h@UvAGFws4RncsnDhCdzXt/eXO9c4CBnUT3f8BQ "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 44 bytes

```
{($^a,{[R~] .comb.Bag{~9...0}:kv}...*)[$^k]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkMlLlGnOjqoLlZBLzk/N0nPKTG9us5ST0/PoNYqu6wWyNDSjFaJy46t/V@cWKmgVO2gEl@rYGunUJ2mUANkKimk5Rcp2BgqGBrY6QBpIyNDBQTLEMIyNIKwLA2NjI1NUNjGILaRobGRkbEhVAbBMwLLWiABiAoUESOwHWiK/gMA)

- `($^a, { ... } ... *)[$^k]` selects the `$^k`-th element of the infinite sequence starting with `$^a`, where `$^a` and `$^k` are the first and second arguments to the function, respectively.  The bracketed expression is an anonymous function that generates each summary number from the previous one, passed as `$_`.
- `.comb` splits the number `$_` into its (string) digits.
- `.Bag` assembles those digits into a Bag--a set with multiplicity.
- `{~9...0}` slices into that bag with the digits from 9 to 0.  The leading `~` stringifies the `9` and gives us a sequence of strings, not numbers.  (The Bag knows the difference.)
- The `:kv` adverb on the slicing subscript `{...}` does two things: it returns a flat list of key-value pairs (ie, each digit along with its multiplicity, in order from 9 to 0), and it omits elements from the slice which don't exist in the Bag.
- `[R~]` reduces that list with the operator `R~`, which is the `R`eversed string concatenation operator `~`.  That gives us the required summary of the previous number in the series.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
F{Åγøí˜J
```

-1 byte thanks to a tip of *@ovs*

Inputs in the order \$k,n\$. Outputs as a digit-list (unless \$k=0\$, in which case it outputs \$n\$ as is - although we could take input \$n\$ as digit-list as well to be consistent).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/frfpw67nNh3ccXhv8/7@hAZchAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCf7fqw63nNh/ecXht8P/aw@t1/kdHG@gYxupEG@oYGoAoIyNDHTgDLGFkaARmWBoaGRubIDONgUwjQ2MjI2NDiDiCY4QiZwQEQL4FEgCrRxEAqTBEUxILAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F        # Loop the first (implicit) input amount of times:
 {       #  Sort the digits of the current number
         #  (which is the second implicit input-integer in the first iteration)
  Åγ     #  Pop and run-length encode, pushing a list of digits and a list of lengths
         #  separated to the stack
    ø    #  Create pairs of these two lists
     í   #  Reverse each pair
      S  #  Convert the list of integer-pairs to a flattened list of digits
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I think `Åγ` should be able to save a byte here

Comment: @ovs EDIT: I'm an idiot.. it pushes both lists separated :/ Thanks for -1

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 73 bytes

```powershell
param($n,$k)for(;$k--){$n=-join("$n"|% t*y|group|%{$_.Count,$_.Name})}
$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJfS8MwEH/vpwgjk1ZaWdIKG2MwGPoiTHGPIqPW1LluSU1aVNp@9npp6lq26ZHC3e/P3YU0FZ9Mqg3b7bxISFbjeFbUaSjDvY25ixMnFtKe4sTznALzmbcV79weYD4ohyi7/C7fpMjTcljg9dVC5DxzIVmGe1Y5lYV5XVnW3LYQhIvm9shFBM7IOSBN6aKAEEp9EvQISoHTBkiOYTgUsj5M6Bl4QqjvB2ZoO4FMTmlfLwCNNX3dFwDUmNrW/tGOPZr6/wsoxDnFuBdmTzr@i6XmFqQnIKd@0nRwUIluhbwJo413/7JlUYaKxgWPinACH/tKAWWvaIbw2lCSqXyXAXCBYxCCzuAqjyKmlFa2Eo99dB0a0dPDapGrTOzNtOe5Gadj1dnbTtMDt9Qo7@o7XSdd/fi7UjvZMJUF/1X9Aw)

Same byte count using `$ofs`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJda4MwFH33V4SSrjp0NNFBSxEKZXsZdGN9HKM4F9fVNnFR2Yb6292NcVXabpcIuefjniuaiE8m0w3b7ZxQSFbjyC/qJJDB3sTcxrEVCWliEaX@aDTDseNYBeb@APNBOUTZ5Xf5JkWelMMCr68WIueZDZdlsGdVZWBeV4YxNw0EZaO5ObYRgTO2DkjT2sgjhFKXeD2CUuCUAS7HMBwKtz5M6Bl4Sqjrejq0TSDTU9pVC8BgRV/3BQA1pna0e7Rjj6bu/wIKdU4x6ZXek07@Yql@C9ITkFM/aSZYqES3Qt4E4ca5f9myMENF44KPinAMD/tKAGWvyEd4rSnJ0nyXAeBsxTs3L3AEclDrPJzmYcjSVBlapcM@ukGN6OlhtcjTTOx16PNcp6padfZ20uzALRXKu/5O9XHXP/5u1iZrpjLg96p/AA)

Takes two integer parameters and returns a string or an integer

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＦＮ≔⭆Φ⭆χκ№ηκ⁺№ηκκηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTwbG4ODM9TyO4pCgzL903sUDDLTOnBCiFEDA00FHI1tRRcM4vzSvRyABxgLyAnNJiDSQhqHCGpjVXAFAnUFTT@v9/Yy5LQyNjY5P/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `k, n`. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Input `k` and loop that many times.

```
≔⭆Φ⭆χκ№ηκ⁺№ηκκη
```

Filter the characters `0-9` that are present in `n`, prefixing them with their count and joining the result.

```
η
```

Output the final value of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>112</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>123</s></sup> 125 bytes

```c
f(n,k){int c[10]={!n},t=n,i=-1,l;for(;t;t/=10)++c[t%10];for(;i++<9;t=l?i+l*10+t*exp10(l=log10(l)+2):t)l=c[i];n=k?f(t,k-1):n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHdaoMwFL7fU2RCIZpIjXYXNs16MfYUVkZJYyexadHAZOKrzx1rLO2YHI/6/SU5yvAo5TAU2FDtd6WxSGYsykX3bHpqhaGlCBmteHGuMbfcLgWLfEJkZhcgm@CSkE3Krai2JakCFhEbqPbCIlyJ6nwcnz6J/bX1KyGzMudG6G2BLdUh89eG98O47GlfGuyj7gnBNQJWNfbDZDkSqIsoYlBxfNdZTFHK4iRZ9fzRpCfTqAKj80Ld6WB/Slp1cErQrBgEJ2w1LwD58dyZ41jqIuTnvg6gK6lVPWV4u/Y93rXpG9wvHkX334nnfDAuhMf1S3NQLdgi7l43qCm/1bnA8878pQOCG8IRIVf1PKb5NAaS3LiufM4faD3T@l@6AXr6/4@4Avw2p7/GSw2SAnuLA4IKX8e@aHYGTm4o0hQ19DafRgiVu/D@qR9@ZFHtj80Qfg1hdfoF)

*Saved <s>a</s> 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*
*Added 21 bytes to fix an error kindly pointed out by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld).*
*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!*
*Added 2 bytes to handle \$n=0\$.*

Comment: Hello! I posted mine instead of suggesting because I think it's slightly different approach, Idk if I have to apologize but I feel so because usually I suggest, but sometimes I'm greedy and don't want to give away my codes :-p

Comment: @AZTECCO Yeah, I've noticed you started doing that now.  If you post a C answer before I do I either help you or refrain from posting in that challenge.

Comment: Wait.. I coded it completely on my own without see yours before, that's the main reason I choose to post separately.. If you feel I compete with you well it's right, that's a competition after all, but if I golf your answer then I suggest instead of posting separately.. That's for sure.

Comment: Btw since I have to steal your pow(log10..) to correct my answer I live my attempt at your disposal as a suggestion [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldDBasMwDAbge5/CFAp27RBLziCZJvYiuwyPBlPmDeNb6bNnztKSsGUt0034s/glX/XeD0My3mQTqJfRHNXp8JEkHauKIic1NokDWwpaP3WU2D@nPVirwe69Do8T8WxN5kiZcs1gldecd2CZQ/kR6Ty8v4Yo1WkjPlOI@SC3u7eXuDW9BCOKV1TXogFAdNCsIMTiLmxsfhMxGZgMlm7VABYjbqIO0LlmZnCJBd0N7K4rlBSjfVjV5e171DKD@2PnJUb3H46l7vJ2UWOc67LY3sU43wXWNPyYPfN2cx6@AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: in the future feel free to post your own answer if you find a different and better approach, I think it's fine and interesting to compete in the same language, and it happens to other languages too. :)

Comment: @AZTECCO No, I won't be changing the way I post.

Comment: @AZTECCO Your answer fails for any number with \$0\$s. For \$n=12222222222\$ and \$k=2\$ - you get \$3112\$ should be \$103112\$  (using `r*pow(10,l=log10(c)+2)+10*c+i`, and changing all `int`s to `long`s), where mine doesn't.

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVHdboMgFL7vUxCTJiCYiu0uLGW9WPYU1iwNxc5AsVGSmhlffQ4nNu0yczyR7w84iugsxDAU0BCFutJYIDIa57zrieWGlDyiRLOiqiGzzK44jRHGIrNLJ5rgEuNdyizX@xLrkMbYhtfqBmlMNNfVmcZQI5ygrUWai6zMmeFqX0BLVETR1rB@GHe9HEsDEegWwD0jYGVjP0yWAw46SgBNkodOEwJSmqzXm549O5R3xAS4olM9iGR7lcLK0yTbUJe4pps52QUnc6eeo6m3i89jHbouhZL15A8O7XtyaNM3974EBDyu14H3uSkBOO5dmpNsnS1m/nMHmvJLVgWcT4VWHgjvCAMY/6rn4cw3MS7JD@mXz9kTrWZa/Us3jp5@@jMuHX6f0V/jtXaSAgbLE3AVvY592RyMu7khQBHQkPt8Gs5l7sP7RT98i0Ifz80Q3YZIX34A)

Comment: No problem @Noodle9 that's fine.. I'll continue to either post my own answers or suggest as I feel more appropriate. Since I managed to fix my answer on my own I reopened it (i was checking [1-9]digits because 0 didn't appeared in test cases)

Comment: @att Great stuff - thanks! :D

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: Fails for n=0, k=1

Comment: @att you could tell him (and me too) that OP required n=0 handling since you asked for clarification. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8459/84844

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>121 125 117</s> 116 bytes

```c
E=10,r,c,t,i;g(n,k){for(;k--;n=n?r:E)for(r=i=0;i<E;r=c?r*E*E+c*E+i:r,i++)for(c=0,t=n;t;t/=E)r*=t%E-i||++c%E?:E;r=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldLdaoMwFAfwe59CCoLRiDmJA2sWvMpb7GZktITSbITsqu2zu8SP6bbQsgNeJP@fJ8cPVR2VGgYpgGCLFXZY82Nu8AldDu8256eq4kaY3nYShQ0rtCBcP0tuheptIQtZKn/pzmJdlqNRgmAnDHfc1UIiWwiXyUpfr2WpMtl34V7Db8P5VZscXZL0w2rjDvkue3sxO3zMCU4JQryuUxINYQohntIlBYjmbMlZJAdK4fv0sPhL0snMQ1C/ihqg3qRR9DmjPVDGmpUBeMeggf0dPI/fhCmCffqhl/N9NrbazjDt3MeU/YdTXw95u6kwzvKwtH2I6fpeIKbhV@@Vt/HvttS2NaHjvwA0SW7DFw)

- Saved 1 thanks to @ceilingcat
- Fixed: now works with n=0 , k>0  as required.

[Try it uint64_t](https://tio.run/##lZJdT8IwFIbv9yuaGZJ9dNLTTQKUylUvvDNcmxhTYDZoJbW7MMBvnx0wmNhIPEmTnvM@5/RtN5mVUtY3Ssu3ar5AE6Wt/VovPm9f7@vKJYPi2SLBgWCDJbZYseBULqPTVmO3Q6t4s/wwEVtlGdNcT81YxE3BcMUJUxPBDJdTk4hEpNItNTZYpemekZxgyzWzzPa5iE3CbU9kartNU9kTUxg3zZrt6vcXpaN4E6C1cWcuo7A3f9IhLiOCEYlj1u8j4hXhIIJfpa0K4NXzVs89OlAKp9Ob5DeCDszRBHWZlwHqGOSFqiM0AprnxRkDcFwOBYw6cPg4e6gGRXjRc7xF0ZhpWu5@NLU2nLaf2LVyqPwN0/w/OHVxFR92orHT3pkOr8L0/Dzgo@Fi9hkf@j9fG93RhO5/CaBBsKu/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel (Insider Beta), 108 bytes

```
=LAMBDA(q,k,IF(k,LET(a,f(q,k-1),x,SEQUENCE(10)-1,y,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,x,"")),CONCAT(FILTER(y&x,y))),q))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnVfgN6n5ytPTEHau?e=cAAsE5)

Set name f equal to the above formula.  Spreadsheet requires Insider Beta version of Excel to work currently because of LAMBDA.

#### Explanation

```
=LAMBDA(q,k,
IF(k,                                      # if k <> 0 then
     LET(a,f(q,k-1),                       #   a = f(q,k-1) 
         x,SEQUENCE(10)-1,                 #   x = [0..9]
         y,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,x,"")), #   y = count of each x in a
         CONCAT(FILTER(y&x,y)))            #   concatenate y&x if y > 0 
     ,q))                                  # else q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 354 bytes

```
mod R is pr LIST{Nat}+ CONVERSION . ops k s : Nat Nat ~> Nat . op f : Nat
~> String . var N K : Nat . var X Y :[Nat]. eq k(N,0)= N . eq k(N,s K)=
k(rat(f(s(N,0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)),10),K). eq s(0,X)= X . ceq s(N,X K Y)=
s(N quo 10,X(s K)Y)if size(X)= N rem 10[owise]. eq f(nil)= "" . eq f(X 0)=
f(X). eq f(X s N)= f(X)+ string(10 * s N + size(X),10). endm
```

The result is obtained by reducing the `k` function with \$n\$ and \$k\$.

#### Example Session

```
Maude> red k(1, 10) .  --- Expected: 41122314
result NzNat: 41122314
Maude> red k(1221, 0) .  --- Expected: 1221
result NzNat: 1221
Maude> red k(1221, 1) .  --- Expected: 2122
result NzNat: 2122
Maude> red k(1212, 1) .  --- Expected: 2122
result NzNat: 2122
Maude> red k(912334, 1) .  --- Expected: 1112231419
result NzNat: 1112231419
Maude> red k(912334, 3) .  --- Expected: 412213141519
result NzNat: 412213141519
Maude> red k(21322314, 1) .  --- Expected: 21322314
result NzNat: 21322314
Maude> red k(21322314, 123) .  --- Expected: 21322314
result NzNat: 21322314
Maude> red k(21322314, 2222) .  --- Expected: 21322314
result NzNat: 21322314
Maude> red k(888888888888, 1) .  --- Expected: 128
result NzNat: 128
Maude> red k(888888888888, 2) .  --- Expected: 111218
result NzNat: 111218
Maude> red k(1888888888888, 1) .  --- Expected: 11128
result NzNat: 11128
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod R is
    pr LIST{Nat} + CONVERSION .

    ops k s : Nat Nat ~> Nat .
    op f : Nat ~> String .

    var N K : Nat .
    var X Y : [Nat] .

    eq k(N, 0) = N .
    eq k(N, s K) = k(rat(f(s(N, 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)), 10), K) .

    eq s(0, X) = X .
    ceq s(N, X K Y) = s(N quo 10, X (s K) Y) if size(X) = N rem 10 [owise] .

    eq f(nil) = "" .
    eq f(X 0) = f(X) .
    eq f(X s N) = f(X) + string(10 * s N + size(X), 10) .
endm
```

Maude doesn't have logarithms for integers, only for floating-point numbers, so the only good way I could find to "concatenate" integers is to convert them to strings, concatenate, and convert back.

## Core Maude + Cheating, 331 bytes

```
mod R is pr CONVERSION . ops k s : Nat Nat -> Nat . op f : Nat Nat -> String
. var N K S : Nat . eq k(N,0)= N . eq k(N,s K)= k(rat(f(0,s(N,0)),10),K). eq
s(0,S)= S . eq s(N,S)= s(N quo 10,S + 512 ^(N rem 10))[owise]. eq f(10,S)=
"" . eq f(N,S)= if(S & 511)> 0 then string(10 *(S & 511)+ N,10)else "" fi +
f(s N,S >> 9)[owise]. endm
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod R is
    pr CONVERSION .

    ops k s : Nat Nat -> Nat .
    op f : Nat Nat -> String .

    var N K S : Nat .

    eq k(N, 0) = N .
    eq k(N, s K) = k(rat(f(0, s(N, 0)), 10), K) .

    eq s(0, S) = S .
    eq s(N, S) = s(N quo 10, S + 512 ^ (N rem 10)) [owise] .

    eq f(10, S) = "" .
    eq f(N, S) = if (S & 511) > 0 then string(10 * (S & 511) + N, 10) else "" fi + f(s N, S >> 9) [owise] .
endm
```

If we make the small assumption that no digit occurs more than 511 times, we can avoid having to import `LIST` and keep the intermediate summary packed in an integer with 9 bits per digit tracked. The bit size is sort of arbitrary since Maude has unbounded integers, so I picked 9 bits to avoid paying 4 extra bytes for `10` and `1024`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 72 bytes

```perl
sub g{($c,$d)=@_;$c=join"",map{(@e=$c=~/$_/g)?@e.$_:""}0..9for 1..$d;$c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHda8IwEH/3rzhCxARi7aUWrNJZXwaDPQx8dEWcrcXhZ1sZQ9y/3l2Cc@t0u5ckv6@7cLs0X/lVVRxeIDsKPlc8kWE0HfB5@LpdbhhT69nuKKI0JOSjw6edTA6j1OHTPmMn13GCxTYHdByekOdUrd8hSmblDEIQDaCa7N@ECwjoylhdEPOGLqLWHnZrhNYIpKfjCkbQdNZh1DfgALXndU3TcwcMbtAeDUCxhvbrAgKtzUZ7VzN@09r7X6Cpbip6P8rMqXt/str@AmsC/O3Hc4IcNMw@aAu8TIsShF2GhKO1GjhPi8OqpPVkwkradxM3VvB1x5gijHaXLzflQrBMNNvoFwqabb@Q5LPPPjSL5w1TEFmjuuSm@0uUjmEIrafReNyCPrD70cMjiLNOMmpzqj4B)

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub g{
    ($c, $d) = @_;
    for (1 .. $d) {
        $c = join('', map {(@e = $c =~ /$_/g) ? @e . $_ : ""} 0 .. 9);
    }
    $c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 112 bytes

Chunk function (can be executed using `loadstring(code)("42",0)`). Expects `n` as a string and `k` as either number or string. Doesn't play well with TIO; replace the `return n` with `print(n)` to test.

```lua
n,k=...for _=1,k do m=""for j=1,9 do c=""..#n:gsub("[^"..j.."]","")m=m..(c>"0"and c..j or"")end n=m end return n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYnRCsIwEAR/5ThfWghLfVPh@iOiUtNWaJsLRPP952Vflpk56mSmYRcAay70knPYac6UhLmJzcW1iegCOOnt863vju9Ppw3gBwfmPkkCujjywJPOFL1RLh4WJ5VE7cvyq0VJzezSZsMf)