# (Robbers) Fast and Golfiest Season 1: The Lord of the Strings

Tags: code-golf, string, cops-and-robbers, fastest-algorithm

### Fast and Golfiest Robbers Thread

Welcome to the first season of **Fast and Golfiest**, a cops-and-robbers challenge! I designed this challenge to encourage competitive coding for efficiency (fastest algorithm) to become more popular on the site.

The rules are simple. The cops choose problems from LeetCode, a competitive coding platform, and solve them with code as efficient and short as possible. Now you, as the robber, will try to golf up their code, **without** sacrificing code efficiency. That is, the time complexity of your code must be smaller or equal to the cop code's complexity. You must also use the same language as the cop. Here's the link to the [Cops Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263049/118810). Note that for the robbers, **golfiness matters most**! However, if your time complexity is lower than the cop code **and** shorter than theirs, your score will be 2.718 times the original!

Your answer post should include the following:

1. A link to the cop post you cracked.
2. Your code, its length in bytes.
3. The UTC time of your post.
4. The time complexity of your code (must be smaller or equal to the cop code's complexity).

You should also edit the cop post to say "Cracked" and add a link to your post.

Your score is the percentage reduction of the code length in bytes compared to the cop code (with the 2.718 times efficiency bonus if you got it), rounded to the nearest integer! **Edit**: Sorry, it seems unbalanced now so I have to nerf the robbers. The robbers' score will be divided by 4.

If you have any advices please let me know in the comments so that this challenge series could be improved. Thanks in advance!

Leaderboard (Periodically updated. Please note that I rank individual answers instead of answerers to encourage quality over quantity.):

1. 9 points: ATOI String to Integer by The Thonnu
2. 5 points: Concatenated Words by CursorCoercer
3. 4 Points: Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters by CursorCoercer

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 84 bytes (35.4% reduction), cracks [ATOI string to integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263060/114446)

```python
lambda s:min(max(L:=-2**31,int([*re.findall("^ *([+-]?\d+)",s),0][0])),~L)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Q3ISc5NSEhWKrXIz8zRyEys0fKxsdY20tIwNdTLzSjSitYpS9dIy81ISc3I0lOIUtDSitXVj7WNStDWVdIo1dQxiow1iNTV16nw0uTJzC_KLShSKUqFm2xYUgYxI01AyMVLS1OSCcxUUFHTRhEwMLY0VyjNLMhTK84tSioFyEEMWLIDQAA)

- UTC: 09:28 (updated 09:38)
- Same time complexity as the cops' answer I think.

Comment: I know it's already cracked, but you can golf 2 more bytes with `t:=-2**31` and `~t`: [attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Q3ISc5NSEhWKrXIz8zRyEys0SqxsdY20tIwNdTLzSjSitYpS9dIy81ISc3I0lOIUtDSitXVj7WNStDWVdIo1dQxiow1iNTV16ko0uTJzC_KLShSKUqFm2xYUgYxI01AyMVLS1OSCcxUUFHTRhEwMLY0VyjNLMhTK84tSioFyEEMWLIDQAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen  I was literally about to edit that in lol!

Comment: Two souls one thought, I guess. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 44 bytes (6.4% reduction), cracks [Removing Stars From a String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263081/25180)

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;s[i-=*s++-42?0:2]=*s;);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBBCsIwEEX3OcUQEdJotVYXYqwexIqUNNGAttKJgogncePGQ7n0JqaNSmeTmbz5n5_cn3KzlfLxeJ6sDqevvhGayV1WcQyuuqyYSSKBKxMmHHu9cBIvo1m8doMIxO2reXdMIfenXMEcbW7KwW5ByLk0ObEKbeMGzo5cCYBmGAh3HitTWM1oSruY0rSgfajBjRB3Tw6ZKVjt4EWNA45Wa0iA7pWynMsy54qKP4w9VFWGitfVYmPP0ohnVMBwqA5HewG0LsLWLTUhcdTE8n3c6sd1Kv_Q3yd9AA)

-2 bytes thanks to c-- (original cop).

I think this involves undefined behavior. I'm not exactly sure. But it works in the exact compiler version.

It doesn't work for empty strings, but the specification says 1 <= s.length <= 10<sup>5</sup>.

- UTC: 2023-07-20 18:38:43Z; 2023-07-21 03:55:34Z
- Time complexity \$O(n)\$ (same as cops' answer)

Comment: very nice, you can even declare `i` outside the function for [-2 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBLDoIwEIb3PUVTY1IKGAQXxooeBIghpdUmSg1T3RhP4sYN13HvbSzgazbz-DJ__plbKzZbIe739mRVOH8GmisqdmXDwLso01CdRhwyHaYMfD-cxetoEReu4R6_vnceI12L_amSeAm20mayWyF0NrpCVoLt1bCTQxeEsaLgcZePja6toiQnY8hJXpMAd-CKkJujQ6lr2ikMS70CTLMCp5jspbSMCVMxSfgXxgOUTQmSdfHHkoH1k94RTL1fHf_VSWdhuOrzkRc). Also, there's definitely UB in the unsequenced access and modification to `s`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes (6.4% reduction), cracks [Reverse words in a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263072/114446)

```python
lambda g:print(*filter(str,g.split()[::-1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3dXISc5NSEhXSrQqKMvNKNLTSMnNKUos0ikuKdNL1igtyMks0NKOtrHQNYzU1oXrs0jSUSjJSFYqzKxUyixWSckpTlTS5gIIKChmpOTn5CuX5RTkpCgoQQaDZ-flAXmpFYm5BDlAlxJQFCyA0AA)

- UTC: 14:04 (updated 14:18)
- Time complexity \$O(n)\$ (same as cops' answer)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 145 bytes (18% reduction), cracks [Concatenated Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263073/73054)

```python
lambda z:[i for i in z if any(q&z==q for q in g(i,0))]
def g(a,b=1):
 if b:yield{a}
 for i in range(1,len(a)):
  for j in g(a[i:]):yield{a[:i]}|j
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5NCsIwEEb3PUXIQhKIYHcSyElqF1OT1Ck1_SEu2tpDuHZTEL2Tt9G0FVcfM-_Nx9xfdedPlZseVh2eF2-3-_ethHOmgfQyQWKrliBBR3qCloDrWLPplWpm0ASQMxQ7ztNIG_sdQGQq5jIKeiY7NKUeYIz-RS243LBYlMYx4MGcWbF0QYIy5b-7RGI6Xov1MVq36DyzbKC6yqkg9Ah-jbAYOV_MaVryAw)

- UTC: 14:39
- Time complexity \$O(n)\$ (same as the cops')

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 112 bytes (5% reduction), cracks [Simplify Path](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263078/52194), 2023-07-20 18:02 UTC

Just some minor golfs like realizing `elif` isn't needed and tweaking the string used to construct the final output. -1 by [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)

```python
def f(p):
 s=[]
 for x in p.split('/'):
  if x=='..'and s:s.pop()
  if x not in'..':s+=x,
 return'/'+'/'.join(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxCsMwDEX3nEKbbdLaQ7eAe4pupUMhNlFJLWE7NCXk7K4TMnSQ@NLjff7mgcKllN558JJV10Cy90cDniLMgAFYJx4xS2HERgE9zNYKrcUz9JC6pJlYqoNAoFytDXeptfOpgejyFEPV2zr6RRhkUuUz4OjgFidXSxFslXjKWw9HDFl6seAK5yssXqJahSpmoLczjdG6rj0bT3TE@vw79vwD)

Comment: [112](https://tio.run/##TYwxCsMwDEX3nEKbbdLaQ7eAe4pupUMhNlFJLWE7NCXk7K4TMnSQ@NLjff7mgcKllN558JJV10Cy90cDniLMgAFYJx4xS2HERgE9zNYKrcUz9JC6pJlYqoNAoFytDXeptfOpgejyFEPV2zr6RRhkUuUz4OjgFidXSxFslXjKWw9HDFl6seAK5yssXqJahSpmoLczjdG6rj0bT3TE@vw79vwD "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes (13% reduction), cracks [Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263083/73054)

```python
def f(s):
 m=x=0;c=set()
 for y in s:
  if y in c:
   while s[x]!=y:c-={s[x]};x+=1
   x+=1
  c|={y};m=max(m,len(c))
 return m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETvfsXWiwltoeJN2S8pPZg0wVATJRtRsX67jVhoYWF33gzD9nNoOlds21Np0Ix4mYDFCW@VRFKB8QR052EG44CiB0YfQu4Cxsa0Cug@PU44l/KKy36v1XTGfPe/W75xmdfKoq0nZi@tckzyWO1VGLwDu9VEyof4QFoLGUeIlCMWyY8LcbD8j/Xj@FLjkey9cYFlNEipiDK@fQA)

- UTC: 18:40
- Time complexity \$O(n)\$ (same as cops')

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 168 bytes (2.9% reduction), cracks [Count and Say](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263093/112488)

```go
import."fmt"
func g(n int)string{s:="1"
for;n>1;n--{c,o,f,k:=1,"",rune(s[0]),s[1:]+"_"
for _,r:=range k{if r==f{c++}else{o+=Sprintf("%d%c",c,f);f,c=r,1}}
s=o}
return s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY9BasMwEEX3PoUQBCw0LhHdFLvTMxS6DCEY1TLC8chI8kroJN2YQqGLXqi3qeJm9Qf-8N__H5-j236WXk_9OLC5t_S1RtM8_X7beXE-PnAzR16ZlTQba2KWogjRWxpTaJGrYjnf0YvqqGmSBgcGphYVcA5-paEOp-NZQDip9iz5ZX9nF_At-p4KcUrWMI9okpYyD9cwJCfxbSmEaGp-eD9oDhqM6Axo9KByrgK6XPkhrp5YyPe-uFe8DagFSzvGshaZ6oo-I3s8lkPKYr3esq9UWyiLrBBVru4h2_avfw)

- Time: 2023-07-20 21:46:57Z
- Time complexity (same as cops' answer)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 122 bytes (1.6% reduction), cracks [Edit Distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263077)

```py
lambda a,b:(d:=range(len(b)+1),[d:=[x:=d[(j:=0)]+1]+[x:=1+min(x,d[(j:=j+1)],d[j-1]-(i==k))for k in b]for i in a])and d[-1]
```

A bit of a cheap crack.

Time: 2023-07-25 02:11:18Z

Comment: May be cheap, but nice work all the same. Turns out there's two more bytes to be saved in that little area too [TIO](https://tio.run/##VYtBDoMgFET3PQVxBRGTmm4aE05CWXwFK1o/BmxiT0/Bpo1dzcybmeW1Dg4v18XHXtziA@ZWAwHeNlQ3wgPeDX0YpC0ra8ZlYnJrhJZ0bMSZqbJWZQZ1OVukG9dyVBW1QkyMf0Zj@inWO08mYpG0KlubLSgGqImWVa3i4i2utKfF4HwwBSeFd6Fg7PQrkhhcrcNcms10zz0cJ9qGFbDb76Eb5m88biCXfyQDSCS@AQ)

Comment: If we switch to a later version of Python, we can [save 4 more bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY5BDoIwEEX3nqJh1YaSyM6Q9CTYxUCLFGVqSk1w7THckBi9k7exBTW6mv_f_5OZ6-N49q3F6daI7f3km2zz9AfoKwUEeFVQVQgHuNP0oJFWLM0ZLwMrx0KosivEWqa5TKPN094gHXnAMqNGiD3jc6ULDdZYR_bEIKlklCZKkAxQEVVmuXzfvhydQU8bmrTWDTrhJHF2SBhbfYMwNHpjMYZ61PVpNr8VZQYPWM_rQ932H_vbgRj-kQggkOWVaVrmCw) by dropping the parens around the 2 walruses.

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 171 bytes (3.9% reduction), cracks [Generate Parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263127/112488)

<sup>Hover over any symbol to see what it does</sup>

In plaintext:

```
i>:?v~l2,b2.
10-1<.02}}
:?v~{{l2,06.
v-\&'('o:2*[{1+}]$:
\:?v~$}}&1-b2.
')'/.321o
>:?v;
1+&\&:2*[{1-:}]?v:@&:&l2,-+?!v$
{{&>:?v~}}50ao./~0}]
.61-1&>1-&:2*[{/>1{{69!.|.!7f<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaT46P3Z+bDIsYjIuXG4xMC0xPC4wMn19XG46P3Z+e3tsMiwwNi5cbnYtXFwmJygnbzoyKlt7MSt9XSQ6XG5cXDo/dn4kfX0mMS1iMi5cbicpJy8uMzIxb1xuPjo/djtcbjErJlxcJjoyKlt7MS06fV0/djpAJjombDIsLSs/IXYkXG57eyY+Oj92fn19NTBhby4vfjB9XVxuLjYxLTEmPjEtJjoyKlt7Lz4xe3s2OSEufC4hN2Y8IiwiaW5wdXQiOiIzIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

- Time: 2023-07-26 14:58:41Z (updated 15:42:38)
- Time complexity \$O(n!)\$ (same as cops' answer)

[image: control flow]

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 184 bytes (4.6% reduction), cracks [Generate Parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263091/112488)

```rust
fn f(z:i32)->Vec<String>{if z<1{vec!["".into()]}else{(0..z).flat_map(|i|->Vec<_>{let b=f(z-i-1);f(i).iter().flat_map(|c|b.iter().map(move|d|format!("({c})")+d)).collect()}).collect()}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDBbsIwDIbvfYqQU6w1EW0vE4XyEJN2qSpU0gRZSlNUAoemfRIuHNgjTNqr7G0Wtk7CJ_u3_euzr_f-fHKfJeVcNeiwszQmNF2mCa1uH2en-ev3l7ZEs2GFWQq8eFdy_eZ6tIfCoybDOvEXJRclpQKt6xhUkzIn5dlSiAGENrXbtfWRjTj-Le8Kb5Qj-03w5MgTyDVDEOhUz57n5bj_Fx91213U2Iy669vaLRhlXk5A4aUBELIzRknHYHrOp5l_G_jbGi0D4iMS4hjonbHBxK-2UzhYswwgj36bD7aabEiZxGmcVXk029zmd_wA)

- Time: 2023-07-21 05:06:39Z
- Time complexity \$O(n!)\$ (same as cops' answer)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 66 bytes (7.04% reduction), cracks [Sum of Scores for buit strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263094/91213)

```c
f(s,l,i)char*s;{for(i=0;s[i]&&s[l+i]==s[i];++i);s=l?i+f(s,l-1):i;}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVBLCgIxDN3nFGVEaZ1RdCfWUfAaKlI7HwO1I5PqYsSTuHHjyhN5G1s_oEk2ebxPyOWm16XW1-vt4Ire6DEvOCUmQaG3qu6SPBVVzTEdSFrgqtOhhYlxlaZhk3GMQlJqZhi_VL2hGKM8f5zuLbTaHLKcTchlWPW3U_iFarRlwOBYYQYuJ8dDJuuSgBMwtvcEV_ConS1tlLCQwLzK5JaTEELCGcAzYKfQ8uDxlr2Moo3yHXnSF1DNxk-jmj_QV9g_J3-f8AQ)

Based on [This C tip from G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/91213)

Comment: I was hoping to see a proper golf, it's on me for leaving it open to that

Comment: @c-- Sorry about that, especially after you nicely let me save a byte before cracking my other answer

Comment: no worries, no need to be so gracious about it :p