# How Super is this Prime?

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

A [super prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-prime) is a prime whose index in the list of primes is also a prime:

```
3, 5, 11, 17, 31, 41, 59, 67, 83, 109, 127, 157, 179, 191, 211, 241, 277, 283, 331, 353, 367, 401, 431, 461, 509, 547, 563, 587, 599, 617, 709, 739, 773, 797, 859, 877, 919, 967, 991, ...
```

For this challenge, an "order 2" super prime is defined as a super prime whose index in the list of super primes is a super prime:

```
11, 31, 127, 277, 709, 1063, 1787, 2221, 3001, 4397, ...
```

An "order 3" super prime is an order 2 super prime whose index in the list of order 2 super primes is an order 2 super prime:

```
5381, 52711, 648391, ...
```

And so on.

### Task

Your task is to write a program or function, which, when given a prime, outputs/returns the highest order of super primes that the prime is a part of.

In other words, how "super" is the prime?

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the solution with the lowest byte count wins
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden
- The index of each prime in the list of primes, super primes, and so on, is assumed to be 1-indexed
- You must output:

  - 0 for primes which are not super primes
  - 1 for super primes which are not order 2 super primes
  - 2 for order 2 super primes which are not order 3 super primes
  - And so on
- You can assume inputs will always be prime numbers

### Test Cases

```
2 -> 0
3 -> 1
11 -> 2
211 -> 1
277 -> 2
823 -> 0
4397 -> 2
5381 -> 3
171697 -> 2
499403 -> 2
648391 -> 3
```

Your program must in theory be able to handle any order of super prime from 0 to infinity, even if it can only do the first few in a reasonable time.

Comment: Is `31` a valid input? If yes, is the expected output `2`?

Comment: Next prime with order `2` after `499403` is `506683`. Found with Mathematica in ~ `20` s. And checked in TIO in `1.2` s

Comment: @Arnauld Yes and yes

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110812/56656)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12 11</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆRJfịƊƬḊẎċ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a prime integer and yields the level.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5BX2sPd3ce6jq15uKPr4a6@I93/D7c/alrz/3@0kY6CsY6CoaGOghGYMDfXUbAwAgqZGFsCmabGFkBRQ3NDMxDPxNLSxAAoZ2ZiYWxpGAsA)**

#### How?

```
ÆRJfịƊƬḊẎċ - Link: prime number, P   e.g 
ÆR         - get all primes in [2..P] in ascending order
      Ƭ    - start with L=that and collect up while distinct applying:
     Ɗ     -   last three links as a monad - f(L):
  J        -     indices of L -> [1..length(L]
   f       -     filter keep if in (L)
    ị      -     index into (L) -> next level, less than or equal to P -> new L
       Ḋ   - dequeue - remove the initial list of primes
        Ẏ  - tighten - to a flat list of all of the numbers found at all levels
         ċ - count occurrences of (P)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

```
If[PrimeQ@#,1+#0@PrimePi@#,0]&/*Log2/*Floor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtOqAoMzc10EFZx1Bb2cABzAvIBHINYtX0tXzy0430tdxy8vOL/geWZqaWgJTnlUQr69qlOSjHxqrVBScn5tVVcxnpcBnrcBka6nAZgQlzcx0uCyOgkImxJZBpamwBFDU0NzQD8UwsLU0MgHJmJhbGloZctf8B)

Primes of order \$n\$ are those that are a result of applying `Prime` (with `Prime[x]` the `x`th prime) on an integer \$2^n\$ times.

Comment: Thank you for cool ideas! But what does `/*` mean here?

Comment: @lesobrod `/*` is [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html); `(f/*g)[x]`=`g[f[x]]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes

```
Þp¥(¨₂›æ;)ḟ›&›)⁽æ$ŀL‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiw55wwqUowqjigoLigLrDpjsp4bif4oC6JuKAuinigb3DpiTFgEzigLkiLCIiLCIyIC0+IDBcbjMgLT4gMVxuMTEgLT4gMlxuMjExIC0+IDFcbjI3NyAtPiAyXG44MjMgLT4gMFxuNDM5NyAtPiAyXG41MzgxIC0+IDNcbjE3MTY5NyAtPiAyXG40OTk0MDMgLT4gMlxuNjQ4MzkxIC0+IDMiXQ==)

### Explained

```
Þp¥(¨₂›æ;)ḟ›&›)⁽æ$ŀL‹
              )⁽  $ŀ   # While applying function ⁽ on the result of function ) is true, collect results.
               ⁽æ      # Function ⁽: Is argument prime?
Þp¥(¨₂›æ;)ḟ›&›)        # Function ):
Þp                     #   The list of all primes
  ¥(     )             #   #register times (starts at 0):
    ¨₂  ;              #     Filter the top of the stack by:
      ›                #       item index + 1         
       æ               #       is prime
                       #   This gets the (register)th order super primes
          ḟ›           #   Find the index of the function argument in that list
            &›         #   Increment the register for the next iteration
                    L‹ # Length of that - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84 bytes

```javascript
n=>~~Math.log2((g=n=>{for(i=k=0;k<n;i+=!d)for(d=k++;k%d--;);return!d*n&&1+g(i)})(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5BDoIwEAXQvaeAhaRjg9BWA6bWG3gIQgFrSWsKujFy9SpBV8Is/8ufmWvxKLrSqVsfGysrXwtvxGkYzkV/2ba2oQg14pM8a@uQElqkXB8NV1iEEsZMCo0x12sZxxy4q/q7M6HcmCgiuEEKXoAMgC@t6WxbjStRjYJxKECQJEG6mjE2GZkxQiaj/0Z/NtOjWbbYyylb@mXHDou9Pcu/95h/Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>106</s>  <s>98</s> 66 bytes

```
   (a=Prime@Range@PrimePi@#;0)//.c_/;!FreeQ[a=0&@@a[[#]]&/@a,#]:>c+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNC0AwGADg36LVIjIi@Wh6T864rqW39WKHOWh@/8TtuTwO/UkOvTUYdhlilPNtHcGK10Hwe7bAhiIRIjebGKLpJloUyoIDoFJMay4AM6b70aQlD8tjyX/z8rBDU7dVV4YX)

Thanks to @att!

Old less golfed version for such noobs as I am:

```
(a=Table[Prime@k,{k,PrimePi@#}];  
  c=0;  
  While[  
    MemberQ[a=If[#<=Length@a,a[[#]],Nothing]  
     /@a,#],  
  c++];
c)&
```

Comment: Great work! But for `n=648391` it will timeout? It seems better to store a result table in advance.

Comment: @138Aspen This is code golf. Answers only need to work in theory, given enough time and memory.

Comment: Yes, you are true. "Your program must in theory be able to handle any order of super prime from 0 to infinity, even if it can only do the first few in a reasonable time." I omitted the rule.

Comment: @138Aspen  Yes, you are right in terms of efficiency, but in CG the size of the code is important. And if it solves the problem in principle, it is enough. I know that Mathematica can solve this problem more efficiently, and I’ll work on it (^_^)

Comment: [-22](https://tio.run/##HctNC0AwGADg36LVIjIi@Wh6T864rqW39WKHOWh@/8TtuTwO/UkOvTUYdhlilPNtHcGK10Hwe7bAhiIRIjebGKLpJloUyoIDoFJMay4AM6b70aQlD8tjyX/z8rBDU7dVV4YX)

Comment: another [-15](https://tio.run/##HYvLCoMwFET3@Y2AVIjVPGqSgpJFP6CPZXBxkahZGEpJV6X@ehq7GWbOYVaIi1sh@hHS1KWLe8bFHqC7vvzqzB3C7Awu6/qIz33GTWEMWIuHoagNlEPFi3R7exdtPoRocdVPZrfbY4SwfRAjiBNEKUHsH1ISpFhGgutcT1xlSiVt9yW0Fk12rVBcU/RNPw) using depth as counter

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅP.ΓDāåÏ}˜I¢
```

Very slow for larger inputs due to the `āåÏ`. The test suite below uses the legacy version with a slightly modified (1 byte longer) version to speed it up significally - although it'll still time out for the largest two test cases.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//8OFUC7Ok0TEgcOlw499y5xJwqL//zMx) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXS/8OtAeemHJ5wuu1I4@Glh/trD62vPLTI5r@SXpjOoS3/o410jHUMDXWMQNjcXMfCyFjHxNjSXMfU2MJQx9Dc0MzSPBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅP        # Push a list of all primes <= the (implicit) input-prime
  .Γ      # Loop until the result no longer changes, retaining any intermediate results:
    D     #  Duplicate the current list
     ā    #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
      å   #  Check for each index whether it's in the list
       Ï  #  Only keep the values at the truthy indices
   }˜     # After the changes-loop: flatten the list of lists
     I¢   # Count the input in this flattened list
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 354 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFRS8MwFIXf/Rci7MFGZtq6rWaBqiAIbk4RfAhXyVy6BW1SshQLo7@9S9cOMiQPuefcnO8mJOd2I3Ju5TdvmvmMV3QUT6IEkxezEqbVMVkYmYuFXOg/YeZia@mDzgu9lVZqlabvfPkrWH8G7cLPixoGpKIHh71xtRbpZd9O2wlAjNjSXVUTRTH52EgXV1N6HIgq2iErxiQA2knkKvLvFkwBO@AA6g55VxRCrZgrkRuiggBIxlSZf8EtnelV6ZgOpktblLbud3qFyaM2TFKM5PRZqLXdtARAMgjQU8ZmIl8K89p63X0cEAaD81M/wH3niJWOe28E/2FA2tXZ0GQshOHQvUXZs4xFXo2xJ8JTNR57ahL6sThK/OZNNPGTeIxHJ/04SeJrP99999Fo9g)

```
NMax=648391;OrderMax=4;PrimePiPowerNest=Composition@@Table[PrimePi,{2^#}]&;x=Prime[Range@*PrimePi@NMax];res={x};n=1;While[n<=OrderMax,x=Table[x[[i]],{i,x[[;;PrimePiPowerNest[n][NMax]]]}];res=Append[res,x];n++];f[num_]:=Module[{i,output},output=-1;For[i=1,i<Length[res],i++,If[MemberQ[res[[i]],num]&&!MemberQ[res[[i+1]],num],output=i-1;Break[];];];output]
```

---

How does it work? Or Ungolfed version:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];


NMax = 648391;
OrderMax = 4;



PrimePiPowerNest[n_] := Composition @@ Table[PrimePi, {2^n}];
PrimePowerNest[n_] := Composition @@ Table[Prime, {2^n}];
x = Prime[Range[1, PrimePi[NMax], 1]];
res = {x};
n = 1;
While[n <= OrderMax,
 x = Table[x[[i]], {i, x[[;; PrimePiPowerNest[n][NMax]]]}];
 Print[x[[;; 5]]];
 res = Append[res, x];
 n++]



f[num_] := Module[{i, output}, output = -1;
 For[i = 1, i < Length[res], i++, 
  If[MemberQ[res[[i]], num] && ! MemberQ[res[[i + 1]], num], 
    output = i - 1;
    Break[];];];
 output]    (*input 648391 output 3, 648391 is 3 order super prime*)

f[2]//Print
f[3]//Print
f[11]//Print
f[211]//Print
f[277]//Print
f[823]//Print
f[4397]//Print
f[5381]//Print
f[171697]//Print
f[499403]//Print
f[648391]//Print
```

the \$k\$-th element of \$n\$-order super prime is just `PrimePowerNest[n][k]`