# Determine if an Array contains something other than 2

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Take an array which consists of positive integers or arrays, output if it only contains `2`s.

Output should be a truthy or falsey value (Sorry if this destroys answers)

### Truthy Test Cases

```
[2]
[2,2]
[[2],[2,2],2]
[]
[[],[]]
```

### Falsey Test Cases

```
[1]
[22]
[2,2,2,1]
[[1,2],2]
```

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) Are forbidden.

[Default IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) rules apply.

Code-golf, Fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Can we take in a string representing the array?

Comment: Will there be objects other than numbers and other arrays in the arrays

Comment: There will only be arrays and numbers, and a string representing the array is fine.

Comment: Is it okay if we output `0`  for truthy testcases, and some positive integer for falsey ones?

Comment: Can we assume input numbers are positive?

Comment: Input numbers will not be non-negative, and any unique output pair is acceptable...

Comment: @ATaco Does "unique output pair" mean that "a positive integer for falsey" is not allowed?

Comment: I'll allow it, as it's still clearly distinguishable from a truthy result.

Comment: @ATaco so what exactly do you allow, and why would a cat program be invalid?

Comment: Is it OK to return true` in one case and raise an error in the other? I assume no, but I can shave a byte off if the answer's yes.

Comment: Atleast one output should be uniquely consistent. And yes, error is fine.

Comment: You should clarify exactly what outputs are expected. `Default IO` would imply Truthy-falsy, but the comments say that at least one output should be consistent. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12305/31716

Comment: Alright, I'm going to be specific in the challenge, as this comment section is getting too much.

Comment: What kind of numbers? Compex int, compex float, float int, int , not negative?

Comment: What about:" Take an array void or contain integers or contain arrays of integers or array voids, output if it only contains 2s."

Comment: FTR and in the name of proper mathematical thinking: the array `[[2]]` does _not_ contain a two.

Comment: Can the array contain floating point numbers like `2.2`?

Comment: I know this challenge is almost 6 years old and there are a lot of comments, but I still don't see an answer to _user58988_'s and _user41805_'s comments: can the input contain floating point numbers like `2.2`? Also, in one of the comments you mentioned "_input numbers will not be non-negative_" (aka input-numbers can be negative, 0, or positive). If this is correct, some of the answers (mostly the regex-based ones) currently fail for it and test cases with `-2` would be appreciated.. (PS: Rules that have been clarified in comments should _always_ be added to the challenge description.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Given the sheer number of answers that ignore the commented restriction (And the age of the challenge), I'd rather now state that answers needn't worry about numbers other than positive integers. I'll adjust the challenge description to specify this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
2=p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29kW/D/f3S0UaxOtKEOkDSKBQA)

Technically, this could just be

```
2=
```

Since an array containing any zero elements is falsy, but this seems cheap.

Comment: A list containing 0 is falsy? Oh man.

Comment: I don't think the 2-byte version is valid, since in the comments ATaco said that a unique output *pair* is valid.

Comment: I believe `2=` fails for empty matrices, or?

Comment: @stewiegriffin That seems like a strange edge case to need to handle, but conveniently it does work: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29kW/D/f3R0rI5CdGwsAA "MATL – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Yes, `2=p` works fine. The shorter version in the end, `2=`, doesn't. Also, "the strange edge cases" are two of the test cases. :-)

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
f=lambda l:l>=[]and all(map(f,l))or l==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VY5BCsQgDEXX9RShKwVnQJcFexFxkaEIheiUkl3p2a21MDgJfPJfwiclOsL0WRBootn5gHkBJJIJNxk1KfXdgZyzhcGBF3DX4G3Qv1F35l48pIMViaahssGbpvY/orbpYswT0XwQItYnGNYMPDW07WtmGI8TXjMc5/iuBwlZsoYoWalyAQ)

---

At time of posting this answer, it was still allowed per [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/64121) meta consensus to output via throwing an error / not throwing an error. Therefore this answer at 26 bytes was valid:

```
f=lambda l:l==2or map(f,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBjlWNra5RfpJCbWKCRppOj@b9EwVYhmksBBDijjWJ14EwdJA5IAiKCJAgU4gKTsUAxzmhDMGmEagQQGiIZYwgxAsyP5eJKAzqkRCEzT6HECihUUlRpBZYpKMrMK1FQqq5V0LVTqK5V0gOqy00s0SjRUUjTKNHUBCpKrUhOLSjBotw1KMg/CKFD8z8A)

Comment: That's a neat way to check whether an element is a list.

Comment: This is why I don't like that consensus.  It really ruins python golfing.

Comment: However since you are going by exit code you don't need the `all`, anything other than an error is truthy.

Answer (score 11):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>43</s> 33 bytes

I smell... ***recursion***.

Thanks to *Emigna* and *Leaky Nun* for saving 10 bytes!

#### Code

```
a([]).
a([X|T]):-(X=2;a(X)),a(T).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@5@oER2rqccFpCJqQmI1rXQ1ImyNrBM1IjQ1dRI1QjT1/v8HykUbxepEG@kASSOgagA) or [Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@5@oER2rqccFpCJqQmI1rXQ1ImyNrBM1IjQ1dRI1QjR1FPX@/wfKGkFVGenAWEAhHTAXLgKTAIrHQtmGMG1I@oEQJhxtCNcPAA)

#### Explanation:

For non-Prolog users, a list is formatted in the following way: `[Head | Tail]`.

The `Head` is the first element of the list, and tail is the remaining list.  [Test it here!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@5@RmpgSX5KYmROfWlFSlJhckl@kEe0BFFSoUQgBCsfqKIB4OmCOpt7//1g1GOooGOkoGOsomKCpBwA). An important case here is that the **tail** of a list with 1 element is equal to `[]`. You can [test that here](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@5@RmpgSX5KYmROfWlFSlJhckl@kEe0BFFSoUQgBCsfqKIB4OmCOpt7//1g1GKIpAwA).

```
% State that an empty array is truthy.
a([]).

% If the list is not empty (covered by the previous line), we need to check
% whether the Head is equal to 2 or whether the head is truthy.
% After that, we only need to check if the remaining list is truthy.
a([Head | Tail]) :- (Head = 2; a(Head)), a(Tail).
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
F;2E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9mbeT6/3D7o6Y1//9Hc3FGG8XqgEgdCA3iQjgQPkQQKBYLZhnCFAMhhB1tCFHMFQsA)

### How it works

```
F;2E
F    flatten
 ;2  append 2
   E all elements are equal
```

Answer (score 9):

## Octave, 13 bytes

```
@(x)~any(x-2)
```

[**Verify all test cases.**](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776BRoVmXmFepUaFrpPk/JbO4QEM9pKg01UpdkytNI9ooFkLpQBlAAR0wDyYAFQaKxgKZEP1uiTnFMAMMoQYgDAJCqGC0IdSg/wA)

This is an anonymous function taking one input argument, `x`. It subtracts `2` from all elements, checks if there are any non-zero elements. It negates the output to get `true` for cases where all values are zero.

This works because `x-2` works for matrices of all sizes, including the empty matrix, `[]`.

`x-2` would be sufficient if there couldn't be empty matrices in the input.

Answer (score 7):

## [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 28 bytes

```
Select[Flatten@#,#!=2&]=={}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9H5yak5pcEu2Wk1hSkprnoKyjrGhrpBZra1tdq/Y/oCgzr8QhzaHaSAeIjGqBiAsuVl2rU12LxAeqMa6t/Q8A)

Comment: I think that the input `{0}` is allowed; that would result in a false positive.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>22</s> <s>19</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```js
a=>!/[^2,]|22/.test(a)
```

---

### Test it

```js
f=
a=>!/[^2,]|22/.test(a)
console.log(" "+f([2])+": "+JSON.stringify([2]))
console.log(" "+f([2,2])+": "+JSON.stringify([2,2]))
console.log(" "+f([[2],[2,2],2])+": "+JSON.stringify([[2],[2,2],2]))
console.log(" "+f([])+": "+JSON.stringify([]))
console.log(" "+f([[],[]])+": "+JSON.stringify([[],[]]))
console.log(f([1])+": "+JSON.stringify([1]))
console.log(f([22])+": "+JSON.stringify([22]))
console.log(f([2,2,2,1])+": "+JSON.stringify([2,2,2,1]))
console.log(f([[1,2],2])+": "+JSON.stringify([[1,2],2]))
```

Comment: Nice one! I wonder if it could be shortened some more, but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks, @Arnauld; still haven't figured out a way to improve on it.

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Kritixi Lithos for saving 3 bytes.*

```
\W|\b2

^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfE14Tk2TExRWn8v9/tFEsV7SRDogEMnXATDAPJADkxwJpQ5ASqDogBHGjDSHqAA)

Comment: Seems to fail for lists that contain `-2`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
˜YQP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@396TmRgwP//0dFGsTrRRjpA0igWAA)

**Explanation**

```
˜      # flatten list
 YQ    # check each element for equality to 2
   P   # product of list
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `2` work instead of `Y`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: `2` works as well. I just like the fact that there are no numbers in it :)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
∧/2=∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@@/4qG3Co47l@ka2jzq6/v93VDDiAmIwqfGoq8lIUwdMKQAZIBoo/Kh3DYTUgbAMIRqAEMQCKtIwBKk2AgA)

#### Explanation

```apl
∧/                         Only
  2=                       2s are equal to
    ∊                      any of the elements in the enlisted form of the right argument
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
FreeQ[x_/;x!=2]
```

It also works in Mathics. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S1OwVfjvVpSaGhhdEa9vXaFoaxT7P6AoM69EwUFLIU1B30GhutqoVkeh2kgHTIE4EDaYCxYCitSCGIZgdTDVQAgWqDaEqK79DwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Cases[t=Flatten@#,2]==t&
```

Pure function returning `True` or `False`. After `Flatten`ing the nested array and calling it `t`, `Cases[t,2]` returns the list of elements that match the "pattern" `2`, and `==t` checks whether that's the whole list.

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
(#//.{2->{},{{}..}->{}})=={}&
```

Not as short, but more fun. Starting from the input `#`, two replacement rules are applied until the result stops changing (`//.`): first, all `2`s are replaced by `{}`s; and then any list whose entries are all empty sets (`{{}..}`) are replaced (repeatedly) by empty sets. If the rest is an empty set (`=={}`), we win.

Comment: [Outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120353/60042), but I still really want to know what is being done here.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>28</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes - 5 bytes saved by G B

```
->x{x.flatten-[2]==[]}
```

Despite "flatten" being really long, it's still shorter than regex based solutions or recursive stuff that has to rescue errors in the base case. Ruby's built-in conflation of sets and arrays, however, is amazingly useful sometimes.

Comment: x.flatten.uniq==[2]

Comment: @NickM - that won't work on test cases like `[]` or `[[],[]]`. `[2,*x].flatten.uniq==[2]` is slightly longer

Comment: x.flatten|[2]==[2] would be shorter.

Comment: @GB and `x.flatten-[2]==[]` is shorter still. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: And yet regex wins: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120781/18535 :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

An anonymous function, takes a `String` and returns a `Bool`.

Use as `(all((==2).fst).(reads=<<).scanr(:)[]) "[2,2,2,1]"`

```hs
all((==2).fst).(reads=<<).scanr(:)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#LYpBCsMgEEX3PYWELmYwEeKyxFzEuhBrqWBscSw9vlUJA3/@@7zDhqRCKj5bV67fFEPyJA77gTstO3E@sWVnE@f0ev/AMUIUw6lO2RgBlJIonlRQQPb2QWrbUJCzKcMNtalVS3PRcu7Z6jzqoD40Nu2vXTm9dh31enp/)

## How it works

- Haskell doesn't have builtin mixed-type lists, so we take a string as argument.
- `scanr(:)[]` generates a list of all suffixes of the string.
- `(reads=<<)` tries to parse a number at the beginning of each suffix, combining the successes into a list of tuples `(n,restOfString)`.
- `all((==2).fst)` checks if all the parsed numbers are `2`.

Comment: How about just `not.all(\`elem\`"2,[]")`?

Comment: @zbw That fails because of numbers like `22`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda l:l.strip('[],2')==l*('22'in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VY7RCoMwDEWf7VcEX9KOTrCPQvcjXcHOKQjVlZo38dtdrTBcApfkXHLJoJ@7d9Pr7cA3vloojoGjsVKh0NrfOCqF4wxe7AQaDIOjCqOs/I3yshzGSS4wIZbVJlaYOqv6j0hdX2LqMyLvlrHhE4Eg/UFNRp1bet1SW8U@eNf1HAEloshmiONMUK4b3B@wbmWVridHnCQM/LgUYv8C)

Takes in a string without spaces, outputs a bool.

Checks if removing all the characters `'[],2'` of `l` gives the empty string. Also checks that `22` is not a substring -- if it is, the input `l` is used in place of the empty string to compare to the result of removal, and that always fails.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

```js
f=a=>a.map?a.every(f):a==2
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=a=>a.map?a.every(f):a==2

console.log(f([2]))
console.log(f([2,2]))
console.log(f([[2],[2,2],2]))
console.log(f([]))
console.log(f([[],[]]))

console.log(f([1]))
console.log(f([22]))
console.log(f([2,2,2,1]))
console.log(f([[1,2],2]))
```

Comment: You need to count `f=` because you referred to it.

Comment: @LeakyNun Indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
2-a~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@km1j3/3@0kQ4QxgIA)

**Breakdown:**

```
           % Implicit input
2-         % Push 2 to the stack, and subtract from input
  a        % Any non-zero elements?
    ~      % Negate to get true for cases where all elements are zero.
```

---

Well, [outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120365/31516). But I'm keeping this, since I'm quite happy I managed this all on my own (even though the task is super simple).

Answer (score 3):

## R, 28 bytes

```
function(x)!any(unlist(x)-2)
```

`unlist(x)` turns a (nested) list into a vector. Then `2` is subtracted from that vector. `any` converts (with a warning) numeric to logical and checks if there are any `TRUE`s. This is inverted with `!` and output.

This works with nested lists because `unlist` by default works recursively to unlist all list entries of the initial list.

This also works with empty lists, because `unlist(list())` becomes `numeric()`, an empty numerical vector. Coercion by `any` makes it `logical()`, which is interpreted as `FALSE` by `any`, and then reversed to `TRUE` by `!`.

Comment: `pryr::f(!any(unlist(x)-2))` saves a couple of bytes.

Comment: this is the same length as `all(unlist(x)==2)` as well.

Comment: or you could also say `any(unlist(x)-2)` which returns a consistent `TRUE` if there is a non-2 value in the flattened array and a consistent `FALSE` if all the values are `2`...

Comment: @Giuseppe Not sure if `TRUE` counts as falsey though :/

Comment: @BLT that's codegolf magic, imma check that out.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam it tends to get confused for more complex functions but for simple ones, it infers the arguments so you don't have to declare them (or write `function`). If only the package name were shorter...

Comment: @BLT, still very nice. Makes any answer using `apply` with an anonymous function that bit shorter.

Comment: @BLT maybe add it here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r?s=1|1.4077 ;)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I did a few months ago: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111578/62105

Comment: well, there's still not a consensus on meta, but https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2192/67312

Comment: @Giuseppe I think this answer is pretty clear, and has a lot more upvotes than the other answers: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/59530

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
_=>(_+"").split`,`.map(c=>!c?2:c).every(c=>c==2)
```

*Saved 5 bytes, thanks to @Shaggy!*

#### Test Cases :

```js
let f =

_=>(_+"").split`,`.map(c=>!c?2:c).every(c=>c==2)

console.log(f([2]))
console.log(f([2,2]))
console.log(f([[2],[2,2],2]))
console.log(f([]))
console.log(f([[],[]]))

console.log(f([1]))
console.log(f([22]))
console.log(f([2,2,2,1]))
console.log(f([[1,2],2]))
```

Comment: `f([])` and `f([[],[]])` should be truthy

Comment: @Arnauld Is it correct now?

Comment: I think so. :-)

Comment: Think you can save a couple of bytes with `!c` instead of `c==""`.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for pointing that out. This challenge was actually posted as a CMC in the Nineteenth byte. That CMC did not have anything to say regarding [[],[]] etc kind of test cases. When the challenge got posted on the main site, I quickly added my solution (It even asked me CAPTCHA!) without looking at rules! Thanks once again! :)

Comment: Save more with `("'+a)` instead of `a.join()`.

Comment: @Shaggy Won't that fail for `[[][]]` and similar cases?

Comment: Nope, it'll still return `true` properly.

Comment: One more: replace `!c?2:c` with `c||2` or maybe even just `c|2` - you'll need to double check that against the test cases .

Comment: *Actually*, you might even be able to use `c^2` thus allowing you to replace `c==2` with `!c`. Again, you'd need to run a full set of tests to double check it works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

No cheating. Uses nested list as input.

```python
f=lambda a:all(type(x)!=int and f(x)for x in a if x!=2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#PY3BCoAgEETP@RXbTaGLHQW/RDxsmCCYiXSwrzdtKRZm5w0D07yOeGwOARXGyK8777yKWYd0ASYHvpM/C1QICRCChzrrVbQ/M2wyq12GLvQHEhBT2DP7OvmV@5E3ksrMKjbl0qf5mBXtAQ)

Comment: -1 byte: `int!=type(x)and`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
^(\W|2\b)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfpxETXmMUk6SprfL/f7RRLFe0kQ6IBDJ1wEwwDyQA5McCaUOIEpCoCYQJhCDBaEOIagA)

Comment: `\W` doesn't seem such a good criteria : `2.2` is a number that isn't `2`, yet I suppose it would match

Comment: @Aaron I have just asked the OP on whether the array can containing decimal numbers. If they state that floating-point numbers will be present in the array, I will change my submission.

Comment: Yeah, I see RosLup asked the same question yesterday and hasn't got an answer yet. I hope OP will come soon to clarify !

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
2‚˜Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/0qGHW6TmHu///j442itWJNtIBkkaxAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
F=2Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9ma/Rw14L///9HRxvF6ihEG@kogGijWAA)

Slightly different than Leaky's algorithm.

Explanation:

```
F=2Ạ
F    Flatten
 =2  Check if equal to 2 (vectorizes)
   Ạ Check if there isn't any falsey value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
˜DOsg·Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@396jot/cfqh7YH//0cb6UBhLAA) or [Try All Tests!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#K6v8f3qOi39x@qHtgf8rlQ7vt1JQstf5Hx1tFKsTbaQDIhFMEAMkAKKA2BAkDpUEQhA32hCiLhYA)

```
˜D      # Flatten and duplicate
  O     # Sum one copy
   sg·  # Get double the length of the other copy
      Q # Check if they are equal
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>126</s> <s>55</s> 27 bytes

```
s->s.matches("(\\W|2\\b)+")
```

Port of [*@KritixiLithos*'s amazing Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120356/52210), excluding the `^...$`, since `String#matches` always matches the entire String and adds the `^...$` implicitly.

-2 bytes thanks to @Jakob for reminding me of `^...$` isn't necessary for `String#matches`.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZCxDoIwEIZ3nuLC1EYggZXoG8ji4AAMR6lahJbYamKUZ8eCLC7YNLmkue@@P3cNPjBUPZdNfR1Zi1rDHoV8eQBCGn47IeOQTV@ASqmWowRGDuYm5Bk0TW1j8GzRBo1gkIGELYw63OmoQ8MuXBOfFMXxnRRFRTc@HdMJ7@9Va/Fl6qFEDZ2NXcR5CUi/mYenNryL1N1EvW2ZVhIZMeLnSenTOX6NCVwoqwpm1Il2EVpfucr9M8QuyzlewD4XXR7/XGDwhvED)

Comment: I hate to nullify all your work on the list solution, but couldn't you coerce to a string and use the string solution?

Comment: @Jakob You mean in the explanation? I am using a regex String solution at the moment. I've just kept my original List answer and it's explanation, because the String solution is a port. Are you asking to just remove the List solution? Or add an explanation for the String solution?

Comment: I mean that as long as you have a list solution you might as well shorten it by using the string solution in it. Like `boolean c(java.util.List l){return(l+"").matches("^(\\W|2\\b)+$");}` would work, right? Just wanted to point that out in case you were planning to further golf the list solution.

Comment: Oh and you can lose 2 bytes by removing `^` and `$` in the regex, since `String.matches` only tests against the whole string.

Comment: @Jakob Removed the List answer entirely, converted to Java 8, and removed the `^...$`. Forgot about that, even though I've used it quite a lot of times in the past..

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->x{x*?!!~/[^2!]|22/}
```

Using a regex is actually shorter, because joining an array also flattens it.

### How it works

```ruby
->x{
    x*?!                -> Join array using an exclamation mark
        !~              -> String does not contain
          /[^2!]        -> characters different from '2' or '!'
                |       -> or
                 22/    -> '2' repeated at least twice
                    }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2tXUV2hZa@jWKcfHWekE1tjZKRf@79AIS062ig2lgvMgNGGMIYRUOo/AA)

Comment: Curses! Nice work. What's this `x*?!!~` construct?

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
2ṁ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4c7GR417/h9uf9S0Bojc//@PjuZSUIg2itUBUzpQBkgAwoMKQIWBorGxXApACsQ1hOpC6AZCqGC0IUx3bCwA)

#### How it works

```
2ṁ⁼  Main link. Argument: A (array)

2ṁ   Mold 2 like A. This replaces each number in A by 2.
  ⁼  Test if the result is equal to A.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḟ2=p
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lRTElQjglOUUyJTNEcCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjIlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMSUwQSU1QjIlMkMyJTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElNUIlNUIyJTVEJTJDJTVCMiUyQzIlNUQlMkMyJTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElNUIlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMSUwQSU1QiU1QiU1RCUyQyU1QiU1RCU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAxJTBBJTVCMSU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAwJTBBJTVCMjIlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMCUwQSU1QjIlMkMyJTJDMiUyQzElNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMCUwQSU1QiU1QjElMkMyJTVEJTJDMiU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAwJmZsYWdzPUM=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ḟ2=p  # Implicit input
Ḟ     # Flatten the list
 2=   # Check for == 2
   p  # All are true?
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 3 bytes

```
2-ž
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FkuMdI_uW1KclFwMFVhw0z7aKJYr2kgHRAKZOmAmmAcSAPJjgbQhSAlUHRCCuNGGEHUQcwA)

```
2-      Minus 2
  ž     Check if all elements are zero
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
2#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73@j9hO3KQGyk9j@gKDOvJFpZ1y7NQTlWrS44OTGvrpqr2qhWB0jogCkQB8IGc8FCQJFaIIOr2hCsEKYcCMEC1YYQ5Vy1/wE)

`` is `\[VectorLessEqual]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

Takes `x` as the string representation of the list. This also assumes like in the example the representations have no spaces.

```python
lambda x:set(x)<=set("[],2"*0**("22"in x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYVWcWqJRoWljC6KVomN1jJS0DLS0NJSMjJQy8xQqNDX/FxRl5pUopAFljXSAyAioJlZJ8z8A)

---

### Explanation

Both of these take the characters in the string representation of the input and determine if any characters other than `[], 2` are in it.  They do this by casting to a set and comparing to the set of just those characters.  However this fails if we have a number other than 2 which has only digits of 2 (e.g. 22 or 222), in order to patch this case we multiply the string used to create the set by the negation of whether or not `x` contains `"22"`.  If it contains it this will be the empty set, otherwise it will be the same as before.

Comment: [`lambda x:set(x)==set("[], 2")`](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYVWcWqJRoWlrC6KVomN1FIyUNP8XFGXmlSikAQWMdBRA2Cg2FigMAA)?

Comment: Fails for `[22]`

Comment: @LeakyNun Fixed

Comment: @LeakyNun Your suggestion fails for `[]`

Comment: `lambda x:set(x)<=set("[],2"*-~-("22"in x))` for -1

Comment: @ovs Already took that byte off a slightly different way, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP<7.0, 29 Bytes

Input as as string array JSON encoded

```
<?=!ereg("22|[013-9]",$argn);
```

## PHP<7.0, 42 Bytes

use the deprecated function [ereg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php)

```
<?=!ereg("22|[013-9]",json_encode($_GET));
```

## PHP, 50 Bytes

prints 1 for true and nothing for false

-1 Byte for other wise remove `!`

or + 1 Byte for true 1, false 0  add `+` before `!`

```
<?=!preg_match('#22|[013-9]#',json_encode($_GET));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgSssvSk1MztCI5oo2iuXSiTbSAVNADoQN4YKFgCKxIIYhWB1MNRCCBaINoapjE4tV4t1dQzSr7e3@29jbKhYUpabH5yaWAG1RVzYyqok2MDTWtYxVVtfJKs7Pi0/NS85PSdWA6NG0/p@anJGvFJOnZF37/2tevm4y0HWpAA)

Comment: You don't need the `$r` variable: `<?array_walk_recursive($_GET,function($i){$i-2&&die;})?>1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ohm, 6 bytes

```
∙e]Å2N
```

Uses `CP-437` encoding.

#### Explanation:

```
∙e]Å2E
∙e           ■Evaluate the input to form an array
   Å         ■any(              ,             )
  ]          ■    flatten(input)
    2N       ■                   lambda x:x!=2
             ■implict end of any and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 46 bytes

```
<?=!preg_match('/:"(?!2")/',serialize($_GET));
```

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Could you please give an example? All the test cases seem to work. If you test it not through a browser, do you pass scalar values of `$_GET` as strings?

Comment: `<?=!preg_match('/:"(?!2")/',$argn);` and input is a string representation of the serialized array - 11 Bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 6 bytes

```
!-.nQ2
```

Very similar to my CJam answer. I'm still new to Pyth, so please tell me if there's anything I can golf off.

Explanation:

```
    Q   Input:     [[[], [2]], [1]]
  .n    Flatten:   [2, 1]
 -   2  Remove 2s: [1]
!       Not:       False
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
c dÍ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=YyBkzQ&input=W1syLDJdLDJd)

```
c dÍ     :Implicit output of array
c        :Flatten
  d      :Any truthy (non-zero) when
   Í     :Subtracted from 2
         :Implicit output of negation of result
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 1.9+, 19 bytes

```
->x{x*$/!~/^2?+.$/}
```

Form is stolen from [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120781/6828)'s answer. The main difference is that I join on a newline (the default value of `$/`), which lets me write a shorter regex by using the `^.$` special characters that have specific interactions with newlines.

The trick that makes this version-specific (1.9 and higher) is the use of the "possessive" quantifier `2?+`. Like `2?`, it'll match zero or one instances of a `2`, but this form will hold onto that `2` forever and prevent it from being matched by the `.`, so a `2` on its own line won't match the overall regexp.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 90 bytes

### Submission

```
fun r(i:String):Any{return i.replace(Regex("[\\[\\]2,]+"),"")==""&&!i.contains("22")}
```

## TryItOnline

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##jVKxTsMwEN3zFYeHylatSGSMCFIrmEHARjtYrVMsXLuyHQqq@u3l7DRJF0ousSVf3r13zrtPG7Qyp1PdGHBUla/BKbNh5cz8HJwMjTOgcid3WqwkfZEb@U3J@2KB77LgyylhnBBWVYRMJjcqX1kThDKekqIg7JhlaxEErLTwHt6kDw94pF9CgzK7JpSAKhzi2TYhJebWaikMy7LYkKYMKtDKh6f6DrH3lKX8FjWQxgm3AVy@hHPbcMgAIykEufV9NU35GH0b5w8F4xBcIxn/G8JHgAa6y6qrhXQEK2Jw/Q@8RUgttL96j2IMiMdnDF2n3N2zxSd4u9fWAY0@oN2tH51BnUloO1rkEihPM5EH23pJWT92BAgHHDPW16oaaKy9qRJv3o7PJXuM8OHsHmbeSxeUNY/OWUfJXKxBGL@XLjZYAoEpDPqDxjEb9h12FLShJP4DeMZxlmvCsuPp9As)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
2J≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIySuKJiCIsIiIsIlsyLDIsMl1cbiJd)

Append a 2, check if everything is equal

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```raku
*.flat.all==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy8tJ7FELzEnx9bW6L81V1p@kYJGTmZearGmQjVXcWKlgn2ahl5JUWJesYZ6dKy6rZ26hqa6pp5rmKOPpjVX7f9oo1iuaCMdEAlk6oCZYB5IAMiPBdKGICVQdUAI4kYbQtQBAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 21 or 25 bytes

```
#(every?(set"[]2 ")%)
#(every? #{2}(flatten %))
```

The first one takes the argument as string, second one as an actual nested list.

`#{2}` is the set with one element `2`, calling it with an existing element returns it and for a non-existing it returns `nil` (falsy).

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 280 bytes

```
w(x:Union(List(Any),NNI)):Boolean==(x case List(Any)=>(g:List(Any):=x;leaf? g=>return true;for i in g repeat(q:=w(i);q=false=>return false);return true);r:NNI:=x;r=2=>true;false)
m(b:List Any):Boolean==(for i in b repeat(q:=w(i::Union(List(Any),NNI));q=false=>return false);true)
```

ungolfed and test

```
f(x:Union(List(Any),NNI)):Boolean==
      x case List(Any)=>
              g:List(Any):=x
              leaf? g =>return true
              for i in g repeat 
                         q:=f(i)
                         q=false => return false
              return true
      r:NNI:=x
      r=2=>true
      false

h(b:List Any):Boolean==
    for i in b repeat
          q:=f(i::Union(List(Any),NNI))
          q=false=> return false
    true

(5) -> [[i, m(i)] for i in [ [2],[2,2],[[2],[2,2],2],[],[[],[]] ] ]
   (5)
   [[[2],true],[[2,2],true],[[[2],[2,2],2],true],[[],true],[[[],[]],true]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
(6) -> [[i, m(i)] for i in [ [1],[22],[2,2,2,1], [[1,2],2] ]  ]
   (6)  [[[1],false],[[22],false],[[2,2,2,1],false],[[[1,2],2],false]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
```

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 7 bytes

Input is in the form of a CJam array literal.

```
q~e_2-!
```

### Explanation:

```
q  e# Read input: | "[[1 2] 2]"
~  e# Eval:       | [[1 2] 2]
e_ e# Flatten:    | [1 2 2]
2- e# Remove 2s:  | [1]
!  e# Not:        | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
⌠♂i⌡Y2#@-b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@/@oZ8GjmU2Zj3oWRhopO@gm/f8fHW2oYxQLRAA)

Explanation:

```
⌠♂i⌡Y2#@-b
⌠♂i⌡Y       call the function until the result stops changing (fixed-point combinator):
 ♂i           for each item: flatten
     2#@-   set difference: all items that are not 2s
         b  cast to boolean (1 if list is not empty, else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 26 bytes

25 bytes of code + 1 for `-n`

```perl
map$.&=$_==2,/\d+/g;say$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUBFT81WJd7W1khHPyZFWz/dujixUkXv//9oIx0wjP2XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24eAA)

Answer (score 0):

### TXR Lisp, 30 bytes

```
(opip flatten(all @1(op = 2)))
```

Run:

```
1> (opip flatten(all @1(op = 2)))
#<intrinsic fun: 0 param + variadic>
2> [*1 '()]
t
3> [*1 '(2)]
t
4> [*1 '(2 2 ())]
t
5> [*1 '(() ())]
t
6> [*1 '(() (1))]
nil
7> [*1 '((2) 1 ())]
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src), 6 bytes

```
⎕ḟ2=Π←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9tef//4o6V4bifMuKJoM6g4oaQ//9bMixbXV0)

### How?

- `⎕` evaluated input
- `ḟ` flatten
- `2=` element-wise equality with two
- `Π` product
- `←` output with no newline

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>68</s> 64 bytes

```
(defun n(l)(or(and(consp l)(n(car l))(n(cdr l)))(not l)(= l 2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxCsAgFIPhq2RrXN17GNEWBImi9vz26RK@8MeSR1uL6Xk/QSyOtTMoMVaNBvtiDN1wlI6Mde52o8DbX2w9a4LCRXpHjz1upx8)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
q]2{.n
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q%5D2%7B.n&input=%5B%5B2%5D%2C%5B2%2C2%5D%2C2%5D&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

```
F=2Ạ
```

Gained a byte because of a failed test case.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N1ujhrgX//wMA)

Comment: This fails on the [[1,2],2] test case.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Fixed at the cost of one byte.

Comment: It is now a dupe of this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120371/44874

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 19 bytes

```arturo
$=>[[]=--flatten&2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?XcylLS)

```
$=>[            ; a function
    []=         ; is the empty block equal to...
    --flatten&2 ; the input, flattened, with 2s removed?
]               ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 9 bytes

```sh
<<<${@/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVnNlQ4k/tvY2KhUO@gb1f6PjlZQqYaw9fUVahVsbRWUlBRiY9XUgGqsYhRCamogDLda63QFFYeaouJaLq40BSMQhpEQCGQrKQEJQ5AgQgbENYTKG/wHAA)

Falsey: output contains a number. Truthy: anything else (spaces or empty string). Link includes a test harness that prints `T` or `F`

Comment: This doesn't really do nested lists does it? It just seems to be space separated numbers

Comment: True, Zsh only does 1-dimensional arrays/lists

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 4 bytes

```
Ƒ2=Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//2EQj23ML/v@PjgUA)

```
Ƒ           implicit input; Ƒlatten array
 2=         is each element equal to 2?
   Π        product (returns 1 for empty array); implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
r=2
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJyPTIiLCJbMixbMl0sMl0iXQ==)

```
r=2
 =2 # Is each element equal to 2?
r   # Product
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/×⬚1/×=2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__IyBmIOKGkCAvw5c9MuKKkOKIp-KLhH7iioJbXQpmIOKGkCAvw5firJoxL8OXPTIKCmYgWzJdCmYgWzIgMl0KZiB7WzJdIFsyIDJdIDJ9CmYgW10KZiBbW11bXV0KZiBbMV0KZiBbMjJdCmYgWzIgMiAyIDFdCmYge1sxIDJdIDJ9Cg==)

```
/×⬚1/×=2
      =2  # where are elements equal to two?
  ⬚1/×    # multiply columns, filling missing elements with one
/×        # product
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 9 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(⊢≡2⍴⍨≢)∊
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=03jUtehR50KjR71bHvWueNS5SPNRRxcA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFDSMFI00QCUSGmppcj7CIG2lqAgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Alternatively, another 9-byte solution:

```
∧/'2 '∊⍨⍕
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9SxXF/dSEH9UUfXo94Vj3qnAgA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFDSMFI00QCUSGmppcj7CIG2lqAgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)