# Matrix with 1 to L(n), in all n columns

Tags: code-golf, matrix

### Challenge:

Take a list, **L** containing positive integers as input:

```
3 5 2 1 6
```

and create a matrix where the n'th column contains the vector **1:L(n)**, where shorter rows are padded with zeros.

#### Test cases:

```
3   5   2   1   6
-----------------
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   0   2
3   3   0   0   3
0   4   0   0   4
0   5   0   0   5
0   0   0   0   6

1
-
1

1   2   3   4   3   2   1
-------------------------
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   2   2   2   2   2   0
0   0   3   3   3   0   0
0   0   0   4   0   0   0
```

#### Rules:

- Optional input and output formats

  - List of lists is an acceptable output format
- The matrix must be as small as possible (you may not pad it with more zeros than needed)
- Shortest code in each language wins
- Explanations are highly encouraged

Comment: May we distribute the ranges horizontally instead?

Comment: No, they should be vertical. If you use a language where the words horizontal/vertical doesn't have any meaning then it's optional. (Could be relevant for languages where lists of lists aren't associated with either horizontal/vertical directions)

Comment: @StewieGriffin What sane language doesn't associate dimensions with nested lists?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, How many insane languages are used on this site?

Comment: @StewieGriffin It depends on how you define *insane*, but if your language doesn't have any concept of dimensionality at all, I'm not sure how sane it is.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer R for one doesn't see matrices as nested list, but rather one long list, which wraps around row-wise.

Answer (score 20):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```r
function(l)outer(m<-1:max(l),l,"<=")*m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHM7@0JLVII9dG19AqN7ECKKCTo6NkY6ukqZX7P00jWcNYx1THSMdQx0xT8z8A)

Explanation:

`outer` applies its third argument (the function) to all combinations of elements of its first two arguments, generating a matrix of `TRUE` and `FALSE` where each column has `TRUE` where `1:max(l)` is less than or equal to the corresponding element of `l`, for the example where `l=c(3,5,2,1,6)`:

```r
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Then supposing the resultant matrix is `A`, then `A*m` -> `A[i,j]=A[i,j]*i` which coerces `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0, producing the desired result.

Comment: I think - you can save 2 bytes, by replacing `function(l)` with `l=scan();`

Comment: @AndriusZ but then I'd have to wrap everything in a `print` so I would lose those bytes.

Comment: I think, you don't need to wrap everything - [TOI](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8e2ODkxT0PTOr@0JLVIQyPXRtfQKjexQiNHU1MnR0fJxlZJUyv3vyGXCZcxl9l/AA)

Comment: @AndriusZ we've definitely talked about this before. The only answer to [this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13743/67312) gives a +4 penalty for using `source(...,echo=TRUE)` and reading from stdin as a full program, if you have an alternative suggestion, by all means weigh in there, but as far as I'm aware that's the closest we have to an R consensus on full programs and it stands for the time being.

Comment: Late to the game: [save two bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@7@gqLLIyipNI7@0JLVII9dG19AqN7FCI0dTJ0dHycZWSVMrV/N/mkayhrGOqY6RjqGOmabmfwA) using [this tip] (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111578/80010)

Comment: @JayCe yeah, that would make this an `R + pryr` answer rather than a pure R answer, which technically counts as a separate language.

Comment: @Giuseppe Didn't know that - I've seen this used in so many answers. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
"@:]Xho!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8nBKjYiI1/x//9oQwUjBWMFEyA2UjCMBQA)

#### Explanation

```
"      % Implicit input, L. For each k in L
  @    %   Push k
  :    %   Range [1 2 ... k]
]      % End
Xh     % Collect all stack contents in a cell array
o      % Convert to double matrix. The content of each cell is
       % right-padded with zeros if needed
!      % Transpose. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda x:[[-~i*(i<a)for a in x]for i in range(max(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDoMwDADAr0RMNjIDRTAgeEnI4AoClsBEgSEs/Xoqbrrw3NupTfbjlHc@vjOb1Ftb/aQEGRj9GQ0bUZPcW3kbWdcFDk6QEF0OUfSG0oNtqKUP1dQ5pGsJYzFpgfkP)

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
PadRight@Range@#&
```

Contains U+F3C7 (Mathematica's builtin `Transpose` function)

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

#### Usage

```
PadRight@Range@#&[{3, 5, 2, 1, 6}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
>  {2, 2, 2, 0, 2},
>  {3, 3, 0, 0, 3},
>  {0, 4, 0, 0, 4},
>  {0, 5, 0, 0, 5},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 6}
> }
> ```

#### Explanation

```
PadRight@Range@#&

         Range@#    (* Generate {1..n} for all elements of input *)
PadRight@           (* Right-pad 0s so that all lists are equal length *)
                   (* Transpose the result *)
```

Comment: @downvoters why the downvotes? Could y'all explain?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it is because you are lacking the function signature or an input of arguments, which causes your code snippet not to be a black box!

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 26 bytes

```matlab
@(x)((y=1:max(x))'<=x).*y'
```

Anonymous function that inputs a row vector and outputs a matrix.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0JTQ6PS1tAqN7ECyNZUt7Gt0NTTqlT/n6YRbaxgqmCkYKhgFqv5HwA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `x = [3 5 2 1 6]`. This is a row vector of size 1×5.

`1:max(x)` gives the row vector `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`, which is assigned to variable `y`.

The transpose of that, i.e. the column vector `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]`, is `<=`-compared (element-wise with broadcast) with the input `[3 5 2 1 6]`. The result is the 6×5 matrix

```matlab
[1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 0 1;
 1 1 0 0 1;
 0 1 0 0 1;
 0 1 0 0 1;
 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Finally, multiplying (element-wise with broadcast) by the column vector `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]`, obtained as `y` transposed, gives the desired result:

```matlab
[1 1 1 1 1;
 2 2 2 0 2;
 3 3 0 0 3;
 0 4 0 0 4;
 0 5 0 0 5;
 0 0 0 0 6]
```

Comment: I was hoping to see a MATLAB/Octave submission. I implemented this without putting any thought into it, so it was probably more than 40 bytes. Very nice solution :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
€L0ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdMaH4Nz2/7/jzbWMdUx0jHUMYsFAA) or as a [nicely formatted test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/UdMaH4Nz2/4f2q1zeKvO/2hjHVMdIx1DHbNYrmhDIMtYxwSIgSJIfFMdMx1zHQsdy1gA)

```
€L   # For each: get the range 1..input
  0ζ # zip, padding with 0s
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

Returns a list of lists

```
T0mḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkJtb/Kip8X@IQe7DHYv///8fbaxjqmOkY6hjFgsA)

#### Explanation

```
  m    Map over the input
   ḣ   Range from 1 to n
T0     Transpose, padding with 0s
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Rz0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@oyuD/4Xb3//8NdYx0jHVMgNhIxxAA)

### Explanation

```
Rz0  Input: array A
R    Range, vectorizes to each integer
 z0  Transpose and fill with 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
.tSMQZ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.tSMQZ&input=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D&debug=0)** or **[Verify all the test cases (with pretty-print)!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.tSMQZ&input=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C5%2C2%2C1%2C6%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

```
.tSMQZ   - Full program.

  SMQ    - Get the inclusive unary ranges for each.
.t       - Transpose, padding with copies of...
     Z   - ... Zero.
         - Implicit print.
```

A non-built-in transpose version [would be](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jmm%2ahd%3CdkQeS&input=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C5%2C2%2C1%2C6%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&debug=0):

```
mm*hd<dkQeS
```

This works as follows:

```
mm*hd<dkQeS   - Full program.

m        eS   - Map over [0, max(input)) with a variable d.
 m      Q     - Map over the input with a variable k.
   hd         - d + 1.
  *           - Multiplied by 1 if...
     <dk      - ... d is smaller than k, else 0.
              - Output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 17 bytes

```
;M╗♂R⌠╜;0@α(+H⌡M┬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9hY3R1YWxsef//O03ilZfimYJS4oyg4pWcOzBAzrEoK0jijKFN4pSs//9bMywgNSwgMiwgMSwgNl0)

Explanation:

```
;M╗♂R⌠╜;0@α(+H⌡M┬
;M╗                store the maximal element (M) of the input in register 0
   ♂R              range(1, n+1) for each n in input
     ⌠╜;0@α(+H⌡M   for each range:
      ╜;0@α          push a list containing M 0s
           (+        append to range
             H       take first M elements
                ┬  transpose
```

Comment: Yeah, Actually actually needs zip with padding support...

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 3 bytes

This uses the new feature of Pyke, hex encodings... The best part is that we tie Jelly! Raw bytes:

```
4D 53 AC
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=4D+53+AC&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&warnings=0&hex=1)

The ASCII-Pyke equivalent would be [4 bytes](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=MS.%2C&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&warnings=0&hex=0):

```
MS.,
```

## How?

```
4D 53 AC   - Full program.

4D         - Map.
   53      - Inclusive range.
      AC   - Transpose with zeroes.
           - Output implicitly.

-------------------------------------

MS.,   - Full program.

M      - Map.
 S     - Inclusive range.
  .,   - Transpose with zeroes.
       - Output implicitly.
```

[Here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=MS.%2CJ&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&warnings=0&hex=0) is a pretty-print version with ASCII, and [here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=4D+53+AC+4A&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&warnings=0&hex=1) is one with hex encodings.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>62</s> 57 + 1 (`-a`) = 58 bytes

```perl
$,=$";say map$i*($_-->0),@F while++$i&&(sort{$b-$a}@F)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFybo4sVIhN7FAJVNLQyVeV9fOQFPHwU2hPCMzJ1VbWyVTTU2jOL@opFolSVclsdbBTTPaIPb/f0MFIwVjBRMgtlAw/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/biIA)

Comment: Nice answer! You can save 1 byte with this too by moving to `"@{[...]}"` instead of setting `$,` and (I'm sure you probably don't want to but...) you can replace the `sort` call with an additional flag `-MList::Util+(max)` and call `max` instead.

Comment: @DomHastings Under the rules of the time, the -M flag would have been added to the byte count, significantly increasing it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 39 bytes

```perl6
{zip (1 X..$_).map:{|@_,|(0 xx.max-1)}}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoIwEITvPMUcjJREGusPBwmGq2/gwcQYrQkJQtOCosCTefPFcGuJh8lm55vMrpI6j4baSNwjfo692xPTc3mRSIb2lSkwgT3nk2PAbye1abv0OOvYHE1DexOKoO@Ha6mRZ4U0LPi8@aPUF0NzV1QIt0izQtUVWg@g6oOWps4rJLA3mINBTNCGfJf1Z87nin77s7KuHHQVf8ita19w/phnVNoPSwBr0oIkSJEnPDHulq3G@eNf)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{                # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  zip

    (1 X.. $_)   # turn each input into a Range that starts with 1

    .map:        # map each of those Ranges using the following code

    {            # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢@_｣ 
                 # (｢@_｣ takes precedence over ｢$_｣ when it is seen)

      |@_,       # slip the input into a new list

      |(         # slip this into the list

        0        # a ｢0｣
        xx       # list repeated by

          .max   # the max of ｢$_｣ (implicit method call)
          - 1    # minus 1 (so that zip doesn't add an extra row)
      )
    }
}
```

Note that [`zip`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/zip.html) terminates once the shortest input list is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/c8eefd5e0d7cd1078cf157bd0a2d61ab), 136 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `Int32[]` `i` An array of ints
- **Output** `Int32[,]` A bidimentional array.

---

#### Golfed

```cs
i=>{int m=System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(i),l=i.Length,x,y;var o=new int[m,l];for(y=0;y<m;y++)for(x=0;x<l;)o[y,x]=i[x++]>y?y+1:0;return o;};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
i => {
    int
        m = System.Linq.Enumerable.Max( i ),
        l = i.Length,
        x, y;
        
    var o = new int[ m, l ];
    
    for( y = 0; y < m; y++ )
        for( x = 0; x < l; )
            o[ y, x ] = i[ x++ ] > y ? y + 1 : 0;
            
    return o;
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Take an array of Int32
i => {

    // Store the max value of the array, the length and declare some vars to save some bytes
    int
        m = System.Linq.Enumerable.Max( i ),
        l = i.Length,
        x, y;
        
    // Create the bidimensional array to output
    var o = new int[ m, l ];
    
    // Cycle line by line...
    for( y = 0; y < m; y++ )
    
        // ... and column by column...
        for( x = 0; x < l; )
        
            // And set the value of the line in the array if it's lower than the the value at the index of the input array
            o[ y, x ] = i[ x++ ] > y ? y + 1 : 0;
            
    // Return the bidimentional array.
    return o;
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestBench {
    public class Program {
        // Methods
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Func<Int32[], Int32[,]> f = i => {
                int
                    m = System.Linq.Enumerable.Max( i ),
                    l = i.Length,
                    x, y;
                var o = new int[ m, l ];
                for( y = 0; y < m; y++ )
                    for( x = 0; x < l; )
                        o[ y, x ] = i[ x++ ] > y ? y + 1 : 0;
                return o;
            };

            List<Int32[]>
                testCases = new List<Int32[]>() {
                    new[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 4 },
                    new[] { 3, 5, 2, 1, 6 },
                    new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
                };

            foreach( Int32[] testCase in testCases ) {
                Console.WriteLine( " INPUT: " );
                PrintArray( testCase );

                Console.WriteLine( "OUTPUT: " );
                PrintMatrix( f( testCase ) );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void PrintArray<TSource>( TSource[] array ) {
            PrintArray( array, o => o.ToString() );
        }
        public static void PrintArray<TSource>( TSource[] array, Func<TSource, String> valueFetcher ) {
            List<String>
                output = new List<String>();

            for( Int32 index = 0; index < array.Length; index++ ) {
                output.Add( valueFetcher( array[ index ] ) );
            }

            Console.WriteLine( $"[ {String.Join( ", ", output )} ]" );
        }

        public static void PrintMatrix<TSource>( TSource[,] array ) {
            PrintMatrix( array, o => o.ToString() );
        }
        public static void PrintMatrix<TSource>( TSource[,] array, Func<TSource, String> valueFetcher ) {
            List<String>
                output = new List<String>();

            for( Int32 xIndex = 0; xIndex < array.GetLength( 0 ); xIndex++ ) {
                List<String>
                    inner = new List<String>();

                for( Int32 yIndex = 0; yIndex < array.GetLength( 1 ); yIndex++ ) {
                    inner.Add( valueFetcher( array[ xIndex, yIndex ] ) );
                }

                output.Add( $"[ {String.Join( ", ", inner )} ]" );
            }

            Console.WriteLine( $"[\n   {String.Join( ",\n   ", output )}\n]" );
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `136 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 17 bytes

```
{a*~x</:a:1+!|/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pO1KqrsNG3SrQy1Fas0a+o5eJKczBWMFUwUjBUMAOyDYEsYwUTIAaKAAA2CAsF)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 142 bytes

```c
i,j,k;main(c,v)char**v;{for(;++i<c;k=k<*v[i]?*v[i]:k)printf("%c ",*v[i]);for(i=48;puts(""),i++<k;)for(j=1;j<c;)printf("%c ",i<=*v[j++]?i:48);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoMwEIRfpQQKiYkHfw7iJvggxYMsaDepVqL1Uvrq3aq3HmYO8/ENpgMiMxlvAowdTRLNpvDexSTZ4N0/owStySIEF2yy3ahtzq6DmiNNay/FFS/CnKOCQyBXVjC/1kUKoQxpbQOoA3iXgd@v/k2ybpe91m1DdVkp@DBzxjkXXO7JOfti/@iGhdOxyH8)

Comment: [137 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYu7DoIwGEZ3n4LUmPTGwGUgtIRXYDcMpFL8W0EC2MX46v4iw/lyhu@YeDAG8XzrLUx91ERGzQtMm6XkYiIieTiBdNKrsYOJGhmYuXcL50G97XOhSgjQzRVaJn3lNQ@71seWnqn/A6q8UPNrWykhTLoKhNBesSN2e@qEaDXUeVECY@qDiAmmmGG@k2LyNfbRDSvGY5b@AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 38 bytes

```
a=>[[i<j?-~i:0for j:a]for i:0..max(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/R1i46OtMmy163LtPKIC2/SCHLKjEWRAO5enq5iRUaiZqx/wuKMvNKNNRj8tT1svIz8zRyEwvAuLikSFNBW0FdQUEBIqOjkKYRbaxjqmOkY6hjFqsJBP8B)

Comment: Let me guess, the bug is the space after it?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes. The question mark will consume the character after it to make sure it's not another question mark but I forgot to compensate for the extra character resulting in it being skipped.

Comment: Seems you got a pull, you can now remove the notice :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 37 bytes

```
D,g,@@*,bL_1+0XA$p$+bUp
L~*,€RAbM€gBc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HwUFLJ8kn3lDbIMJRpUBFOym0gMunTkvnUdOaIMckXyCV7pQMVJmVn5mn41Cnw6UABMZGzllcXEDtRZkpOg4QMcPYpFAwA6ilGqS6Nu///2hjBVMFIwVDBbPYf/kFJZn5ecX/dXUzcwtyMpMzS4DM4oLU5My0SluQSQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
x=>f=(t=1,s,e=x.map(y=>y<t?0:s|=t))=>s?[e,...f(++t)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsIwEIDh3Se5o2cwVh2ql259iZAh1FSU2hRzSAu@eww4OvzT9z/826f@dZ9lO8VryB3nhc3AIKwpUeBFPf0MK5v1Iu2uSR8WRDaptYGUUgNUlaBrrMvnTR@nFMegxniDDmxNR9qTppNDQPxjXbCmQ6lMvyV/AQ)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...Array(Math.max(...x,t=0))].map(_=>x.map(y=>y<t?0:t,++t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1i5aT0/PsagosVLDN7EkQy83sUIDKFKhU2JroKkZC@QXaMTb2lWAGZW2dpU2JfYGViU62tolmpr/rbmS8/OK83NS9XLy0zXSNKKNdUx1jHQMdcxiNTUxJA2BUsY6JkAMVAJS8B8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 115 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,m=0;for(int j:a)m=j>m?j:m;var r=new int[m][l];for(;l-->0;)for(m=0;m<a[l];r[m][l]=++m);return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVHBTsMwDL3zFT42WhttDDg0dIgPYJcdqx5Ml42UJJ1Sd2ia@u0lScsBMaRYcmy/@L2XBs@YNfvPsdbYdfCGyl7vAJQl6Q5YS9iGayyUVVlBncQMkAlfH3z40xGSqmELFgoYMdtc/RDoArmW9kgfqSmW4tC6gIUmR2aKZmNemtyIMzpwhZVfcYOpSl3FSaGzbLMULOQBbZ4xtNw0UiwWhgknqXcWnBhGMRE59e/aE5n5nFu1B@MVJTtyyh7LCtmkhmRHyc/S6rpOH9P7dJU@DVHVn/7qv7pHrdMHHx493HAkMoigyTVlTz2x344675nlwdfQm/bMXgWfIQfHYhFgd@lIGt72xE9eEGmbNP7/eE9K81fn8NJxaiexCbL5sRuomeowfgM)

```java
a->{                  // Method with integer-array parameter and integer-matrix return-type
  int l=a.length,     //  Length of the array
      m=0;            //  Largest integer in the array, 0 for now
  for(int j:a)        //  Loop over the array
    m=j>m?            //   If the current item is larger than `m`:
       j              //    Set `m` to this item as new max
      :               //   Else:
       m;             //    Leave `m` the same
  var r=new int[m][l];//  Result-matrix of size `m` by `l`, filled with zeroes by default
  for(;l-->0;)        //  Loop over the columns
    for(m=0;m<a[l];   //   Inner loop over the rows
      r[m][l]=++m);   //    Set the cell at position `m,l` to `m+1`
  return r;}          //  Return the result-matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
+1⍉⬚¯1∵⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAgKzHijYnirJrCrzHiiLXih6EKCmYgWzMgNSAyIDEgNl0KZiBbMV0KZiBbMSAyIDMgNCAzIDIgMV0K)

```
+1⍉⬚¯1∵⇡
      ∵⇡  # range of each
   ⬚¯1    # filling with -1
  ⍉       # transpose
+1        # increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Would be 4 if Japt's transpose padded with `0` instead of `null`.

```
mõ zÔÕ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bfUgetTV&input=WzMgNSAyIDEgNl0KLVI)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 48 bytes

```
Ans→A
List►matr(1 or Ans,[A]
[A]
For(I,2,max(ʟA
List►matr(I(I≤ʟA),[B]
augment(Ans,[B]
End
Ansᵀ
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Similar method to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142065/91262).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 20 bytes

```
{+(1+!'x),'&'-x-|/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW1jDUVlSv0NRRV1PXrdCt0a+o5eJKczBWMFUwUjBUMAOyDYEsYwUTIAaKAAAxkQrR)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 76 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Ba8JAEIXv@RXvOAMh1BY9hG6gx0I9FU@Sw6i7YWXdhM00VMTfHlcR5zDMe3wM37iXIHO/O9q9Yi0@4lIUwCQBrgb9@FG331Fb0zzOV24ZZg6mCZULomsZaDINLaA9QnWSf85rIG8a78h/mok9bBgt3pirLvV/gz3QE9T@/nUGDtbhlBVIUjfW@EpJzttfTT52LdfYRK8w2Q95htxqiOQeivRRYlnivcSixIqZM3MtrvMN)

```scala
l=>l.flatMap(v=>(1 to l.max).map(i=>if(i<=v)i else 0)).grouped(l.max).toList
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BSwMxEIXv/RXvmMASrNIeiit4FOxJPJUexjZZIkl2SaaiLfvbt0lcqqeZee/jDS8dyNE09R@f@sDYkg24LICjNjDCbfBqE@9eAu/lvN@EPdqKAl/k4PMlluAeTnn6lor7QlbfKeOItzTgUtiTRvtUDcBnuMj2TwKsgbB4bH9hmU3tksbdDIx1jqqL/WnQR@FVsmf97@O4mBv4XEdQ7NIGzzHSz@6Now1d6fIeLN8KDFllF4QRJUE8NFg1uG@wbLCWUtbIcZqu)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(l: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val m = (1 to l.max).toList
    l.flatMap { value =>
      m.map { i =>
        if (i <= value) i else 0
      }
    }.grouped(m.size).toList
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(List(3, 5, 2, 1, 6)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 10 bytes

```
0|:>:@i."0
```

No surprises

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxyqDGys7KIVNPyQAicFNPkys1OSNfIU3BWMFUwUjBUMEMLKCuDhM3BIoaK5gAMVAWomvBAggNAA)

```
0|:>:@i."0
      i."0   NB. create 0..n-1 range for each atom
   >:@       NB. then increment
0|:          NB. transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 8 bytes

```
ṀR$ᵒ{≤0I
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fuse7mwIUnm4dVL1o84lBp5LipOSi6FSC_ZHG-uY6hjpGOqYxXJFG4IwkGesYwLEQNFYiDIA)

Longer than other answers, because Nekomata doesn't have a padding builtin yet. I'll add one in some future version.

```
ṀR$ᵒ{≤0I
Ṁ           Maximum
 R          Range from 1 to that
  $         Swap
   ᵒ{       Make a 2D array by the following function
     ≤      If left <= right, return left
      0I    Otherwise, return 0
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 8 bytes

```
R:∑0*ᵚ+Ť
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FmuDrB51TDTQerh1lvbRJUuKk5KLoTIL9kcb65jqGOkY6pjFckUbgjCQZ6xjAsRA0ViIMgA)

```
R:∑0*ᵚ+Ť
R           Range from 1 to input
 :          Duplicate
  ∑         Sum
   0*       Multiply by 0
     ᵚ+     Add this to each element of the other array
       Ť    Transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⍉∘↑⍳¨
```

Anonymous tacit function.
Did you know that APL's Mix function automatically pads with zeros?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wSFR72djzpmPGqb@Kh386EV//@XpBaXFINlNIwVTBWMFAwVzDQ1DIEIyDZWMAFioJgmF1idTrSBnmls2qEVYB4A)