# smallest number of steps for a knight in chess

Tags: code-golf, grid, graph-theory, chess

If you place a knight on any square of a chessboard, what is the smallest amount of steps to reach every position?

**Rules**

- It is an 8 by 8 board.
- The knight starts at an arbitrary position, taken as input.
- The knight moves 2 squares in one direction and 1 square in the other, for example, a knight on the square marked N can move to any of the squares marked X:

```
. X . X .
X . . . X
. . N . .
X . . . X
. X . X .
```

**Example** 
With input `1, 0`, we start by putting a 0 in that position:

```
. 0
```

We then put a 1 in the positions that are a knight's move away from that 0, i.e. they are 2 squares away in one direction and 1 square away in the other. We don't fill in the 0:

```
. 0 . .
. . . 1
1 . 1 .
```

Then, we fill in all the empty cells that are exactly two knight's moves away with 2s:

```
. 0 . 2 . 2
2 . 2 1 2 .
1 2 1 . . 2
2 . 2 . 2 .
. 2 . 2 . .
```

Then, the 3s:

```
3 0 3 2 3 2 3 .
2 3 2 1 2 3 . 3
1 2 1 . 3 2 3 .
2 3 2 3 2 3 . 3
3 2 3 2 3 . 3 .
. 3 . 3 . 3 . .
3 . 3 . 3 . . .
```

And we continue until we've filled the entire 8x8 board:

```
3 0 3 2 3 2 3 4
2 3 2 1 2 3 4 3
1 2 1 4 3 2 3 4
2 3 2 3 2 3 4 3
3 2 3 2 3 4 3 4
4 3 4 3 4 3 4 5
3 4 3 4 3 4 5 4
4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5
```

**Challenge**
The pattern printed for a knight, as short as possible, in any reasonable format.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice challenge idea! You need to include the desired output, so that the validity of answers can be verified. Also, a fixed output can make the challenge less interesting. Consider taking the starting position as input

Comment: Also, are you sure the numeric array you show corresponds to a queen? It looks like that of a horse to me

Comment: To illustrate my point about fixed vs variable input: with fixed input an approach based on compressing the array of numbers (regardless of their meaning) can be shorter than an approach that actually uses the rules for the moves. I got 27 bytes vs 33 bytes respectively in MATL. The fact that compression is more efficient makes the challenge less interesting, I think. If you maintain fixe input, please remove "for example" from the text, and add the [tag:Kolmogorov-complexity] tag

Comment: It is not a fixed output, it depends on the strat poosition.

Comment: I edited the challenge text. Please make sure that it is as you intend. Also, you should include several more test cases with input and correct output

Comment: is a flat list of 64 ints a reasonable output format?

Comment: also: is a single number between 0 and 63 (index of cell in row-major order) ok as input?

Comment: @ngn I would prefere a coordinate input (x,x)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. However, we usually don't accept any answer for `code-golf`. If you really want to accept an answer, you should wait one week or so and pick one that satisfies the winning criterion (i.e. the shortest one).

Comment: @Arnauld I chose it, cus it is in javascript (The language I am familiar with, and not a language I never hear of but see a lot on this site like MATL or charcoal). The challange is to get the smallest size of code. Wy bothering writing in a language when knowing yo cant get under 22 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>24 23</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
W8p¤ạṢ€ċØ½ʋƇ$ƬŒṬĖP€o/’
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of integers and yields a list of lists of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//VzhwwqThuqHhuaLigqzEi8OYwr3Ki8aHJMasxZLhuazEllDigqxvL@KAmf/Dh0f//zEsMQ)** (The footer pretty prints the grid)

#### How?

Repeatedly finds coordinates reachable from the current list of coordinates starting with just the given coordinate. Then creates grids from each of these lists with their grid number at the identified coordinates and reduces these with logical OR to keep the first non-zero value at each coordinate. This has the initial position as \$1\$ rather than \$0\$, so all numbers are then reduced by one.

```
W8p¤ạṢ€ċØ½ʋƇ$ƬŒṬĖP€o/’ - Link: integers [x, y]
W                      - wrap -> [[x, y]]
             Ƭ         - collect up while distinct applying:
            $          -   last two links as a monad:
   ¤                   -     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 8                     -       eight
  p                    -       ([1..8]) Cartesian power ([1..8]) -> all coordinates
           Ƈ           -     keep those for which:
          ʋ            -       last four links as a dyad:
    ạ                  -         absolute difference (vectorises)
     Ṣ€                -         sort each
        Ø½             -         [1,2]
       ċ               -         count occurrences
              ŒṬ       - convert to grids of zeros with ones at the coordinates 
                Ė      - enumerate -> [[1, 1st grid], [2, 2nd grid], ...]
                 P€    - product of each -> grids with 1s replaced by grid number
                    /  - reduce by:
                   o   -   logical OR (vectorises)
                     ’ - decrement
```

---

Alternative 22, same method just identifying the existence of `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` by filtering for those which, when sorted, are invariant under the operation of getting the range of their length (`[1,2]`):

```
W8p¤ạṢJƑ$Ƈ¥Ƈ$ƬŒṬĖP€o/’
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>272</s> <s>264</s> <s>193</s> <s>190</s> 188 bytes

```
;=nF;=xP;=yP;=sS*'9'64+*8y xT0;W>9=n+1n;=r~1W>8=r+1r;=c~1W>8=c+1c;=a~3W>4=a+1a;=b~3W>4=b+1b&?5+*a a*b b&&&&>8=x+a r<~1x&>8=y+b c<~1y>E Gs+x*8yT=qGs+r*8cT=sSs+x*8yT+1q;=i~8W>64=i+8iO Gs i 8
```

Input is 0-based horizontal and vertical coordinates, each on separate lines.

A fitting language for this challenge... or maybe not...

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrU9tIFv2eX9FoM1htCWFn2CxYtKmEJVOpnZhsYIbatZ3QarVtTWTJ6AFmbPHXmdt6tvwiQxWUpD59X33uo/mD3tOQBc4sOvB8mz8zl4Yh@o/njCfRRRD4AeLziHt2iNK3RZIBPtMg5PV1aU@B@hJ7kTN9GXcVBZxOF8z3wiiIWeQHKsWLaOKERujHAeOEJrDizG4mTsTDGWVczdenNGIT9fCr2h8MB/1BCN@TzlBb/qP/deANm@rAW77GuHmIkxnn32E14FEceEgS3m8Nl0svdt0kE2bpjLTwwuURosQy@JwzVYJjMxchthBC6Jl46MgQIj0bYWyB7SoFNYbLvXE0wTrtsyFOIh8cd7zxRquSJA0Huv7f54sr0h@aWah@p27MF2FEI4ehmTgF1cILy1gLjzmCKN7TAHxomfQ0FZPrN6mmZf4xkn7v06FRyDKdkcpwbg9LJF@TIPbSsAf@A/L4Q8aIxOZWPN7wfYt3qRCjWgRcL55aPNiCKxYB9973XU69LcByNclZ9SsEI6BuSbwsdCskC@OZkK6nor7ZNKLAtcxRSckGZ/L3at8mT/L3OmjNjeKDDON3rjAvR1DkgNXUY9wfZV5LbuzvS8YDH7OnIgpCeBmCPCRr/Cm4XmXT9Ych7r87@P@weai3S8rT/X1xwEKmqlwrQhtO7Hg6K525LZx5neZngm8TN5pUruxVtu7v09qxjWUcknF7dWCSkXkWhxNVfMVmlioXvd8/frnsfbroXZNFkifMR5t70QoHXnK/Tw/@/DYUf1sHJ98gBKsBSIWCsckuNjkCBGyqxyfd6owcwGUhynAiUGCuM/aEHMmTfoUZltTMDN6CEhl87zs2au2J8yksN6sEleuyevub993zHzzklJahRs20xm095qkLuIivFN0fpdfA1tZDCgHN04XiVVLlCxWnqG1LXCn2V5zRqFQ6cAI1eCf8oA6fxu5OeLMOt5172ctqSZxE7RAKUZ9oNDGANx6TpB6C39sOSTmnnudHCFTBmSDrEf3JA18BU337b@quFP5EX9QH4mPXl/TN/Ifd@irxy@WeSk9b@IecbzZ/wHs@n/meICmNeGoQinyojR4fA9/uOQLjeABGulsqyal8blvrTbeGqhG/on0PGuJu3kvVuyR@Ly@pOOO8EFIrIUUFEe12JQcUAVaxsqszpPJy518IJfOnYCZPtxhKGYy/uUsOjvhWRAea44vBERSyCJV6jtIYYpjjwsHVsHmGB@1D/U1KKxENYJYlEwk0iGElG2KokQ13Aqw0RFtiy2VDaYgHXLlUDa2i6IFVU8cDJtnoLvaBUNxjfiw@c7uDXi9ocruppaf21/NIb7fwctlaqVn5gLCrZgknbnNArnC99AhQpcsI@IxT6D1yBXqB8eWotZPxJUo@VPiYd1fYRe2rR491aEICfhc7AVeVUahgfSFG5HTJkpbYxHHtb7PAZzwUqA@/9c6vP172rqre/AFqwK7WLLEkO2CYzEsxfUvqdOlJS7OqKfHqrJNmnbY08GHGGC7maTEfixcb5mP7lBWzsV3MxiOSWmQUpghle6MtdPrkQO/2xogG43gqBo7XC1trJwiUoJHwEjqqJRqpybPAjnAinbEIhMp0S@crIwV8YitjhRBHaPbs0SknVvYMqkPC1mfXdINqGEaJKitLVsUVoT1yfE9VtFJqGR4LFSNnupVqRNGRollGJqPs4pqyVpsurT84iwwnTPmrw7iUjHJVKOBjJ4x46iJeQGjbolcVF6SVu4Sq9MAkNI1hyLMgUeeURe4jgl6A2IQG8AYzi@t7Y6hJZkUQOiSWpBECU3Yu@WjzJIMbqGpJeYDl2lONUdl9w9xIA6Xno3shGQpl7NrC1lSFvQe1UsoqEXCslyFQPiu6ikk3v5Ipim6R9/FoxAODuq7PVBjAbV8EiaotYEQLJnIdKG/BlRJbYPh3k2ng6gNkHFfb0IXTlfQmZ4jcunEg8ZWBp2DMCDNC14EbYktHB9VkX1QahhPZsi@ZZbXWPXJ98PXozcnRydt/vTl520y/BtSz/akIm7z/QtEp6YqQ0VpoK0jjXUNAykTPwptbZcndDQw4K8zMJBmjwJ@eAwPOfRsGzfzuhDuFufJxGizHvYvEzCYb@T41ksqfzrNP@eUy/Ssv36bLZR@qO7fFUeW/6aa8IBp87qxWcQm7VypI71r1C1AN@WuJFB7LhhTJJKP/LbjVLce3WrALy8LI9uPIeAigcYPALM@xTmsxu6wLqrTm0pTBIL0e5mQDpp1tkV@wESC4sxFzK3rjq1uslzOTbIkGFBVFpDou0Whz32rOH6whxb1gE7K5hhR9eRPycA2Z3gY2IH9al@lvtvPrGjKdujcgT0tkSZVii5gIyi3ynu72PeNte8627xElf@Oe/XKPSou8rv2f5izf1qll3vLFbbRjrWekKW3LVvVNASMSrFZbxJV2uQSV0vW@nsjUyO/nFin1WzXhN6XwheieZi1pTbySbhvJ/DETAU2fdOnGYLF133@RNqVBq@zWrdolTRflX3otKhgt/ksphCyXilKP2lWuwE5VFJteUGUTe11zCS5avRjrz6gGU2VhAnQ4rDGtMkmzRS@uGsZTQ6549as74CA6RRWBieW@/wY64fPzc/tV69WzSbwPJpl/Nskj/IZXzcZJ4@2R1jx@RPPrlnnTPSGe1vZMEjy1b7rHJNDagUlY9sK0NjMJffr5pntEqNamJrGyF0trW/tn/9SaFNGmhax9@IENc42i4PSpPRcvj5qFGLw8di/QL6E2B53X5A6eguYxuwZb8m9a@84kztPxTfftEXG0Y@cS4MhBx38B)

Here's the Knight code translated to Python: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRb8IgFIXf@RUnfYKCiZ2b6Yzsj5hmoRUdicEKNLO/voNaU9PsgQS@A/eec2n78HO1m7J1w3DUJ/iu9sGELmjqBZRALdCwHYHVv98eEllGcLo6GBgLp@xZ04u21LN0CeYUBXsNsxhLKF6P4lSDS/iDqSLQl3RfSrVQg6MNI3A6dM4@OCH32NzYQI1tu0AZI/0SJHsv/rPPDDm27wJl3vO7QCGwZiSZt7O/bbKWmJtZOdpNsFnCkaqZrt7E5iGMSv2vksai8jiGvIaU@JgoUiTF3XRKeWreTKf4ZFXs7/sSyh7Ttp@2KbI/jJEq9kVvO/kkDXcVe7YEFuPwr3O48YIRsvjHMWHrnuXMLi5eVmwYCrL@Aw)

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>34</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
8t&Oli(9:"tt3Zv&+3=Z+g<@Q*+]q
```

Input is a cell array with the vertical and horizontal coordinates, starting at top left, 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36JEzT8nU8PSSqmkxDiqTE3b2DZKO93GIVBLO7bw//9qQx3DWgA)

#### How it works

```
8t&O      % Push 8×8 array of zeros
li(       % Write 1 at the position taken as input
9:"       % For each k in [1, 2, ..., 9]
  t       %   Duplicate. This is the current pattern, to be extended. A 0 in an
          %   entry means position not yet reached. A non-zero value indicates
          %   the required number of moves plus 1
  t       %   Duplicate again
  3Zv     %   Symmetric range: [1 2 3 2 1]
  &+      %   5x5 matrix of pair-wise additions
  3=      %   True for entries that equal 3. This gives a 5×5 matrix containing
          %   the 8 possible moves for a knight
  Z+      %   2-dimensional convolution of the two above matrices, maintaining
          %   the size of the former (8×8) in the output
  g       %   Convert the result to logical: non-zeros become 1
  <       %   Less than (element-wise)? This indicates *new* available positions
  @Q*     %   Multiply element-wise by k+1
  +       %   Add, element-wise. This updates the pattern with the new values
]         % End
q         % Subtract 1 element-wise. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 8):

## [gbz80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.5.2/gbz80.7/) [machine code](https://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html) on [Better Game Boy](https://bgb.bircd.org/), <strike>128</strike> <strike>127</strike> <strike>124</strike> <strike>123</strike> <strike>118</strike> 117 bytes

```
11 03 04 21 80 FF 06 08 0E 08 7C 22 0D 20 FC 3E
0D 22 3E 0A 22 05 20 F0 70 26 2F CD 7A 01 52 18
08 64 64 01 00 80 FF 00 00 76 24 3E 37 BC 28 43
3E 07 BA 38 3E BB 38 3B 3E 80 2E 0A 83 2D 20 FC
82 4F F2 BC 38 2D 7C E2 D5 14 1C 1C CD 7A 01 14
1D CD 7A 01 1D 1D CD 7A 01 15 1D CD 7A 01 15 15
CD 7A 01 15 1C CD 7A 01 1C 1C CD 7A 01 14 1C CD
7A 01 D1 25 C9
```

Eight more bytes can be saved from severe compromises to printed data, read the [assembly source](https://github.com/SNBeast/Knight_Board_GB_ASM_Golf_Thing/blob/main/source.asm#L9) to learn more.

As a detail of the Game Boy platform, it must be placed at 0x150, and be jumped to from the entrypoint at 0x100. I opted to not count that because of it being standard GB dev practice (the entrypoint gives you only four bytes to work with).

I know that this answer sucks in terms of length (all those calls!), but I was overcome by the urge to do it for a problem after [seeing someone else do x86 real-mode machine code elsewhere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185978/114388), and for this problem to get it to 0x80 bytes. I have no idea why I did this, I'm an ASM noob, but here we are.

BGB is specified because of the desire to print the answer. BGB has a debug print function that is only usable by its debugger (and that of no$gmb and a few others).

The initial position is encoded in the second and third byte and zero-indexed: second is y, third is x.

As for checking my answer, I suppose the only way is to have you download my ROM, or for you to assemble my assembly using [rgbds](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/). I have put both on [GitHub](https://github.com/SNBeast/Knight_Board_GB_ASM_Golf_Thing). My assembly is incredibly undercommented.

Edit 1: Shortened corrective increments and decrements into a push and pop, saving one byte.

Edit 2: Moving various things around allowed saving 3 bytes, as well as much better pruning.

Edit 3: Remove decrement that was never necessary, saving 1 byte. That's embarrassing.

Edit 4: Removing a useless load and moving things around in the init loop to allow use of postincrement indexing saved 5 bytes, and the ability to remove <strike>9</strike> 8 bytes with severe compromises was identified.

Edit 5: thejonymyster reminded me that I may assume valid input, moving one byte from compromises to saved.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: whoops. it took me this long to realize that the repository was private. fixed.

Comment: I'd like to point you towards this site-wide default: [you may assume input given is valid unless otherwise stated](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24152/107310)

Comment: @thejonymyster Thank you, I somehow skipped that whole page.

Comment: @SNBeast its ok theres like a million metas and defaults :P it's better to play it safe when you don't know anyway right? doing the "if you remove this requirement you can shave x bytes" thing is pretty standard around here anyway :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
GraphDistance[8~KnightTourGraph~8,#+8#2+1]~Partition~8&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@9@9KLEgwyWzuCQxLzk12qLOOy8zPaMkJL@0CCxTZ6GjrG2hbKRtGFsXkFhUklmSmZ9XZ6H2P6AoM68kOi3aQEfBIDb2PwA)

Using the built-in `KnightTourGraph` function.

---

If the strict output format is required:

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 69 bytes

-6 bytes and fixed a bug thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att) and [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```
StringRiffle[GraphDistance[8~KnightTourGraph~8,#+8#2+1]~Partition~8]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z@4pCgzLz0oMy0tJzXavSixIMMls7gkMS85NdqizjsvMz2jJCS/tAgsU2eho6xtoWykbRhbF5BYVJJZkpmfV2cRq/Y/AGhISXRatIGOgkFs7H8A)

Comment: Nice solution, but can you make the output look like the one in the question? Not like a 2D array.

Comment: @Bjop Flexible output rules are highly encouraged and considered standard for most questions here

Comment: But is is a challange and the output is part of it. You manage make it work so why not take the challange, to hard to make the desired output? And how can you compare the answers if the result is different?

Comment: @Bjop Are trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: @Bjop The community norm allows flexible output because it enables a wide array of languages to compete on equal footing while _concentrating on the fundamental computational problem that makes a challenge unique._  Adding strict output effectively turns a challenge into 2 challenges: 1) solve the problem 2) convert your languages native representation of the solution to some fixed format.  In this case, eg, 2) is "output a 2d wolfram array as a matrix of numbers," which is not an interesting or new problem.

Comment: "And how can you compare the answers if the result is different?"  Informed judgment of the people reading them, which is how answers are graded anyway.  Fixed outputs are mostly an artifact of sites like hackerrank or competitive programming competitions, where answers must be graded by a computer.  Here we don't have that requirement.  You are still free to enforce fixed outputs if you want, but I thought you might like to know why most people don't.

Comment: @Jonah thank you for the clarification

Comment: `StringRiffle` for 69 bytes w/ strict output

Comment: Your current strict output format one omits the last row. (The 69 byte one doesn't (`StringRiffle[GraphDistance[8~KnightTourGraph~8,#+8#2+1]~Partition~8]&`))

Comment: OP was edited to remove the strict output requirement

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [numpy](https://numpy.org/), <del>138</del> <del>136</del> 133 bytes

```
lambda*a:(S:=sum(D:=-abs(mgrid[:8,:8].T-a).T,0))-(amin([*D//2,S//3,2//S],0)+S&-2)+equal(*D)*(S&-~amin(S)//6==-4)*2
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY49DoIwGIZ3T8Ek31dbq5UY0qQbN6ibOJQoSmJL5WdwcfMULiRG7-RtBHF6kvcv7-Ptr82pdN0zV-mrbXIWf-5nY7O9IUaClqpuLSRSMZPVYI9Vsd_KmMp4N98wg_MNXSAyMLZwsCUJ54JqzldUcK53vTfTUyZwdri05gwkQQK9cPvFNXK-VopFSMQkr0obuNb6a1BYX1YN-Z9hvipcAzks-jU6YDlAjIhohLQ-eBWmLnUhjqWuG_kF)

Example, with arguments 1,2 (a=`[1,2]`):

```
mgrid[:8,:8]
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]   [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]    [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
  [7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]   [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]]
```

This produces two matrices that hold the co-ordinates.

```
D:=-abs(mgrid[:8,:8].T-a).T
[[[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]  [[-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5]   [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
  [-6 -6 -6 -6 -6 -6 -6 -6]]  [-2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]]]
```

Transpose, subtract `a`, and transpose again: this subtracts the arguments from the two matrices, respectively. Also take the absolute value and negate.

This produces the negative vertical and horizontal distances from the given square.

```
S:=sum(D,0)
[[ -3  -2  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6]
 [ -2  -1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5]
 [ -3  -2  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6]
 [ -4  -3  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7]
 [ -5  -4  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8]
 [ -6  -5  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9]
 [ -7  -6  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10]
 [ -8  -7  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10 -11]]
```

Add the two matrices for the negative taxicab distance from the given square.

The reason for the negation is that we really want rounding-up division,
but only have easy access to rounding-down division with `//`.

\$\lfloor\frac{-n}{d}\rfloor = -\lceil\frac{n}{d}\rceil\$

```
O:=amin([*D//2,S//3,2//S],0)
[[-1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -3]
 [-1 -2  0 -2 -1 -2 -2 -3]
 [-1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -3]
 [-2 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -3]
 [-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -3 -3]
 [-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -3 -3 -3]
 [-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -4]
 [-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -4 -4]]
```

The `*D//2,S//3` part produces concentric octagons corresponding to
the furthest points the knight can reach in a number of moves. `2//S` is 0 with a RuntimeWarning for S=0, −2 for S=1, −1 for S≥2; it makes a difference only in the case S=1, changing the values of the squares adjacent to the given square from −1 to −2.

```
S-(O+S&-2)
[[1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 0 3 2 3 2 3]
 [1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4]
 [2 1 2 1 2 3 2 3]
 [3 2 3 2 3 2 3 4]
 [2 3 2 3 2 3 4 3]
 [3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4]
 [4 3 4 3 4 3 4 5]]
```

A correction for parity: the number of moves should have the same parity as the the taxicab distance `S`. Add `S`, round down to the nearest multiple of 2 (by zeroing the low bit), and subtract `S`; also negate and simplify.

Finally, some more adjustments:

`+equal(*D)*(S&-~amin(S)//6==-4)*2`

- The squares two steps away along a diagonal should have value 4 instead of 2.
- If the given square is a corner square, the diagonally adjacent square should also have value 4 instead of 2.
- `equal(*D)` checks for squares sharing a diagonal with the given square.
- `amin(S)`, the negated highest taxicab distance, is −14 if the given square is a corner square, and otherwise ranges from −8 (for a centre square) to −13.
- `-~amin(S)` is one higher: −13 for corner squares, −7 to −12 otherwise.
- Floor-dividing by 6 produces −3 for corner squares and −2 otherwise.
- On the diagonals, S is even. ANDing with −2 = ...1110<sub>2</sub> leaves it unchanged, whereas ANDing with −3 = ...1101<sub>2</sub> zeroes the twos bit, mapping both −2 and −4 to −4.

The result:

```
[[1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 0 3 2 3 2 3]
 [1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4]
 [4 1 2 1 4 3 2 3]
 [3 2 3 2 3 2 3 4]
 [2 3 2 3 2 3 4 3]
 [3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4]
 [4 3 4 3 4 3 4 5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) (*without* numpy), <s>142</s> 135 bytes

```py
lambda x,y,k=[9]*64,r=range(64):[k:=[(x*8+y!=i)*k[i]and-~min(k[j]for j in r if(i%8-j%8)**2^(i//8-j//8)**2==5)for i in r]for _ in r][-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BCoMwFAX3nuJvhCSNKMVKKuQkIS2Cpv0GowQLuukReoFu3NQ79TZV224eDG8W85y7sb-2bppet95E4v0oKwOGDHzkVqqjZlnKvfSFu1QkSynNA7BqYGI3apkEYFoPZ0AHPl90q1AXrozuDTpiVa3Xu95uQEMwFFEdCsrY_kQwjhdaZkUpD3R1cXN1AJ1H1xNLv1WzIQlPfvBP_QA)

Takes in x and y coordinate as separate inputs, outputs a flattened square list. The code for finding if two positions are a knight's move from each other is taken from [Arnauld's answer to "Where can the knight be in N moves?"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145676/113573).

---

-7 bytes from @CursorCoercer by moving the code onto a single line & into a lambda

Comment: -2 bytes by moving it onto one line `def f(x,y,k=[9]*64,r=range(64)):[k:=[(x*8+y!=i)*k[i]and-~min(k[j]for j in r if(i%8-j%8)**2^(i//8-j//8)**2==5)for i in r]for _ in r];print(k)`

-7 bytes by putting it in a lambda `lambda x,y,k=[9]*64,r=range(64):[k:=[(x*8+y!=i)*k[i]and-~min(k[j]for j in r if(i%8-j%8)**2^(i//8-j//8)**2==5)for i in r]for _ in r][-1]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) Numpy, 126 bytes

```
lambda*z:H[z]
from numpy import*
x=mat(tri(8)).I
x-=x*x
x+=x.T
H=8-inner(*([kron(x,x)-eye(64)<0,1]**c_[:8]).T).A
H.shape=4*[8]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc4xCsIwGEDhPadwa_6YhCpFgpjBre7d2iJVUyyaNMQUUgcv4lIQvZO3kVKnb3rwnh_b-3Nrhlcti3fnaya-j2ulD6eK3Ndpfi9R7Vo9M522_azRtnWeoCB15bF3DRYAfIcCk4EEFOYy8AylUrDGGOUwwfnFtQYHGoCpXuFVApuYLkpCjvt8LUrgGfAtSvntXFklE5KL8n_BrGuMxzWOaQx0ZDGynEhoAvSmrIwKU5gIpmgYJn8)

### How

The entire solution is precomputed, the function itself does no more than a simple lookup.

The finalised lookup table is 8x8x8x8, but while building it is reduced to 64x64.

We start by setting up the single step matrix and then take powers to cover sequences of moves.

##### 1 1D considerations

The 1D case is easy but useful to build on. We can go 1 or 2 units up or down. If we represent that in a 2D source-target matrix *x* this means that the two diagonals just above the main diagonal must be set and the two below.

##### 2 Go 2D

The two dimensions must be combined in an AND like way because the restriction 1 or 2 up or down holds along both axes. The Kronecker product does that, but there is the additional constraint that if it is 1 or 2 along one axis it must be the other along the other axis. This can be enforced by giving the 1. and 2. off diagonals different signs. After Kroneckering the valid bits will all be negative.

##### 3. Construct 1D

There are many ways to construct *x*. The shortest I found was: Get the upper or lower triangle. Take the inverse. This is almost what we want only shifted one unit to the centre. This can be fixed by taking the difference with the square. Finally, we must add (or OR) the transpose.

##### 4. Putting the bits together

After taking the Kronecker product we need to add the identity matrix so taking nth power gives the indicator of what's reachable in up to n steps. Conveniently, as the matrix at this point is boolean valued multiple paths to the same target are only counted as one. To get the right distance indices we must count in how many powers a target does not occur. Therefore, the type of the matrices must be changed to int *after* taking powers but *before* adding them together. We do this by taking the inner product with a vector of ones which forces coercion to int and then sums.

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org) Numpy, 131 bytes

```
lambda y,x:65-((D:=Z==y*8+x)+sum(D:=D|M@D for _ in Z)).reshape(8,8)
import numpy
Z=numpy.c_[:64];X=Z//8+Z%8*1j
M=abs((X-X.T)**2)==5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc7LCoJAGIbhvVcxm2h-HQ-FxWD80MJtuxYyGaKlZOQ4eICEdl1GGyHqnrqbMFs98MIH3-OtuuZUyv6ZYfhqm8zkn_slLpJjTDp29ZYLk1LfQ4HY6dy4glG3xRD822btk6ysSERySQSAVaX1KVYp5YyDlheqrBoi20J1msCf1iHaeUt3vwpQ2DY3xITrs7O2wTipKQ3MwNqCrs8BcfG_Yqoqlw3NqMMcYAOzgfmIy1xgdapwGspQTmEc9f3oFw)

Conceptually straight-forward approach. Form the full 64-by-64 indicator matrix of knight's moves (by checking for Euclidean distance \$=\sqrt 5\$). Repeatedly multiply by it the indicator vector of the starting position.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>129 123</s>  122 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to a suggestion from [@Coder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114260/coder) on [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145676/58563) to a previous challenge*

```javascript
f=(x,y,n=0,m=[...s=1/0+''].map(_=>[...s]))=>m.map((r,Y)=>r.map((V,X)=>V<=n|((x-X)*(y-Y))**2^4||f(X,Y,n+1,m)),m[y][x]=n)&&m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjRCoIwFADQX@lJ79Xr0uix62fIRFaIaRhuE41wsH9fYo/nvNtvu3bLOH8yY599CAPDRo4M56S5EUKsXJzzNI6V0O0MDy6PVIhc6qNgoXrH8kdFckd1Y@MBtkxiAi6rEZPkcr96P4CkmkxakEYk3TjVbIoNRpEOnTWrnXox2RcMUNApRww/)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  x, y,              //   the current position (x, y)
  n = 0,             //   a move counter n
  m = [...           //   the output matrix m[], initialized to an array
    s = 1 / 0 + ''   //   of 8 arrays made of the string "Infinity"
  ].map(_ => [...s]) //   i.e. ["I", "n", "f", "i", "n", "i", "t", "y"]
) =>                 //
m.map((r, Y) =>      // for each row r[] at position Y in m[]:
  r.map((V, X) =>    //   for each entry at position X in m[]:
    V <= n |         //     do nothing if V is less than or equal to n
    (                //     or if the squared product of
      (x - X) *      //       x - X and
      (y - Y)        //       y - Y
    ) ** 2 ^ 4 ||    //     is not equal to 4
    f(               //     otherwise, do a recursive call:
      X, Y,          //       pass the new position (X, Y)
      n + 1,         //       increment the move counter
      m              //       pass m[] unchanged
    )                //     end of recursive call
  ),                 //   end of inner map()
  m[y][x] = n        //   set the current square to n
) && m               // end of outer map(); return m[]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⁰ＮＮ⟧Ｆυ«≔⊟ιη≔⊟ιθＪηθＩΣιＦ⁸Ｆ⁸«Ｊλκ¿›⁼⁵⁺Ｘ⁻λη²Ｘ⁻κθ²℅ＫＫ⊞υ⟦⊕Σικλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBagMhEIbPu08xxxEsJIFCoadQSkkhqdDeQg92Y7qyrrtRpz2UPLsZQ7aEHBydz9@Zf2xaHZpBu5wVxRZJwnYmYeVHShvqv0xAcZN@isd6PwRAEvBXV8sY7bdHNYxoWdry7S07FPZK/fgxYHtJVbA@4ZOOCd@pZ5ko9Fz3QcC0c/3poZPQFUll94AvwejEZp4PpF3EewnKUeSGvwzX1vPZFS8SFryucVf6Fyw4voWd9dqhMqZDJgL@P2Hlm2B645PZTQbZgARXxq@O9THnOczy3Y87AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⁰ＮＮ⟧
```

Start a breadth-first search by placing a `0` at the input coordinates.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop over the squares as they are discovered.

```
≔⊟ιη≔⊟ιθＪηθＩΣι
```

Set this square to the current number of steps.

```
Ｆ⁸Ｆ⁸«Ｊλκ
```

Loop over the whole board.

```
¿›⁼⁵⁺Ｘ⁻λη²Ｘ⁻κθ²℅ＫＫ
```

If this is an empty square that is a Euclidean distance of √5 from the current square, then...

```
⊞υ⟦⊕Σικλ
```

... save this square as being one more step away.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 153 bytes

12 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!

```c
e;r(*b,x,y,l,i){for(;i--&&x>0&y>0&x<9&y<9&l<9;b[e=x+y*8]>l?b[e]=l:0)e="XVTPJFDB"[i]-65,r(b,x+e%5-2,y+e/5-2,l+1,8);}f(*b,x,y){r(memset(b,1,324),x,y,0,8);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Ba4QwFITv@ytCYCUxkeq2W9zGbKGUHnraQykF8aA2LkJ0S7SQIP712qe1hT7yGCZ8mUkZlDpvz9OkhCF@wS13XPOaDtXFEFEHgefZY@g5WJscPAerk4MoUiUtc36cHfU9mEzqu5Aqid9eX07PT48POK2z4HbPDYFMprb7YMcdU1ezahbxmIqxWgvpYEijmk71AEf8endDl3@ECzU1ed0SioYNgqnbHhVpHGVisRW8QBEcuvqLQWRmHJIoEiCJRDEoY78J/zD7g9kVszP2R83zYQCrCN6@I8yh2SIGoT6Ks7VxgT77jmC83oybcfoqK52fu@kb)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>191</s> <s>179</s> 176 bytes

*-15 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
f(a,x,y)int*a;{a[x=x*8+y]=!memset(a,1,256);r(a,x);}r(a,x,b,y)int*a;{for(b=0;++b<9;x/8==y>>3&a[x]+1<a[y-=8*~(~b&1)*~-(b&2)]&x>>6==y>>6&&r(a,y,a[y]=a[x]+1))y=x-~(b&1)*~-(b/2&2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLaoQwFIbX41NYoSHRyKhtxRLji9gsEjuWCFqxs0gY9NXtORZm6Crk@28kXfrVdfveU80d98xO11iLm26ddHGVeCWfxsv4c7mCnvPirWRiQSsT63Fy8wj13ws1MhNJYup34c6VlL5pXgiUqSSvdetTWcUb3QzJWbyl1JCCKeKapjycJSHY6Tk4lfxLMealSzd6j5wLCIl1n@mxym7BCXfhElrYtnUF@xbxnQ/Ah4MPBz/NC@CeRs@fYcRD3Vp46aCYAG0NHvLHFCED9J@sQTBqO1Esw37dlq8KjPiHGc8wM1ONxv0X)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 121 bytes

```
.+
*#8*$(8*_ ¶
^(#)*((?<-1>.)*)_
$2$#1
s)+`(?<=(\d)(....|.{11}|.{13})?.{7})_|_(?=.{7}(....|.{11}|.{13})?(\d))
$.(_$1*_$4*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0vZQktFw0IrXuHQNq44DWVNLQ0NextdQzs9TS3NeC4VIxVlQ65iTe0EoKitRkyKpoYeENToVRsa1oJI41pNe71q81rN@Jp4DXtbEBOLCpBGTS4VPY14FUOteBUTrf//DQwB) Takes input as a pair of 0-indexed digits. Explanation:

```
s)`
```

Run the whole script in single-line mode where `.` also matches newlines.

```
.+
*#8*$(8*_ ¶
```

Treat the input as base 10 and insert that many `#`s followed by an empty chessboard of 8 rows of 8 `_`s terminated by spaces and newlines to bring each row up to 10 characters.

```
^(#)*((?<-1>.)*)_
$2$#1
```

Replace the `n`th character of the chessboard with a `0`, removing `n`. (`$#1` is just a weird way of saying `0`; I can't use `0` literally because it will tokenise with the previous `2`.)

```
+`
```

Repeat until no more changes can be made.

```
(?<=(\d)(....|.{11}|.{13})?.{7})_|_(?=.{7}(....|.{11}|.{13})?(\d))
```

Search for all empty squares that are a knight's move away from a square that already contains a digit (which will always be the largest digit so far).

```
$.(_$1*_$4*
```

Replace them with the next digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
8 8#{x&1+&/'x@&'4=*/4#i-\:'i:!8 8}/9*~(!64)=8/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs7JQsFCurlAz1FbTV69wUFM3sdXSN1HO1I2xUs+0UgTK1upbatVpKJqZaNpa6HNxpSkYKBgCAGgsDDo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 155 bytes

```perl
sub{$_=$"x64;($x,$y,$i,@_)=@_,"$x$y"=~/^[0-7]{2}$/&&s/(?<=^.{@{[$x+$y*8]}}) /0+$i/e&&push@_,map{/./;$x+$&-3,$y+$'-3,$i+1}21,41,12,52,25,45,14,54while@_;$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5Ra8IwEMff9ymChKhNNKamrhKv9mXb4wYT@uC0tEVnQEttJ0sp7VfvIu7guPsd///dFYfy7PWXGuEj9NUtbXAMeGAWUo2wYbhmWLMwHkMYswE2uB5Ax/fb2eR517gt5oRUfLRewX7ahM0WG4prx9@17RjxGcWaHwgpbtXJui9J0fApV3cNmcztaoqH96qpaF3BpGDCZZ7LXI9JjwnJPPl70udDGCsct716Kkqd/yCCjyPBZmMEHar4tPFbjslXzr/LvleQvyowHwpqm9WnM1wOF5I6fo3MZqaiYAk5FbmCshNR4ENJRakge0BGRaYg6eZRICGhIlGQPiClIiVrjzoJSpwUpcSGNRiaoHLVCXOHmqYos1AHL@itosbe3MDVdqXjZxv7y/@MiqsC3flRsJCgqa/frRxp5P8B)

Somewhat ungolfed:

```perl
$f=

sub {
  $_ = $"x64;                      #init board string to 64 spaces
  ($x, $y, $i, @_) = @_            #move x, y and i from head of @_ param array
  ,
  "$x$y"=~/^[0-7]{2}$/             #if x,y within board
  &&                               #and
  s/(?<=^.{@{[$x+$y*8]}}) /0+$i/e  #space found+replaced by i+1 in current x,y
  &&                               #and
  push @_,                         #push possible jump to cells to todo-queue
    map {/./; $x+$&-3, $y+$'-3, $i+1 }
    21, 41, 12, 52, 25, 45, 14, 54 #knight pos cells digits x-3,y-3
        while @_;                  #...all that while there's more to do
  $_                               #return filled up 64 char board string
}

;print &$f( 1 , 0 ) =~ s/.{8}/$&\n/gr,"\n";
```

Output:

```perl
30323234
23212343
12143234
23232343
32323434
43434345
34343454
45454545
```