# A challenge for rookies

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, chess

Print or return the following string:

```
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*

*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
*....... .*...... ..*..... ...*.... ....*... .....*.. ......*. .......*
R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
```

This represents all the possible positions of a rook on an 8x8 chessboard and for each the possible moves it can make.

- Standard I/O methods apply, you can output as a string, list of lines, matrix of characters, etc.
- The characters used must be exactly as shown, you cannot substitute them for others.
- Trailing whitespace is permitted on each line, and trailing newlines are permitted, but otherwise the output and spacing must be exactly as shown.
- This is code golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Several answers have a full line of spaces at the end of the output. Is this acceptable as a combination of trailing newlines and trailing whitespace on each line?

Comment: "*A challenge for rookies*"? Heh, I'm too rusty to solve any more challenges

Comment: @DLosc Yes, that's acceptable to me.

Answer (score 39):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29 27 24</sup> 23 bytes

```
' .*xR'{~*/~,0,.~1+=i.8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxC8IwFAb3/oqXDD6bPL80BMQEuyg4iUN2J2lRF1ehkL8eo5vDTXfcs0aV/HWrUmTuNHimMRGT0ECpsQEd8/lUmWDemZdiXJFBULwdH9jVvrscQAyTqcm1IKwEvdPBOu1d@TZ/RdjDtkOkuEAh/Px0u79orh8)

My initial observation was that the output is essentially a row-wise function table of the 8x8 identity matrix with itself, where each evaluation is simply an ordinary addition table: `row_i +/ row_j`.

This can be simplified further by flattening the identity matrix first, as follows:

- `1+=i.8` 8 by 8 identity table, plus 1:

  ```
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
  ```
- `0,.~` Add a column of zeros

  ```
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  ```
- `,` Flatten:

  ```
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  ```
- `*/~` Multiplication table with self:

  ```
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0
  4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `' .*xR'{~` Convert to ascii. This returns the required pattern.

Comment: brilliant! i'm stealing this :)

Comment: ended up shorter in k because of the "identity matrix" primitive (`=n`) and out-of-bounds indexing returning spaces

Answer (score 11):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @G B*

A function that returns a list of lists.

```ruby
->{(a=0..70).map{|x|a.map{'.*R '[x%9|_1%9<8?1[x%10]+1[_1%10]:3]}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3nXTtqjUSbQ309MwNNPVyEwuqaypqEsEMdT2tIAX16ApVy5p4Q1VLGwt7QyDH0CBW2zAaKABkWBnH1tbWQkzanhYdC9amUFBaUqwQb6igpaCurgCVXbAAQgMA)

#### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

Alternatively, outputting the string to STDOUT takes two extra bytes.

```ruby
71.times{|x|71.times{$><<'.*R '[x%9|_1%9<8?1[x%10]+1[_1%10]:3]};puts}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN13NDfVKMnNTi6trKmrgbBU7Gxt1Pa0gBfXoClXLmnhDVUsbC3tDIMfQIFbbMBooAGRYGcfWWheUlhTXQgyDmgkzGwA)

Comment: You don't need to splat the range.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>86</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s></sup> 81 bytes

```
lambda r=range(71):[[" .*R"[i%9|j%9<8and(i%10<1)-~(j%10<1)]for i in r]for j in r]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwdI0BVuFmKWlJWm6FjcDcxJzk1ISFYpsixLz0lM1zA01raKjlRT0tIKUojNVLWuyVC1tLBLzUjQyVQ0NbAw1des0siCs2LT8IoVMhcw8hSIwMwvChBqsXFCUmVeioZWbWKChpKSXlZ-Zp6OQpqGpqaNQnFpgqx6Tp64JUbpgAYQGAA)

-1 byte thanks to [@loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)

Comment: `lambda r=range(71):[[" .*R"[i%9|j%9<8and(i%10<1)-~(j%10<1)]for i in r]for j in r]` for 81.

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>34 32 30 24</s> 20 bytes

```
".*R"a+\:a:,/|+|3,=8
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxT0tMKUkrUjrFKtNLRr9GuMdaxtQAAMmAE/g==)

idea from [jonah's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/24908)

`=8` identity matrix

`3,` prepend a 3

`|` reverse

`+` transpose (this will extend the 3 to eight copies)

`|` reverse again

`,/` raze

`a:` assign to `a`

`a+\:` add-each-right, i.e. make a matrix in which element i,j is `a[i]+a[j]`

`".*R"` index into this string. out-of-bounds indices generate `" "`-s in the result.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 77 bytes (@xnor)

```
f=lambda*_:[[" ",I[i%10<1]][i%9<8]for i in range(71)]
I=f(I:='.*'),f(I:='*R')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3fdNscxJzk1ISteKtoqOVFJR0PKMzVQ0NbAxjY4EMSxuL2LT8IoVMhcw8haLEvPRUDXNDzVguT9s0DU8rW3U9LXVNHQhTK0hdE2qoYkFRZl6JhlZuYoGGkpJeVn5mHlCRpqZOcWqBrXpMHkwhzBUA)

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org), 79 bytes

```
J=[]
f=lambda I=J:[" "[~i%9:]or I[i%10<1]for i in range(71)]
J+=f('.*'),f('*R')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3_b1so2O50mxzEnOTUhIVPG29rKKVFJSi6zJVLa1i84sUPKMzVQ0NbAxj04CcTIXMPIWixLz0VA1zQ81YLi9t2zQNdT0tdU0dIK0VpK4JNVaxoCgzr0RDKzexQENJSS8rPzMPqEJTU6c4tcBWPSYPphDmDgA)

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org), 80 bytes

```
J=[]
f=lambda I=J:sum(zip(*8*[iter(8*(I+7*I[1:]))],8*' '),())
J+=f('R*'),f('*.')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3A7xso2O50mxzEnOTUhIVPG29rIpLczWqMgs0tCy0ojNLUos0LLQ0PLXNtTyjDa1iNTVjdSy01BXUNXU0NDW5vLRt0zTUg7SAXCCtpaeuCTVXsaAoM69EQys3sUBDSUkvKz8zD6hCU1OnOLXAVj0mD6YQ5hAA)

This uses the good old grouper to create lots of 8 and to mix in the separators.

Comment: Interesting trick with modifying the default argument! [Here's a 76 in Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSXRKlpJQSm6LlPV0io2v0jBMzpT1dDAxjA2DcjJVMjMUyhKzEtP1TA31Izl8rSNTtPQBMl4AmXU9bTUddS1gtRj/4OEKkCKgdJWBUWZeSVKSnpZ@Zl5GhWa/wE "Python 2 – Try It Online") with something similar, though [Python 3 doesn't accept it](https://tio.run/##FcoxDgIhEEDR3lMQks0AIRuJhbqRA9DaIgXGRce4A8FtbLw6Yvnzfvmsj0y7Q6mtJfuKy/UWJ88Z918cjlPIlTmPg9meTEg9kCGxGuk@i72RYeOsT0L@xXURMCrQoM4gQysVaRVqiUVwPj4zku6r1O@5WLgQyPYD "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: [77 bytes in 3.8+](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRK94qWklBKbouU9XSKja/SMEzOlPV0MDGMDYNyMlUyMxTKErMS0/VMDfUjOXytE3T8LSyVdfTUtfUgTC1gtQ1/xcUZeaVaGjlJhZoKCnpZeVn5gFlNTV1ilMLbNVj8oAqAA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Nice, took me a moment to understand what's actually going on there. Note that I modified the body to show off an equal length variation.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <sup><s>26</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>21</s></sup> 20 bytes

```
'.*xR '8XyQO9Y(le&*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X11PqyJIQd0iojLQ3zJSIydVTUvz/38A)

-3 bytes thanks to [@Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

#### Explanation

Port of [@Jonah answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/91267) to MATL

```
'.*xR '8XyQO9Y(le&*)
       8Xy              % 8 x 8 identity matrix
          Q             % add one
           O9Y(         % add a row of zeros to the end
               le       % flatten
                 &*     % multiply with itself
'.*xR '            )    % convert numbers to required codepoints
```

Answer (score 6):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 125 bytes

```
s/^/Rssssssss/
s/.*/&&&&&&&&/
s/.{8}$//
s/.{8}/& /g
y/s/*/
h
y/R*/*./
H;H;H;H;H;H;H;H
g;H;H;H;G;G
s/.{584}/&\n/g
s/.{1244}$//
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhY3a4v14_SDiqFAn6tYX09LXw0KwNxqi1oVfRhLX01BP52rUr9YX0ufKwPICNLS19LT5_KwRoFc6VCWu7U7WKephQlQb0weUDOIa2hkYgIyFeIIqFsWLOSCMAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 102 bytes

```
main(i,k){for(i=9;++i<82;puts(""))for(k=9;++k<82;)putchar(k%9&&i%9?i%10|k%10?i%10&&k%10?46:42:82:32);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjfTchMz8zQydbI1q9PyizQybS2ttbUzbSyMrAtKS4o1lJQ0NUHi2WDxbJC4JlAiOSMRKKZqqaaWqWppn6lqaFCTDSTALDU1MNPEzMrEyMrCyMrYSNO6FmIb1FKY5QA)

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>111</s> <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
#define F(X,c)for(X=0;++X<9;putchar(c))
main(i,j,k,l){F(i,10)F(j,10)F(k,32)F(l,i-j|k-l?i-j&&k-l?46:42:82);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjezlVNS0zLzUhXcNCJ0kjXT8os0ImwNrLW1I2wsrQtKS5IzEos0kjU1uXITM_M0MnWydLJ1cjSr3YBMQwNNN40sCJWtY2wEpHJ0MnWzarJ1c-yBtJoaiGFiZmViZGVhpGldC7ESajPMBQA)

Comment: also [102](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjfTlFNS0zLzUhXcNCJ0kjXT8os0MvNKFCJsLawjdHWtC0pLkjMSizSSNTW5chMz8zQ0q900MnUMDTTdNLIgVLaOsRGQytHJ1M2qydbNsQfSamoghomZlYmRlYWRpnUtxDaopTDLAQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 80 bytes

```
;=i~1W>8=i+1i;=j~1;W>8=j+1j;=x~1;W>8=x+1xO+I?j iS*'*'8xT'R'S*'.'8xT'*'' \'O''O''
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVj7U9vGFv69f4XQTbHWEsLOdHobC8EklHSYNiY30GZubSderda2iCw5eoBTW/nX23NWr5VfpAzDSNpvz2u/81ju6QONWeQtkpMgdPnfzKdxrPwaeNNZchVFYaTwZcIDN1bE2yrLAW9pFPPmurSnRL1Lg8SbP427TSJO5ysWBnESpSwJI42SVTLzYjMO04hxm2aw4i3ez7yExwvKuFasz2nCZtrpB20wHA0Hwxi@Z72Rvv7P4MMwGLW1YbB@Rkj7lGQLzj/BasSTNAoUSfigM1qvg9T3s1yYYzC7Q1Y@TxRqOyZfcqZJcGIVInCLbdv0Ah96MsSWns04dcB2jYIa0@fBNJkRgw7YiGRJCI57wXSnVVkmwqHc/f/t1a09GFl5qP6gfspXcUITjykLPAXNISvH3AqPNYEoPtAIfOhY9EyIKfRbVNdz/5gtvg/oyCxlWd5EY6Swh2WSr1mUBiLsUfioBPwxZ0Tmcied7vi@xzshxKwXAddP5w6P9uDKRcC9CkOf02APsFrNClb9BsGIqF8RLw/dBsnidIHSDSHqo0sTClzLHZWU7HCmeK/37fKkeG@CttwoP8gw/tlH8woEVTywmgaMh5Pca8mN42PJeOBj/lRGAYVXIShCssWfkut1Nt29HpHBy5M/R@1To1tRnh4f4wGjTE29U1Ebydx0vqicGZfOPBP5mZFx5iez2pWj2tbjY9o4tqmMU2TcUROY5WRepPFMw6/EylPlqv/H9bub/pur/p29yoqEuXZ5kGxw4Cn3B/Tkr48j/Ns5efERQrAZACEUjM0OsclDELCpGR@x1Zt4gMtDlOMwUGCuNw1QjuTJoMaMKmrmBu9BYQY/hJ6rdI7wfErLrTpB5bqsjX8PPgXhY6B4lWVKq2Faa9yMuXCBlPGVovut9Bq6@nZIIaBFulCySapioeYUdV2JK@X@mjM6lUoHyaAGH4SfNOHz1D8Ibzfhrvcge1kv4Uk0DqEU9YYmMxN4EzBJ6in4ve@Q1EsaBGGigCo4E8X5ovzFo1AFU0P3X@quFX5Pn9QH4lM/lPQtwsfD@mrx6/WRRs865Jucb7e/wXu@XIQBkpQmXBikJCHUxoBPgW8PXAHjeARG@nsqyZl8bnvrzXkD1SB@Tfs@NMTDvJeqd0X8flFSSc55FNIoIWUFwXa7kQMqgjWiHuoMQl7h/BOhZOEczORii6lWwfiXu@Tg4LcyOtAcnwwOUsixqdRz1NaIwBwXD29H7Qsy7J4azwWtMBrALEcmEmjAYSUfYqiZD3cIVlvYlth63VJb@EBql@qhFYseWDX3AmCSq3xOQyAUD1iY4mfu9pRnK5qNd7V0YX8zj4xuh6zXnY2aVQwIh2oWOjEuAIXC7dKDoFqXGfEFp9B75Ar0BOOrUesg4yuUfKjwseiusIu6t18C1qOZHfHPqRdxTZ3EKjFWOCKLJUdaYjPPdz8uopDxGFGvf@9f3l3f9G/r3vwaasCh1iyxJD9gmMwrMQNH6nTipKVZ1ZJ4ddETWaevTXKaM4bjPI3zMb64MB@7Z6ycjd1yNp7YwiKzNAWVHU320OmNB707mCo0mqZzHDierVy9mymgRJmgl9BRHWykFs8DOyGZdMYYCI0ZjsE3Rgr4xDbGChRn0/w5oHNuO/kzqI5ttj27ig2aaZoVqqoseRVXUXvihYGm6pXUKjyOUo6cYivVbdVQVN0xcxlVF9fVrdp049xzlpheLPhrwLiUTQpVSsSnXpxw4SJZQWi72KvKC9LGXUJT@2CSMk9hyHMgUZeUJf4XBXqBwmY0gjeYWfwwmEJNsmqC0JHtSBohMFXnko@2SDK4gWqOlAdErj31GJXfN6ydNFD7ofKAkqFQpr6LtgoV7hHUSimrMODEqEKgvlUNjdjnxZVMVQ3HfpVOJjwyqe@HTIMB3A0xSFTrACM6MJEbQHkHrpTEAcM/WUwHVx8h47jWhS4sVsRNzsTceu9B4qvDQCWE2cyMfQ9uiB1DOakn@7LSMJLJlr3LLWu07okfgq8/PH/xw4sf//v8xY9t8TWigRvOMWzy/ivVoPY5how2QltDWi9bCKkSPQ9vYZUjdzcw4KI0M5dkTqJwfgkMuAxdGDSLuxPplebKx2myAvcywZlNNvKVMJLKny7zT8XlUvyVl8diuepDTef2OKr@T2wqCqLJl95mFZewR5UCcddqXoAayN8qJHosG1Imk4z@Gbl1Xo1vjWCXlsWJG6aJ@RhB4waBeZ4TgzZidtMUVGstpKnDobgeFmQDpl3skV@yESCktxMzxt743ZgY1cwkW6IDRbGI1MeFjbbwreH8yRYS7wW7kO0tJPblXcjTLaS4DexAfr8tM9xt54ctpJi6dyDPKmRFlXILTgTVFnnP@f490317LvbvwZK/c89xtUejZV43/k9zUWzrNTJv/eQ22nO2M9KStuWrxq6A2RKsUVvwSrteg0rpet9MZGoW93PHrvQ7DeHvK@Er7J5WI2ktspFuO8l8nYuApm@f053BYtu@/yJtEkGr7TacxiXNwPIvvZYVjJb/pUQh67WqNqN2WyhwhYpy0xOqXNvd1lyBy1aPY/0F1WGqLE2ADkd0ptcm6S724rphfG3JFa95dQccRKesIjCxPAyeQyf8G34s2/vafX/@k@3pXc@y7792LXy717v3lr0s3pZ6d3mjX1/cK95tu9Vu/bS8a71rwaMpHtutljJs3bTw9x8)

Comment: ... but this is a problem about a Rook, not a Knight...

Comment: @Neil Well you're in luck, cuz I also got a [Knight answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251122/96039) on a problem about a Knight :P

Comment: Nice, that's certainly a fitting challenge to answer in!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
8⁼þj-‘×þ`ị“.* R ”
```

A niladic Link that yields a list of the lines of characters. The empty lines have trailing spaces.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//OOKBvMO@ai3igJjDl8O@YOG7i@KAnC4qIFIg4oCd/8KiWf8)** (Footer joins with newlines)

#### How?

Implements [Jonah's brilliant method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/53748).

```
8⁼þj-‘×þ`ị“.* R ” - Link: no arguments
8                 - 8
  þ               - ([1..8]) table ([1..8]) with:
 ⁼                -   is equal?
    -             - -1
   j              - join
     ‘            - increment all values
        `         - use as both arguments of:
       þ          -   table with:
      ×           -     multiply
          “.* R ” - ".* R "
         ị        - index into (1-indexed and modular, so 0 gives ' ')
```

Comment: You can remove the trailing `”` at the end, it is implicitly closed

Comment: Only if it were valid as a full program, which I don't think it would be without joining with newlines.

Comment: I guess you're right, I forgot about Jelly's smashing.

Comment: You've accidentally used `#` instead of `*` in your string (although it doesn't matter for the byte-count)

Answer (score 4):

## [gbz80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.5.2/gbz80.7) [machine code](https://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html), <strike>73</strike> <strike>72</strike> 70 bytes

```
21 00 C0 06 00 0E 00 16 00 1E 00 36 00 78 B9 20
01 34 7A BB 20 01 34 AF BE 28 08 3C BE 28 08 3E
52 18 06 3E 2E 18 02 3E 2A 22 3E 08 1C BB 20 DB
36 20 23 14 BA 20 D2 36 0A 23 0C B9 20 C9 36 0A
23 04 B8 20 C0 76
```

As an ASM rookie, I gladly accept.

The string is returned in $C000-$D247 ($1248 long, nice). You may check it by copying that range using an emulator debugger (it finishes very quickly, you'll know it's done if the program counter is on or after the halt) into a text file and opening it with a text editor that supports LF. The emulator I used is BGB.

This code can be placed anywhere in a ROM and jumped to from the entrypoint, or called as a routine if the $76 (halt) at the end is replaced with a $C9 (ret).

Source, which may be assembled with [RGBDS](https://rgbds.gbdev.io):

```
section "Header", ROM0[$100]
    jr GenerateMetaTable    ; the generated binary could be placed anywhere because of the lack of calls and jps

    ds $150 - @, 0          ; Make room for the header

GenerateMetaTable:
    ld hl, LotsaSpace
    ld b, 0                 ; meta-line tracker. each of these hardcoded zeroes is necessary because all of these registers change
.outermost:
    ld c, 0                 ; sub-line tracker
.mediumOuter:
    ld d, 0                 ; meta-row tracker
.mediumInner:
    ld e, 0                 ; sub-row tracker
.innermost:
    ld [hl], 0              ; we're out of registers (besides a which is used for comparing), but we have this convenient value we're pointing to that will get overwritten anyway.
    ld a, b
    cp a, c                 ; meta-line == sub-line -> rook move or rook position
    jr nz, .skipFirstInc
    inc [hl]
    .skipFirstInc:
    ld a, d
    cp a, e                 ; meta-row == sub-row -> rook move or rook position
    jr nz, .skipSecondInc
    inc [hl]
    .skipSecondInc:
    xor a, a
    cp a, [hl]
    jr z, .period           ; [hl] == 0 -> neither rook position nor rook move
    inc a
    cp a, [hl]
    jr z, .star             ; [hl] == 1 -> rook move
    ld a, "R"               ; [hl] == 2 -> rook position
    jr .write
.period:
    ld a, "."
    jr .write
.star:
    ld a, "*"
.write:
    ld [hl+], a
.innermostEnd:
    ld a, 8
    inc e
    cp a, e
    jr nz, .innermost
    ld [hl], " "
    inc hl
.mediumInnerEnd:
    inc d
    cp a, d
    jr nz, .mediumInner
    ld [hl], "\n"
    inc hl
.mediumOuterEnd:
    inc c
    cp a, c
    jr nz, .mediumOuter
    ld [hl], "\n"
    inc hl
.outermostEnd:
    inc b
    cp a, b
    jr nz, .outermost
HangMachine:
    db $76                  ; directly encoded halt, saves one byte over "halt", which automatically adds a nop
                            ; this is here to prevent the program from repeating endlessly. that may not seem problematic, but if a tester stops it while [hl] is being used to hold the match count, they'll copy a bad output.
                            ; to make GenerateMetaTable a function, just replace this with "ret"

section "Memory", WRAM0
LotsaSpace:
    ; we need $1248 of space, but we can't just ds it because WRAM0 is $1000 long. no formalism for you. we don't bank-switch ever, so it's not a problem.
```

Edit 1: "ld a, 0" -> "xor a, a", -1 byte

Edit 2: rearranging character loading jumps allowed removal of one, -2 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 64 bytes

```
R7*$(9*$*R)7*$(¶9*$($*7*$(9*.$*)¶)R7*$(9*$*R
%8,9,`.
 
8,9,`.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/nyvIXEtFw1JLRStIE8Q6tA3I1lDRgojqqWhpHtqmiVDDpWqhY6mToMelwAVhaHP9/w8A) Explanation:

```
R7*$(9*$*R)7*$(¶9*$($*7*$(9*.$*)¶)R7*$(9*$*R
```

Replace the empty input with the pattern of `R`s, `*`s and `.`s. Note that `*` is Retina 1's string repetition operator so actual `*`s have to be quoted as `$*`.

```
%8,9,`.
```

Clear out every ninth column.

```
8,9,`.+
```

Clear out every ninth row.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｅ⁷¹⭆⁷¹§ .*R∧﹪⊕ι⁹∧﹪⊕λ⁹⊕⁺¬﹪ιχ¬﹪λχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDD3FBHIbgEyE2H8RxLPPNSUis0lBT0tIKUgPy8FA3f/JTSnHwNz7zkotTc1LyS1BSNTE0dBUtNnNI5UGlksYCc0mINv/wSmPpMHQVDA02gIiSxHIgYDFj///9ftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ⁷¹                             Literal integer `71`
Ｅ                               Map over implicit range
    ⁷¹                          Literal integer `71`
   ⭆                            Map over implicit range and join
        .*R                     Literal string ` .*R`
      §                         Indexed by
              ι                 Current row
             ⊕                  Incremented
            ﹪                   Modulo
               ⁹                Literal integer `9`
           ∧                    Logical And
                   λ            Current column
                  ⊕             Incremented
                 ﹪              Modulo
                    ⁹           Literal integer `9`
                ∧               Logical And
                         ι      Current row
                        ﹪       Modulo
                          χ     Predefined variable `10`
                       ¬        Logical Not
                      ⁺         Plus
                             λ  Current column
                            ﹪   Modulo
                              χ Predefined variable `10`
                           ¬    Logical Not
                     ⊕          Incremented
                                Implicitly print
```

Actually using ASCII art drawing commands seems to take 51 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BDoIwEETP8BWbPbWmGnoi6o1w0RNRfoCUqg3QmgJqYvj2igjBxIunzUxm3qy4ZFaYrHTuKJsoE8XZmlbnBFdIt/7JWCAhhek@fW/fVtfUkFRVsiaKAQ8og48qBtXXvMg8COcMkrKtCR5wSqwZ4ALpO9P5v9CAQSyFlZXUjczHjZ2eHdVvrYe6l1ilmzGC0C@EfPBH1F8cBsGM2sTmrqdHv4idc255K18) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 69 bytes

```
f()=matrix(71,,i,j,Vec(".*R ")[if(i%9&&j%9,(i%10==1)+(j%10==1)+1,4)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN13TNDRtcxNLijIrNMwNdXQydbJ0wlKTNZT0tIIUlDSjM9M0MlUt1dSyVC11gCxDA1tbQ01tjSwYy1DHRDNWE2LYvuiCosy8Eo3ikqKs_Mw8jSJNTYUahSIFG10FoC2xEEUwmwE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>99</s> <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```
[[" R*."!!((f(i%10)+f(k%10)+1)*f(k%9*i%9))|k<-r]|i<-r]
(%)=mod
f=fromEnum.(>0)
r=[10..81]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8HOal1lBR9HP_dQR3dXBeeAAAVl3VquRAXbmKWlJWm6Fjcjo6OVFIK09JQUFTU00jQyVQ0NNLXTNLLBtKGmFohpqZWpaqmpWZNto1sUW5MJIrk0VDVtc_NTuNJs04ryc13zSnP1NOwMNLmKbKMNDfT0LAxjIRbszE3MzFOwVSgoLQkuKVJQUSjNy8nMSy1WSITIL1gAoQE)

Comment: You don't need the space in front of the list comprehension. For ATO, you can use the CPP pragma and then write `a =\ ` and continue on the next line without indentation. (Also `intercalate "\n"` is exactly `unlines`) 
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8HOal1lBR9HP_dQR3dXBeeAAAVl3VquRAXbmKWlJWm6Fjcjo6OVFIK09JQUFTU00jQyVQ0NNLXTNLLBtKGmFohpqZWpaqmpWZNto1sUW5MJIrk0VDVtc_NTuNJs04ryc13zSnP1NOwMNLmKbKMNDfT0LAxjIRbszE3MzFOwVSgoLQkuKVJQUSjNy8nMSy1WSITIL1gAoQE)

Comment: @Laikoni thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 171 bytes

```rs
||(0..71).any(|x|(0..72).map(|y|(x/9,y/9,x%9,y%9,y/71+1)).any(|(x,y,a,b,l)|print!("{:
<1$}",if a>7||b>7{' '}else if x==a&&y==b{'R'}else if x==a||y==b{'*'}else{'.'},l)>()))
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a188ba240a058efcb579ddd6aab4447c)

Answer (score 3):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 131 bytes

```cs
_=>{T[]F<T>(T x,T y,T z)=>new T[72].Select((_,i)=>i%10<1?x:i%9<8?y:z).ToArray();return F(F("R","*"," "),F("*","."," "),new[]{""});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZhPa4MwGIfvfoqXQCERl667bKt/ujHmYYwdnLCDSBGbjkAbR7SttfSzu2js2HnboYMEgk@i78@gz@nNy4u85G24EblXVpKLdwf0NUmTNFj67dwPDnGShl4c4BhqJ4a9mg3xA8F2ECfXVyl9ZSuWVxjPHa72@Why6U1m9ZSPbr2b2X7aEBoX91Jme0xcyaqNFBDiEKMIOchWExBx1LJDOixVeJIeEDoS99i6lj4TsPpDvYgtwLfuUGTrAXZ0goEUaOqgpx460qBoADuybKoHUPsEAynQ1EFPPXSkQdEA1DY5/yznz4KMiEagsziQEdEIZEQ0ApkPZEQ0AhkRjUAm59xFND/MiPgrEZFrWdtMQgM@LDFC5NSOqsEPhmYWfShEnqktQmPJ15gQVTQeq92yWDH6JnnFnrlgeHj8qeACP4otl4VYM1HRF7br7jvQdKU/qgPf/@pffcuIWLboI4jbfgI)

---

Makes use of an inline generic function:

```cs
_ => {
    /* both the characters within each row and the rows in the whole string follow the same pattern
     a default string, a different string at every 10th string,
     and a space string at every 9th string, starting at 8

    e.g. R******* *R****** **R***** ***R**** ****R*** *****R** ******R* *******R
    the default string is "*", the special character is "R" and the space is " "

    for the whole result string, the default string is "*....... .*...... [...]"
    the special string is "R******* *R****** [...]" and the space is either "" or " " (both work)

    */

    // generic function (defines T as the generic type), inputs of type T
    T[] F<T> (T specialChar, T defaultChar, T space) => 
    // create a new T[] of length 72, and set each element according to its index
    new T[72]
        .Select((_, i) => 
            // special char every 10th element
            i % 10 < 1 ? specialChar : 
                // space every 9 starting at 8, otherwise default
                i % 9 < 8 ? defaultChar : space
        ).ToArray();


    // construct rook (special) row string
    var a = F("R", "*", " ");
    // construct default row string
    var b = F("*", ".", " ");
    // correctly typed space for next func call
    var c = new string[] { "" };

    // construct whole string using default, special and space strings
    return F(a, b, c);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
q["",q" .*",q" *R"]
q l=[l!!(0^m 10-0^m 9+1)|m<-mod<$>[10..80]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflflFpsG/O/MFpJSadQSUFPC0xpBSnFchUq5NhG5ygqahjE5SoYGuiCKEttQ82aXBvd3PwUGxW7aEMDPT0Lg9jY/7mJmXkKtgq5iQW@CgWlJcElRT55CkCj//9LTstJTC/@r5tcUAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>140</s> 102 bytes

```c
#define a(z,y)for(int z=8;z--;putchar(y+10))
main(){a(i,)a(j,)a(k,22)a(l,i-j|l-k?i==j|l==k?42:46:72);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIVGjSqdSMy2/SCMzr0ShytbCukpX17qgtCQ5I7FIo1Lb0EBTkys3MTNPQ7M6USNTRzNRIwtEZOsYGQGpHJ1M3ayaHN1s@0xbWyDD1jbb3sTIysTMytxI07r2/38A)

```c
#define a(z,y) for (int z=8; z--; putchar(y+10))
main() {
  a(i,) // 10 = space
    a(j,)
      a(k, 22) // 22+10 = 32, space
        a(l,
          (i - j) | (l - k) ? // subtract is quicker than != here
            i == j | l == k ? 42 : // if the x matches xor the y matches, print asterisk
              46 : // if neither match, print dot
                72); // if both match, print R, only the last number has 10 added in the macro, so 82
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Would it be shorter to use `puts` with `&` of the char?

edit: it seems it's not possible like that, you need a variable first, if it was possible however, you'd need brackets which is still 102 bytes

Comment: Suggest `i-j&&l-k?46:42` instead of `i==j|l==k?42:46`

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 24 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊏⊞×.⇌♭≡'⊂0+1⊞=.⇡8" .*xR"
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqP4oqew5cu4oeM4pmt4omhJ-KKgjArMeKKnj0u4oehOCIgLip4UiIKCuKJoSZwIGY=)

Port of @Jonah's [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/97916). Tip: when looking at the output on the Uiua pad, set the font size to the smallest by clicking the gear in the upper right so you can see the output without line wrapping.

```
⊏⊞×.⇌♭≡'⊂0+1⊞=.⇡8" .*xR"
                 " .*xR"  # place ascii replacements on the stack
            ⊞=.⇡8         # 8x8 identity matrix
          +1              # increment
      ≡'⊂0                # add column of zeros
     ♭                    # deshape
    ⇌                     # reverse
 ⊞×.                      # outer product
⊏                         # select
```

Comment: There's a leading space on each row (because 0 is put on the front), which is not allowed.

Comment: Porting ngn's K version and applying some stack tricks gives 21: [Try it](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=YSDihpAg4oqP4oi2IiAuKnhSIuKKnsOXLuKHjOKZreKJoSfiioIwKzHiip49LuKHoTgKYiDihpAg4qyaQCDiio_iip4rLuKZreKKoOKKguKKnj0u4oehLjgiLipSIiAjIDIxCuKJhSBhIGI=)

Comment: The leading spaces have been fixed. Feel free to add the K port as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 97 bytes

```factor
[ 8 identity-matrix 1 m+n [ 0 suffix ] map
concat dup outer [ "\0"" .*R"zip substitute ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy/CsIwGMRRnHyKI6NiqZvoA4iLg@JUO8T0Kw1Nk5o/oL58/Coux3F3v2ulis7n2/V0Pu4xyNgVLF4rCgj0TGQn15O3ZCBDcCpAOxxyhR10Qzbq@N78kBe2GNYWFUqE1LYc1Pw4QjmrZFw2aYRLkTwvxL2czRdCoFhdxEePDDwCX3H9h@qspDHTVMDonjB6bSOXJFWXvw)

A straight translation of @Jonah's excellent [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/97916).

- `8 identity-matrix` Make an 8x8 identity matrix.
- `1 m+n` Add 1 to each element of the matrix.
- `[ 0 suffix ] map` Add a column of 0s to the far right end of the matrix.
- `concat` Flatten the matrix into a list.
- `dup outer` Take the outer product with itself.
- `[ "\0"" .*R"zip substitute ] map` Convert the resulting matrix to the required code points.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 42 bytes

```
iR·* 7o*·. {7ñä}$FR7jdpbñGï{7ñäGGkdd{p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzPo0HYtBWnzfK1D2/UUpKvND288vESsVsUtSMw8K6Ug6fBG98PrIaLu7tkpKdUF//8DAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 6952 b72a 201b 376f 2ab7 2e20 1b7b 37f1  iR.* .7o*.. .{7.
00000010: e416 7d24 4652 1637 6a64 7062 f147 ef7b  ..}$FR.7jdpb.G.{
00000020: 37f1 e447 476b 6464 7b70                 7..GGkdd{p
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/) (REPL), 24 bytes

```
" .*xR"⊏˜×⌜˜⥊∾⟜0˘1+=⌜˜↕8
```

Outputs a 2D array of characters. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=IiAuKnhSIuKKj8ucw5fijJzLnOKliuKIvuKfnDDLmDErPeKMnMuc4oaVOA==)

#### Explanation

Ports [Jonah's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/16766), which you should upvote.

```
" .*xR"⊏˜×⌜˜⥊∾⟜0˘1+=⌜˜↕8
                        ↕8  Range(8)
                     =⌜˜    Equality table with self (8x8 identity matrix)
                   1+       Add 1 to each (main diagonal is 2s, rest is 1s)
               ∾⟜0˘        Append 0 to each row
             ⥊              Deshape into a flat list
          ×⌜˜               Multiplication table with self
       ⊏˜                   Use each element of that 2D array to index into
" .*xR"                     this string
```

---

Just for fun, here's a different solution (27 bytes) that outputs a 2D array of 2D arrays of characters (feels appropriate, but goes against the challenge's I/O requirements and also is longer):

```
{".*R"⊏˜r(+´‿=⋈)⌜r}⌜˜r←↕8
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=eyIuKlIi4oqPy5xyKCvCtPCdlajigL/wnZWpPeKLiCnijJxyfeKMnMuccuKGkOKGlTg=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
8Þ□›0j:v*` €xR`İ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI4w57ilqHigLowajp2KmAg4oKseFJgxLAiLCLhuaDigYsiLCIiXQ==)

Another port of Jonah's answer.

Comment: Sadly, we don't have a shorthand for `.*?`

Comment: `j` now does work on lists, so this can be updated

Answer (score 1):

## [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) (Java), <s>191</s> 188 bytes

```
void f(String x){System.out.print(x);}int i,j,x,y;for(j=0;j<8;j++){for(y=0;y<8;y++){for(i=0;i<8;i++){for(x=0;x<8;x++){int X=i^x,Y=j^y;f(X*Y<1?X+Y<1?"R":"x":".");}f(" ");}f("\n");}f("\n");}
```

Or, expanded:

```
void f(String x) {
    System.out.print(x);
}

int i, j, x, y;
for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                int X = i ^ x;
                int Y = j ^ y;
                f(X * Y < 1 ? X + Y < 1 ? "R" : "x" : ".");
            }
            f(" ");
        }
        f("\n");
    }
    f("\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, nice answer! You could save 4 bytes by using `int X=i^x,Y=j^y;f(X*Y<1?X+Y<1?"R":"x":".");`.

Comment: [152 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kK7EsccFNm4LSpJzMZIXknMTiYgXfxMw8hWouqFhxSWIJkCrLz0xRyAXKaASXFGXmpUfHKiQWpRdrKlQvLS1J07W4OaMssUgh0Ta4srgkNVcvv7TEOi2_SCMzr0QhUyfL1kAnQifSOsvGzMQ6Ua8AaEBJTp5Glra2qoWdmb1STJ6SlZKSpiZYh62BdSaSOg2NCC2NSNssfYu4LFULTRtD-wjtSCCpFATUUwHEekqa2hqZqhYgMQWIOZoRtplA9Zkg860h7ltcy1ULYS1YAKEB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 36 bytes

```
VJU71sm@>".*R "+!%NT!%dT_<7.|%d9%N9J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8wr1NywONfBTklPK0hBSVtR1S9EUTUlJN7GXK9GNcVS1c/S6///f/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), <sup><strike>151</strike></sup> <sup><strike>145</strike></sup> 137 bytes

```java
for(int y=0,x,a,b;++y<72;){var s="";for(x=1;x<72;s+=x++%9*(y%9)<1?' ':a+b<1?'R':a*b<1?'*':'.'){a=~-x%10;b=~-y%10;}System.out.println(s);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc5NroIwFAXguau4MSGlFIm8iT-lcQVOnkPj4OJfahAMLaQN4c1dgxMSdVHuxvJ0dL6cewfn9jhhjd0ruVRpJrewzVApWKLMoRl8O6VRu6gLuYOzu_grXcr8uN4AlkdFoXlW-jCavq6HovRlrsGKcWhCDFPOmE0mP5w2NZagxHDI-x8jYm76XjFhGPNmgW-9GU3iBQEyR5b2-nUK_hWQOYkIbVD8jYwXj3nqYHu0K6v0_hwVlY4ubpPOcl9R3n4G3dvBV133yTc) Link is to a "normal" Java version, as I don't know if the link to the online JShell will stay valid.

[Jeffrey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251116/92572) made me aware of JShell, which saves a couple of bytes compared to a lambda function or an interface. **EDIT** It also reminded me that ternary `if`s don't always need parentheses. Thanks!

-8 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!

Comment: [135 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc4xboMwFAbgnVM8RULGmCDIkibG6gm6lDHK8KBN5IpAhA2yheiaQ2RBSnqo3KYQMv2f3v-G_3r_wRaHR3JuskLmkBeoFHygLKFzXjelUY_RVvILTmPjpbqW5XG3B6yPikL31-jD8u1xOVS1J0sNVkSBCTDIOGM2Wa847VqsQYnFgk8_RkTcJOuYKyaMu_E9625oEr8TIFtk2aTPUf5TPtmSkNAOhWHMjSOeid-lndCnVunvU1g1OjyPi3RReoryfp5z652XhmHOfw)

Answer (score 1):

## Dart, 173 bytes

```dart
main(){var l=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],s="R"+"*"*7+"*......."*7,p=" "*7+"\n",i,j,k,m;print([for(i in l)...[for(j in l)for(k in l)...[for(m in l)s[(k^m)*8+i^j],p[k]],"\n"]].join());}
//       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7            
//345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

Pretty-printed:

```dart
main() {
  var l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      s = "R" + "*" * 7 + "*......." * 7,
      p = " " * 7 + "\n",
      i, j, k, m;
  print([
    for (i in l) ...[
      for (j in l)
        for (k in l) ...[for (m in l) s[(k ^ m) * 8 + i ^ j], p[k]],
      "\n"
    ]
  ].join());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 100 bytes

```perl
print$_%72?$_/72%9?$_%9?($v=1==$_%72%10)&($h=1==$_/72%9-$_/648)?R:$v|$h?'*':'.':$":'':$/for 73..5184
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCVe1dzIXiVe39xI1RJIAwkNlTJbQ1tbsIyqoYGmmoZKBkQArEgXSJuZWGjaB1mplNWoZNira6lbqeupW6koWakDSf20/CIFc2M9PVNDC5P////lF5Rk5ucV/9f1BVqXmp5aBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⬚@ ⊏⊞+.♭⊠⊂⊞=.⇡.8".*R"
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=YSDihpAg4oqP4oi2IiAuKnhSIuKKnsOXLuKHjOKZreKJoSfiioIwKzHiip49LuKHoTgKYiDihpAg4qyaQCDiio_iip4rLuKZreKKoOKKguKKnj0u4oehLjgiLipSIiAjIDIxCuKJhSBhIGI=)

A port of ngn's [K answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251115/78410), which is also based on Jonah's J but adds a deliberate out-of-bounds indexing trick. With size 4 instead of 8, the following vector is generated:

```
[1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4]
```

and its self outer product by addition gives

```
╭─                                         
╷ 2 1 1 1 5 1 2 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 5  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  5 4 4 4 8 4 5 4 4 8 4 4 5 4 8 4 4 4 5 8  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  2 1 1 1 5 1 2 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 5  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  5 4 4 4 8 4 5 4 4 8 4 4 5 4 8 4 4 4 5 8  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  2 1 1 1 5 1 2 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 5  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  5 4 4 4 8 4 5 4 4 8 4 4 5 4 8 4 4 4 5 8  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  1 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 0 1 4  
  2 1 1 1 5 1 2 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 5  
  5 4 4 4 8 4 5 4 4 8 4 4 5 4 8 4 4 4 5 8  
                                          ╯
```

In this matrix, 0, 1, 2 correspond to `.*R` respectively, and anything larger is a space, so "index into `".*R"` with any out-of-bounds indexes mapped to spaces" gives the correct matrix of characters. Any number >= 3 works for the padding; reusing 8 saves a byte over hardcoding any other number (which requires a space between the two numbers).

```
⬚@ ⊏⊞+.♭⊠⊂⊞=.⇡.8".*R"
              ⊞=.⇡ 8        identity matrix of size 8
        ♭⊠⊂     .         append 8 to each row and flatten
     ⊞+.                    self outer product by addition
    ⊏               ".*R"    select; convert 0, 1, 2 into ".*R"...
⬚@                           and all others to spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
8LδQ>0δª˜Dδ*" .*xR"sè
```

Another port of [*@Jonah*'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251105/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//zhMzrRRPjDOtMKqy5xEzrQqIiAuKnhSInPDqP9Kwrv/) (Footer `J»` is to pretty-print the resulting matrix of characters.)

**Explanation:**

```python
8LδQ          # Push an 8x8 equality matrix (8x8 of 0s, with main diagonal of 1s):
8L            #  Push list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
              #  (implicitly use it twice since there isn't anything else on the stack)
  δ           #  Apply double-vectorized:
   Q          #   Equality check
    >         # Increase each by 1
      δ       # Map over each row:
     0 ª      #  Append a 0 to the row
˜             # Flatten the matrix to a single list
 D            # Duplicate it
  δ           # Apply double-vectorized again:
   *          #  To create a multiplication matrix
    " .*xR"   # Push this string
           s  # Swap so the matrix is at the top of the stack
            è # Index the matrix into the string
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```