# Minimal number of jumps to reach a square

Tags: code-golf, chess

*A Knight in chess moves two squares vertically and one square horizontally, or two squares horizontally and one square vertically (with both forming the shape of a capital L)*

---

Given a Knight current square in a chess board and an array of unavailable squares, calculate the minimum number of **valid** jumps required to reach a target square. If no route is available to reach the required target return 0.

A **valid** jump is a move that:

- Does not go out of the board (8x8 square board)
- Does not overlap with another piece
- Follows the Knight L shape move pattern

---

**Input**

Knight square, array of occupied squares, target square. Input might look like:

```
f("b3", ["c4", "h7", "g5", "a8"], "b7")
```

- You can use a set of coordinates instead of chess algebraic notation. It can be 0 or 1-index. Example: `b3 -> (2,3)` or `b3 -> (1,2)`
- You can assume that `Knight Square != Target Square` for every input.
- You can assume every input square is valid and non overlapping
- Input values can be taken in any order you'd like

**Output**

Minimal number of **valid** jumps to reach a square, or 0 in case no route can be found

---

**Test Cases**

```
"e3", [], "f5" -> 1
"e3", [], "f6" -> 2
"c4", [], "f6" -> 3
"g1", ["f3", "g3"], "h4" -> 4
"c4", ["d6", "b6", "e5", "e3", "e4"], "f6" -> 5
"a1", [], "h8" -> 6
"g1", ["h3","h5","g2","g3","g6","f3", "e5", "e6", "d4", "d5", "c1", "c3", "c5", "b2"], "b7" -> 7
"h1", ["f2", "g3"], "h3" -> 0
"d4", ["b3", "b5", "c2", "c6", "e2", "e6", "f3", "f5"], "a8" -> 0
```

Comment: [Pretty much related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251050/smallest-number-of-steps-for-a-knight-in-chess)

Comment: Can we take input as `[x,y]` tuples instead of strings?

Comment: @mousetail yes, you can use a set of coordinates or tuples as stated in the challenge ^.^

Comment: Oops should have read better before replying

Comment: are you sure about the 6th test-case `g1,e2,c1,b3,a5,b7` seems to be a valid path in only 5 jumps

Comment: @bsoelch my mistake, I was missing one unavailable square. Should be fine now

Comment: Right, someone started [a funny conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/how-many-jumps) from this.

Comment: b3 should be (2,3) when 1-indexed and (1,2) when 0-indexed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 154 bytes

*-17 bytes, thanks to The Thonnu*

```python
def f(s,b,t,k=0):
 p=s,
 while(t in p)*64<64>k:p=[[u,v]for i in range(64)if([u:=i//8,v:=i%8]in b)<any((x-u)**2+(y-v)**2==5for x,y in p)];k+=1
 return k%64
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZNdToQwFIUTH1lFU2PSjkUH6CAZxY0QHigUSmYEws84bEVffNE96WrsD-gEx5cL9H73nNMCrx_N2Iu6ent7H_rcDj5fMp6DHHWEkZ7swjXeWqAJO2KBZ1HuOepBWYEGr3z64NPH3bYJo2gghzivW1CqXptUBUc-xWWOomEblre3ATnI61UQyzbDD0k1InS0B7xauddotA_qJgw3SuJIRmMQ3--uQ8cCLe-HtgK7K5-ahF8XjYqY1nWboU7Fm5kIJiyVvULAm7LK-BF10TrGpKx6eefE2HZiy1LDgu8b3qJEbjI9VciRkU0w2Zddj56SxqwQhjExvRRjy2paJTrJQO5BAqKYAJhvIMbg0n4Ezv-MPzPugknpX8ZbMIWjGJgrOVh4UNGCzjQ9qwgzX9FMV77RVc9zCic3gLGa3yzmE2dOJALpcQkk459PJKQiFFIcFq4q6rGQjlPUyVZHyKiueiV1dNVMqleYq0Oxu3lTdwtDMR2Be3oE3kyvF3RmjoBpB2Y89WRqjsP9zWWSyneoFJPgR9F8ePMv8g0)

Goes through all reachable fields until target is reached, aborts after 64 steps and returns 0

Comment: [163 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZPRToMwFIYTL3mKpotJu3U6WIdExRchXFAotNlkDDBuz-KNidF30qexpwU1qDcn5fQ7__-3wNNbc-rVvn5-fn3oy2X0_lLIEpWkY4L1bBuv6LWHmrhjHnpUeidJj3SNGjoP-W3I77bXTZwcULlv0cFsJIm-vIyYPo9SaGlg26yuJAk5TXVJAEKC3mb1iZDj8pCsUjqfBwtyMmvfruN4A7NHdnJO6c12EfseamX_0NZoex5yF_XjrIGs-X7fFqSDnCOT4EzkZq9S-ELXhTySDoyYrnuzMjZLP_U8GFZy18iWZOa0-U-FkjjZjLKd7npynzWuwwSlzO3llHpe04LoIIPlGjOUpAzhcoMpRbPlHfL_Z8KRCSZMzn8z6wlT-cDgEuRwtcZAKz7S_E9FXIRAC1vlxlY7Lzke3BClML-ZzGf-mEhFxmOGDBP-nUgZRayMOK4CKPBYGcch6mBrIxTcVtvJfVstk9uOCGwocTUe6mpiqIYrCH5ewXqkVxO6cFcgrINwnnYyd9cRfOdySc07BMUs-lJ0H974r3wC)

Comment: 64 steps are more than needed but I guess cutting this by a few doesn't help with golfing as long as it is still a 2-digit number and one can create examples where the minimal number of jumps is bigger than 10.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 143 bytes

Expects `[source, target, occupied_0, occupied_1, ...]` where each square is a pair of 0-indexed coordinates.

```javascript
f=(a,n)=>(g=(n,s)=>(i=b.indexOf(s))>1|s&136?0:i>0|Buffer(' "/3OS`b').some(v=>n&&g(n-1,s+v-65)))(n,...b=a.map(([x,y])=>x|y<<4))?n:n>9?0:f(a,-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZRNb9swDIbv@RWEDqmEyUps56NtahfbsHMR5GgYqCRbdopWbqM2SLF0fz2jpQzb0MswND6QMiHoeV8S0p3cSqc368fnyHZVfTiYjEpuWZbTJqOWu361zpRY26re3RjqGMvjvRvG6ex6fLnOx/svL8bUG3oGZJTerG7VGROue6jpNsvtcNhQG8XcfdpGsyljDI8UQqhMigf5SGmx468lInb716urCWPX9tLmF3iwQRXRD8sOqyVk4CDLoQAndCs3X1Hn52c6ZhDBxZzDOWZXxCWUi0ExANxH6pRwIGaKscA6h4/9RiOI/wLNTgdKAkhPTg1KA6iJe1Db4wpivL0mJR@GRNDkvSNS9YkoH@upjx5dT/4XjaBpAMng6Px0rZv92To1945a1E9atEKapA/9b4P@jj09mvSGK9@Jyle0P0P7PdpXVHJsAYLmAdQGR2mYUXKCGY0DKCiTvnVEeVEqyPRQHeaV/LZifl08FPOPoHIgTLf5JnWLzwFIDoqDe4KS9Xf@O@rQnXXdfS3uu4YaWqyWVDIOmBQmfEzck39LVktWMrYYvLHF4Sc)

#### How?

This is internally using the [0x88 encoding](https://www.chessprogramming.org/0x88). Converting the input to this format is a bit costly, but it makes basically everything else easier and shorter (moves, square comparisons and out-of-board detections).

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this really shorter than using [your answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251094/36398) to the other challenge for the first input and then indexing with the second input?

Comment: @LuisMendo Good question. :-) I'll have a look later.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 236 bytes

Define `z` as:

```
=LAMBDA(p,q,
    LET(
        a,OFFSET(
            INDIRECT(p),
            {-2,-2,-1,-1,1,1,2,2},
            {-1,1,-2,2,-2,2,-1,1}
        ),
        b,ROW(a),
        c,COLUMN(a),
        d,TOCOL(IF((b<9)*(c<9),ADDRESS(b,c,4),NA()),2),
        e,FILTER(d,ISNA(XMATCH(d,$B1#))),
        IF(SUM(N(e=$C1))>0,q+1,z(e,q+1))
    )
)
```

Within the worksheet:

```
=IFERROR(z($A1,),)
```

Knight square in cell `A1`, target square in cell `C1` and occupied squares in spilled, vertical range `B1#`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 59 bytes

```
Ｆ…β⁸Ｆ⁸⊞υ⁺ι⊕κ≔⟦θ⟧θＷ∧¬№θζΦ⁻υ⁺θη⊙θ⁼⁵ΣＸＥμ⁻℅ξ℅§κπ²«→≔⁺θιθ»Ｉ∧№θζⅈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZA/b8MgEMXn@FOcmA6JLm0SRe1kWa2UIa3VLpWsDMQmAQWDjSF/WvWzu9hupDI8Dp7e3Q9KyV1pue77vXWA2bXUIpO2wR2DFaUw3q4o5KGTGBjkOnSoGKxN6UQtjBcVHimlT0nadepgsGi3DNp4PkulBWBqKny1HjMbjMeWwRelDF6U9sLhRpnY7tY2mnIwU3Md6uc2cN3hgsFHqDG35yHAG6wZTLk3VynDNV5i5lanfm0qccEjgyZiReeeTgu@k9nGngQ@vquD9JFw9od8G67oRP6T5E5F2Ix3fuT/x87gE4fn9n1ByjlhUJBqGTeyG1UsRn0YdU7iV5D9kmz7u5P@BQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ…β⁸Ｆ⁸⊞υ⁺ι⊕κ
```

Create a list of all valid chess board squares.

```
≔⟦θ⟧θ
```

Start with one reachable square.

```
Ｗ∧¬№θζΦ⁻υ⁺θη⊙θ⁼⁵ΣＸＥμ⁻℅ξ℅§κπ²«
```

While the target has not been reached and there are still more squares that can be reached...

```
→
```

... increment the count of jumps, and...

```
≔⁺θιθ
```

... append the newly reachable squares to the list of reachable squares.

```
»Ｉ∧№θζⅈ
```

Output the count of jumps or `0` if the target was not reached.

51 bytes by taking input as Gaussian integers:

```
≔⟦θ⟧θＷ∧¬№θζΦ⁻ΣＥ⁸Ｅ⁸⁺κ×μＩ1j⁺θη⊙θ⁼₂⁵↔⁻μκ«→≔⁺θιθ»Ｉ∧№θζⅈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVCxTsMwFJybr7AyvSju0KaRKjpFFWxBVWFAijKkwTROnZjEdhEgvoSlAwh-qV8DL46R8HBn-9n37t77d1kVfSkLcTp9Gv0wXZ5_EqX4voWsyynpgpX3VHHBCCTtPVxLDWtpWg0dJS9BQMkVF5r1kPLWKLgxDaTFIywpcbQReH2g5JY3TEFDybpQGvxZ7Qd2uReoVg2HpH0e9pedKQTKIfVsK7FpPBR3SgqjmWuGYodRhLx6k1QeGVxs-b7SaHniMvyJ82CM8uZteo7urYsh0L8wlNwBiq0-1K5UbhhfmT89Cj8_02weRjUlWRTGSDOLi3BhcW4xqnFeMRby8e8v) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>378</del> 336 bytes

Port of [@bsoelch's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264739/110802) in Scala.

Saved 42 bytes thanks to the comment of [@Kjetil S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFNb6MwFLznV7iWWj1vIQmEkBTqSqucqm5PVU9VD@bbG0pYcLKJEL89a5uUZJG6i8SYZ2bejJ/rkOXsuAl@xqFAz4wXqDlGcYISqD14LIQhX2IE3kv8662v3w1x8fPJkwudEtrsWIVKKqlQE18Va/rk/854HsNVOQ43hZAGNQhyc7O@dx3SlBSSTQX83pyibSF4jlzH31I@Wfo7yq@XPk/QVXBWwtbYEakux/Ge16JuQlbHsDcOhD7A3tySbxpv4WDu5LdCSuctOfA4jzrxWGx@SKm/vqVW66@vXacdqQOv5IFfRMWLlFCoYUrMu4VRg0VM545oRgbsxJDzUD3euurdCHtlAitgcl7jD1bCihgrCAk5IqT0H/IIwKq09tD3qmKHTznx0GvBBaKoGSH5lHJX5AVkgOMZNpCyAmIgnMwxIWgyMR@Q9R@m2zPtITN0vmDOhszU@mTiRLXH6QwrTeb0Gufr7jhylSbQGM816i6xgwfO82EXZl1mzJY90/1Hxkx2x5k0wqmtQJWpdD@FP0XQcSJHo94JLY2aE@qdwNYBg0VvuxjaZhejsS9HM@s106EmOo8m0G5B56/1YTcm@5yxS63uXC5s@VffdtQe/wA)

```scala
def f(s:(Int,Int),b:Seq[(Int,Int)],t:(Int,Int),K:Int=0)={var p=Seq(s);var k=K;while(!p.contains(t)&&k<64){p=(for(i<-0 until 64;u=i/8;v=i%8;if !b.contains((u,v))&&p.exists{case(x,y)=>(x-u)*(x-u)+(y-v)*(y-v)==5})yield(u,v)).toList;k+=1};k%64}
def C(s:String)=(s(0)-97,s(1)-49)
def h(a:String,b:List[String],c:String)=f(C(a),b.map(C),C(c))
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJNb9swDL3nV7ACWkir48SJkwZZXaDALgM67DC0l2EHWf7S4tqGrWQJivz2jJId2xk8xAeapJ74nkhWgqf8dMr936FQ8I3LDD5GAEEYQUSrNdCvmbIADbPAX8OLrNTPLvfLAnWJ2ay1Ax5M2dnT9QB2vIQCI12BVqzNbd7QeLAxiT@JTEOgN4Ut8kyhmIoqBnd3NeoRli5ryoEpRqO8BCrhcQxT2GZKpgj5DA2i@7aIlTCB1cDZzpzdDp7JCG78TgvdWrBjRlBhh3t8SQUfIHiFmvcWHBh4T@jBGLYMPrXePdADejuTazzPgwUc2SXlQYZpAA2LrXLdqwZgGnDvgWPi46jN3eKLRzrTTE3keRnoyf1Qpcxi1h9POwxKuC8QHSfEllkQ7r/jsG2R8PJZ0SnDObaRw2xefZGxVCjcYX2qJEyLsKT8zNVtSB3jdoiejv42RLTWyfVa2e@8qGOM6rxgNRNAw/WOA6C8jPFhz2XJD2cKrPuaya5wgVmVZrTRRsI5seqdw9okWhAc32QyfmoaeQW@bOGzQbhw/wOfD8Jj5wwnkSYi8Zzoi4nbXnSv8JBgqS/6xoYLY02p0CX/aFgMluJOX3KyauHLa5IT5CEJUpJ4po0OY9TRvKURY4QFrrEmIxxjDUaYjD8zUv2HlvthkDvptWvWb9e8vTgdvBh07fINr18rMUVE3bpZp7bWr3cDf3x1Ufw4Op5OfwE)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(s: (Int, Int), b: List[(Int, Int)], t: (Int, Int), k: Int = 0): Int = {
    var p = List(s)
    var kVar = k
    while (!p.contains(t) && kVar < 64) {
      p = (for (i <- 0 until 64; 
                u = i / 8; 
                v = i % 8; 
                if !b.contains((u, v)) && p.exists { case (x, y) => (x - u) * (x - u) + (y - v) * (y - v) == 5 }) 
            yield (u, v)).toList
      kVar += 1
    }
    kVar % 64
  }

  def coord(s: String): (Int, Int) = {
    ("abcdefgh".indexOf(s.charAt(0)), s.charAt(1).asDigit - 1)
  }

  def helper(a: String, b: List[String], c: String): Int = {
    f(coord(a), b.map(coord), coord(c))
  }
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(helper("e3", List(), "f5")) //-> 1
    println(helper("e3", List(), "f6")) //-> 2
    println(helper("c4", List(), "f6")) //-> 3
    println(helper("g1", List("f3", "g3"), "h4")) //-> 4
    println(helper("c4", List("d6", "b6", "e5", "e3", "e4"), "f6")) //-> 5
    println(helper("a1", List(), "h8")) //-> 6
    println(helper("g1", List("h3","h5","g2","g3","g6","f3", "e5", "e6", "d4", "d5", "c1", "c3", "c5", "b2"), "b7")) //-> 7
    println(helper("h1", List("f2", "g3"), "h3")) //-> 0
    println(helper("d4", List("b3", "b5", "c2", "c6", "e2", "e6", "f3", "f5"), "a8")) //-> 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You can shave off 24 bytes by replacing `"abcdefgh".indexOf(s(0))` with `s(0)-97` and `s(1).asDigit-1` with `s(1)-49`

Comment: ...and 18 bytes by removing return type `:(Int,Int)` and `:Int` twice.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 62 bytes

```
{0^*&~^?[;z]'64{?,/x@y}[i!i@&'(4=*/4#)''i-\:/:i:(+!8 8)^y]\,x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJy9k01ugzAQhfecwnGl8NOkxMQYYqsK9wgBxQ4YbkBK6dnLTEt/Vu0i4MVIIxh/772Ra9nvimD9VhxP6uXsCt4fN2GX3YZTu2qztevx5yDkD77rtttchrKV3uMqJalf3M75phscx8reC6TaspKVKnhlpZ/lsht/PiSEHwanfiLWo9WeKlrH1CchYWSJ8wssEBwtCTb8G7xfEmwZgMG2hdJwlMDnB6PjqxiLhlLFUEBC9SOKeAbwBRw3Kd4v7nn/X2CMusGUwayNptCtmHbwkQK0V4wHWgNjBr4aaDWM6QTlJ/8DN7jjL9woAYZ38ztGExqYGp2ABIPbjiaf9edTV/SS3kGW8w6bHb6X)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 59 bytes

```
1 :'1{.[:I.[e."1(u-.~,j./~i.8)(]~.@,&;[<@#~2j1=&|-/~)^:a:]'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZLPattAEMahx32KYQ3SbiKNvZJsi3UcRAOFQOmhV6EUSdYfC4eW1oYENXqRXtxDHyKP0j5Nd0dOmpYedsR-M_P7dgZ9-94dHzm6Naw1uODBDLQ5PsLV-7dvfhz2tR__XCnQruox1deYVsiVOPg4eB1Ohy3GUmQDJp6zSi-SyRB0au189aeDvNG5ztwR8evVrWTvXiNYUgqiQsc7u9DJJMkkiMlg7uKZJxPip9oTIIR3LlUXyLPprFM3W4xAnk8zAxfKr5BMXMbK20-7u7UWbl6Um6puWhe2xszpJXQIrgrCaL5YxqQGTs_21Ze9GTgEPWMAhzUCEZxLcDkid-HzXb7bwb1J2lcLjr2-99HuRIKvQfTmPOCDPsgaepRwMJX_ESVjVdl-TKzfCj8EkNkFzxivQu5BmnnA6zkH_xLUX9qCtIDxMvpHCxlvlNV4bct5E3KbbSPKRk8dfLOw2YJiNadI9VXEX9DmjOfqyaGNSVs8O7Smg7emmTeBDfbaGOLJ-oQli01EkZRSUaSakpQiINNiSQZLxtvTCMHLEULKmuVsxhEKIhQjkyrLcZzgj-_4ErNDS8jjE0GOf93xOH5_Aw)

Takes input as complex numbers.

To handle all 3 args, we use a J adverb which modifies the list of illegal positions, and takes the target and start positions as the left and right args, respectively.

- `(u-.~,j./~i.8)` Generate the full board minus the illegal spaces
- `(]~.@,&;[<@#~2j1=&|-/~)^:a:]` Collecting each step's results until you reach a fixed point, starting the initial square, find all legal spaces that are \$\sqrt{5}\$ away from the current positions.  In this way, we spider out stepwise to every reachable position
- `[e."1` For each steps results, is the target position in that list?  Now our list of lists (the step results) will become a single 0-1 list, with the first `1` representing the index we seek
- `[:I.` All `1` indexes.  Returns empty list for no matches.
- `1{.` Take the first.  Exactly what we need, and since taking 1 from the empty list returns 0, it also handles the no match case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 192 bytes

```haskell
n=99
q=[-1,1]
(#)=elem
g a b p c=last$last(1+g[w|s<-a,x<-[1,2],y<-q,z<-q,w<-[zipWith(+)s[y*x,z*(3-x)]],all(`elem`[0..7])w&&not(w#b)]b(p++a)c:[n|all(#p)a]):[0|c#a]
f a b c= min(g[a]b[]c)n`mod`n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVNNjpswFJa69CmeSDWxJ2YUyO9Eobsuup5FF5alGGMgKhASSPOj3KSb2VS9Rq8xc41eoLZhhnRaNYsXeN_Pe4aPbz9SUX1RWfb4-H1fx-786WcR3N-jbcBcj3oc4R4JVKZylICAEEqQQSaq-r0p2Bsk7HCplq6gx6XLPOpzelq6W3o25aBb53X5eV2neEAqdro90vMtHrlHwjkVWYZXxnnFhnd3M04ONzfFpsaHXkh4iMvBQBC5YMXFEHslEZws2PAie4Kj2O4iA8jXBU6Y4CHjkhSrfBOtiuYcz-9-1adSwcN2L3YKAmCfipojJDfFV7WrYbGAh3q3LhJwP7SkV4wdKZy40cRwBBdi6Is-1X-n5sbrczikSitA_2JNjHeb_GOxzxGqVVVLUanKyC2OsaNGDgXGKTjxxCEUPEL_AU0N5HeQHP8JjToo8QzkxEbsJCPHkNKxIY3f6p1oakihrWpiq5WpsdN5TzqZ8F7GpnMDTf8am2q9k2orJ_FNMbeJ9m_3aYfYgdHYVtuRnq2WI20n9O0K4czMmXVz0vZ4_vXxRoY07EhRc7zQ-oXNBCuQzVH9botmL_3sjZGYN0bWh1-9sb4JBcO4SYP2bi60prnQKp0hwq8VgRHoOFLIRamjEJqYSM2MCMBFr6kR3Ws7SxdetW8j1IYPIZSLdaEbpU5nbSJosw5BANH_HfscNdl_-ZZ_Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 166 bytes

```perl
sub{($s,$e,%o)=@_;@w=(0,$s);while(($n,$s,@w)=@w){$s-$e||last,push@w,map{$n+1,$_}grep{($a,$b,$c,$d)=map{$_>>3,$_%8}$s,$_;!(($a-$c)**2+($b-$d)**2-5||$o{$_}++)}0..63}$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZPfj5pAEMff/SumZD1Bd1VYQXsEy3uT3kvfrCH8WMDUA8JibKP0X7ezeoc926S1PO3Ozny@35kMlai39omk3knuooNOJCWC9kvD8wPX33v6lBJpuPt8sxW6Tgq8UX@Pr3vjQCQj4njchrKh1U7m/p4@h9WBFCOTkqDNalEhMKQkoiSmJDG883OwXHJ87y9aJRa475AbMhIbw6E10knEMBOPzD4eSYnp7WhktNPx2OEtKdqT20vLWu@tADTB2TK1Nbjn85ZgAqzpFeDcDbA6QDz7LwDvAJnJlvkMoymHjGv/CpjdOMBo4kDkgLBBcBAz7S8AuwOEysHi7hacNy1Ec4zmHHIbMgsbgcxRHSk3DiQzSGyITYg5xDZElqYA8w6QKwdczcC6ZwbTDpDgDMIFRiMOESpZEOMkLKWNJv68IR3AOPTU/fm7TjZFtWsoEPGtEnEjkkA2opIGeODjnnZpsgnrc1qRUPDLON5VG5GoNLXfMBlP3MVQJwNmGuz9fFTWCXmAFi548H7AZBWyfL0y2WI9yV65QM5qSHkg6Y3I5b@hZntVu5bVQu62yO0A3m0H8AEG5dcBPMLg09NnePo4uFRX9aZoUq3PHAnwtuQR@glm/Ho@28ez/FJo9FX2t2nRFxv0pV@3155@Ag)

```perl
sub steps {
  ($s,$e,%o)=@_;        #start, end, occupied set as hash from input args in @_
  @w=(0,$s);            #initial work (steps,square)
  while(($n,$s,@w)=@w){ #while work left to be done
    $s-$e||last,        #bail if current square $s equals $e end square
    push@w,             #register new work/new squares to be checked
      map{$n+1,$_}      # (new steps, new square)
      grep{                       #filter
        ($a,$b,$c,$d)             #coords of current square ($a,$b)
          =map{$_>>3,$_%8}$s,$_;  #...and potential new square ($c,$d)
        !(($a-$c)**2+($b-$d)**2-5 #pythagorean horsyness check of new vs current
          ||$o{$_}++)             #...non-occupied new squares
                                  #...and register new square as occupied
                                  #...with ++ to not enter it again
      }
      0..63                       #loop through potential new squares
  }
  $n                              #return n steps from last work
}
```