# Approximate My Squares

Tags: code-golf, math, approximation

*Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJHtqMjrStk) by [tecmath](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCb7w5aTnt7YeXBcVCY0mgFw)*.

An approximation of the square root of any number `x` can be found by taking the integer square root `s` (i.e. the largest integer such that `s * s ≤ x`) and then calculating `s + (x - s^2) / (2 * s)`. Let us call this approximation `S(x)`. (Note: this is equivalent to applying one step of the Newton-Raphson method).

Though this does have quirk, where S(n^2 - 1) will always be √(n^2), but generally it will be very accurate. In some larger cases, this can have a >99.99% accuracy.

### Input and Output

You will take one number in any convienent format.

### Examples

Format: Input -> Output

```
2 -> 1.50
5 -> 2.25
15 -> 4.00
19 -> 4.37               // actually 4.37       + 1/200
27 -> 5.20
39 -> 6.25
47 -> 6.91               // actually 6.91       + 1/300
57 -> 7.57               // actually 7.57       + 1/700
2612 -> 51.10            // actually 51.10      + 2/255
643545345 -> 25368.19    // actually 25,368.19  + 250,000,000/45,113,102,859
35235234236 -> 187710.50 // actually 187,710.50 + 500,000,000/77,374,278,481
```

### Specifications

- Your output must be rounded to at least the nearest hundredth (ie. if the answer is 47.2851, you may output 47.29)
- Your output does not have to have following zeros and a decimal point if the answer is a whole number (ie. 125.00 can be outputted as 125 and 125.0, too)
- You do not have to support any numbers below 1.
- You do not have to support non-integer inputs. (ie. 1.52 etc...)

### Rules

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14102#14102)

Comment: Note: `s + (x - s^2) / (2 * s) == (x + s^2) / (2 * s)`

Comment: My solutions: [Pyth](https://www.github.com/isaacg1/pyth), [25 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=W%3C%5E%3DhZ2Q+aYZ%3B%2B%3DeYc-Q%5EY2yY&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A5%0A15%0A19%0A27%0A39%0A47%0A47%0A2612%0A643545345%0A35235234236&debug=0); [14 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Js%40Q2cc%2BQ%5EJ2J2&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A5%0A15%0A19%0A27%0A39%0A47%0A47%0A2612%0A643545345%0A35235234236&debug=0)

Comment: Does it need to be accurate to at least 2 digits?

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes. 47.2851 can be represented as 47.28, but no more inaccurate.

Comment: @totallyhuman 47.2851 can also be represented as 47.27. But it cannot be 47.26, as that is flooring and then removing 1/100

Comment: Shorter note: `s + (x - s^2) / (2 * s) == (x / s + s) / 2`, if you take `x` as a floating point value instead of integer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are allowed to do that.

Comment: @downvoter Another case of a downvote & go... what’s wrong? Can I improve this question?

Comment: Sorry - looking at this I just realised I was the downvoter, but I don't remember downvoting it (apparently 2 days ago - must've clicked the wrong button). I made a trivial edit and upvoted, sorry about that! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to [Olivier Grégoire's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire) simplified mathematical formula - see their [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146447/53748).

```
÷Æ½+Æ½H
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9sNth/ZqgwiP////G5kZGgEA)**

#### How?

```
÷Æ½+Æ½H - Link: number, n
 Æ½     - integer square root of n  -> s
÷       - divide                    -> n / s
    Æ½  - integer square root of n  -> s
   +    - add                       -> n / s + s
      H - halve                     -> (n / s + s) / 2
```

Comment: 7 bytes: [`÷Æ½+Æ½H`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9sNth/ZqgwiP////G5kZGgEA) First time trying to use Jelly so I might be wrong. I wish I knew how to store `Æ½`, though, to not repeat it. That might save another byte.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierGrégoire! `Æ½ɓ÷⁹+H` would not recalculate the integer root, but it's also 7. `ɓ` starts a new dyadic chain with swapped arguments and then `⁹` refers to that chain's right argument (i.e. the result of `Æ½`). `Æ½ɓ÷+⁹H` would work here too.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> ... 36 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @JungHwanMin*
*-1 byte thanks to @HyperNeutrino*
*-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech*
*-3 bytes thanks to @OlivierGrégoire*

```python
def f(x):s=int(x**.5);print(x/s+s)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsMgEETv@xUeY1oMrq5iSr@k9NZKczEh5mC@3roeSmH2MQszzHYenzVhra93FHEocs73JR1DGUdF8rbt/ZnyJcsJa1x3UcSSxAPVVVA73REa0DcYdpYdMdBpDjpryJKxnDWELIvGqecMoo9WBALdFAA9mADWA3ngOvzK8Ff9Ag)

Comment: -2 bytes: `s+(x-s*s)/s/2` to `(x+s*s)/s/2`

Comment: -2 bytes using a function

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I only get [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##TY3BDsIgEETv@xV7LIhtWNgSavwS46029gJNqQl@PYIHYzKTubyX2d7HMwYqZX4suHRZTOm6x1eYuyxlz@eexWXb13B0@ZRkEkMaqCxxx4xrwBspZIW61Sskp9DUtXW5lkZdgdEatmxshQxTiyUz3ifA72EhYNA1HsiB8WAdsIPmwk@FP/MD)

Comment: Oh sorry I accidentally deleted a character after testing and then counted the bytes after :P yeah just -1

Comment: Can you not omit `+.0` and replace `/s/2` with `/2./s`, saving two bytes?

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsMgEETv@xUeY1oMrq5iSr@k9NZKczEh5mC@3roeSmH2MQszzHYenzVhra93FHEocs73JR1DGUdF8rbt/ZnyJcsJa1x3UcSSxAPVVVA73REa0DcYdpYdMdBpDjpryJKxnDWELIvGqecMoo9WBALdFAA9mADWA3ngOvzK8Ff9Ag)

Comment: [36 bytes as well](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwEEX3c4pZNlVSMskkpOBJ1EVFigVNS@kiPX3MuFDhz@MtPn@WfXvMicp4upTn8LrdB8x9k7spbU1uW83q8FPV1eK8YsYp4Zn0Ebme@SBWUKiwYk6MBeSNFL2z7Ng66VomiSPr9bUHxGWVH2OTlSoEDKYmAgWwEVwADiAr8N2Av4U3), using a lambda instead.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>43 bytes</s> 29 bytes

```
x=scan()
(x/(s=x^.5%/%1)+s)/2
```

Thanks to @Giuseppe for the new equation and help in golfing of 12 bytes with the integer division solution. By swapping out the function call for scan, I golfed another couple bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTWqNCX6PYtiJOz1RVX9VQU7tYU9/ovxGXKZcll5GZodF/AA)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQlOj2LYiTs9UVV/VUFNbo0K3OM5IU79Y3@h/moaRJleahimIMDIzNNL8DwA "R – Try It Online"); more generally, you can use the "header" field of TIO and put a `f <- ` to assign the function. But still, nice solution, make sure you read [Tips for golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r) when you get a chance!

Comment: [31 bytes using Oliver Gregoire's formula](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQlOjQl@j2LYiTs9UVV/VUFO7WFPf6H@ahpEmV5qGKYgwMjM00vwPAA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 32 bytes

```java
n->(n/(n=(int)Math.sqrt(n))+n)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDLasMwEEX3@YohYJCooxD5UZqSQqHLhi5CV6UL1Y9UqTNypXEgFH@760cSW0jM4Wq4c5mDOqmFKTM8pD9NWX0VOoGkUM7BVmmEvxnARXWkqC0no1M4tn9sR1bj/uMTlN073rcCHFo/UZEuRF5hQtqgeDGtQfaOyp7fyswqMhbyTYOLJ4ZLhhumkfhW0bdwv5YYcn6HfCmbx96wMP0Myhw52FymdEf6N4xGXE35YWR5P3Iw0cOJHk1YxqvJgDgMojAKwol5EMnuhjKIX69qPUTOjWVd7D70eojOb8l3Z0fZUZiKRNkukHI291YyXYOXezj3u24fcqHKsjg/u2F5rFM5H@zrWffq5h8)

### Explanations

The code is equivalent to this:

```java
double approx_sqrt(double x) {
  double s = (int)Math.sqrt(x);  // assign the root integer to s
  return (x / s + s) / 2
}
```

The maths behind:

```
s + (x - s²) / (2 * s)  =  (2 * s² + x - s²) / (2 * s)
                        =  (x + s²) / (2 * s)
                        =  (x + s²) / s / 2
                        =  ((x + s²) / s) / 2
                        =  (x / s + s² / s) / 2
                        =  (x / s + s) / 2
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle the specification: _Your output must be rounded to at least the nearest hundredth_

Comment: Well, it is rounded to lower than the nearest hundredth, so it's totally valid.

Comment: Ah, I see, my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f x=last[s+x/s|s<-[1..x],s*s<=x]/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcWxDYMwEAXQVX4J4TDyEYKQ8AhMYLlwAQqKQYijcMHujime3tfLbw4hpQXRBC@XlSo2cstYW61UdCQvGU10DafNrzsMNn9MKI5z3S8oLCUsEzqCfgwE7glt/p3vMv5odukP)

Explanation in imperative pseudocode:

```hs
results=[]
foreach s in [1..x]:
 if s*s<=x:
  results.append(s+x/s)
return results[end]/2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```apl
{.5×s+⍵÷s←⌊⍵*.5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqPdPD04u1H/VuPby9GMh/1NMFZGvpmdYC5RWMFEwVDIHIUsHIXMHYUsHEXMHUHAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```
X^kGy/+2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyIu271SX9tI//9/IzNDIwA)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 34 bytes

*Thanks to @Olivier Grégoire!*

```
s;
#define f(x)(x/(s=sqrt(x))+s)/2
```

Works only with `float` inputs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3bCoMwDIbv@xTBMWjxNA91jM4n2bwQZ6XgYbO9KIivvq7VsQXykfCHfE3YNY0xkqHDo@VibIFjTbCOsSzla1Z2Ib4kcWrEqGCoxYgJWhDY4v1UK1CtVLcKSljSKABqO9lwsUjPFpmbcjdRh7RI3GGRZzSnWU6jle3fphmwc4jyxEBcE0vfF2QLd@Ffqq2P400tKsJ@6XO2Hzj2jvw@egHob7Si1bwb3tedNGE/fAA)

## C,  <s>41</s>   <s>39</s>  37 bytes

```
s;
#define f(x).5/(s=sqrt(x))*(x+s*s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU3LCoMwELz7FYulkGhs6yOWYv2S1oNYIwEfrckhIP560zUtXZgddmeYaaKuaaxVhbd7tEKOLQhi6IEfiSrVa9Z40ICYUAWKWjlqGGo5EuotHuBsD90qfaughCVhwBnEGy4MkjODFDlD5ogkj9GQZynPeJrxtXAJYpqBbDGyPBUgrzHuMJTUid8SZ@unWoPBFkFcoaxo8VefMyYI4u/FffQZmJ@0eqt9N6KvO2WjfvgA)

## C,  <s>49</s>   <s>47</s>   <s>45</s>  43 bytes

```
s;float f(x){return.5/(s=sqrt(x))*(x+s*s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc9NCsIwEAXgfU8RCkJSrdL8VCR4EzchmFJIo2YiFEqvbhxcN87yfbyBZ9vB2pxBO/8wiTg6syXe0zuGozpRuMIrJsxYQ@c9NMD0mseQyGTGQFm1VATvGTFytN65W6gP@IMzprdFFaX7Q5ci8XORRLklyy1VJt53G8OQCGIvhZJKyN@KNX@s82aA3PrpCw)

---

*Thanks to @JungHwan Min for saving two bytes!*

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc9NCsIwEAXgfU8RCkJirNr8VCR4EzchmFJIU81EKJRe3RhcN85qmI838EzTG5MSKOsmHZHFM1ngBq8Q86bCI76DxzOFPZATPh8pUCBqTYOPaNSDx6RaKpTnGfLJ4npn774@5D@MELUtsijtH7oWiV2KxMspUU7JMrGu3SiWCWXsBJdCcvFrsaaPsU73kBo3fgE); edit: Thank you, but credit @JungHwanMin for finding that.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3bCoMwDIbv@xTBMWjxNA91jM4n2bwQZ6XgYbO9KIivvq7VsQXykfCHfE3YNY0xkqHDo@VibIFjTbCOsSzla1Z2Ib4kcWrEqGCoxYgJWhDY4v1UK1CtVLcKSljSKABqO9lwsUjPFpmbcjdRh7RI3GGRZzSnWU6jle3fphmwc4jyxEBcE0vfF2QLd@Ffqq2P400tKsJ@6XO2Hzj2jvw@egHob7Si1bwb3tedNGE/fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 22 bytes

```js
x=>(s=x**.5|0)/2+x/s/2
```

We don't really need an intermediate variable, so this can actually be rewritten as:

```js
x=>x/(x=x**.5|0)/2+x/2
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

x=>x/(x=x**.5|0)/2+x/2

console.log(f(2))           // 1.50
console.log(f(5))           // 2.25
console.log(f(15))          // 4.00
console.log(f(19))          // 4.37
console.log(f(27))          // 5.20
console.log(f(39))          // 6.25
console.log(f(47))          // 6.91
console.log(f(57))          // 7.57
console.log(f(2612))        // 51.10
console.log(f(643545345))   // 25368.19
console.log(f(35235234236)) // 187710.50
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

*Another one bytes the dust thanks to H.PWiz.*

```hs
f n|s<-realToFrac$floor$sqrt n=s/2+n/s/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hr6bYRrcoNTEnJN@tKDFZJS0nP79IpbiwqEQhz7ZY30g7Tx9I/s9NzMxTsFXITSzwVdAoKMrMK1HQU0jTVIg20lEw1VEwBGFLHQUjcx0FYyBtAqRNgdjIzNAo9j8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>47 44</s> 38 bytes

```
{s=int($1^.5);printf"%.2f",$1/2/s+s/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZD9SgMxEMT/z1OEUkG5mOxHNptD9ElEOISCtBTxWoqIz34mOcWrYEMCkwzzYzPDaTtNH@P9y/5wvcYnLzd3r2/lslldedo87ldujYHC2I2BPqeJ7O2DRS9gpCryJAabjB7AYD9LVnu@QrDD8@E47HbvS7uzBV5ypDUnnsBwQ6QKjjrLHi/QFnalcaFJy6mXS1Ms7JrTOkXC9j9Bj/BfbmF2lgKJmBRZonCcKxFO2Zci/uRI3I9RcgIOoJ0QxSGyQyCXpTcsVHckTq3rrIpQCj@DlVf3/dxZgV@YqmONjjS7mPEL)

NOTE: The TIO like has 2 extra bytes for `\n` to make the output prettier. :)

It feels like cheating a bit to use sqrt to find the square root, so here is a version with a few more bytes that doesn't.

```
{for(;++s*s<=$1;);s--;printf("%.3f\n",s+($1-s*s)/(2*s))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRSsQwEEXf8xVhWaFr0mRmkum0VP0SX4pQEJdVtisi4rfXJFXsCm5IwjA39zC5w9vTPH@Mz8eqN2a6nm5ut9jv@qmu@5fj4@E0VpsrR@P9YWMnU22xTm92vqJ07z7nmXR9p9ExKM4VOWKFpYwOQGG3lEH0@fJeDw@n12G/f1/LRqOn5CPJPnYEKhREk8FRlrLDC7SVnGkh0bj4xPGlKVZy9kmeosHyP0aH8J9vJRpNnphVEwNHDnGJhEPTuhTEHx@x/RGSj8EClOMjW8RgEci23KnAlHek0JSsWxGEFPgZLHXtd9tohl@YiA0SLUlrY4tf)

Comment: well you could say this is AWKward. I’ll show myself out. edit: originally I planned for the question to shun using sqrt, but there’s too many answers and I’ll get tort if I change it so my original idea works.

Comment: 'AWK' puns are fun :)

Comment: instead of `sqrt($1)` you can use `$1^.5`

Comment: Thanks @Cabbie407 don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: You're welcome. Some other things: you don't need the `\n` to get the output, the printf in awk doesn't need parentheses and the formula can be shortened to `s/2+$1/s/2`, which results in `{s=int($1^.5);printf"%.2f",s/2+$1/s/2}`. Sorry if this comment seems rude.

Comment: The comment is fine. I knew about `printf` but had been using `sprintf` recently which does require the parentheses.  I didn't think about simplifying the expression. I like the "\n" for the multiple inputs, but you're right, 2 bytes is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
:√I:‟/+½
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3A%E2%88%9AI%3A%E2%80%9F%2F%2B%C2%BD&inputs=2&header=&footer=)

For `n=2`

```
:        # Dup -> [2,2]
√        # Square root -> [2,√2]
I        # Round -> [2,1]
:        # Dup -> [2,1,1]
‟        # Rotate stack right -> [1,2,1]
/        # Divide -> [1,2]
+        # Add -> 3
½        # Halve -> 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
DtïD.Á/+;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fpeTwehe9w4362tb//xsBAA)

Port of my Vyxal answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 92 bytes

Thanks to @JungHwan Min for the tip in the comment section

```
(λ(x)(let([s(integer-sqrt x)])(~r(exact->inexact(/(+ x(* s s))(* 2 s)))#:precision'(= 2))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsIwFET3nmKgi/4oRfqTtFTQi4iLUEIJ1liTLLLyYt7BK9VYePBmBiaY8W7TWs3GTwhb2dHDLCt9P5QFzTbRNZLzyU42NPEVErK4CXoHstmMqbk4vwU60gGZ9oiIQhTz36I6LcGOLrqnr@kMLpNYa2JotIUB3EMOUD10D@5aRqekVloqDan5j2LZldMP)

Ungolfed

```
(define(fun x)
  (let ([square (integer-sqrt x)])
    (~r (exact->inexact (/ (+ x (* square square)) (* 2 square)))
        #:precision'(= 2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 54 bytes

```powershell
param($x)($x+($s=(1..$x|?{$_*$_-le$x})[-1])*$s)/(2*$s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCE4i1NVSKbTUM9fRUKmrsq1XitVTidXNSVSpqNaN1DWM1tVSKNfU1jEDU////Tc0B) or [Verify some test cases](https://tio.run/##FYrRCsIgFEB/RcYNdLsutJbsofqQCBmhNLBtzI0Et283g3M4L2cav2b2b@NcSnYdXks/DsTGqZu7D4XAshUFf6WiriFs9wi6BM2dgbCzBxdPVoJnRyr/2ZPEBkWmRanw1OJZYaNQXoTcDrEATfiNFBW1BHS@fw)

Takes input `$x` and then does exactly what is requested. The `|?` part finds the maximal integer that, when squared, is `-l`ess-than-or-`e`qual to the input `$x`, then we perform the required calculations. Output is implicit.

Comment: Wow. I've never been able to comprehend how people golf in Windows Powershell

Comment: @StanStrum You're not alone, lol. :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

*-3 bytes by using Olivier Grégoire's formula*

```
^^':2;g:>/+2/!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P8/Lk7dysg63cpOX9tIX/H///@6mQpmJsamJqbGJqYA)

### Explanation

```
code              explanation                   stack layout

^^                clear preinitialized stack    []
  ':              push input and duplicate it   [input, input]
    2;            push 2 and swap ToS and SoS   [input, 2, input]
      g           nth root                      [input, s=floor(sqrt(input))]
       :          duplicate ToS                 [input, s, s]
        >         rotate stack right            [s, input, s]
         /        divide                        [s, input/s]
          +       add                           [s+input/s]
           2/     divide by 2                   [(s+input/s)/2]
             !    output                        => (s+input/s)/2
```

Comment: shouldn't that be floor instead of ceil?

Comment: @mudkip201 Updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
½Ṡ§+K/(⌊√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DehzsXHFqu7a2v8ain61HHrP///xubGoGQiZGxGQA)

There is still something ugly in this answer, but I can't seem to find a shorter solution.

#### Explanation

I'm implementing one step of Newton's algorithm (which is indeed equivalent to the one proposed in this question)

```
½Ṡ§+K/(⌊√
  §+K/       A function which takes two numbers s and x, and returns s+x/s
 Ṡ           Call this function with the input as second argument and
      (⌊√    the floor of the square-root of the input as first argument
½            Halve the final result
```

Comment: I think you want actual division, rather than `÷`

Comment: @H.PWiz whoops, I do, thank you. That was a remain from an experiment to find other solutions

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
←Đ√⌊Đ↔⇹/+₂
```

## Explanation

```
code                explanation                        stack
←                   get input                          [input]
 Đ                  duplicate ToS                      [input,input]
  √⌊                calculate s                        [input,s]
    Đ               duplicate ToS                      [input,s,s]
     ↔              reverse stack                      [s,s,input]
      ⇹             swap ToS and SoS                   [s,input,s]
       /            divide                             [s,input/s]
        +           add                                [s+input/s]
         ₂          halve                              [(s+input/s)/2]
                    implicit print
```

Comment: Just saw this and it was a good minute until I realised it’s not Pyth. Great answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little language I've been thinking about for a while and just decided to actually make.

Comment: Is ToS top-of-stack... and if so, what’s SoS?

Comment: ToS is top of stack, and SoS is second on stack

Comment: Nice, I’ll see if I can delve into this language; I like it!

Comment: I'll start writing some documentation for it - I mean, I have my notes, but they're a mess :P

Comment: That’s a lot of `elif`s, consider using `switch/case`?

Comment: When I get around to rewriting it, sure. But that may be a little while, as I'm still playing around with functionalities.

Comment: @Stan Strum: Sadly, that is not an option in Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python

Comment: I realized that shortly after I made my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 39 bytes

```cs
v=>(v/(v=(int)System.Math.Sqrt(v))+v)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9PSwMxFMTPyad4xwTjlubPiqzbS8FTC0IPHsRDmkYbWBNMshFZ@tnXLKXIe8NchvkxJt2bEO08Juc/4fCbsv3qsBl0SvAy4ZR1dgaeR2@eTmE8DpbB1TcQQ8jQw1z6DSkrUnrifKbXimav87k5fMdMCqV3ha743OFbXQnuBHvtPKF4wqjoCNmmvNXJptro7c/bO0zAGSgG60WPDPgDA1FdVldVvF3XQCuFkkrIGhKKLy@5aHdwqTT0UZdpcwZyI4Dz/ySKUYWjbfApDLZ5jS7bnfOWLMPIEqO0w@iC681/)

A C# version of [Olivier Grégoire's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146447/73579).