# Produce a m*n table in HTML

Tags: code-golf, code-generation

## Input :

Two decimal integers `m` and `n` that respectively give the number of rows and columns of the table.
`m` and `n` are greater than or equal to 1.

## Output :

A table in HTML that has m rows and n columns.

The table should be displayable by a modern browser of your choice. Most browsers will display everything properly even if tags are not closed. Proper indentation and spacing is optional.

There should be at least one (non-whitespace) printable character in each cell.

**Cells on the first line should use `<th>` tags while the ones on the following lines should use `<td>`tags.**

## Win condition :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest source-code for each language wins.

#### Input example :

```
2 3
```

#### Output example :

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>A</th>
   <th>A</th>
   <th>A</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>A</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

or :
`<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77244/discussion-on-question-by-potato-produce-a-mn-table-in-html).

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) with [MiServer 3.0](https://github.com/dyalog/miserver), <s>31</s> 30 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts stdin for the two-element list `[m,n]` and prints strict XHTML to stdout.

```apl
(⎕NEW _.Table((⎕⍴0)⍬1)).Render
```

Example session:

```apl
      )xload C:\Users\Adam.DYALOG\Documents\MiServer\miserver.dws
C:\Users\Adam.DYALOG\Documents\MiServer\miserver.dws saved Wed Mar  7 17:19:40 2018
      Load ''
Development environment loaded
MiSite "C:/Users/Adam.DYALOG/Documents/MiServer/MS3/" loaded
      (⎕NEW _.Table((⎕⍴0)⍬1)).Render
⎕:
      2 3
<table id="id691498143"><thead><tr><th>0</th><th>0</th><th>0</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7X1rbxxHkuB3/oqa9oyralTsF6lXN0mBoihLXom2RVn2DskzqruLZFnN6lZVNUm53fpgH7wUVxys1zDs@7B3O54ZmFgYGNza3gEEGAvI/4R/ZC8emVVZr@6m7Jm9PRwtk91VmZGRkZGRkZERkXa/O9t5bHd7O/9xdvR32/9hnP3287XVd7T3yvftVtcx8PvZyXdV8@zkm5pplu85XsfxsezM2ck/abOTf6jc/Vur2trqyur6@vK9v9XeXL53f11746Z29/b66r0Hq/e0uXJ1aniNdtcOAu319TfWZqjSSs/bd/yQH2mGHWi21t61fbsdOr6277TDnm9qYU@zvY627ff2tHfv3qEvy2/eKTN@uw5@0bZ7/p4danv2Y83uBj0tsPcdLdi1@47mevzS7Xlc53bIZVyv3R10nEDz7D0n6Ntt@NgahFoIMKNHmu/0fSdwvJAgUAvdXuBoHTu0CdzBruMBUlqv9T5gTDW1dg/Ku14QdycAsICg7QPsXqjt2123AxgQ8tQY43a9F@4SAvgce4o9RvwDqlqrVn@FzQddBygJZR3/wA0cSQs30PYc2@O2GvQQft4PAO@zp78jEiLcsIe/6bFGjaTKYJthD3/j45kZBALsdPuNs0/@Af7evQN/a9rZ3/93fNrvw7e5eS33BzF4AJ1HytXL1SrDCntrgz2oNYTqN@8hsPqVywTP2Nc8k1t5cPO2tu0eQkmA8r14CxhaNbNxdvyxx@2ffDMikB3nrUEvdBCovrlZ0gHAPR3@HH8FXzc3@Tv@hQelkh6EvttHuFzbDe4521jXqC5CE/DcPDv6eq5@aRHq3binFMRSlbOTU@6H72I3zp79cHb05dC4UIFKm7qmLxKATz7Damcnv69T4UFAPX76z5vwGP6cnTzfDOHviz/VoGjVChHSyfMKlpDPEADRsG/7oYv853Q0LCCwXgHuQqhVrX52dAxo1aofAsYdX@3auuvtdIkyRm0RKAdSwRI9rC9xb@Oie31RtEoAv6N/VFZSRpbFOUttNxpVGosnoopgnagoDyIWbcEvfVZffEBdFWPaqjzAEddf/EnnIT36ukIFL@jQ0weNB6LY2dM/Ilme/fAAmtGdVd2sPBAN7IWiAaMedx8E37@eHZ0yLAC@6FOrIBS/b/iyad9klOi7z@CIN2isTp7j2@EoRgweLRowNp9iAxYNE35s4HDxoMl@Rd2nmb4GM5wQ1Ms6Uel7c6F69vQPKLRX4rItZweExjtuuMvtA5/8zpBDgC0953IaTdNbzqEYAOTSu@@WV@/ihFy//dra8h38tLo2o0xFMYGryrPapbPjP56dPK1d@hCaGM4kJ@9cDehXXkBmaRj6bY9l1q5zaHectrtnd2PpZgQmCjPdgsLPzRiJy5cvz6QlAs6J789OvgV2Rbwt3W61O862bvG35esrN1Zv6iMWFY1t1@l2tP6g1XXbKNB9mAGhP0Bqnh1/pONHvbjkNgh6WZQ@jynrDbpdURQ/6jNCfs7@HD@iNwGsECgLhSQWovXo7zSaxr0@vgxGUk7bvm8/boaP@0233ez4vX7TC5q0Gvn7TvMRCrzmo37TgYFphjNS3lItmKC4JkVQxCg0ltttXDkSPZ@JGIRHzagt8MynmmYFKGLoq2u6VquZhn4X6ts7Doi5ZWrIt72H2pJW003Zxn3f7msqmzVub0fCJYGO/MHe8ywW2NMM@uQfqyBwtfqHQAFeE0AUi/fQT2@w14KlJQWqse50cRmmmYVjSRX0dKkVO3DuuEGoXS3Pw//1mZy1K6IHfLp/6/Y6TMapKNK2PVziWw6qM6jyRKRJNA/N1nKa9WlxreLQvcEaRR7FGqvAzEW1QUjiIme9vowTNCgA4HWYVDMpqERcYB/sQ8BjZnC/c0ZN39BJ6J26bfjGK1J@e8ADYoHIey3hGbULbtuEVUrf2AKCQi/yRgY4I48eyGbtPMBWDlWsmJNQ4ns7rGF13KDftR@DPAB1NBi0dwsaqi9KdkgXWPY62Fd4/1VBZ0URsX4ffzyOIGNeF5GhmAIwUrB2Wrr14lTImBenVhF33N6eyQGC4/yZvqXPFBSOWSgrB4xoSlVMsWQZsGatrkWiAyBhLSkWC@QjyD8X1qIPnL@EkMS3oiFtVuwrQmAP@TAqhD8btS2QpaFWonaCEsDpDUChJo3@WrJoHYoKtKjJeHeSKji3pSG216B514PFFWqFWtexO4iFfnbyWx150/U6bpv3JLBDCn0HdxewlbL37fU2aDAhSGbcH@BewNNob8V8HjUW7WyA2Vuwb9K6KBB729oGynSL8LNQAh84MeZuaOH@xKP9z9YUy0qDJwOKY12QkPUp8QVVEhB3vJ9IsNIjlPoGUTZuHymDStsc6ENymKg3nR7iyaWjHRztbrJUvzYzxcL0My1K2Ab2/u07dwokBslRVjmycgaaWYSNiBiwbc3wgrQc1ld4wTno@Q81YAfaTbth4HS39VgVu1SrIeKptSwHlUf9MWtPnoCZas0pEBKT1hmc0ABeDuHCuGUG8eDyn8GyZMk6FRR4sEIZpPzHeo0VyUJ4gb8ysnrCmoWvn0TMJbnj7Pj3@QtZlsETghXILmSyFPm88/N7YQ@YwJmZYrFDjHCC5K83uBtiCj8BjGBP92W833hxqm8PPFJO4Z3zfhl@/9LQDYvkjYmo/OIXv0BxqL3/1sDxH8NYwdRaf@y1twe4vTflfLaELAp3aU2lJjyUXAfQjCYb0QAQtIJyqeuCjAPdvEgjIAwWcafF4wbDey6N6Gdd/FOjl9coibSzk2@Aa4yIPcwfv6iePTuCPeIFhQdnJq3SIAKPvlSXO1ivSd/6PbRy/NXYSRZBlHMiWrSVYolF9n0yUYT@2547iuZxv9vc9vxW2ARCNVvNQTto0lZysuhH6r4GSxfJI8UQRpY8se4qS5KYb7j3IETgFfy2AIHUlIRt6XFLFDg6JuRQgpY2K7SHfHtlXavVtRqsKXPaFe1qisiw64eKtO/fhEmJRiH4VcFf2/gL@X/Tx18t/BXqG9zCybdUcWscuVXsavUrC0AsXiMQp1RHeE4OL8HuXZgMmPDpPUG0b5c2iwj7gQ7MgeLr@KON6pZB22f4tWxuGPNAxNolED9/aFUAibFIE7EBaYA7iT@gICy3MG7bHq2vTVAh4rFewXmPmx4acB7ZxGBve6KByJgg4GSWqSewzJXZOILvQVYdz2nzojY0ikuz2CSLgvfY8MqY4Prf7nXkzHyf2WNQr1cv6xaWs/RSQ7cAEC9CYYD9wxf5mqdUNOJ1cW296TWJBKxhynmeQw0sNQvdHYAWY7t@DnVia7NAOKX04HDXY31nJhaOlj6MJvVNEKkesCCQFN6srRNZ7szWU/tMEgmigT37obPOmHimpTd0TSFgRA61nqSEpP7aOkhnrGvpcU3qrMJLgJkyw6Vp0UOrogHM67FxDFbhtXUcaTbqaMJgk15YFbTS0lchQdT9SAuYyxO2xtq6ZGfqQ2qeKIirs4YUthErFbNkLMEZ@ZmfzzyPEmRGlnkrUsFvghZPJANm6UqmsIOg13ZtVMtpzRSzZ9@GZaDVTQwM0vMRrOuI0NnJ/0DbIi6UKTpFe0kSRGgCfvYDW9iHLbRGo0EbRdYTNMwB/QHSe/ooCQCxXe87gFdXleUl0rA3tb1BQBaPELrq4balp9ntNuyFVPOCYaDAhpmomxXfRPKRHNOLaPyWZUB5KPkWkrGiC2NAhsI088MejCUdykzek8hKQ0GVtXVdmICJyUDfMHSL9cXnwBcm26v1UQQ@QqHheJ2MUe8vZzekk5u4873W@@q@mM91cJ1u15qtWBTRwRDwOA5OkJLPOHzhwIcp7YZi3Jjd@DhLBeLIOjTY271ut3egBcgT20Bgf9B1cFcKml0Hd509MoDBGPTDeC84ZkzEcq@sQhn7gWKRKzDAyXWFejgLOt3OYA82uHKbYcuNRvqUUTdNWHTEviJGYer9a6zaK9OFd6TFu08JHWT4YrvGqt@nTAY8WUI8ngjdAdQYodCITVOIQwoLR3BtptBqKWlUH0ci5xAGEEVNu9sLcHBHRAsQb/Js6tMkPfCH@U6uBX3QEx2YfBJpt58modivwK4MOqoV/5BlxhPb6T37ccv52bu3xd3bmtw9kE@/N56IToIq9VWivzCabO2Nj36ygEgfXIT1ASDm78mwqaNjXPAsWu4stAPk7GIkSscf0b@PcwDm7k2Q6iWk@s9NxxLTsTSZjsuv804iQaj8oRcC5lpOLwyrZuIBJGnDxx@3MofEMVABio49hUEmFzFcCGktbOVRjQwy0GJRt1IDFdUj5WVMPXyfV4@1nTEVqcCEvSeXTM@@v7x5NrUQdZyEifb/lRVp8vqz/BMXnL/cYvOzLjQvLT0mLS75C0t6TfmZ1pOX7sWkNeQnrx@FovunStSfXZoWSNIJUlTUYqv4zFQCNCM8JwnOrNBMC8y0sCwye/BMkURHYbZnBw@bwa67HTadoA2zLGgOPBetIV3YxDdhUxc03ebq3ZmYhGT/wN1@yho2zcE8bn7pkBU0iVgokRxYvYtbKLmDQrzIPn496NrBrpbHFikO2bP9h1oJt58lbTNu8PryDc3dNgjg0Sl1FQBLvyR8bJJzCNvgcEsXQUxvCZlC6nEQGqIRxEziLJObfIJuNtRehWELAgsLX2vb88OBsDX0vO5j4UknSgHheoNuRy4Fm0oLMEAIY6AvRtAn0uVtz0UzksYjb8BG/bHmOSAB9no@CtsejhnMDPXEQjABcha2s/kEGh7TTsf10Z4kauHaoRrCDfFcGv2ElJ6b167WtfnLIK4jS@fVDUmpk2@VWlvpoyigfTFGKcn5OEmBtDKOfC4clSrk0IOOSiPuNrSRVlAzCof8ATQ3ENZW3EPh38SvkKWxqaMvyxegnfmtKU3/NDki36j8E3TguhxFOtJy4h9k2A0XUayNs6by/DSe0BSp5AoX9eQemm/MZE6bEsjyFJdrkZhNOa5XBW0Zuli@dGv1bo5rVkLUkYYRKRHR@tsMD8Nm19l3us2g33VDYfsMmniovhfsxDrZ@sCnE3A6qh6OdFaDxDmztuv4ioV0tcv8TkcvgQOt2eIoOrbEEUKvlFUbTUIcAmIk8O47h6EmZw5hiqNwYRPeLwQooTaGujmrfN8aRU1AyQsV6hcOrmXQe6uBJ2RfY3kCtygZF7qrjkdEXKN2of6hRyd@A69ld22vjZ3xya2459Onh04I@pzesjvCsUCPgSque5eqeMZsELij02qkZRAiclj5fFuchhM9nqIy9@LU8H78c92s4wkA6gen3LPjj/Qm8IjsM1bGqYumSXROlA605J/34pTeJw3LAdpVV@32rha1rDApfFM5R1ii0oYOYDHUmbAvXsYv8Le6F5R1y7N0gATw9HzHpFBHfXQ7XX84@vHPBrpmfgZEe/oVnwrcfJcIVFHPGzrOtjfGeyU2@mbMjBGtopmGCN2Fp9qgL6z4dEKaMtiea4k3EnZcHP8nkQcpYRFPc19afekk@734JJtFqCyY6QdPa4QXn3iwj3FAmzH2YKfjC5qNst/n6seQ3WXRnsx@nWxUTlmmY6u05g/rqEOyFgoVhWH6@cgXIKLOyL6QWq9w3To51CS1a9TW@k30ZwGZlZZitEGKR/IeejKi7sKeOQAWZrCj2pTpBZ/uKkI70b6qCQA81FnR293Ak9@@OLQ8@VYno/KnUovjRaOfsSE13tl1QetGQEu872OnnJeAyuZtADQbOe8js1MDOctGTBWc/c5eP3zM9A5wm@kc4tacHIM6PU8PWSmCDXYsAHZF@EXMGEaCTsjYYrVj3eYzeSiu0jex2YdV4sDtdjW7ewAji3t5cosCLfONtVXN4dWEtLTYa8LUAtoYSwRhm4w72saUqxB6gIkjmj3Rk@SKEw1Xes1hvVhddfhJvO7o12EZ2BiOtgC5AD3M9PQKIICini1XH2WZEkAXadSPvk6uUvlzg8Tyi9OcdSHqh6xoUKTA7w0DFUbC/UvYYr04TR7OoXxKDevXOPEBN9NUvRNg/JPlYBuRapEnl@oZkXvKIo5AkucisddbUtSFvdfJW@VNGNU9h06sAHwzBJngzigcjrFDKLJxrqM2ZYPQ8zzHx0CewA1CZCw6i9vrAbuxB8xsED7ukrxh0KpvIVpOep6j9bYb0ePZRFDRNrCz13aUt2kTEXriCfdD4EfhdRO1FqhwgX@gSFyNGqrQMWxcbq18vQyFYd60gdW3B13uEeiTXdtX3OUUPAgAaJC7MOC2bhp6S9eMmlbX5kxTW1rShrt2Y9hqbNSsujW3NRoB8LY9gJVa1KCIIn3X1tXZPNFbkKJxkIry2Rs@bVy@rtCbF6fxK7mGsAeh4jef2PJLz0rJbuRW4vsZD3XpVcZ@QbHhDgibOYfAhe7Zv8NCp4@GaHzA83mOT0HwKejS35eURVq2h6AwslkLipqWPtJzGuADdfKmAnnbdR@iO0HMAWLAJ5iExRkE@ftpyr4ZZSgZ92Da9R20tgYZhsjZMgnyocXMYkc1k7Qu/FDgKm3UF3lao5hSnZ5ZoeuMbSVJyWLfZCZquiguXi45BPD@NAsNf3AFdRmlnLfksyCYo28uRB3oz@RvndmxoIYlyKeioJgMVPgQhiak2CAhcWsLIgTNRF0caVvUUhzFANw/U7yZJ4zE5IiakYFhWtRUWNRMwfY6AT4raaGdYog5wQfTNKf2ROvP5EPOMEdUM@nhkfXySPgdsrErMzkz@4U8kyGvPYDk68vvat5@v7nv@K3m9l7YJJnaDEAHPWx2miQCIgnN0p7jUSuxx1CQWJGCgRuSGwjuNGITFCos5PbUdXGxCtwOrj4aoxC1AGXhrWt3u1Tad0jrmdcQvSBeqgzdOXTagxAW@vdhZQ1oZTWV18LApIPC1OUwXUPHtVPXdsO9rlqShEtnioKgHkwsOX7tADqj0IA/WYsKPBQOHhizsiWcce85eNCUdcyNQgDpZCAb70deSujSy869w5E@LgKQIhQJmpAiCGHJEMsBgzsNeTMnPF0p5k4vwSIh/TAJAT0RDkM@gw1uEsMaU694eYm4UEFHBO7MZAWRQjsKUarx6IAq2nH6sDbULPROGuw5ch@etGZHR3hdWLQ6ad9swFIOg6B8oq06NRUrMfwpyG6HnsRjWhD8hezMxxI5ZaixiMELRcUQqI9w2FXQwCE8/hiJjSs9gEW5YOVVJzb8jJ2b6oVxZ/EUijlfTpYcoIc4LbQOq2QAeJ6RmAp7@AiV4ZMFnzpxfxjYVP2Yn8LiWhBRltpjEvXnmK3aZKsHhdRQBI6@3euhqhk/2MEHpvbGPSwXkw36pEcygmupGkiWFzLsMJ4ViJDCExuoABsmnFAvTuWMenGagpZDE4PGzTTEwKGpLjtqP3nEMpTnjs3PvFxnMuBSy@FWgRve0KbIVco/oR00P2iGE4U2c4HIAmFrvLDxsiX3Ynj@L6UC7D36IGX83gEuibjcUQ0z2vNwEgeRfUH6W3aE50C8FUquoTYvoNAQSrOydOOLDz9nNeH3andNAN4d7HnaLsdjBdIQi5AQIdGUxC/GKl7rDgAgrPO@e4h4YzcpysqOgmEGfdiaOx1LO9ioNbcoSo2Ebkf4MLB7cwKNHP8Bmxc5G9dEXFMO6OtBNKdzIq5I1b1S1a6IdAIiusnkkryLwXh0yzYX65xK4CBuBDZm@SClwI68LV@cGqK2iYdGxx/pKjv7ho2x92XFD1OaINHC@TzllGm@OB2SkxWumQQ2Xn@h/CefHUyhrJH1JKCd9BtiBL0AD3G7fNjrNdsDH3bscQQhFoUx851g0KWouYh5eAKg@6vfEYzF4BN1YTTd0BF5PdwofUgpGLRu4/PSNBoPHV1g1gluYFEgyfJOaVS4vOKiEURnAEHAzz6Ln3EV8ThRXx3HuHwSCdH6giBmRCXiV1gEOvA24W90/DGrVL5Zlt1GRjI8edgRmIkRSeBf1IcJ/ShiTgAgTz0pdAlgbIdsMryWFqT53DIFm4GIJO643yPF6eCc8ZO2HimxchOkSNyki1eqnJ1b0uvk42nb2nKnY9jagTmlO7Vt2PYQNWFMWcFqMk9UqTTjt4YhVWQxiWk1eo67ZNR4caclpu5zepx8PTIPUmZBWqjIAigNguIrpc057w@O/g3bu67Vq7VapVaPSXK4h6bdIQrzEWc3ES5toK01W83Q3mm2nJ0mzufYsPwmHkQkPNtoMYPa5xx1ipAhuohICR3T8uTEEwIe5A2C51@R9YacTzxhwqejHY56VuOHMTPRAfCF7fFkfUB7TzYTVXD9bffQGBY62n1bBmtB13GTa@9U9IWKjKpZYqyAGNE7fkWPkT7Rc/yiv6RzmjIfEwexDdXTLG1NL/Y64@EFpC0d422dxRIL49ISrD50ngSzPPZCMy3H6@S6ok2B11YWr63p8SLbeIzWsu/jDnQ8ZmkfMoaK5Mfxsox32bEpTotEgMTAYjEcVFRbHKGw252OJvBhxi6lmozS7pD3l5Y8MkBpe/xRXkcZJQEZEDNaZyff1vBEvabVKxJYq9frOran424Y0X@CdGuprhYxRPhtGYmemC/jCEfLAjkUed6F1b298ZizjxziJuvGlMO0Y2Qfr10GraalnxfjBIOtPVi@c/sGMZjCVLXaVO5siWQzKNGg5SZqk823QKL10MUjjjqOxRnLPjvkszYSaJTP7WfKA5BybU3H9StpFVjvgHUbcWbC0TJzCjzNyYWYoCRD4OOMSuUhFpJzjtTGWGdk/XgWBJfIUfTsB1x7UJGIwZDA4swyaL59TKfCFwGYQeicfAuzDs808dtM6tRAuq4ANFRzRzweOI8zbkQYxm4kAoIlsY6@FOP24hT2rqQ5Yd/i3ZkiAEiYSTynxGY4ysFmWIzNjiM0IcJHKkWM0UjPOJ/v8QGumMvoHoOzG3dBtE6lTmae6IsoNpCYysH2W5bx@rtsHKN23iIXwbwcCkLDg1JK9fyMC0oBKg64CiSvndcGzFDeVdxGAydsBugw9bBJfozNAUy1Qw6nbt5yDsWZZBQ4Tbn/OEJUUSPyvEIjf9B0lq@gK/fuz37YyziH4oEMn0sTPkgV4WCZ8taMw62hD1hsYenVkp4j3KCz3o7DmQljT3wmQez9lQ7EfrUbNkG0v7rDf@y9Pv3FSd/UN7DJVPR1RounU2rVIYkw7m4@GUinz25qhYibj7QLxZeS6ZEX861SpLs5iDwlN98@hB/hIZ0@LuRUbWPSnaXKY2klORtWP/lW@kIC5nya1TLJJbKW6xSZ6d9h2qEx8mcUUzJ4qPU4/SXMg34vcNVo43FsLwUELKBWxXiyp3o@5kwJOWtJh4ZPMAlwSpD/NMyRR5xvICeHgIwlx3nxarnc1KDwAE/Rg8iN7mFk2IB3OPTNV185FHHy@sryjStX23aH1x2ZOKA4ZQAdHyKG6J4bub8ZaXZlNpV8a0HDpgETpPSqbl2BUaJ2VMskjmE0hPAZWzg7@XOSPaErS4jc03/eFNMXR/vUmOVxh5UGP2FVXGdaMylvWhzXKDg/dcrFowANKDNCjMxyNDI5g4dSQxUg6E6lDBPFMh/QoRJFM7fs9kMq6JCNIxJIDEXf1BcBQGr7Jd102rtO@yHZ1PYG3dDFg3jpyx3SxAMgS9IbnbGJYIB64pNBxsHR2vF7gz5@20whwH@Pvg5BIdMECJHO1XfimOzNCPcEMSJPe3IDwv1YE2U7QOGEADKFkUhKikq4yLeq9JZcizq9Ae7JOYGU8DHvOF13zw1lbhIzhXo0ApSeNdkS/U2TJqdfJWVMRGcYxNEp8lzciUS3MUOU9CCEzUfWM7jAExg3KT/RExg9yEDT@Lq8SMlrKImKQEdaDxMR9QIMNg@7V@hirv/WS3kMq77C0v0q6ygskMOqtNcFIUS2g1z/q6KQunj3meODTYfDzcO/nPd1Hs0Zr782yc/ppJ3afY93yD6f4zUuzVVrWB29OCX6iz3GdH7XhxvN2habJf9hGGeGPf4KHygu2A2ym9AyxamLFtbXaPeDG2OpUnoSBQQaNzCHDQyp2hJaZhAbgxMPYdpVGkna9aCfN3sF4PhFhh0AUd9iO1LEsaKZumwmCvuyKtZhlnf3w31c1xIbAVjlPdxXqrQkI8GCvig1c0/kP8LMx6d6hV5k2aWHLNBa8pBVWjD8UgRyqwa8lt6QaDz4SMLIxzDaOsm5hatHM45OolQuA9bFabvbdx1KFG4HeLDEpzxkzFpSaCgkKnKQgjjBpi6zQDj5M25coBdisy@eJLuDoCpcM9Etep7bN17Leccc7cuoix7v8CkJSQs2@rFrM7nY@rYXoA9K3Fllb3@@7TYNJ4IXz4bT7qyliXNhSVijlC10I2FbwtmAFEvtsQUAoWRyu4ioMgNK@si4eEFYlxKb9HgPSG1o@iIbL4E69YULFW4zsccUzdEEkxA/TeSoSe1UVPWAPRsVB/@U050A/hZbV5Mb3HxvbcwYiMeij/tk501ssHFjwrkbYVXYFSdTnV45j7pkysqhrjxVJ1tHPg2Vk/Xc3LuCK0hAbW2wfCJJIlKesRaSb9/INsHGjTFNjIaFTeQbLRR//4imZJ0g0rECRWd@QN@sEYGxwselAqxyDA/p4/vITpLY8SswFNsHPjHH8IYQB2yfb@jW@Bw2eDqRdK1@O3S7QeoUi8TQ6L7vAMcGaClsenuwxFEQBbtUgUrAiUU5Nw@WFMf6hTcriCNUmdaRtgOYgjXylUZ2jWsrASp08sp@4dMdVul6jlGSOsVbQymzq/nn2XX00PTorFJkH6M0W7yE0WNiNviYU19J07UXZDw0jj8yjPqPXxACqHDham2ph6YhNYpJt3JmJXq4RHnTMlxZz/EMju84CIt8iQxC5kLNxPHOcerMJh7h7NYz54SVMw3SqcOEkhcdbuLRcZrE2TPXmFvXyFUjZtlmN8G0yFwyB@5/NVbV9b8ir3blGbglk7kJhv3kMx1D@P5T@bWrRUOdy61j0oTC9Ov@BO4ubnksb8uYNkUOp@NbQidQIlvwG3BQE3NzIjMH9eb7sD9stkC387tTMBYGS74fAGOkb4RJHkSMLzYcTVlwY2taiKVSo1YfTV26XmrgWjpthdqU5fC4csqiJSxbmrIwJ3ialmyqljCBvjWrtmVhEA79noPfdXpSpycYmjMlhtimNfVwbWyUXi9ZpQ8@qJasjdIK/JqrX7502SqtzJWs@XL9CvzUa5fmL8KvSxe3rBKUK71R2tqKG5CQSvN1WX3Lmq3VryDAwL5RsurlK/NX5y9fvnr5SvXK5St1hFNfK8Hvt7DVX1o1@AwkqEPFjdKD25eul0QmrdJFfFW6VbLi1sjTsnRz/dbdtb/9NdSnDiPqpc1BtboMeFMqLkTkCgCYRwDUQPS@dP21e3/zDuJVm5@HNktziMbd1964Tp2Dz78GcHP1VJtElzUo8jeiS9gRxnNjvl6@eLV2eb5er2/l0D5UvHgk/VPkAwSwZQHbKv3mA0T8EiH@6m8eEIW4q7eulGTvuEdX56nUa4Jq@Pnu61wGMH6TXv4tjFmaiDj2@O7q9V9er1ID2L1quTp/qVa7fPHq5dqVWv1qde7yRRrPrXP2bGwZIVVyObWwPEiLqHSL9rDDS9Vqo0HL3o9/TtZRnOWh7ItTkDYbW6MtcvjHVtG6hvcC0Vf8Ez0ubZZKo6nmz3DKYqVmqbGxNW1haL5RryVK68MPao1SJ7BL5J1VRKFh6YNaSZbLI2tNm7JaHK/L151pJRFTJuzZJUsEmQXiZPDu2@v38TzYt0GL6CaWKVjjoPmqaLIax/j1u5xj6du6NpcpH5Lynl/HuDiPgWWWHugmJU3WP4AfXbt46bJp6HbQ0Q14ohsA@ooZuZQnYdci2LUUdAKg6To2UYe3NVCOrl7lb3NoQeWkR5YhUbDqGjd6dvIvV6umCK88Z6vQUj5w7ISaSkNNpAGql2FrLa2Nh4QSjg4DCf90o6rVEeRFM6peL0DBUyftVem0FtS5FUrMAH3Dc08dfW3gDeuhGPEhCnAf8Y3ASIFoYHRhv2uOYYMEF5DWGsqgv3pNzTjjd5kG9@5Q08TBcTdEjocbLqimc9qLP10FDFXPqWkEV2EGCVTaYHdNShtoa4@aXu@tZnv34TRuvr23xH1kkaOKbmwMrS2zZJR/fc0sNcT9drXNegOvuFPEF7SAddFqDaR8hLA45Ojp7x6lLvtTahENHxENk6GFjxCgoLqkQIr5gO9UtiuqBd9wis1p8@ZE@PK/OTmFlh@ITO8IoT6@fsK3PPf9zztn42aK5WqCmx5lLl3MFeVj4Fql9uEHJY7D3pibs@bnt7Ym1BuWbKiMrgh@aTTSp@FeDkFv4iUJUzAtFpO32B3//uzkf0bX70kmG@r6CEtpOVH6@FzfhcWgBwNz0PO7UVTU5FrnrWGIhgxRTavVY7E/ua5uoOvAnFabn75WqhoG1sOzdhsezml6y3fRwREetwGb@pwZLUOpgUFBRs4@yQROkRCz/Z0mBe411xwP1l4HIxrI@s9hqOx59GCl6e23czLXd1zafdr@4zJn7KRUkNJCkolSdby23Q8GXbJ1UMhqZAIpJ7N2RnmZhYeQE5BdlWMMe2zCjhu3OJKG7dfGQvXsk3/csw8p6Ef0akbJWdYRzkdKnLyIxdkTmXp621GUDub1CJzuPl6/Gp@MHja07DrAuUfaWdpAEREP0HEcgg7YaVdFRgVyQuCO1bNRjfGazGJGuekBhoRPXB6scJnlB9IPuqqk6ZRBXnKAo4sj/1iNFgvjxy/oWsZnR9dqF/Cmx1HFYJRkLXnDAAwMZS/YsTjMx99Bm04NaBAto0pM/bWzk9O1xBCoYZrirktxfwOdpiYudVAzKj1Y2biGHcYT5lO6ePPZ8bW5C@IC1Xl4OFfdyk1aE4UtUYeWanSpgItHZEentcVrdXFxUnuA3qti0GDUXCeTzU6GVqqzZ9agpAFIhU9rE2L9ZP2zk2@Ifd7ur/eAAfGgBfCvU46EnXGp48hUDiSC/v@Wwh5khFPRfQqRINAyDQIXsPPiwEXXPNS8B@1w4FPSHB9mSW@P3alCZTrm3RaacFgBrFAGEKktjf0B6G/FPnTx5p/HmIMxZB9nmKniNmJuz0xeJkC@VF3H3uaJ1aIDAsyZgkAsPLHacw9RkGzT/b8uRud8kwSxLCbW2dM/1PDWRW3H8Rx0Y5AbjWRxPN8ilBE4/sHdCSApz3UeU7aX0A0HHYfi7Q/dvYHq7O05lAPzCtufUa@avVa7xGZYOm@Ch1BIm8P7G2Ucyyf/0LVVDRSreT3e/8CMzExWOUUxgQQwtQBJB3qymklA@b5gnqg0vT/5LNGS8Eo@e/ZDXVGh6mfHfyBgimurhYe9lrbd7dnwB7dkFp14wYhy4Mehpd1YXbmZCvr68YsKuSN5eMzscYYh/2GCXovVBhQ5@a6aPcKyhk@iO4YVB@yjY8SuYpA1gm56BfWqfhklUP2KRmYJ@Ix/r5r34jtvLP1Xr/76xe9/qZtCWTMunD37dxRcc@XLr9fKNfSU/PGLe6YRXTp9af6iGKT/9eHZF3@PNL9H43upXJ1fffGn@px2sXxRww/luvHrmmnM/vjnObNWzfyYo2T0fcdBjoSekyTDayC/iTpoce6NKA8AyTg86EeybFwjasE/9XY9Ei6UIAmvlLrmgSD/AUPhRHB@lAULJ4/MgkXJV9feuM@3kIpcNsw96iw/@rshIUbxVjQyoxenBgaXd@1Zdo5H9@KubbIL5X4ikc9ISh85/OJOb2UVA7BLxNvUrefsbnJog3QNUtnSarg8ccEPsWQ2Niua3bbI0AYCg26fjak/yskXBZprMDODcpPvn0dQeAzTaWnaL@85@y5eX9bQ6vW52mXtlzOvlMXN1uT7IO6svxXudYXDVAatUGhGpGJgeqiWHYAyLEeit01Je3YcuhcEKN7wnUcDF0TP4iadBnUe293eTqTRuT1e7smdojbmFuT39vli9SgjabLU2h2GM2gHMp13rZoH7r6IGsvvkexG5JmQrLzS80IRcArLXhTQHYqeqxBmcdwcXHnxjZDQFRckLnpmBRWi9AVQ28RRU7KhW7CGdB1yt9J15QpPVAL3ybtNFMip@96bQH6@4V3UjQ/q0EuVLtDErHFQTJMIqVHkRBDRjzxS9zBlLJGxKnxQHQodpRsXqTLnzw6BH6M8dZ2ew/55u/Y@XxXMNyuEtsgnnGzkTeGQLQdp1w4iJ226RRRzx9A1NBSJHiOsGYBEXDJA5PIaeDtwgpgRmEpBb@C3STvHCEGxTg8CPsukRkTYsoHLL67hwJS@2@nAitpCP1bf3adLI2BoMQS@mJsxYQgFHL4nbvfmeVjGb7FrL2cq3YZRoc7QNagal5wGtLwOXMDmNWYK0HylD73FtIY9P2wPwiBxyBsAmbEqXXrQ0XAT5JtjJi8mtUmxIgb349nirft378jBC1J3g@UDe/2taMQUYLz1rPCft2/D@HV2nCkhrt/Mgxhf93guYK@vr@ehF99Uu@65/f600G6s5KF2g6QoySO/150OksLouef2xPX0jsbaBvaXw1IR/SeO5vCJhypr4CQMephHtbe3B@SiMbVDEHqtQegEUzDr22s3Vm/GWfIjuULutQh@4DFDdsbDdfGog4AVBj27CogokUWxuJMbnQKglMWHzALnASp2hEWIkosFTtHzwCSxMx5RXt7PA5SyPo4HyokhzwMUNh2TgFKR8wHlDcA4ktJOoBhmDtCIP1eIsZcj1sOlw0UzKo09/OWwdZ0ojOl6kCgYDIz9wL/QNC/Gcp2K2ZhnHt/IiunxoTmbLI0uplMmrN6TKazf4yyV5G0rcokQVFqlKBtzPDvydAPCixc@fo@7VVRkrwnLpTSyjZJuRQ9Y@8q1hCr@O6hfWxuwAdkaVhsN2MXIONOy1N8wSQnaOX77@cqdZZCU4obmfGcm0q0Ow8QdgBOCbmOXmciXFWTatezdgPfWbw@jLdnzhjglql1qNPRMdsqj0wr@T4lcPhIZ0WRWl@dm2Uj3xuTMLM/TQWoiG4SJ/SNn4OLbHYuwTKOGBi@Bx7C6SIlk0ObEeDby7h@gAxV5NEp7od@OK1obRZlmnuc1PrZPxX5qYlN4MKVjWFUTSXpq1Q95eA@K4GIc@7Rg65OAiYssp0pdIt28nv7uYKbIsyu6I806yMnCmMiZd3b0dU2O/He1Cs2a448PprievFoYxViQQnOatg/GMGo1P5dW9nJQ8tI/mChF8KI1bD22lGB2QMqZUtJHhYN1H7Vne9rE7WR9pWRfnBXBspWlQtiKcssrujommo1Wa/VO22SN6JYfW1020@HNUXEbczSAaOdMErLC5dql2tmzf6sV9f4m6fcv0/1qovvT9p@3F1MSILq26HwUEJfipkhQLUjjo@GGZdqpb@dIf@JzmQMSN6txfL50W4QNX8@/vS1OqMmL8iuqixZ/5tjnyuUWdACY9G6MlAje5SMJEt3Ydg8fOph5fsqODOtLH3IO3YbFYj/Vl1UPN9sO9olNY1ny4VYH8cL4uPh@cizL27L7vruz4/igO3NwBqk5FikTFqk4FtmxE6Z7NEDDqvH0qwrALBtrzgEn2nmj26EP6gkylqCjkXUn5C@i9BPS58asJ42@3@s7fvhYA6KBDsS9iJksq25xNTshe2YUGyGZM3wbzw6dgybljRX3v7ieGvVBb/AeYShGKeRPvmM1zVzAmGehsp18K1U3Ma5AE98u34btzKGTyPdpCN1OKHumRcbmg7OjL0HxgCoRAdXrSkg55HobhFCFgqH5o1JpJjdNdOouo8tnT//IWm2RGiu1XVZnWemVXcxecWJgmmnRGV1knVZwKr5/OnHYE8@MnWhgcu@1o7upkfQKfTGqYJ693pfX/gZnb@YC@08@VcqviyPaTl6OZEFoi9RucyMe4cToosm7fvb0DzgpXfOCuzXFig06FENj5fk9JZl97vGZ6kQtJ0A8m5HXUTD0u7brjSiVDU4LOiDnaFqMv2uGzW2gpfOo6T2iBxgoACzOF7ptu34Q3u89dLxmSL@Vg/RHzSlcImbiNDpk/QniCYhvBHLarHZdRG3JFF2obu06dKqN9okeJd5x/L6PokGjahphpxFiaLvC2p0ZNpPu0OyfVVLrUjGyaVB8MZaLkuTXTPwNU4F2ebgbVEBbymEC64GGW3bKAicujQGE6Oy1iFkuTMopj2klbDyl4MjkV3Q8gdPLOhmZRXBEAmmZ4wizumraEjxeLMHnUgJTRhOtMuLEX6assKJ7D9kGja2IgDi1NcUoG8nCbOuUflbT9/B3jIgGTxdLO/hpDz/tpZGrExlFivUkyVrOjuuRXZny7SM53LzOv5LX@@gtIkBIiXJLjBIikk@uuekxyo4MG0oSCJQlevQqB0MmXzmffqLSGArOE76xgSG6UBC9TQAtx6VRZ0MtNrZILWGaWGXkTItt8OiN6saDTkAsvFYhuqaQdYLEEKBY24XNMhI57PWpt/h9sYRfM9yIri3CIabny0AhW@EualUkPwKKx@MvpoOcK@QWY3fjaU6WfbUpI4GXGTOBgl7MBonbN5Q4IhIdrOjRx/yQN3YKcdzAilUhIVDjI/lYOio35OXcv7Azk38FgsgNaPE9DDuZgJv0/QapXOBx6sX0DYV0BH5cEXcVUjMYBL@oF1z1AAWXahPubECwxx@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@0/Zu539jHloVwZABHDKe@UtR13H0Sz1OhIpybzCx5NuR32ejGzl4XVMO0SLL506Z5CA6UIXZXNqTEzRRQdjW7RSgHI5A5RK9Q0ZYMc5t8qrGZOTwEne9NGLVIYtsi3WH7LAyZOdvJPvdKMFhsLI3DS4ya2aFlM6MiY@l@TB9VB@b99SKab/4sZymND@aOazmRPlbTisvkna4zrDacbIUlmG@X6@VxsZUHe@ERfk@mdngh719GxfM8HgPxYWiFN8imHCmS2TL6bhtpsuMILTUevKbQuPAHO2@dhbbHPw48F@SLGdzo6qEs9p3d0tzt7GWLql0M@Fcix68njerQKnkb2wjyQBYZB6kBKlinXtaercX@PvhSkY46f4kSW@Wa501mhzVN7EqnZ1@Tp71TrPMXfCR@UdgF@fG4gtkXtqadiFs91cjoJCi7dUTBlB5YsptKxJbAMvakvioT0lNOjqRdgz@cdqMApVfCZqGaNBzaNwElc8pC444F6HOSIJTscCWpQifiG@nyipG50Z@@dhOakF6wf8QXudOrAzVmJhcQOMQj3X@CLYdDt3CZZw8UpO9cwTf5bQGTlGD1RrlhxxOvkxbEcLDc/foE4Q5N41XKqfg7edUy@Vy1fxKAhUcHMqyqu8prQNCkphlU3@QJh/H3yHV4/NR6RbGs54gDbOo8iO93qhi/vOSDEfGawJuFSlJJHrrjvZTFG4xczExrA3svtsryXi3mDpw6mKm40x50FCTwYOqaE9C29pOnjDgWTs0gG4lHAC0YGYUia8pytCLa/I93A79s7FqiseAkCO/@6YSAdvQOLQ2jwkaqCudsy9aiAvIa@DuzaFVt1heOwjAQUuhPf7bXD1l1RXYMKaKwXV08MWntuWErJhJVUh3hI79oPnWqkKrJ/vtL1nOPdnLd5ouO25@Y4dmBzNS1MuNOLbmKm8K7j7YS7ETroGY83Pqie9mLvoHfcfTYO03Vl8V0Q58eU3dPDiXjXDRp38@XRE4dOeKO1DATwNUN@xpEPfkI/CMeVXsdJ4JnphVKiiU02RftN0MWT@szT3zGjF3rHcmCBVp@Nr7lEzhQkGPAFJ7q6hRO0VszlSeklgtFik3C7N@jzxXd06miJbLqAcwcfsubrBgkA8RGXrz24/0DMwQPOudFx7G50nBNPtkY6aLK28CHdDL1DYZMopdFtIm2ml9dXk@5Zzxjoyfigjq/JMaSkYOZsD4rEeTuKJZkQKAnajiycpXqevC9m9zlgkgTqEYO8NO9LcLMJHDlSCwgxy1Pg5WeAwrcq5il2nctnVxDIuawqIFnp3Rffi84qcIbi0UzTwuT4FygyyRFSiRLdBIoX6m2LaHMOHqX1wg21HQyXEWfMcuEpT2QK4nJlUwyazP/2KRJI3DKfNZuM41iAFgsQteUxBpZpWDF6qnFkCPmU0SfxVEb/xClcclyWnPDtwGnmb1VkZA4ya476gsE/mf1cdSbPag2ch5HpMqgqx/zZjh2VdVms6LhNItAusNESrPKYxnLttPkPJzTXLgMVtBQl8nMApvec@XtIBCdjqCbNaHUgSHCKcCzcRUTPEojgU0uUSLSSl9g15XG3SiFzWW@7oYiiw43UGx75jqALzFhLCZSRBgM/CrkWcAS7rr6jATu//lZZRPElC5UNQifQVuxul@LxVugS8xt4AawSJXQDxPCOjTojZyJ5B3mU39HHlYEf9OTig1Hq2/agGy7DZ13XasC54l9No4QGKSTeoYAejhJU9wZxCeTBLOPj4AG0RVnqFgzEDgeawohlnkbupV9Z8l3U7dwEnsgXIvf2LTXEkX/kI2SE3QRxpbzyyPdOliszqfkMVyLAz6aHmlOSbxxJly0wrSSYzFHZJpfDYl4SLJkal7tOuNvDYye95zn6uA2dxLa599jtNHfzBSUsSr/4xS9gSu2ByGTl3d6mZdQJYoty8U4wZ5Rkau0qbn@hkNgER4OyLq68T@9vH1PwFsj1251x@hDtNHdpl5nTuMpImMC9qDUiafQSe/eKbiEK08hW2sfulpnMhTvXFEeMl1EMi8RT4r4K0mm9nrbKtxZoxgL8Xlqo4G@zPCOc3hybgynx1zasRVoLtYyuto1ZYbRdX3P38ELO/gDzeLPJEkThQ1A6Qptzx6RdqW9ShC2pBtM6IqNNz7b0Rd3imx0wjHzd3nbwIgw8ijsYx6xNe78ZNveDptPcbbYLHAwj3ZLr4M6c9@6RMsnxy2IHH93jmdoY8AXU3mMFdwa40oPdxEpCrUqcM2BegvhOUGKhzGxTrbHRS6nQpGZJFT1W91FK8plF@lYre18YTOLRqLw43Q/GTQ@uo5p00goiyELoBMYw6ahz0S2TncfwB9Pa6zlGaHs/8iH3rV2rP4Xd2lDrmJlKU1woR8dAPRhVHur0JiGt4BWwFY0o5nACvgrH81SHw@Jbg@5DGczvy0mpHfSiXB8JUSiuvaHQq@9Edo8h7zNzLuhWP2NN1XGM7WaoWChvIjet4LYI1AeITp40cvKkUWJLU1QTPfM1xyyonyNayc8a/nH82Od5/gahtPN98lmIFj50uFlo@ZUlfWrxGo5jmNxDehwYVebQlV1uc685aA7awUQhFsU1U8ghhTCXAgBVUsYds6/cvHsfIYunLt3ot7BUegUd4SX53Fly86DETF/TlTTu4kXTqopG/Ifaq1HUp6eH2quvSOs8ucmjtPlW5rrCO/1q9csL0If4/jbZkLFXIR3QiO8RzLuuzdzYq0SO6MZA1HkCSzOm3Kd74/XXFl595Te/@c3V5pIuejmoxHTzeUT9cZMtJeUK47tyFQlZWWZtV4Zf6v7IRTK@X0@Zh18pg8LNL7c9XTpH6wYu66RSmDkymPeQ4wzJhes1XhQB4OSJzHW@XomC1xZEqNqSPkpsV2/j@rs24SCTvNrQWYIWa2mKEfH3FitolJqCkm7sOuLKCZZdbkcGLtldDF1@jKUUwCLg2e3ICnxDdlEVuVqIpGbHdIaWcAqTJdxO/ntB5PEKnTiEddN3OXNOgKe/S@hkpCNOGWOK@pJchFAWeNNki@drxa34diNazuDrMEp8cvS1kstJjLxGOcwqfM5sKA9NYgbxAApYFDYW39HznF3HRoCgWXAcbo/odG1KNcwwLFS5jz@iszfDEBGxmCIujmdFucRxYwemeSDuxUqFiWmRTS1mIWxASzagenMcmAsS6tnxV1OHn3XsnG2s/JzwHRibg9OmxFKcI4y@yG06nsRmoWUIzWqr3WxN0VhLeBQunD37d4xzr@LtO5vo4vhleRHPgm0x5x5imsTNEp3tyF4YrYptCoEmJLQygHwHGga8Hh3bBaGOqJezkwxSatKeUpWzviB1RsOQSkLqpXKCuLb6DnRvWF/gJGzfNzjy/HvTGDqUse77kQgH/940I0UnB17iZBmJMM5u5peVjEYFprGJFrAcyyfDLrB/FhjCpEKlaGMF3ZvQsCFqmudCIFLIU@OX5x@pWKOUfF5mWclhdfxRBtAUirlwPEB8R28Ogl22m7Wb7S6fPTndvZ/Ai2gBXck1bEv3HvZFVPzY8px7IkoVTpSsaq1l6E924XntIqeRwORrmHGVTzRzfX6YpwT@luIIM8mrOFEJBqadwwqKDVb@xIM5SXGPwJMjL7Tg/5Rxp0MAGvZufN4Dz0qBzMlZkirGSvpYCMchOh@OEpBZMuqKkmG@j2FKuDmtoDL@UvokCs/saP8lmOjcXKIM9dTDljtmU1jl1VHDjV561KIUvx68lIPxsw/WhJue/qpjNg2lQCQ4fjgti8cBhb3t/8/vY/idZM9PllRTc/0dO5hIS9Rgnv2QGLSM/u072yN5Lmz3pk2wQUETWP9qeZ4VZNZ17F6@g52fVH98utN8mwzox1GCobj5cXfAMcLRuvZSONf/ujjzAXWv9f6U8uOqRA/vxNSLYPIx15Rgx1IgakWaG/CA7733H3ELqR7L9iKM3EDG5EdbMNSfOT0Wd51yMImswF9XoCYnykr3iHTF6cnEDWcRkgDZwnk71G5PK7iHyngr2@DEtj9OwkX20NQET5CA8/ykSsj0Cby9yABgIHK/IgoZaMcU@xFhyzStqHtiW5IDyOJrGlJvRtlHCa2fWzxncwrOXJ3UcwnlPGBgUCQUUXtSJUO@Lyqf6rEgy@h2WDS31CzBU0kYXjjSCaqkED46rbxSVmAu5suPSPhnDwso1wS7iTVbzSBagdfFde98O4E04Ik7HRZL5XK5NG6VYIhoWGmdnfwrbs7lbcmBWQnEuVcil1GLDLJYgJ6aSyAvN/WS/J7Y6uPd6S0QMIGcEv/EaGLsvEQA5@nZybcvTvVFJW8xFaMEt8pt9osK8GBocLyjtDjBRj0OgqSHtFUfvTgtMOu@5niR6W6iQud2KOAOEwqii8CF@q/ncnJVDfGMdZQ65y3cKEoToDgbTlgCI/8c8RKYiE/RRHRv@jCNComyaseK9JCo/Hk2Sp2w2xJ5EIcwwY9ON0U6Nbz@G7/RLeBmBaiPF6pxzqiUkGcnj5vkfhxMm8gOxxIPXPh4AG9aqYos5iqgzAiLl01vmouZ2KLw7vrtYe3CBViivsbOsae7zIb4HXX3k09x8Xo@Qj9vmRLR0st6KlMkRobpwMpEBozPQloMeU6I19gIFVmMC5yPtoBZ7YKHyP328zsraAnE45jalerZs38zxXPoUj557tr@w07vwDvfYADQV8pYdfnNO2UJok4nSmMHA50L/9MGZAwHDaXEEENCpF7Y5JSYODoLC7CYLC3p5OrxZx6mMVSvJ6ku5MdC33ekjz/6MMxu23tu93EDiDh35aL2tue2gT6lJfL/X6hA6SU9J0QIYaGDFBNSpBhv4raquY65j97w1jFN3R3Xc4Lmfd/da95EFwJM8AqrzvVurz3FJWXx9Tlvry@/ttqIvscvImfJJDJ6XyaDwUN3RKukpyrhBxTpO1Bxl/KnBH2Zii9RKMAgXLuLrhzqrUAFuLBzvvOYXKYTiwZluaPczbiWJ6HFQO6trr99535hVxeyHVvK9iKJM4zi0hRgpsY6AS8RC4sDTUkukXsj4WBWWEKIQhlGwBqTxJGom@GtRF3Ky0cfjr4uL8Kk0XRZEbuI@gIsmOnpIpRbqQfV@Mu99dtmOTWV5ExS5hOeYx19ySoV3WpfFgcxgBCGUGcQRjUGkUXkLJjgL06JaPghQxiipxbZKjKSDCPBtPVBC5Nz4Mzj/Hk7@0236Tv9bnPbPbyDv@5NKVEVqwhW5YubN4Yjw7z26/KFzc3/9ssPt8StgJubVc5BAwKi7eCVMs6Oc0ieTtF5VoD8sxkDvEeH@NDvX8H/m5sqJNV3GybzJtp8XtV@FdWOwtXkRlGNkxO3Z5druSky8Wdnn5wo/pE3Ui9OZbJAhCLujXzxp7qINd23fRcdXgIyuGwPPNJkA8pdZmlBzw/hF/sVcE6oPTts70LxlrONfjDwML1bN6jBjZ39LeyzgbRAHvj8xSliQKmBP4@KmKafTGwrOhbgQLvhgPRquh0tk0@AzgQRMdzgEmgO1Y@eZQ9bsB5NU/Q1SdeFFa24qoTPnUj3GBmI32w0a1um0m9@Vt/Cs0t/QkrbhGcAfuG0Q0QPZRczk9jTCAcV@a7BJiUKqdAaWqIoOfbdcALSBTGdRQO@YQJ8zOpFNaiEEgEGJTZkXMJG7Oy2tTUzPvX@jV77uk0XRei7YdhvVCoHBwflg7mgvdvrgdgACYvehgH@eo9aLttBX58MlS8pQLgV@EZ3blF8aYVfLL95O6igzfNimdzQJgCE4nfw4jlUVWZgGNBVZ0bKjTd546BeTTKjBpsoZNIa2FvNsKJQFhxTAbBG@U9/DqgESIFcTwUNNe2xzdicheqjCB6ndsXLlITxxEYutWXsgQA7AT2bMEKWJs6bMUTYRXwt3zdmmRqkBQSZTPDo/YhHqUI55sAkj0Lzfg8vQaGcj8zZs5TOvg8YgTzy3UPceuPlS3kMjM@BjZ0uZzDYQJdEx78HGrH8zM@RpCtQ6nYn4C9QBD7jxdtbfH0JAhI/s6mGUYbjxZRdUEpEjE3cn6htqohtKFn5qISCE5R4BaHyI81H1T4uwmBmtVv81k6CUbswq@FVw/GdT7dviBy2C2GHEtsRfrc77/n19lxpKarPvdYy9eE5w1gI/WT93kFd1Ge2A6UHJl3QaPBgvizVViZS7dZkqt2agmp3fyLV7v5Eqq3YfXkvEca8iW94mQ1dpuT4lEOSXbPCXl96kvJMWJDlVeDiGcDPubDhBl8fV9Wi6x7yrqUSxI@PhlK3SUWkj2xveQXGgVDIXgAjJmxc4GYCS@6nyKOYE61caAcqDhrMCUQmyfKS4JL@rcT0qGDIO/yA/tGzTORK7ezpH1HLyavFlywXVjdo2kVTSJkpyoxQGT@mtSnu0ks4Tr08uCxRxfIgnPSxqSbO12YbVIPmbsenLziRm7hfo09uJ2gG7gcOfaHwT6yCT7EIVcAP8gGXELNg3MipFkNB3BvxYIsnhuEzn//4RUWaLWgkTQtRpisP@ao/fir@yiAb7hAaXPHPM1DKv8Egl4iE8p7xiJexj/AHO6KczKo50AHC069WEt1LgtATYkG33I6lx1JBtyLTvZxCJto/RIGlvPwi6lndguiTGrTAgySwJ/oLZzR1e4BDiEW4OlEvpZ4rPJSyncYtDHXRK4O6RU5tut/mrebntDk26VYH/Pgttjk29keNPIqYOadx2SnqxMl3w3QMhZr1iw4/jr7c3hM5c9CXLRd4Bh0x@JT8RHQZ@hW1bw4NPdwlj0/T8dpaNI5sdYiY7VOFA2mbQrMlZ0gk0ZXJmlMrIjlRHB7rlsGnOQqls1xR1DscsJBCQ6gP1Ap2zI86xmd4I3Ijx4KTOFKKAZFpVU7F2SxOQk6ICTaBUyXY87Fq3MQ5WBVVczkxquaFc/OuFM45uJyXc1@cJhg3B3IGEyGsiG1F96GPUePmUAcFikYXndgV@cMUWKiEnSVdZeDP/toMLFq@AGSXoz5Fh4mTKdZpGk7Ggnkx7bHPnRDBFvK8pRSPt1TXl9dX1cCaxNIqXALE8CXSu/3VcjBOyL84Re7F/LyLeWdjSN8oPoJZi@IkFio0vs/5@peEV7wpoijiLStsQOOQ5f8QFryZOa3@fwA)

Explanation:

`(`…`).Render` Render the following HTML element:

`⎕NEW _.Table (`…`)` a new Table with the following parameters:

`(`…`) ⍬ 1` the following content, no special styling, 1 header row:

`⎕⍴0` evaluated input reshapes zero (i.e. an m-row, n-column matrix of zeros)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @RickHitchcock*

Takes input in currying syntax `(m)(n)`.

```js
m=>n=>'<table>'+(g=c=>'<tr>'+`<t${c}>A`.repeat(n))`h`+g`d`.repeat(m-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchBDkAwEADAz0jsRkhw1SZ@slWrSLVSjYt4e4mD48yqTnXosOyxdH7kNIm0CemEzLuoBssyL8AI/Tm8oC5ml75lT1XgnVUEh0gzFYbGv7ayxqS9O7zlynoDEzQILWJ6AA)

#### Demo

```js
f=

m=>n=>'<table>'+(g=c=>'<tr>'+`<t${c}>A`.repeat(n))`h`+g`d`.repeat(m-1)

O.innerHTML = f(2)(3)
```

```html
<div id=O></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
<ŗ>
table⁸ｏ╶［tr⁸⁶｛¹１≡╵dh＠t×⁸；｝］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTNDJXUwMTU3JTNFJTBBdGFibGUldTIwNzgldUZGNEYldTI1NzYldUZGM0J0ciV1MjA3OCV1MjA3NiV1RkY1QiVCOSV1RkYxMSV1MjI2MSV1MjU3NWRoJXVGRjIwdCVENyV1MjA3OCV1RkYxQiV1RkY1RCV1RkYzRA__,i=NCUwQTM_,v=2) or 
[Try it visualized!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTNDJXUwMTU3JTNFJTBBdGFibGUldTIwNzgldUZGNEYldTI1NzYldUZGM0J0ciV1MjA3OCV1MjA3NiV1RkY1QiVCOSV1RkYxMSV1MjI2MSV1MjU3NWRoJXVGRjIwdCVENyV1MjA3OCV1RkYxQiV1RkY1RCV1RkYzRCV1RkY1MCUyOHQlM0QlMjQlMjglMjJ0YWJsZSUyMiUyOSU1QjElNUQlMjklM0Z0LnJlbW92ZSUyOCUyOSUzQTAlM0JidXR0b25QYW5lbC5pbm5lckhUTUwrJTNEb3V0cHV0JXVGRjAzJXUyNTEw,i=NiUwQTEw,v=2)

After fixing 2 bugs (ಠ_ಠ) in the interpreter, [30 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTNDJXUwMTU3JTNFJTBBdGFibGUldTIwNzgldUZGNEYldTI1NzYldUZGM0J0ciV1MjA3OCV1MjA3NiV1RkY1QiVCOSV1MjU3NyV1MjAzQ2RoJXVGRjIwdCVENyV1MjA3OCV1RkYxQiV1RkY1RCV1RkYzRA__,i=NCUwQTM_,v=2) works too

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda m,n:'<table><tr>'+'<th>A'*n+('<tr>'+'<td>A'*n)*~-m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFXJ89K3aYkMSkn1c6mpMhOXRvIy7BzVNfK09ZQh4ukgEU0tep0c/8XFGXmlSikaRjpGGv@BwA) Assumes `m` isn't zero.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 30 bytes

```
’<…È>’sF"<tr>"„hdNĀè"<tÿ>A"I×J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcNMm0cNyw532AFZxW5KNiVFdkqPGuZlpPgdaTi8Asg/vN/OUcnz8HSv//@NuIwB)

**Explanation**

```
’<…È>’                           # push "<table>"
      sF                         # no-of-rows times do:
        "<tr>"                   # push "<tr>"
              „hd                # push "hd"
                 NĀ              # push the iteration counter truthified
                   è             # index into the 2-char string with this
                    "<tÿ>A"      # insert the result into the string "<tÿ>A" instead of ÿ
                           I×    # repeat this string no-of-columns times
                             J   # join the stack to a single string
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 65 bytes

```js
f=(m,n)=>m?f(--m,n)+'<tr>'+`<t${m?'d':'h'}>x`.repeat(n):'<table>'

document.write(f(4,3));
```

Comment: recursion. nice!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>139</s> <s>133</s> 102 bytes

```java
m->n->{var r="<table>";for(int j=0,i;j++<m;)for(r+="<tr>",i=n;i-->0;r+=j<2?"<th>A":"<td>B");return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY@xasMwEIb3PMWhycKWSFPoUNkK6VDo0Clj6aDYcipVlo18NoTgZ3fl1mRN4UA//30H@qwaFbPV91w61ffwroy/bgB6VGhKsHHLBzSO14Mv0bSev64hf/Oozzpk/4OOGIw/Swk1FDA3THomr6MKEAqSozo5LYmo25AYj2CLbWaETdO8EXQpQ7pQQZLMFF4YxuRWxM7mu33sv@SBPMe3ki@EiqBxCB6CmGYRTeJ0w8lFmdVpbE0FTfRM/v708QmKLs4Ax0uPuuHtgLyLK3Q@qbnqOndJdnQNj5SKe/ATvV3dhx/oLfzC02aafwA)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->m->{                  // Method with two integer parameters and String return-type
  var r="<table>";       //  Result-String, starting at "<table>"
  for(int j=0,i;j++<m;)  //  Loop `j` over the rows in the range [0, `m`)
    for(r+="<tr>",       //   Append "<tr>" to the result
        i=n;i-->0;       //   Inner loop `i` over the columns in the range [`n`, 0)
      r+=j<2?            //    If `j` is 1 (first iteration):
          "<th>A"        //     Append "<th>A" to the result
         :               //    Else:
          "<td>B");      //     Append "<td>B" to the result
  return r;}             //  Return the result
```

Comment: I think there's a little typo, you wrote "th" twice.

Comment: @potato Ah, you're right. The code itself and the TIO-link were correct, but my explanation had a typo. Should be fixed now, thanks.

Comment: `(m,n)->{var l="<tr>";for(;n-->0;)l+="<td>A";var s="<table>"+l.replace('d','h');for(;--m>0;)s+=l;return s;}` (106 bytes) I found this one interesting, but not worth it given your current score. You probably can golf a bit your answer using ideas here like the mutable `m`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I initially had a modifiable `m`, but due to the `<th>`/`<td>` differences it wouldn't matter. I still need to check whether it's the first iteration of the outer loop, in which case I need both `j` and `m`, and I need to do the inner loop multiple times, in which case I need `i` and `n`. Instead of going upwards from 0 and checking `j<2` I could go backwards and check `i>m-2`, but it would be +1 byte instead of -1. Your approach of using two separated loops with modifiable `m` and `n` is indeed interesting, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>107</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```c
i;f(x,y){char s[]="<th>A";for(puts("<table><tr>");x--;s[2]=96+puts("<tr>"))for(i=y;i--;)puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEITvfYrQU1Yb0AqCbBvwOUoOMfQnoKkkqbSUPntMA@KcZuabZRXrlQpBY0fnYoFVDdIS14g6r/zA7zl2o6XvyTsaC/l4trzylueAM2PomlLUt@vxx3cA@4GuF9RxAIk4wC1o48lLakN3I22vCpJ@HaL/NALImpGojko/aprKs4Din0oBgGljWz9ZQ06YbSGU4fIF)

-8 bytes thanks to potato

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

The `s` array has to be declared as an array not a pointer otherwise it won't be editable (we set the first h to a d). Most browsers don't even care if your closing tag is correct, so we just close all tags with `</t>`.

Comment: Still works fine if you remove the `</t>` that appears twice and -8 bytes.

Comment: You can shave 4 more bytes off if you move outputting the new row to the inner loop (also, it avoids an empty row): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCoMwFEV3v@Jhl6TEQlMohahgodChU@kmGWys@kBjMeoifnsaXdpu955zeU8FpVJ2g1rVQ/6C0PQ5trsq9v5QjU/HbEEaphnSSVVZByaVkR8@rnHii6LtyHvoDXEgOd8usU9FEwTCpFxGxxP99XcnGUZaoBus0FAqZou6hyZDTZaQdaVisP7Zbl0ZKUweABZkMTGn4FLf4lLHdC8pg2/l0h30ZmsPln8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>42</s> 38 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-4 thanks to ngn.

Full program. Prompts stdin for the two-element list [m,n] and prints unclosed tags to stdout.

```apl
'<table>',∊'<tr>',⍤1{'d'}@3⍀⎕⍴⊂'<th>A'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6TUliUk6qnbrOo44uIKcIxOpdYlitnqJe62D8qLfhUd/UR71bHnU1AWUz7BzVQfr@KwBBGpexggkXhGWkYAQA)

`⊂'<th>A'` enclose this string to treat it as a whole

`⎕⍴` prompt for dimensions and cyclically **r**eshape the single cell to a matrix of that size

`…⍀` cumulatively insert the following function between each vertical pair of cells:

`{'d'}@3` ignore upper cell; place `d` at 3rd position in bottom cell

`'<tr>',⍤1` prepend this string each row

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`'<table>',` prepend this string

Comment: [`'d'⎕R'h'` -> `'h'@3`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6TUliUk6qnbrOo44ujUddTUCBIjt1TR31DHUH40MrHAwfdS161Df1Ue8WiGSKnaM6SOt/BSBI4zJWMOGCsIwUjAA)

Comment: [`(⊂'<tr>'),` -> `'<tr>',⍤1` and `...@1` -> `...⍀`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6TUliUk6qnbrOo44uIKcIxOpdYlitnqJe62D8qLfhUd/UR71bHnU1AWUz7BzVQfr@KwBBGpexggkXhGWkYAQA)

Comment: @ngn All done. Thanks. [Relevant](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43074641#43074641).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 73 bytes

```r
function(n,m)cat("<table><tr>","<th>A"<m,c("<tr>","<td>A"<m)<n-1)
"<"=rep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9PI08nVzM5sURDyaYkMSkn1c6mpMhOSQfIy7BzVLLJ1UkGyUCFUsBCmjZ5uoaaXEo2SrZFqQX/0zSMdIw1/wMA)

Saved 7 bytes with a dirty hack - replace "rep" by "<".

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üÉ$♠═?S┼╪├8°‼←sí☼←T≡┴╜ô‼\↑0ⁿ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81902406cd3f53c5d8c338f8131b73a10f1b54f0c1bd93135c1830fc&i=2+3&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
"<table>"P  print "table"
"<th>A"*    "<th>A" repeated specified number of times
,D          repeat the rest of the program specified number of times
  "<tr>"p   print "<tr>" with no newline
  Q         print top of stack without popping
  .hd|t     replace "h" with "d"
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22%3Ctable%3E%22P%09print+%22table%22%0A%22%3Cth%3EA%22*++%09%22%3Cth%3EA%22+repeated+specified+number+of+times%0A,D++++++++%09repeat+the+rest+of+the+program+specified+number+of+times%0A++%22%3Ctr%3E%22p+%09print+%22%3Ctr%3E%22+with+no+newline%0A++Q+++++++%09print+top+of+stack+without+popping%0A++.hd%7Ct+++%09replace+%22h%22+with+%22d%22&i=2+3&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>72</s> 68 bytes

```powershell
Function F($m,$n){'<table><tr>'+'<th>A'*$n+('<tr>'+'<td>A'*$n)*--$m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJLCsIwEF0npwglkH7sws9C7Afc9AQeQG0HFZq0thGFkrPXxKJWpKDQRV5mhsy8l7yUxRWq@gh57qdFBW1yEak8FYJsoJa4QRhRHs0CQkU0D0wGtxJSCRmJCAvlbp9DHMpKr2O87oMpZSZ4AtPNUg/VjQmhXE8MMLIMzUkcCI9ow9WECL0LtdpKy7O74z6cyYvVwZ2i6d@KRqVfPOhnv9J/vsVwNp7Gnm3L4A/XBuHLzkEY5xIIq/dfTGzKJ1Q4TV8781hnrEuFZ7NXKetKjuv7lKvWELd3)

Here are my test cases and expected outputs (C.f., TIO)

- m=2; n=3  `<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A`
- m=1; n=3  `<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A`
- m=4; n=2  `<table><tr><th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A`
- m=2; n=8  `<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A`

Thanks, @[mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy), for the -4 bytes!

Comment: Brackets are optional. Try `Function F($m,$n){'<table><tr>'+'<th>A'*$n+('<tr>'+'<td>A'*$n)*--$m}`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>24 23.5 22</s> 21.5 bytes

```
;~"able"::"<t"$">".`,_:@"r"^_:@?$"d" "h"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWNzWs65QSgSJKVlZKNiVKKkp2SnoJOvFWDkpFSnFAyl5FKUVJQSlDCaIeqm1ltJKFko6SqVIsVAAA)

Takes arguments in the order `cols rows`. Outputs something like this (for `8 5`):

```html
<table><tr><th>0<th>0<th>0<th>0<th>0<th>0<th>0<th>0
<tr><td>1<td>1<td>1<td>1<td>1<td>1<td>1<td>1
<tr><td>2<td>2<td>2<td>2<td>2<td>2<td>2<td>2
<tr><td>3<td>3<td>3<td>3<td>3<td>3<td>3<td>3
<tr><td>4<td>4<td>4<td>4<td>4<td>4<td>4<td>4
```

### Explanation

```
;~     Define function f(str)
"able"  and call it with str = "able":
:       join
:        join
"<t"      "<t"
$         str
">"      ">"
.      Map
`,      0...
_        number of rows
:       join
@        f
"r"       "r"
^        repeat
_         number of columns
:         join
@          f
?           if
$            row index is positive
"d"          then "d"
"h"          else "h"
           row index
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>68 63</s> 56 bytes

12 bytes in total saved thanks to Adám

Prompts for number of rows followed by number of columns and outputs non-closure option:

```
t←⊂'<tr>'⋄'<table>'t(n⍴⊂'<th>A'),,t,((⎕-1),n←⎕)⍴⊂'<td>A'
```

Comment: @Adám Too trigger happy I am afraid. Looks OK now?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the `∊` or the trailing parens: `t,,((⎕-1),n←⎕)⍴r` or the first two commas.

Comment: @Adám Thanks. Its not my day must be the heat (28C)!

Comment: Merge `h` and `r` into the main expression: `'<table>'t(n⍴⊂'<th>A')t,,((⎕-1),n←⎕)⍴⊂'<td>A'`

Comment: Something isn't right. You only insert one `<tr>` for the body. Each row needs a `<tr>`.

Comment: @Adám Check your last suggested mod nowhere is t defined which I had as <tr>. My expression above yields:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77164/discussion-between-graham-and-adam).

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgnGXI862tP@lwCZj7qa1G1KiuzUH3W3ABmJSTmpduolGnmPerdApDLsHNU1dXRKdDQ0gNp1DTV18kDa@qZqwpWkAJX8B5r4XwEM0riMuUwA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
(.+) (.+)
<table>$1*$(<tr>$2*$(<td>@
T`\d`\h`^.*?r.*?r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0NPW1MBRHDZlCQm5aTaqRhqqWjYlBTZqRiBGSl2DlwhCTEpCTEZCXF6WvZFIPz/v5GCMQA) Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @CowsQuack. Explanation: The first stage uses Retina 1's string multiplication first to generate the appropriate number of cells, then to generate the appropriate number of rows. The second stage then changes the first row of `td`s into `th`s.

Comment: If you know the input is going to be split by spaces, then you should be able to use `.` instead of `\d`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>109</s> <s>107</s> 103 bytes

```hs
n!i="<t"++n++'>':i++"</t"++n++">"
r#c="able"!("r"!([1..c]*>"h"!"H")++([2..r]*>("r"!([1..c]*>"d"!"A"))))
```

So many parentheses… Thanks to @nimi for two bytes (and a loss of genericity)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xDoJADIZ3n@IoA5wXMGhcDJxhY3BzNA6nnHIRDnLUwafHosZg4tI0zde/XyvV33RdD257ziBFdaq1TNFJECI8JHF8Ps4lzStZpAuqwIUA6j7AMo4dASH8WSllTmA5XeGf9nUFZlHEkmTNTg/UPbu0jinWo1PmWiEzTVfrRltUaFo7WM@MenTCChHIYGPeSe8BUJjz6YExGLwQHJWvSgUeFKPFxPcHKAnISY7zoVHGZt0d9@h2loUrf8mHJw)

Without end tags the straight implementation wins at 87 bytes ([Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8g@2VbJpiQxKSfVzqakyE5JW1sj2lBPLzlWyw4onmHnoaQJEjLS0ysCCmkoYVGUYueopKkJVKZkow8xSel/bmJmnq1CQWlJcEmRT56ChrG9keZ/AA)):

```hs
r?c="<table><tr>"++([1..c]*>"<th>H")++([2..r]*>("<tr>"++([1..c]*>"<td>A")))++"</table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>65</s> 54 bytes

*-11 bytes thanks to @msh2108's reminder*

```perl
/ /;$_="<table><tr>"."<th>A"x$'.('<tr>'.'<td>B'x$')x$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WyaYkMSkn1c6mpMhOSQ/Iy7BzVKpQUdfTUAcJqesBqRQ7J3WgkGaFSsL//6YKxv/yC0oy8/OK/@sW/Nf1NdUzMDQAAA)

Comment: Save yourself some bytes. Per an example in the challenge, you can drop the `.'</table>'`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), <s>77</s> 51 bytes

```
<th>A^*$v<tr>vl+(^h)*($^F- 1)A"h"S"d"h+(^l)v<table>
```

(While working on this, I discovered a bug with `h` not working and fixed it)

Golfed some bytes by shortening the html as well as using "split, join" instead of "replace"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sKsov@f/fpiTDzjFOS6XMpqTIrixHWyMuQ1NLQyXOTVfBUNNRKUMpWClFKQMonKMJVJKYlJNq9/@/sYIRAA), use the command-line option `-d` to see the AST (Note: this uses the new node interpreter, so the older version on the website cannot run this.)

This program takes the input 0-indexed and in reversed order, because of Carrot's weird nature, thus `3 2` printing a 3×4 table.

Run the program like so, `./carrot -f prog.carrot input.txt`

Basically creates the header row, then the data rows on another cell of the garden (2D tape), and concatenates them together.

---

Carrot works on a 2D tape, called a garden. Each cell on the garden is made up of three stack modes, string, float, array. There is a value for each mode, called a "stack" (note: misnomer). These stacks begin empty. When a cell is at a particular mode, the following commands will affect the stack that corresponds to this mode, for example in float mode, the operations will affect the stack float. And of course, there are commands for switching between modes. The modes are important because each operator can be overloaded for each mode and each argument type.

In addition, there are two additional modes (these only affect the commands, not the stack directly), normal mode and caret mode. Normal mode works normally, where there are operators taking in arguments and affecting the stack directly. In caret mode, (almost) every character is interpreted literally as a string, and is later prepended/appended accordingly to the stack. Caret mode is started/ended with carets (append) or down-carets (prepend).

Carrot begins in a cell on the garden, in stack-string mode, and in caret mode.

---

Beginning in caret-mode, the string `<th>A` is added to the initially empty stack-string. Then follows the `*` command that duplicates it `$`, the input, times. Then `<tr>` is prepended to the stack-string by the usage of the down-caret `v`. This creates the header row of the table.

To create the data rows, we duplicate the header to another cell. `l` moves the IP to the right empty cell, and `+` appends `(^h)` the string in the cell to the left (essentially copying it to the cell on the right). `()` starts a subshell, a new Carrot program with almost the same tape, and `^` exits out of caret-mode so that we can `h` get the string in the left cell. This is then `*` duplicated by `($^F- 1)`, the next input minus 1, times.

Still in the right cell, `A` sets the array of this cell to its stack- tring split by `"h"`. `S` joins the stack array by `"d"` and sets the stack string to this value. `A"h"S"d"` really just replaces `h`s with `d`s to form the data rows. Now `h` we move to the left starting cell.

Now we append the stack string of the cell to the right to this cell using `+(^l)`. All that's remaining is to add the `<table>` tag, so we do this by `v` prepending it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
<table><tr>×<th>AηＦ⊖θ«<tr>×<td>Aη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@mJDEpJ9XOpqTI7vB0m5IMO8dz29/vWfaoa9q5HYdWw4RTQML//0cb6RjH/tdNBAA)

#### Explanation

```
<table><tr>                         Print "<table><tr>"
           ×<th>Aη                  Print "<th>A" * second input
                  Ｆ⊖θ«            For i in (implicit) range over first input
                        <tr>        Print("<tr>")
                            ×<td>Aη Print("<td>A") * second input
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 58 bytes

K version is whatever is included in `KDB+ 3.5 2017.11.30`.

Port of the Python answer above.  Ends up being 1 byte longer due to having to enlist and flatten multiple times.

```
{,/"<table><tr>",(y#,"<th>A"),(x-1)#,("<tr>",/y#,"<td>A")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 130 bytes

```cs
m=>n=>{var r="<table>";for(int i=0;i++<m;)r+="<tr>"+string.Concat(System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat(i<2?"<th>H":"<td>D",n));return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BSgMxEIbP2acIOSVsu0i9mU160BYPFkQPnmOarQPNRCfZgpR99m2KguBpmPnn@/h9XvpEYfZHlzN/pnQgF88Ny8UV8PyUYM93DlCqemSv37mE2G1H9D1gWfzfcyHAg7V84GaOxqKx55MjTkb0xb0fgxV6SCTrLwdzo6Ft@6gVtdecrGh/BN19Qu@K/NU/AX51GxxjoKujewmfoabQr9YV@7CP4q7OvX0QC1RKUygjISc9zYzpv9ZVmlPF3whKqM4gB7lS8rYiDZuaab4A)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 63 bytes

```
$m,$n=$args;$t='h';'<table>';1..$m|%{'<tr>'+"<t$t>A"*$n;$t='d'}
```

save it as `new-mntable.ps1`. Test script:

```
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 1 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 4 2
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 8
```

output (extra spaces are optional):

```
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A
<tr><td>A<td>A
<tr><td>A<td>A
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A
```

---

## Powershell, 65 bytes, `-replace`

```
'<table>h'+'d'*--$args[0]-replace'h|d',('<tr>'+'<t$0>A'*$args[1])
```

save it as `new-mntable.ps1`. Test script:

```
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 1 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 4 2
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 8
```

output:

```
<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A
<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A
<table><tr><th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A
<table><tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A
```

How it work:

1. `'<table>h'+'d'*--$args[0]` - create a string like `<table>hddd...`
2. `'h|d'`- search `h` or `d` chars in the string for replacing
3. `'<tr>'+'<t$0>A'*$args[1]` - replace each char with string like `<tr><t$0>A<t$0>A...`
4. where `$0` is a captured `group[0]` - the char in the `-replace`.

---

## Powershell, 65 bytes, `scriptblock`

```
$m,$n=$args;'<table>';&($r={'<tr>'+"<t$args>A"*$n})h;(&$r d)*--$m
```

save it as `new-mntable.ps1`. Test script:

```
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 1 3
.\new-mntable.ps1 4 2
.\new-mntable.ps1 2 8
```

output:

```
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A

<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A<tr><td>A<td>A
<table>
<tr><th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A<th>A
<tr><td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A<td>A
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 34 bytes

```
`<∨ø>`?(`<tr>`‛hdn1>i`<t%>A`$%⁰*Wṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgPOKIqMO4PmA/KGA8dHI+YOKAm2hkbjE+aWA8dCU+QWAkJeKBsCpX4bmFIiwiIiwiMlxuMyJd)

Port of Emigna's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
`<∨ø>`         # Push "<table>"
      ?(       # Input number of times:
        `<tr>` #  Push "<tr>
‛hd            #  Push "hd"
   n1>         #  Is the loop variable
               #  greater than 1?
      i        #  Index into "hd"
       `<t%>A` #  Push "<t%>A"
$%             #  Replace "%" with
               #  either "h" or "d"
   ⁰*          #  Multiply this string
               #  by the second input
     Wṅ        #  Join the stack into a string
               #  Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>130</s> 123 bytes

```go
func f(r,c int)(s string){for d,i:="<th>A",0;i<r;i++{if i>0{d="<td>A"}
s+="<tr>"
for j:=0;j<c;j++{s+=d}}
return"<table>"+s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5NDoIwEEb3PUXTVRuqIRoT5aeJN_AKCBQHoZBSVk1P4oaYeAiP4m0sSoyrmcn7Zubd7lU3Pfssv2ZVidsMFIK277RZE9ka8hiNXO1fVo4qx5JqnmNQhtEBD0aDqpiVncYFhyglibmII-FhDImOIQgsSAwitMWMCo8cGoK514Kgea2O0jCukzyufdijwjmkSzNq5UPZuSkFCQa3KBw-CrMgZdiik_9uGkUl3fAtY7-Z_ZE933myHJimb30D)

- -7 bytes from removing unused variable, condensing string literals (@xigoi)

Comment: What's the point of the `R` variable? The code seems to work [without it](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5BDoIwEEX3PUUzqzathmhMFLCJN_AKCBQHpZhSVqQncUNMPIRH8TYWNcbVzOT9mXnXW9WOj0uWn7KqpE2GhmBzaa2bg24c3HunZ-un173JqWZW5hSN46yjnbNoKj7o1tJCYryF1B0VyCjB1CYoxICaooqGYiKFAk86MbVWAZmW6ngbJXWaJ3XIBlQI2IH3xJautyYEs8O5VCA6_5XYvCUmRcbpQPbhvzsbptlCLjn_zfyPrOUqkO-BcfzUFw).

Comment: Also, you can save 2 bytes by [putting the "A" directly into the literals](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5NDoIwEEb3PUXTVRuqIRoT5aeJN_AKCBQHoZBSVk1P4oaYeAiP4m0sSoyrmcn7Zubd7lU3Pfssv2ZVidsMFIK277RZE9ka8hiNXO1fVo4qx5JqnmNQhtEBD0aDqpiVncYFhyglibmII-FhDImOIQgsSAwitMWMCo8cGoK514Kgea2O0jCukzyufdijwjmkSzNq5UPZuSkFCQa3KBw-CrMgZdiik_9uGkUl3fAtY7-Z_ZE933myHJimb30D).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>33</s>  32 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“<td>A”ẋ”h3¦s5ẋ€ṭ€“<tr>”ṭ“¢ssɱU»
```

A full program taking `rows`, `columns` which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxybkhQ7x0cNcx/u6gaSGcaHlhWbgthNax7uXAskwUqK7EAqgPyGOYcWFRef3Bh6aPf///@N/hsDAA)**

---

hmm, also 32 using a table:

```
Ịị⁾hdṭ”t⁾<>j;ðþZṭ€“<tr>”ṭ“¢ssɱU»
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <strike>45</strike> 63 bytes

#### Working solution:

```
(m,n){print('<table><tr>'+'<th>A'*n+('<tr>'+'<td>A'*n)*(m-1));}
```

[Try it online here!](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d4dc45371d8929ecd1cdbe671bb03ced)

Lambda/anonymous function taking `m` and `n` as parameters, displays output to `STDOUT`.

Since tables with unclosed `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, and `<td>` tags still render in modern browsers (ex., Chrome), the output is valid.

#### Old (broken) solution:

My first attempt forgot to switch to `<td>` after the first row:

```
(m,n){print('<table><tr>'+'<th>A'*n+('<tr>'+'<th>A'*n)*(m-1));}
```

Thanks to @Lynn for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 40 bytes

```
J"<tr>"AQ"<table>"J*H"<th>A"*tGJ*H"<td>A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30vJpqTITskxEEgnJuWk2il5aXkA2Rl2jkpaJe4QToqd4///RjrGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 66 bytes

```
="<table><tr>"&Rept("<th>A",B1)&Rept("<tr>"&Rept("<td>A",B1),A1-1)
```

Input is in cell `A1` and `B1`.
There's nothing fancy, really; it's just nested `Rept` functions.
It *does* assume `m > n > 0` and that they're both integers.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 64 bytes

Another port of the Python answer:

```
4 :0
'<table><tr>',(;y#<'<th>A'),;(<:x)#<('<tr>',(;y#<'<td>A'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 161 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XYzdCsIgGIZvZXx4oGBrOs@0YtcREWspBs2JfR1F1266k2AnD@8fb/Qxm1MsdO8w4WMJjaNk5iSwD8HDGXC8Pe0ROKBfeV@ZKs0eLtpOfmlemDBRMJ3poS3mmmy0I5ZEDEpAfWtBbbutl4OS/y0n805U2RWJTH@zo5L3TOcf)

**Code**

```
function f($m,$n){$t=["table>","th>","td>","tr>","</"];echo strtr("
<0<3".str_repeat("<1A41",$n)."43".str_repeat("<3".str_repeat("
<2A42",$n)."43",$m-1)."40",$t);}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($m,$n){
  $t=["table>","th>","td>","tr>","</"];           //array representing the tags its created
  echo strtr("<0<3".str_repeat("<1A41",$n)."43"   //strtr it's called and uses 
                                                  //the array to replace values
           .str_repeat("<3".                      //repeat the tags
                         str_repeat("<2A42",$n)   //repeat the tags again
                            ."43",$m-1)."40",$t); 
   //its repeated m-1 times because head is counted as one row
  }
```

### PHP, 193 Bytes

Full table structure <strike>forgot `<tfooter>`</strike> `<thead>, <tbody>..etc..`

[Try example of the function](https://tio.run/##XY3LCsIwEEV/pQxdNBD7SEo3HSt@h4ikbUoF24Q4LkT89hojuMjmcs@ZC2Nnu@HB@pwe60BXsyZTli48Xdkrpf0JSPU33QEHmrUaQ@nN@PyZkJF0HZxbPcwmuZMjlwGWWEHu4eK01Yq8kUcsJHyf5IBFhSK6NxHXfl//941vy64KXWBReiTWvrcpE1yydvsA)

```
function f($m,$n)   {$t=["table>","thead>","tbody>","th>","td>","tbody>","tr>"];
echo strtr(
      "<0<1".str_repeat("<3A</3",$n).
      "</1<2".str_repeat(
                  "<6".str_repeat("<4A</4",$n)
                       ."</6",$m-1)."</2</0",
  $t);
  }
```

**Explanation**

`$t=["table>","thead>","tbody>","th>","td>","tbody>","tr>"];`

An array with all the tags for the table it's builded and then with `str_repeat` a number refering to an index in the array is written, **then** to `strtr` the string plus the array is passed

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 124 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input from as space delimited integers and outputs to the console.

```vb
?"<table>"
input""i,j
For c=1To i
?"<tr>"
For r=1To j
If c=1?"<th>H</th>"
If c>1?"<td>D</td>"
Next
?"</tr>"
Next
?"</table>"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/317JpiQxKSfVTokrM6@gtERJKVMni8stv0gh2dYwJF8hkwukoggoDRIrAotlcXmmgaRBMhl2Hjb6QFIJLGYHFkuxcwGKpQDF/FIrSkAG6INNQPAgNv7/b6Rg/B8A)

Comment: This doesn't produce the <td> tags.

Comment: @potato - ahh, I hadn't seen that. It's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 86 bytes

```forth
: f ." <table>" 0 do ." <tr>" dup 0 do j if ." <td>A" else ." <th>A" then loop loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCoAwDAS/svSuiN5UCj5FaWOVYkqt74@WeNlhhiXOJTQ7VYiMILQGc1m36K1BB8ca8mfuSVpOHP/P2cXAx9urhqol@AuROelMkAE9SF4)

#### Explanation

```forth
." <table>"         \ output <table>
0 do                \ start loop from 0 to m-1
   ." <tr>"         \ output <tr>
   dup 0 do         \ duplicate n and loop from 0 to n-1
      j if          \ if the outer loop index is true (not 0)
         ." <td>A"  \ output <td>A
      else          \ if outer loop index is false (0)
         ." <th>A"  \ output <th>A
      then          \ end if-else
   loop             \ end inner loop
loop                \ end outer loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 51 bytes

```
{"<table>",/"<tr>",//:y#'(,,"<th>A"),1_x#,,"<td>A"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlrJpiQxKSfVTklHH8gsAtH6VpXK6ho6OkB@hp2jkqaOYXyFMpibAuTW/g@xqlaJrqwrskpT0FOosE7Iz7bWSEhLzMyxrrCutC7SjK3lCok2VjCyhpkNMhdsFpQA8VJAjBR0nlLsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>34</s> 33 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Æ"<tr>"+"<t{XÎgdih}>A"pVÃu`<ta½e>
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=xiI8dHI%2bIisiPHR7WM5nZGlofT5BInBWw3VgPHRhvWU%2b&input=NCAz)

-1 thanks to a clever trick by Shaggy

```
Æ             # the range [0, #cols) with each X mapped to:
  "<tr>"+     #   "<tr>" prepended to
  "<t{        #     "<t" prepended to
    XÎgdih    #       index into "dh" with the sign of X
  }>A"        #     append ">A"
  pV          #     repeated #rows times
Ã             # end map over range
u`<ta½e>      # prepend the compressed string "<table>
```

Comment: You can save a byte with `XÎgdih`.