# Alpha-Numerical Bowtie

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Output this exact text:

```
1                i
12              hi
123            ghi
1234          fghi
12345        efghi
123456      defghi
1234567    cdefghi
12345678  bcdefghi
123456789abcdefghi
12345678  bcdefghi
1234567    cdefghi
123456      defghi
12345        efghi
1234          fghi
123            ghi
12              hi
1                i
```

A single trailing newline is acceptable, but no other formatting changes are allowed.

#### Rules and I/O

- No input
- Output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we use the uppercase alphabet instead?

Comment: @Cowsquack That would be a rule change. It says *Output this exact text*.

Comment: @Cowsquack Nope - lowercase is required.

Answer (score 13):

## C, <s>87</s> <s>85</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```c
j;main(i){for(;++i<19;)for(j=19;j--;)putchar(j?j<i^j<20-i?32:106-j-j/10*39:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchbCoAgEEDR7Wgy5AMCG8OdBCJUM9CDqK9o7WZ/99wMc86lMK6JNkHymfZToFIUjEf5g4daDIDyuK@8pHoiBxo5WA0Une2N7oCBW6Mb56skvqV8)

#### Explanation

```c
j; // same as int j;
main(i){ // same as int main(int i){, where i = argc (1 with no arguments)
  for(;++i<19;) // loop over rows, i = 2..18
    for(j=19;j--;) // loop over chars, j = 19..0
      putchar(j?j<i^j<20-i?32:106-j-j/10*39:10); // output characters:
      //      j?                           :10 // on last char (j=0), output \n
      //        j<i                            // check for top/left half
      //            j<20-i                     // check for bottom/left half
      //           ^                           // 1 if only one half matched
      //                  ?32:                 // if so, output space
      //                      106              // char code for j
      //                         -j            // get desired letter
      //                           -j/10*39    // subtract 39 for j>9 (numbers)
}
```

Comment: I'm amazed `^` has lower precedence than `<`… what a pretty answer!

Comment: @Lynn The bitwise operators in C (and even Java/JS and such) all have a lower precedence than comparisons. This is both nice for code golf and a really nice source of errors (think `if (x & 2 == 0)`, which always evaluates to `0`)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
i=9
exec"i-=1;a=abs(i);print'123456789'[:9-a]+'  '*a+'abcdefghi'[a:];"*17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWkiu1IjVZKVPX1tA60TYxqVgjU9O6oCgzr0Td0MjYxNTM3MJSPdrKUjcxVltdQUFdK1FbPTEpOSU1LT0jUz060SrWWknL0Pz/fwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 15 bytes

```
A9£Sāì9LÂì×ζRû»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f8wNWFiMWX//0E5wqNTxIHDrDlMw4LDrMOXzrZSw7vCu///)

-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//zlMwqlBOcKjU8Krwq7DgsOsw5fOtlLDu8K7//8) by changing `žh¦A9£«S9L` to `9L©A9£S«®` (or `9LA9£S«9L` or `9LDA9£S«s`).

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f8wNWFiMWX//0E5wqNTxIHDrDlMw4LDrMOXzrZSw7vCu///) by changing it to `A9£Sāì9L` instead.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
for(i in abs(8:-8))cat(intToUtf8(c(57-8:i,32*!!-i:i,97+i:8,13)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPITGpWMPCStdCUzM5sUQjM68kJD@0JM1CI1nD1FzXwipTx9hIS1FRNxPIsjTXzrSy0DE01tTU/P8fAA)

- -3 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe
- -5 bytes thanks to @J.Doe

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPITGpWMPCStdCU7O8KLMkVSMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPUXNfCKlOnKLVAw9hIx0grU1PH0lw70wqoWMdQ8/9/AA "R – Try It Online") with `intToUtf8`

Comment: [`cat`](https://tio.run/##BcHBDYAgDADAVXi2Wh5CDJU5dAAkkvQDprJ/vVOzNhTESXfl/oCzZ8RaJkif57hmY6iwJ89ZSJ8XYqCwCNKRVslMW0REsx8) for one byte?

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPITGpWMPCStdCUzM5sUQjM68kJD@0JM1CI1nD1FzXwipTx9hIS1FRNxPIsjTXzrSy0DE01tTU/P8fAA "R – Try It Online") building on your solution, using @Giuseppe's shortcut to `rep` plus the feature of `intToUtf8` that a `0` turns into a `""`.

Comment: @J.Doe great trick!

Comment: @J.Doe : Awesome, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
j=i=1
exec"print'123456789'[:i]+'  '*(9-i)+'abcdefghi'[-i:];i+=j;j-=2*(i>8);"*17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8s209aQK7UiNVmpoCgzr0Td0MjYxNTM3MJSPdoqM1ZbXUFBXUvDUjdTU1s9MSk5JTUtPSNTPVo30yrWOlPbNss6S9fWSEsj085C01pJy9D8/38A)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCu1IjVZKck2MalYw0I3U9O6oCgzr0Td0MjYxNTM3MJSPdrKUjcpVjtJS11BQV1bPTEpOSU1LT0jUz06SdfSKtY6U9vW0FpJy9D8/38A)

Comment: @ovs it would converge into Lynn's answer, so I'll leave this one as is

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 72 bytes

Based on [Taylor Scott's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167477/16766).

```
FOR y=-8TO 8
z=ABS(y)
?"123456789abcdefghi";
LOCATE,10-z
?SPC(2*z)"
NEXT
```

#### Basic explanation

On each line, we print the full string `123456789abcdefghi`. Then we *go back* and overwrite part of it with spaces.

#### Full explanation

With code slightly ungolfed:

```
FOR y = -8 TO 8           ' Loop for 17 rows
 z = ABS(y)               ' z runs from 8 to 0 and back to 8
 ? "123456789abcdefghi";  ' Print the full string and stay on the same line (important!)
 LOCATE , 10-z            ' Go back to column 10-z on that line
 ? SPC(2*z); ""           ' Print 2*z spaces
                          ' (SPC keeps the cursor on the same line unlesss you print
                          ' something after it, so we'll use the empty string)
NEXT                      ' Go to the next y value
```

Comment: That's a really clever use of  the `Locate` command

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>24</s> 19 bytes

Returns an array of lines

```
9õ Ôê1 Ëç°TsH)êÃû y
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=OfUg1OoxIMvnsFRzSCnqw/sgeQ&input=LVI)

```
9õ Ôê1 Ëç°TsH)êÃû y
9õ                      :Range [1,9]
   Ô                    :Reverse
    ê1                  :Mirror
       Ë                :Map
        ç               :  Repeat
         °T             :    Prefix increment T (initially 0)
           s            :    Convert to base
            H           :    32
             )          :  End repeat
              ê         :  Palindromise
               Ã        :End map
                û       :Centre pad each with spaces to the length of the longest
                  y     :Transpose
```

([It did indeed, 4 year ago Shaggy, it did indeed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167405/alpha-numerical-bowtie/254376#comment404603_167407)!)

Comment: I'm wondering now if building this horizontally might not have led to a shorter solution! :\

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 108 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=8a:
PRINT STUFF('123456789abcdefghi',10-abs(@),2*abs(@),SPACE(2*abs(@)))
SET @-=1IF @>-9GOTO a
```

Returns are for readability only.

Tried lots of other variations, including number tables, this was the shortest.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
9LJη.BA9£.sí.Bí)øJû»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v8wNWFiMWX//zlMSs63LkJBOcKjLnPDrS5Cw60pw7hKw7vCu///)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
９Ｒ［］ｚ９ｍ±［］±＋─
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE5JXVGRjMyJXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXVGRjVBJXVGRjE5JXVGRjREJUIxJXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJUIxJXVGRjBCJXUyNTAw,v=3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 bytes

```
9Æ9Ç>YÃê1 Ë?S:°EsH
ê
```

[Japt Interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=OcY5xz5Zw+oxIMs/UzqwRXNICuo=&input=LVI=)

Output as an array of arrays of characters. The `-R` flag isn't necessary to work, it just makes the output look nicer.

Explanation:

```
9Æ9Ç                    create a 9x9 2D array 
    >YÃ                 fill bottom left triangle with "false", upper right with "true"
       ê1               mirror horizontally
          Ë?S           replaces "true" with a space
             :°EsH      replaces "false" with the horizontal index + 1 converted to base 32
                  \n    Store the result in U (saves bytes by not closing braces)
                    ê   palindromize vertically
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell 5.1, <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 57 Bytes

<sup>Thanks Mazzy for -7 bytes</sup>

```
1..9+8..1|%{-join(1..$_+'  '*(9-$_)+' ihgfedcba'[$_..1])}
```

Turns out gluing it together manually saves a byte. Making it all one mega-join also saves 5 more. <s>Also works by turning a range of ints into a char[] to get the a-i.</s> Using a range over the actual letters is 5 bytes better.

Comment: try this: `1..9+8..1|%{-join(1..$_+'  '*(9-$_)+' ihgfedcba'[$_..1])}`. Note `'  '*(9-$_)` contains 2 space symbols

Comment: @mazzy ooof, missing that double space trick. I was thinking of a variety of math statements but the obvious solution never occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 73 bytes

```julia
[1:9;8:-1:1].|>i->println(join(1:9)[1:i]*" "^(18-2i)*"abcdefghi"[10-i:9])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9rQytLawkrX0MowVq/GLlPXrqAoM68kJ08jKz8zTwMoqwlUkhmrpaSgFKdhaKFrlKmppZSYlJySmpaekakUbWigm2llGav5/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 47 bytes

```
9l$lRtH2$PhO18Y"yPvv1=49:57 97:105h19T3$X"32b(c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zJHJSeoxMNIJSDD39AiUqkyoKzM0NbE0srUXMHS3MrQwDTD0DLEWCVCydgoSSP5/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
9ʀṘǔmkrf*ꜝøṗ↵§
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI5yoDhuZjHlG1rcmYq6pydw7jhuZfihrXCpyIsIiIsIiJd)

**Explanation**

A transposition approach.

```
9ʀ             # range from 0 to 9 inclusive
  Ṙ            #  reversed
   ǔ           #  rotated right (last item goes to first)
    m          #  and concatenated with its reverse
     kr        # string of digits, lowercase alphabet, and uppercase alphabet
       f       #  into a list of characters
        *      # repeat (vectorises)
         ꜝ     # remove empty strings in the list
          øṗ   # palindromise each item, center, and join by newlines
            ↵  # split on newlines
             § # vertically join
```

Comment: wow, that's much better than what I had (17-18 bytes)! Very cool answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â4+╤jo♂▐▀3bkWíæß╝╖
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83342bd16a6f0bdedf33626b57a191e1bcb7&i=&a=1)

Explanation:

```
9R$|[|<Va17T|]r|>\|pm Full program
9R$                   Produce "123456789"
   |[|<               Left-aligned prefixes (["1        ", "12       ", ...])
       Va17T          Produce "abcdefghi"
            |]        Suffixes (["abcdefghi", "bcdefghi", ...])
              r|>     Reverse and left-align (["        i", "       hi", ...])
                 \    Zip both arrays (["1                i", "12              hi", ...])
                  |p  Palindromize array
                    m Map over array, printing each with a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
Ｇ↗↓←⁹β←Ｇ↖↓⁹⭆χι‖Ｏ↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9Pwyq0ICgzPaNER8HKJb88D0j5pKYBeZY6Ckma1ly@@WWpGmAhIAdJD0QRVAtQbXBJUWZeum9igYahgY5CpiZQdVBqWk5qcol/WWpRDlAcrFbT@v///7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｇ↗↓←⁹β
```

Draw a lower right triangle and fill it using the lowercase alphabet. (The fill is based on tiling the plane with the alphabet and then copying the drawn area.)

```
←
```

Move left to draw the numeric triangle.

```
Ｇ↖↓⁹⭆χι
```

Draw a lower left triangle and fill it using the digits. (Since the triangle is drawn to the left of the origin, the digits are taken right-justified, so only the digits 1 to 9 get used.)

```
‖Ｏ↓
```

Reflect to complete the bottom half.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

```javascript
f=(x=y=0)=>y<17?(x>y^x++<17-y?x.toString(36)+[`
`[x%=18]]:' ')+f(x||!++y):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajwrbS1kDT1q7SxtDcXqPCrjKuQlsbyNattK/QK8kPLinKzEvXMDbT1I5O4EqIrlC1NbSIjbVSV1DX1E7TqKipUdTWrtS0Ulf/n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaahqfkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 bytes

```apl
(⊢⍪1↓⊖)(↑,\1↓⎕d),⌽↑,\⌽819⌶9↑⎕a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9/b/Go65Fj3pXGT5qm/yoa5qmxqO2iToxYF7f1BRNnUc9e8EiQNrC0PJRzzZLIBcolQjS/T8dAA)

`↑` convert to a matrix (auto pads with spaces)

- `,\` the prefixes of
- `1↓` the first element dropped from
- `⎕d` this string `'0123456789'`
- This gives the character matrix

```
1        
12       
123      
1234     
12345    
123456   
1234567  
12345678 
123456789
```

`,` concatenated with

- `⌽` the reversed
- `↑` matrixified
- `,\` prefixes of
- `⌽` the reversed
- `819⌶` and lowercased
- `9↑` first 9 elements of
- `⎕a` this string `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`
- This gives the character matrix

```
        i
       hi
      ghi
     fghi
    efghi
   defghi
  cdefghi
 bcdefghi
abcdefghi
```

and on this result

```
1                i
12              hi
123            ghi
1234          fghi
12345        efghi
123456      defghi
1234567    cdefghi
12345678  bcdefghi
123456789abcdefghi
```

perform the following train `(⊢⍪1↓⊖)`

`⊢` the right argument

`⍪` concatenated vertically with

`1↓` the first row dropped from (this avoids the repeating of the middle row)

`⊖` the right argument reversed vertically

---

Other solutions

#### 33 bytes

```apl
(⊢⍪1↓⊖)(↑,\⍕¨q),⌽↑,\⎕ucs 106-q←⍳9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9/b/Go65Fj3pXGT5qm/yoa5qmxqO2iToxj3qnHlpRqKnzqGcvhN83tTS5WMHQwEy38FHbhEe9my1Buv@nAwA)

#### 33 bytes

```apl
(⊢⍪1↓⊖)(↑,\⍕¨q),⌽↑,\⌽⎕ucs 96+q←⍳9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9/b/Go65Fj3pXGT5qm/yoa5qmxqO2iToxj3qnHlpRqKnzqGcvhA@k@6aWJhcrWJppFz5qm/Cod7MlSP//dAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>25</s>, 21 bytes

```
¬19¬ai8ñHÄ/á
r ge.YGp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9AaQ8tDaxIzLQ5v9Djcon94IVeRQnqqXqR7wf//AA)

2-4 bytes saved thanks to nmjcman101!

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac31 39ac 6169 38f1 48c4 2fe1 0a72 2067  .19.ai8.H./..r g
00000010: 652e 5947 70                             e.YGp
```

Comment: I know all I'm doing is stalking your answers today but I think this works for 23: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9AaQ8tDaxIzLQ5v9Djcon94iZZ@KleRQrlepHvB//8A "V – Try It Online")

Comment: @nmjcman101 For whatever reason, I can't comprehend how that version works. But I figured out an even shorter one, so thanks!

Comment: It went to the end of a `/\d*` search

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 44 bytes

```
(m]\u:49+i.9),.(m=.,}.@|.)]\&.(|."1)u:97+i.9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I18jNzam1MrEUjtTz1JTR08j11ZPp1bPoUZPMzZGTU@jRk/JULPUytIcJP//PwA)

I tried to generate numerically a mask of 1 and zero to use for indexing, but the cost of getting rid of the extra row was high and I gave up:

```
   (9-.~i.18){0<:-/~(,|.)i.9
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.010`, 49 bytes

```perl
say 1..9-abs,"  "x abs,(a..i)[-9+abs..-1]for-8..8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLBUE/PUjcxqVhHSUFBqUIBxNJI1NPL1IzWtdQG8vT0dA1j0/KLdC309Cz@//@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack), 87 bytes

An anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For y=-8To 8:z=Abs(y):a$="123456789abcdefghi":?Mid$(a$,1,9-z)Spc(2*z)Mid$(a$,10+z):Next
```

This answer is technically a polyglot, and will function in VBA

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <strike>314</strike> 308 bytes

```
<p0+3*67p0+4*77p0+3*77p0-7*88p0-6*88"#v#v>"
"i        "11g1-21p56+1g1+56+1p28*1g1+28*1p  ^       >25*
"        1"92g1+82p56+2g1-56+2p28*2g1-28*2p91g00g`#v_^   >
"ihgfedcba "93p26*3g1-26*3p">^"88*7-0p88*7-4pv     >25*
"987654321 "14p26*4g1+26*4p26*4g12g`#v_            ^
                             >:#,_@#:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BDoIwEETvfEWzvRWb0FLaQkjjl4CiWL2Yvcjv4y7BhJNzedNkprPT/Pi887yuPVZlrXwgOBXC9mLooGIkeALIRS4JCniJXWBMNtoabHxJrmSgjYo9A4UY9miyjSrgVzTQWspEy01ymsFN9gxsTa6qfJHLyD8kGn3mx3y/TVcBbY3Wq5qjBIQ0QIwq6Ao3OFwOk20MvnG1NXSt457j4wi7t9uIOGgoxD@lTp7Gs@z6df0C)

Golfed 6 bytes by placing a `>` with the `p` instruction

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 122 bytes

```
function[r]=f,s=[49:57,'a':'i'];r=[];for i=1:9,r=[r;s(1:i),repmat(' ',[1,18-2*i]),s(19-i:18)];end,r=[r;flip(r(1:8,:))];end
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCsMgEEDRq2SnlsnC0lId8STiQlKFgVbDxPT6Vsjy8/ht6@mXxyhn3Tq1Gjj6AocPD4vPF4gkUJCIjn2IrjReyGu0MJPdITWSAs77N3UpFgFBgzbr/UZRwVS7Emqjosv1fS3lQ7vk@RlAdcEoUo0/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 956 bytes

```
{iiiii}dc{dd}iii{c}cccccc{{i}ddd}iiic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcic{dd}ii{c}cccc{{i}ddd}iicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicic{dd}i{c}cc{{i}ddd}icicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicic{dd}{c}{{i}ddd}cicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicic{dd}dcccccccc{{i}ddd}dcicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicic{dd}ddcccccc{{i}ddd}ddcicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicic{dd}dddcccc{{i}ddd}dddcicicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicicic{dd}ddddcc{iiiiii}iiiiiicicicicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicicicic{iiii}cicicicicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicicic{dd}ddddcc{iiiiii}iiiiiicicicicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicic{dd}dddcccc{{i}ddd}dddcicicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicic{dd}ddcccccc{{i}ddd}ddcicicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicic{dd}dcccccccc{{i}ddd}dcicicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicicic{dd}{c}{{i}ddd}cicicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcicic{dd}i{c}cc{{i}ddd}icicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dcic{dd}ii{c}cccc{{i}ddd}iicic{{d}i}dddddc{iiii}dc{dd}iii{c}cccccc{{i}ddd}iiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZNBDoQgDEVPNIcy/zuZrmfZcHam2uoIiRBUNkB970elcJ74lu/nlbPKMhKhZLKVImEdqlb1mq1tXnY0LngJI4Q/jjM@jFXYcbR4N0zYcPR4NwiUH3F43FBDZuUWQFPfAlj6FdKJ2EMsxU9Hkk811g2SqGNcfegdbv@PWydyuRfG2m6srceuTeta5vwD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 119 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
main=putStr$do i<-[-8..8];[chr$if abs j>abs i then j+96-fromEnum(j<0)*38else 32|j<-[-9..9],j/=0]++"\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw9DsIgGADQ3VN8aTqoCDY2MRBbF/UEjpUBKw0gPw3QzbtjurzxKZG@0tpStJtDzHAXWZCbEnHjhPb9vORnjvUngO7wgCkhlF@GUcVaTyDeCcx1VUNW0oNB7IynGNzDL25ruma3b6m0SUJ7@pk1YIQwfjDHvuEIVS9flfIH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 54 bytes

```julia
[8:-1:1;0:8].|>i->print.([1:9-i;" "^2i;'a'+i:'i';"
"])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9rCStfQytDawMoiVq/GLlPXrqAoM69ETyPa0MpSN9NaSUEpzijTWj1RXTvTSj1T3VqJSylW8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
a=Table[" ",17,18];Do[a[[i;;-i,i]]=a[[1-i;;i-1,i]]=i~IntegerString~35,{i,18}];a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1iamVoSzcVVUJSfbqvxP9E2JDEpJzVaSUFJx9Bcx9Ai1tolPzoxOjrT2lo3UyczNtYWyDHUBXIzdQ3B/Mw6z7yS1PTUouCSosy89DpjU53qTKDO2ljrxP@a1lxcAUDhEgcHB5AVXFyx/wE)

Throws a lot of ignorable errors.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 75 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For y=-8To 8:z=Abs(y):a="123456789abcdefghi":Mid(a,10-z)=Space(2*z):?a:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
9R€z⁶Zµạ106Ọ$Ṡ¡€Uṭ)ŒḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//OVLigqx64oG2WsK14bqhMTA24buMJOG5oMKh4oKsVeG5rSnFkuG4hP/Dh1n/)

Relies on the (likely) unintended behavior that when `Ṡ` (sign) acts on a character it yields Python's `None`. Because of this, `Ṡ` is a one byte check for whether it's argument is a nonzero integer since `None` is falsey in Python. If this behavior is changed then `OƑ` works as well for one more byte.

Function that returns a list of lines.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>107</s> 102 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=1,j;++i<19;)for(j=19;j-->0;)System.out.printf("%c",j>0?j<i^j<20-i?32:106-j-j/10*39:10);}
```

Port of [*@Pietu1998*'s C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167414/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-5 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU/RCsIwDHz3K4IgtGpnpyBot/kF@iL4Igq1btI4O9m6gci@fWYqJCQXcrkL6kYLvN47k@uqgq227j0AsM6nZaZNCrseAjSFvYJhh740XNGspaSovPbWwA4cxNA1InlnRcmIDzYOp6gmExuFK8X7KcbUoRCJVHz/qnz6CIraB8@S1jM2HJnhFBO5wcieMZpLYTeL@TqUS4ECZ6EcL1aEuGo79dN@1pectP8WvhYf9ADbe7p4O540/5l3gWGuznOuvrR20HYf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>97</s> 94 bytes

```python
i=o="123456789abcdefghi";c=8
while c:i=i[:c]+' '*(9-c)*2+i[-c:];o=i+'\n'+o+'\n'+i;c-=1
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M231bJ0MjYxNTM3MIyMSk5JTUtPSNTyTrZ1oKrPCMzJ1Uh2SrTNjPaKjlWW11BXUvDUjdZU8tIOzNaN9kq1jrfNlNbPSZPXTsfQmVaJ@vaGnIVFGXmlSjk//8PAA)

Only posted as an alternative to using `eval()` and because I finally got it under 100. Basically starts with the middle row then works both up and down at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 103 bytes

```vb
a$="123456789abcdefghi"
For y=-8To 8
z=Abs(y)
?Mid$(a$,1,9-z);
For i=1To z?"  ";Next
?Mid$(a$,10+z)Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/P1HFVsnQyNjE1MzcwjIxKTklNS09I1OJyy2/SKHSVtciJF/BgqvK1jGpWKNSk8veNzNFRSNRRcdQx1K3StMarCzT1hCoqspeSUFBydovtaIESZmBdpUmSOj/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>143</del> <del>142</del> <del>127+10=137</del> <del>136+10=146</del> 113+10=123 (compiler flags) bytes

-1 byte by replacing logical OR with bitwise operator.

-5 bytes thanks to Logern.

+9 bytes to fix the median line, that was output twice.

-23 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
char*s="123456789abcdefghi";G{for(;j<18;++j)putchar(i>j|j>17-i?s[j]:32);puts("");}f(){int i=0,j=0;for(;i++<8;)G;g(i+1,j);for(;i-->1;)G;}
```

Compiler flag:

```c
-DG=g(i,j)
```

This macro factorizes the occurences of `g(i,j)`: function declaration and calls.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1LDoIwFADXcooGN22gBvAD@gA3JhzCuMBCy2sQDB83yNWthOUkkxnBlRBmi42ox6IkcT8U2O6q1GSTbDsKOvYjcBzN3uMgqryjmOqvTv2Q49X2g/3heAqjc/4URSlVhfZdPy77gMGi99S2GcySoqvZWsNEJx6g48QRsAzWAQLnuMBssBnIK8eGflosGJmsjaSeSzwG1myZn5B1rnrDb1mi1uQf)

Different approach than [Pietu1998's great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167414/56453), more straightforward (and readable), but higher score.

Entry point is function `f()`; function `g()` handles the printing of each consecutive line.

Could be made a full program by renaming `f` to `main`, but it would yet increase the score.

Pretty version, macro `G` expanded:

```c
g(i, j) {
    for(; j < 18;++j)
        putchar(i > j | j > 17 - i ? "123456789abcdefghi"[j] : 32);
    puts(""); // Break the line; shorter than putchar(10) or printf("\n")
}
f(i, j) {
    for (i = j = 0; i++ < 8;) // Upper half of the tie
        g(i, j);
    for(; i; --i) // Median line and lower half
        g(i, j);
}
```

Comment: [137 bytes - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNDoIwGAXXcgpSN61QQ0UFLODGU2BcYPn7GgRDwQ1ydSsYl5M38wQthdBraEQ9ZLkZqj6DdlvFWlRpt1ERYjt3fzh6fpDeRZYXZQWIJ2PRdpjLkPncsiR5Dv2iY4jlW8bMo3BWV3k7uTvC501hhAifCkxGaHoTIseWkcN/H2BZYcBJ8idKY7bQpBfzkUKDXy1kxByN1dxzYzL0RxR1WipNL0lUYrAl@QI "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: 137 but +10 for the compiler flags though

Comment: 137 is the total, 127 bytes of code and 10 bytes of compiler flags.

Comment: Oops sorry, my bad. Updating now!

Comment: @Logern I took the liberty to rename the macro to `G`, to match the function name.

Comment: Thanks, really interesting improvement! It's nice to see that old stuff is still active. Included with an extra couple bytes shaved off.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>110</s> 105 bytes

```pascal
var i:int32;begin for i:=-8to 8do writeln('123456789'[1..9-abs(i)],'abcdefghi'[abs(i)+1..9]:abs(i)+9)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnNDkQwFEDhV@muZLQJZmiJJxGL2z9uIq3Q8PgVMcvznQ0ODStzm07phJ1ghz7WVa/sjJ648MjARAxEmECuHaNdfUbLqv7@mlZIOpacSwbqyDCfCgpKG@vmBen42uf5U/cPmVtveEo3)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 116 bytes

```
for(;++$i<18;)echo substr($s='123456789abcdefghi',0,$j=~-10-($k=abs(9-$i))).str_repeat(' ',$k*2).substr($s,-$j)."
";
```

Output

```
1                i
12              hi
123            ghi
1234          fghi
12345        efghi
123456      defghi
1234567    cdefghi
12345678  bcdefghi
123456789abcdefghi
12345678  bcdefghi
1234567    cdefghi
123456      defghi
12345        efghi
1234          fghi
123            ghi
12              hi
1                i
```

[Sanbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3fe5bbc2d78e43c73c93ab4da2b39edbc6f1837e)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 103 bytes

```lua
for i=-8,8 do m=math.abs(i)print(("123456789"):sub(1,9-m)..(" "):rep(2*m)..("abcdefghi"):sub(m+1,9))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpLCoAgFEDRrYij9yqF/hq0GE0rISss129BDe/lbFGlNB@BuJGJQhBzED96da9c6QscnsHtNwAtq7ppu15IisMVNZSFZB45B0reE@wJVfa10pOx87K6X/r8tYh2Nyk9)

Answer (score 0):

## Raku, 81 bytes

```
for -8..8 {my \a=(.abs-9).abs;say (1..a).join~' 'x.abs*2~'abcdefghi'.substr(*-a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gfuccj6bof)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>163</s> 148 bytes

```
/w/lm//q/  //j/qqq//k/fghi
1234//l/qqq//m/q//n/dek567//o/i
12/1lwmolwho3llgho34wmk5wek56lnmmcn8mbcn89abcn8mbcnmmcdek56ldek5wekwmfgho3llgholwhi
1lwmi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLDsIwDET3nKI3GJV@gOO00CYl40RRFj5@cIBuRtbM8ytcit9KrVBQgIyuA97IOQMBu/PHpb8OI8BfJ4Yg4rWFab4BCW1HT5VE9WkgneWoEiZtDKPIM95ltXgs6/@07mtgS@NUdnc@m8acJjxq/QA)