# Supreme Sum String

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode, text-processing

## Supreme Sum String

Given an input string, return the word with the highest sum of each of its unicode characters.

### Rules

- The input should be seperated by whitespace
- The value of each word is based on the sum of each character in the word's UTF-16 code
- The output should be the first word with the highest value (in case of duplicate sums)

### Examples

```
Input: "a b c d e"
Output: "e"

Input: "hello world"
Output: "world"

Input: "this is a test"
Output: "test"

Input: "àà as a test"
Output: "àà"

Input "α ää"
Output: "α"

Input: " 隣隣隣"
Output: "隣隣隣"

Input: "    ️  "
Output: "️"
```

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins! Good luck :)

Comment: Will there always be at least one space (at least 2 words)?

Comment: If there's only one word just output the single word, since it's the max

Comment: This would have been more interesting with ASCII instead of Unicode, because more languages could have participated. Requiring Unicode support doesn't seem to add anything to the challenge

Comment: I mostly used Unicode because it has emojis lol

Comment: Since many of the current answers seem to use the sum of UTF-8 or UTF-32 code units, you should add some additional test cases. For example "α ää" yields different results with UTF-8 (383 < 718) and UTF-16 (945 > 456).

Comment: " 隣隣隣" could be used to weed out answers that simply add codepoints (UTF-32). Also, do you really mean to sum UTF-16 code units (16-bit numbers) or something else?

Comment: I mean the number given by Javascript's `charCodeAt` function, which is a UTF-16 code according to the documentation. That's what I used when I was testing how feasible the challenge was. I'll add the other test cases though!

Comment: When you say separated by whitespace... is input separated by newline allowed?

Comment: Yeah, newlines area allowed. Tabs too!

Comment: Can we take input as an array/list of words?

Comment: It cannot be an array, it has to be a string of words with any whitespace characters in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
←→kΣw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhEdtk7LPLS7/////h/m9axTeL98IQQA)

First time using `key-by`. Pretty fitting here.

### Explanation

```
←→kΣw
      w split into words
    k   key on
     Σ  sum of codepoints
 →     take the last(maximum) key
←      return the first in the group
```

Comment: Usurping a 2 year old winner, great work! I know it's short, but would you mind providing a breakdown of what each character does?

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 34 bytes

```
*.words.max(*.encode('utf16').sum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS688vyilWC83sUJDSy81Lzk/JVVDvbQkzdBMXVOvuDRX87@1QnFipYKSSryCrZ1CdZqCSnytkkJafpGCUqJCkkKyQopCqpKOglJGak5OvgLQtJwUELckI7NYAYgSFUpSi0tAIocXHF6gkIgs8mH@pAaFD/Mn7gYSSxYCiWXtQGLq9vc7@oF07xog0des9B8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ð¡RΣÇO}θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/8IZDC4POLT7c7l97bsd/nf@JCkkKyQopCqlcGak5OfkK5flFOSlcJRmZxQpAlKhQklpcwnV4weEFColw7of5kxoUPsyfuBtILFkIJJa1A4mp29/v6AfSvWuARF8zAA)

**Explanation**

```
ð¡          # split input on spaces
  R         # reverse the resulting list
   Σ  }     # sort by
    ÇO      # sum of character codes
       θ    # take the last
```

Comment: Wow, I'm always amazed by the answers made in dedicated golfing languages!

Comment: Why do you need to reverse the resulting list? It's gonna get sorted anyways right? Or does the `R` actually reverse the list after it's sorted?

Comment: @FireCubez For test case `àà as a test` the `àà` and `test` have the same largest unicode sum. So without the reverse `test` would be output instead of `àà`. Btw, Emigna, use `#` to save a byte. ;) EDIT: Never mind. I see it doesn't wrap the input in a list for single word inputs.. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>77 69 59 58 56</s> 44 bytes

A group effort now.

```r
'^'=mapply
sort(-sum^utf8ToInt^scan(,""))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Xz1O3TY3saAgp5KrOL@oREO3uDQ3rrQkzSIk3zOvJK44OTFPQ0dJSVMz2jD2/@EFhxdwJRZzJXKVpBaX/AcA)

Convert to code points, sum each word, negate, (stably) sort, return first element.

Technically the return value is a "named vector" whose value is the sum and name is the winning word, but this seems to follow the rules. If you want to return the winning word as a string, you'd have to spend 7 more bytes and wrap the above in `names()`.

Comment: Is there a reason there's spaces in front of the word? When I run it on`"    ️  "` it prints out `"     ️ "` (with a bunch of spaces in front of it)

Comment: @GammaGames the output is what is called a "named vector" in R. In this case the value is the sum of the code points of the winning word, and the name is printed along with it, which in this case is the winning word itself. The name is right-aligned to the number below it.

Comment: Oh, neat! It looks like it does follow the rules, so I'll allow it. Cool entry!

Comment: `sort(-sapply(...))` is shorter by 3 bytes.

Comment: oh and you can apply `scan()` twice instead of `el(strsplit())` to make this [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzi/qERDtzixoCCnUqM4OTFPo8QWTOkoKWnqlNuCyLTSvOSSzPw8jQrN4tJcjdKSNIuQfM@8EiAfCKINY/8rHV5weIFCYrFCokJJanGJ0n8A)

Comment: `Map` for 64bytes, I am sure it can be improved further.[tio](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzi/qERDtzQvJ7O4RMM3sUCjuDRXB0SXlqRZhOR75pXoFCcn5mmU2IIpHSUlTZ1yWyAJAtGGsf@VDi84vEAhsVghUaEktbhE6T8A)

Comment: oh, and the double `scan` can be shortened to `scan(,"",t=scan(,""))` for -1 byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzi/qERDtzQvJ7O4RMM3sUCjuDRXB0SXlqRZhOR75pXoFCcn5mnoKCnplNjCmJpgEG0Y@1/p8ILDCxQSixUSFUpSi0uU/gMA)

Comment: @JayCe `mapply` does the `unlist` for free.

Comment: Newline is white space (I think) so one scan should be sufficient. Checking with OP.

Comment: With some rebinding of `^` I've got your amazing answer down to [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Xz1O3TY3saAgp5KrOL@oREO3uDQ3rrQkzSIk3zOvJK44OTFPQ0dJSafEFsbU1NSMNoz9r3R4weEFConFCokKJanFJUr/AQ "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.map(m=s=>m=[...s].map(c=>t+=c.charCodeAt(),t=0)&&t<=m?m:(r=s,t))&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzBSgMxEIbvPsWQQ0mwpp6lqYiPUYTGbNpdSZolGepV8OBJRcFzK4gn7woe@0D2DbaTLahsh@Ef@P//myu90MnEqsajeShsM1VNUqMkU@0qnMBEel1zr8jzaiylTBetY9QID5WRptTxnLgz5KKP6lj0ejhU/tSf8KhSHwUZsTFhnoKz0oUZn3Km4RIMFGCZEPA3gwEwyw465dI6F@A6RFf8r@fyzuwCWFYJaDWgTfjLZKA1uv31ar0CvdffETncIzbL5xvYLJ@@Sd5eSd7vSF4@f74e6d5/kDzcto/yi5wwipot)

Comment: That's way better than the code I came up with when I was writing the challenge, mine was ~200 chars long!

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxNCsIwEIX3nmLIKgGNHqD1IiKatlFrg5Em6FZw4UpFwXUVxJV7BZceSG9QJwr@1GF4D@Z9b/piJEyYxkNbGehI5h0fl7bKiW/8eoNzbprc6NRSKsoB8@vCCxhai5uhim0b2j9pQgXzEopIo9bMQz0wWkmudJd2KBEQQAgRSMIYfKZaBSJJqQD3pFIaxjpV0Tfu4NexWLC92ACuACuNfXdc4Xko8tftdQvij381XPjXuGfrCdyz1QVlv0M5zFA2p9t5iT4/oiymz0fuhUsIRvkD)

Comment: @guest271314 doesn't work for the second last test case and some extreme cases like `f(" 龘龘龘龘龘")`

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Appears to return correct result here https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0Qa8TrZtsW2dtF6enrFsXrF@UUlGhqJOkmatnaJNkmaQCper7ggJ7MkQSEBRTZbI1HTJlsDqCTaIPZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmobSh/m9axTeL98IQUqamgoIoK@voJSqxIWmIyM1JydfoTy/KCcFWTlIMUQQXUNJRmaxAhAlKpSkFpfA9YA0gAXQ1R9ecHiBQiKGeogOkCSGjg/zJzUofJg/cTeQWLIQSCxrBxJTt7/f0a8A9uCH@X3NYINARoBklIBS/wE ? What is expected result for `" 龘龘龘龘龘"`?

Comment: Oh nvm `隣(\uf9f1)` was the one in CJK Compatibility Ideograph block instead lol. Thought it was `隣(\u96a3)`, the one in CJK Unified Ideograph block.

Comment: Apparently `龘龘龘龘龘` would be the expected result I'd say.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto The sum of `"龘龘龘龘龘"` is `204280` and the sum of `""` is `55357`, correct?

Comment: @guest271314 the sum of  should he 112191 because of utf-16 encoding

Answer (score 4):

## jq, <s>61</s> <s>43</s> <s>57</s> 37 characters

(<s>57</s> <s>39</s> <s>53</s> 33 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
./" "|reverse|max_by(explode|add)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr './" "|reverse|max_by(explode|add)' <<< 'àà as a test'
àà
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PX0lBqaYotSy1qDi1JjexIj6pUiO1oiAnPyW1JjElRfP//8MLDi9QSCxWSFQoSS0u@a8bVAQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>74</s> 52 bytes

```powershell
(-split$args|sort{$r=0;$_|% t*y|%{$r+=$_};$r}-u)[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0O3uCAns0QlsSi9uKY4v6ikWqXI1sBaJb5GVaFEq7JGFcjXtlWJr7VWKarVLdWM1jWM/f//v9LhBYcXKCQWKyQqlKQWlygBAA)

*Thanks to mazzy for a whopping -22 bytes.*

`-split`s the input `$args` on whitespace, pipes that into `sort` with a particular sorting mechanism `{...}` and the `-u`nique flag.

Here we're taking the current word `$_`, changing it `t`oCharArra`y`, then for each letter we're adding it into our `$r`esult. That turns the string into a number based on its UTF-16 representation.

For once, PowerShell having all strings be UTF-16 in the background is a life-saver!

We then encapsulate those results in `(...)` to transform them into an array and take the last `[-1]` one, i.e., the largest result that's the closest to the start of the sentence. This works because of the `-u`nique flag, i.e., if there's a later element that has the same value, it's discarded. That word is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Comment: it's smart. Thanks. 2 moments: why not `sort -u` instead a reverse? can be enough `+` to convert in the number? `(-split$args|sort{($_|% t*y|%{+$_})-join"+"|iex} -u)[-1]`

Comment: more golf: `(-split$args|sort{$r=0;$_|% t*y|%{$r+=$_};$r}-u)[-1]` :)

Comment: @mazzy Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
eosCMNc
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=eosCMNc&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22a+b+c+d+e%22%0A%22hello+world%22%0A%22this+is+a+test%22%0A%22%C3%A0%C3%A0+as+a+test%22%0A%22%CE%B1+%C3%A4%C3%A4%22%0A%22%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%A7%B1%EF%A7%B1%EF%A7%B1%22%0A%22%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%B8%8F+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%22&debug=0)

I know there's already a Pyth answer but I feel like this uses a pretty different approach <sub><sup><s>and also it's waaaay shorter</s></sup></sub>

Explanation:

```
eosCMNc  | Full code
eosCMNcQ | with implicit variables added
---------+------------------------------------
e        | The last element of
      cQ | the input chopped at whitespace
 o       | sorted by
  s      | the sum of
   CMN   | the Unicode value of each character
```

Comment: Wow, that's really precise! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```python
lambda s:max(s.split(),key=lambda w:sum(map(ord,w)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PckxDoMwDADAva/wFltCXboh8ZMurhIIIsYRTkX5DX/hYSlIVcfT5a1EnR@17541sbw8g7XCH7S75TQWdOComcLW/XZt7S0onFEX36xEVPMyzgV7dDGkpOB1gBhkUkd0@9@xHzuwAUMJVuDi@fUL)

- -3 bytes thanks to Gigaflop for pointing out that no argument is needed in the `split` method.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by passing no args to `split()`, as it splits on any group of whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ḲOS$ÐṀḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4biyT1Mkw5DhuYDhuKL///8iw6DDoCBhcyBhIHRlc3Qi)

```
ḲOS$ÐṀḢ
Ḳ        Split input on spaces
    ÐṀ   Give words that have maximum of:
   $       Monad:
 O           ord(each character)
  S          sum
      Ḣ  First word that gives the max ord-sum.
```

Comment: If the spec is relaxed to input being allowed as a list of words then `O§MḢị`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Where did OP say that was allowed?

Comment: didn't just if...

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, gotcha.

Comment: If you can take a list of words, each on their own line, that would be valid too. I don't know Jelly so I don't know if the 'whitespace' flexibility helps much

Comment: @GammaGames It would help if I could take a list of strings, e.g. `["abc", "def"]`. But at this point there are a lot of answers so I don't recommend adding new methods of input

Comment: That's why I haven't added it, though I do see why it would have been nice

Comment: As of now, you have the lowest answer! Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h`, 8 bytes

[@Emigna approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173427/78039)

```
¸w ñ_¬xc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9COcoXDG@MPralI/v9f6cP8SQ0KH@ZP3A0kliwEEsvagcTU7e939APp3jVAoq9ZSUE3AwA)

---

Another Approach

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-g`, 8 bytes

```
¸ñ@-X¬xc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9COwxsddCMOralI/v9f6cP8SQ0KH@ZP3A0kliwEEsvagcTU7e939APp3jVAoq9ZSUE3HQA)

Comment: Identical to what I was about to post. The need for the reversal annoys me; would've preferred if we could output any of the words in the case of a tie.

Comment: @Shaggy if that was possible, I have a 6 bytes answer for it

Comment: Same 6-byter I started with before spotting that requirement in the spec.

Comment: I'm sorry! Originally when I sandboxed the challenge I figured it could output any of the answers, but I changed it after a little feedback so it was more consistent

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 57 bytes

```
s=strsplit(input('','s'));[Y I]=max(cellfun(@sum,s));s(I)
```

In my MATLAB R2016a all tests arepassed, except that emojis are not rendered properly. But characters are returned correctly

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>117</s> <s>97</s> 84 bytes

-13 bytes thanks @Nevay. Apparently I didn't know I can also use `var` in Java.

```java
s->{var b="";for(var a:s.split(" "))b=a.chars().sum()>b.chars().sum()?a:b;return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxTsMwEIb3PsXJUzI03Ru1bGxMjIjhkjiti5tUtlNUVZWQGJgAgcTC0iIqJpZOIDFm73sw0TcIdpKmDdSyTvZ/3//r7AGOsTkILjKfo5RwgiyCaQNYpKgI0adwMjlOIl@xONfhVAkW9SDUmlWepe02YNYAqVAxf98QupVqvCF0MtnsTscowOsQ4oaxsMwF29KRI86URYDYttdBx@@jkJbtyGRo2V2vfj/CtucKqhIRgefOMoDaBOOYBcDj3m7AYvSJVHToxIlyRlpXPLJCJ3@ItMsnjBKP64D9nKH@kTLo7BxQ9Mo0k08QPPAhAEpsF@qr1QJCyRbsU85juIwFD/6iBiwaW1j1mQS9ERSVqsYbOBe3bLpIF4AH2YI2QEWvV5Au0@X/aSt8vargzfz2Hb6fX4t9wGP4XX9ne7yCzfzhS5fliy5vN7o8ffx83kMeuZnfXedpxm86RLfM98@yXw)

Comment: -13 bytes: `s->{var b="";for(var a:s.split(" "))b=a.chars().sum()>b.chars().sum()?a:b;return b;}`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 45 characters

```ruby
->s{s.split.max_by{|w|w.codepoints.reduce:+}}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->s{s.split.max_by{|w|w.codepoints.reduce:+}}['àà as a test']
=> "àà"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivuCAns0QvN7EiPqmyuqa8plwvOT8ltSA/M6@kWK8oNaU0OdVKu7b2f0FpSbFCtHqiQpJCskKKQqq6joJ6RmpOTr5CeX5RTgqIW5KRWawARIkKJanFJSCRwwsOL1BIRBb5MH9Sg8KH@RN3A4klC4HEsnYgMXX7@x39QLp3DZDoawYpBOoqTlSPBbqsoLqmJLWipCYtGkTF1v4HAA)

#### Ruby 2.4, 40 characters

```ruby
->s{s.split.max_by{|w|w.codepoints.sum}}
```

(Untested.)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivuCAns0QvN7EiPqlSQ82quDRXs/Z/QWlJsUK0eqJCkkKyQopCqrqOgnpGak5OvkJ5flFOCohbkpFZrABEiQolqcUlIJHDCw4vUEhEFvkwf1KDwof5E3cDiSULgcSydiAxdfv7Hf1AuncNkOhrBikE6ipOVI8FOqOguqYktaKkJi0aRMXW/gcA)

Comment: I'm sorry @Jordan, but I think that is not what the challenge asks for. “The value of each word is based on the sum of each character in the word's UTF-16 code” (the challenge) vs. “The result is simply the sum of the binary value of each byte in str modulo 2**n - 1.” ([`String#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-sum) doc). [This test case](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhWt0rvyglMU9dR0HXrri6WK@4ICezRC83sSI@qVJDzaq4NFezNlo9EQgUEg8vVI@N5QJpyk3MSywpzy/Kxqqvuqa8plwvOT8ltSA/M68EKFmaW4tmChfYHKAE0AR1kBhIEcTwpMqS1GK4MJiHJKGArAcsgtCJsBKuAiGErgTFIFTHxv7/DwA) explains better.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 33 bytes

```
FHmCdmcd)Kczd aYu+GHmCdH0)@KxYeSY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380j1zklNzlF0zu5KkUhMbJU2x0k4mGg6eBdEZkaHPn/v0dqTk6@Qnl@UU4KAA)

There is almost certainly a better way to do this, but I spent too much on it so this will do.

```
FH  #For every array of letters in 
  mCd   #the array of arrays of letters [['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']]
     mcd)   #wrap that in another array [[hello"], ["world"]]
         Kczd   #split input(z) on spaces ["hello", "world"] and assign it to K for later
              aY     #append to list Y... " " silences the prints from the for loop.
                u+GH    #reduce the list of numbers by summing them    
                    mCdH    #convert each letter in the array to its int counterpart
                        0)    #the zero for the accumulator and close for loop
                          @K    #get by index the word from K
                            xY   #find the index in Y of that number
                              eSY   #sort Y, get the last (largest) number
```

I would have passed a reduce into another map instead of using the for loop, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Oh boy, a pyth answer! Thanks for the explanation, nice entry!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ θ≔ＥθΣＥι℅λη§θ⌕η⌈η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoMwEEX3nmJwNYH0BK7cFFxIC54gGDEDcRqTUbx9OpZ@Pp@/eG8OLs8fF2vtS6GVcUqRBAdOh0ySiVc0FlpodXfTNX9qdAl3C9Ox/S5ZeGVP7CJGo7EQlH2rLtjLwH65bvxJ7DFYGN1Fm6rhZrtaJVABrQNZijT1ccYv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ θ
```

Split the input string on spaces and assign to `q`.

```
≔ＥθΣＥι℅λη
```

Calculate the sum of the ordinals of the characters in each word and assign to `h`.

```
§θ⌕η⌈η
```

Find the index of the highest sum and print the word at that index.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 66 bytes

Straightforward. See [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173430/80745)'s answer to found a smart using of Powershell.

```
-split$args|%{$s=0
$_|% t*y|%{$s+=$_}
if($s-gt$x){$w=$_;$x=$s}}
$w
```

*Note!* To correct work with unicode, save your script file with `UTF-16` or `UTF8 with BOM` encoding.

Test script:

```
$f = {

-split$args|%{$s=0         # split argument strings by whitespaces, for each word
$_|% t*y|%{$s+=$_}         # let $s is sum of unicode char code
if($s-gt$x){$w=$_;$x=$s}}  # if $s greater then previous one, store word and sum to variables
$w                         # return word from stored variable

}

@(
    ,("a b c d e", "e")

    ,("hello world", "world")

    ,("this is a test", "test")

    ,("àà as a test", "àà")

    ,("α ää", "α")

    ,(" 隣隣隣", "隣隣隣")

    ,("    ️  ", "️")
) | % {
    $s,$e=$_
    $r=&$f $s
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True: e
True: world
True: test
True: àà
True: α
True: 隣隣隣
True: ️
```