# Clockwise matrix rotation

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

The title pretty much describes it all. Given as input a \$n \times m\$ matrix and an integer \$i\$ create a complete function/program that returns the matrix \$i\$ times clockwise rotated by \$90^\circ\$.

**Rules:**

- as matrix you can use any convenient representation you like e.g. *a list of lists etc...*
- matrix values can be positive and/or negative integer numbers
- \$n\$ and \$m\$ are of course always positive integers between 1 and 10
- \$i\$ can be any valid integer which belongs in the following range: \${0...10^5}\$
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules & winning criteria apply but no "winning" answer will be chosen.

**EDIT:** I had to edit the initial question because for some programming languages it takes too long to compute the result for \$i\in\{0...10^7\}\$. There is a workaround to it but since it's a code-golf just make sure that it simply runs successfully for at least \$i\in\{0...10^5\}\$.

**Some test cases:**

````
==== example 1 ====
Input:
5
[[1, 3, 2, 30,],
 [4, 9, 7, 10,],
 [6, 8, 5, 25 ]]

Expected Output:
[[ 6  4  1],
 [ 8  9  3],
 [ 5  7  2],
 [25 10 30]]

==== example 2 ====
Input:
100
[[1]]

Expected Output:
[[1]]

==== example 3 ====
Input:
15
[[150,    3,  2],
 [  4, -940,  7],
 [  6, 8000,  5]]

Expected Output:
[[   2    7    5],
 [   3 -940 8000],
 [ 150    4    6]]

==== example 4 ====
Input:
40001
[[1, 3, 9]]

Expected Output:
[[1],
 [3],
 [9]]
```
````

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

```apl
⌽∘⍉⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jnr2POmY86u181Lv4Ud/UR12LgCRI6r8CGBRwPWqbCBTyCvb3U1CPjjbUUTDWUTACkgaxOgrRJjoKljoK5joKhmCumY6ChY6CKVCBqUJsrDqXKRcOU0CShgYGWKRBsqYGOiBhoEUKRiBjFRSA9uhamoCEzSECIJsMDEACpmCzTHEYBXauJUiJiQEIGAIA)

`⎕` prompt for matrix expression from stdin

`⊢` yield that

`⎕` prompt for \$i\$ expression from stdin

`⍣` do the following that many times

`⍉` transpose

`∘` and then

`⌽` mirror

Comment: Nice, I really liked that it even works for \$i\$ of \$10^7\$. I had to lower that in the requirements because for some languages [tio.run](https://tio.run/) wouldn't terminate...

Comment: @game0ver Yeah, APL is generally quite fast when it comes to munging arrays. Even \$10^8\$ only takes about 20 seconds on TIO.

Comment: Wow, the character for transpose and mirror looks suitable

Comment: @justhalf Yes, APL is like that. Can you guess what flip-upside-down looks like?

Comment: Something like this ⦵?

Comment: @justhalf Basically. Unicode has many [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph). APL prefers the [Unicode APL range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical), so this is `⊖`

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

```
uC_GQE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9Q53j3Q9f9/U67oaEMdBWMdBSMgaRCrE22io2Cpo2Cuo2AI4pnpKFjoKJgCpU0VYmMB)

-1 Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

Rotates the matrix by reversing the order of rows and taking the transpose. Takes and returns lists of lists.

### How it works

```
uC_GQE
u    E - Reduce the second input
  _G   - By reversing the order of rows
 C     - And transposing
    Q  - An amount of times equal to the first input
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
|:@|.^:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a6wcavTirP5rcqUmZ@QrZOoZK5hAmOq6urrqEKaBQhoOGUOcMkY4ZYxxm2ZgALfqPwA)

An adverb train. Right argument is the matrix, left argument is the repetition count.

#### How it works

```
|:@|.^:
     ^:  Repeat the function:
   |.      Reverse vertically
  @        and then
|:         Transpose
         Absent right argument to `^:`:
           bind to the left argument (repeat count)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

Naive implementation. There might be a shorter way I'm not aware of.

```
ṚZ$¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzllRKocW/j/c7v2oaU3k///R0YamBjoKQGAMJI1idbgUohUUTHQUdC1NQOLmUBEzHQULAwOQiGls7H9DUwA)

Comment: Nice, but the last test case fails since for both \$i=40001\$ and \$i=40000\$ it gives the same result.

Comment: @game0ver The output is actually different, but displayed the same way. I've added some code in the footer to format it.

Comment: yep you are correct! Thanks for editing :)

Comment: I think this is as short as you can get at present. Matrix rotation is already on my wish list of possible new Jelly links that I may get round to suggesting at some point

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
(!!).iterate(foldr(zipWith$flip(++).pure)e)
e=[]:e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYw5DsIwFAX7nOJFSmErn4gtbFLOQWFcWOGbWJhgOabh8Jj0iCmmGs1gpjt7n213yaIsZeMSR5NY2Ke/RvF24ezSUFnvgqhr2YRXZMmy4E7pE@eHcSM6hOjGhAoWSq0IG8J69lJTgR/UlnAk7AmrP8GOcCC086TVGm3@9Nab25QXfQhf)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->m,n{n.times{m=m.reverse.transpose};m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5XJ686T68kMze1uDrXNlevKLUstag4Va@kKDGvuCC/OLXWOrf2f4FCmkJ0dLShjoKxjoIRkDSI1VGINtFRsNRRMNdRMARzzXQULHQUTIEKTGOBfNPY/wA)

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 6 bytes

```
(+|:)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcu7EYAwDIPhVdQRHy8nJITE@9BQsAC7G0H33@nTNd@X@9nD@HRZ/VyGEIqFiA0JmxoyGioia8eBglREuKvaFL/4cFFyJAP13LIC1ahVWT/PzMgDWRPxFw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
zV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=elY&input=W1sgMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sCiBbMTEsMTIsMTMsMTRdLAogWzIxLDIyLDIzLDI0XQpdCjM)

```
Rotate matrix by 90 degrees 2nd input times
```

Comment: OK, this one might be hard to beat.

Comment: @Adám agreed, Japt fits this challenge very well :p

Comment: @AZTECCO really impressive!!!

Comment: I knew this would be the solution just from the challenge title! I also knew someone would have beaten me to it!

Comment: I was there at the right time @Shaggy , couldn't miss it!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda A,i:i%4and f(zip(*A[::-1]),i-1)or A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BboMwEETP9VfMpbLdLBVOoClEHLjkJywOVIDqihjkEintz1ObQg5VfbB2x/Nm1@PX9D7Y/Tx3RV9f3poaJZncPCa1bdCJbzOKp1LneaQqSSZScnAo56btcBbeKXOGsrjUo5iuY99SKRlGZ@yEksEV3eJhMB361goni0Llv@@fk/P9aWlOrp2uzm4o14LvOPHnj8FYEcK9mZyOKyl3XBJn6PwaNxgLp1XYLWcPC8uxoPjD3u7gOgH/Twi/DM5qczJ2FlorwoGw93dMFTHohJARjgS1Ci@EV0LqTSmqilK5gr5WW53GBH98EvYLBPicKEuCflyVEBTHQUkDew9aNsi8hMQ/Kzn/AA)

Input/output is a `list` of `tuples`. (The `%4` is a workaround for Python's recursion limit; could save a byte otherwise).

Comment: Nice! Yep that's the workaround (`%4`) I'm talking about in the description. A way to skip that would be using `numpy` but I really like the naive implementation. Also you could save 2 bytes by placing `f=` into Header in TIO!

Comment: @game0ver They can't actually do that to save bytes since this is a recursive function - it needs to be named so they can call it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman good catch! You are right!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Føí
```

Takes \$i\$ as first input; matrix the second.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7fCOw2v//zflio421DHWMdIxNojViTbRsdQx1zEEMc10LHRMdYxMY2MB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/ipuSZV1BaUmyloGTv6WKvpJCYlwJi2hZzKfmXlgClQDL/3Q7vOLz2f63OoW32/025oqMNdYx1jHSMDWJ1ok10LHXMdQxBTDMdCx1THSPT2FguQwMDkDIQC6ze1ACkA6xc19LEQMccotzAwEAHpNwEyDCEmmsZGwsA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F    # Loop the (implicit) input-integer amount of times:
 ø   #  Zip/transpose the matrix; swapping rows/columns
     #  (this will take the (implicit) input in the first iteration)
  í  #  Reverse each row
     # (after the loop, the resulting matrix is output implicitly)
```

NOTE: Uses the legacy version only because of performance. [The last test case times out in the rewrite version.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7fCOw2v//zcxMDAw5IqONtQx1rGMjQUA) Both the legacy and rewrite versions would be the same, though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 6 bytes

Kind of cheating, but Julia has a built in `rotl90` function, that does exactly that.

```julia
rotl90
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3PCsIwDAbwe5/iOzYw4cvWOnsQfI/hwUtxUhj4h/n2Nd1BFBIIyccvt1eZL/qu@Vjvy7MkVnd6XJfVZz9BMaDHQIeAhBFq0x4HRPQR5w5RxH3jeS7Fa4dWYk3@Xg2LbFyzdikQ42aRxGbpHza118nWwQIqUj8)

Comment: No, no cheat at all! It's also pretty fast with very large values of \$i\$ e.g. \$i^{11}\$ etc...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

Takes input as `(i)(matrix)`.

```javascript
i=>g=m=>i--?g(m[0].map((_,x)=>m.map(r=>r[x]).reverse())):m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoMwEETvfsUeE1hltabWQuyHSChio1iMSizi39tosSC4h4WdGd7su5iKsbTN8PG7/qWXSi6NzGppZNb4/qNmJicVmGJg7Ikzl5nZDiszm8@KB1ZP2o6acc7vZin7buxbHbR9zSomOMs9gDxEuCBEbhMqXJUYIUVIEMJduSLcEISLCVCe4tw7skKinXZq/7sEIbhxhRD90ACuzk/j1Uh2ae0jWiVxxouJwsP36ZZavg)

**Note**: The last test case was edited to prevent a recursion error. We can obviously use [`i--&3`](https://tio.run/##bY7NCoMwEITvPsWeSgKrxJ/UWoh9EAlFbBSLMRKL@PY2WiwI7mFhZ4b59l1O5VjZdvj4vXmppRZLK/JGaJG3vn@JHw3RBZOBLgdCnjhTkevtsCK3xSxpYNWk7KgIpfSul8r0o@lU0JmG1IRTUngARYgQI0RuM5S4KglChpAihLtyRbghcBfjID1JqXfsChnb207tP4szBDcOCNGvGsDh/CxZjXSXVh5jq8TP@hLnhYf3sy22fAE) (60 bytes) to support much larger values.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes

Unfortunately `rot90` rotates the input *counterclockwise*.

```matlab
@(x,i)rot90(x,-i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0InU7Mov8TSAMjSzdT8b82Vq2CrEG2oY2RtrGMSa82VkllcoJGrCWWo6wKBuiaEk6aRq6NgqKlp/R8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo!

```
_X!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz5C8f9/I65oQx0ja2Mdk1gA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>141</s> <s>138</s> <s>131</s> 130 bytes

```java
(m,i)->{for(int t[][],a,b,j;i-->0;m=t)for(t=new int[b=m[0].length][a=m.length],j=a*b;j-->0;)t[j%b][j/b]=m[a-j/b-1][j%b];return m;}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZJNT4NAEIbv/opJExPQgS7aqi2hiUcP6kFvhMNC17oI2wYGP0L47XVYWi/ayoHM7rwz88zs5PJdevnybZsVsq7hXmrTngBoQ6p6kZmCh/5oL@IkTiBz9laJbIF2Q/Z3J/yrSZLO4AEMRLB12O96i/ZlXfUhYINQYop5qD1vIcIyIrf3UmTUhy2QRmUsEr9QZkWvSSyjcm9jHsmzNMxtoEtxfpomcT5OE45g/nHqBYm9DCtFTWWgDLtt2FNtmrRgqh3c@1ovoeQmnSeqtFlxH9IdOiRVk7MnYda2DfASL/BSdGgFv752gjO8xuCw4ApvcIoX065DmNpJ/VmndwdCHBZMBbKDaQ5WApigN5sIvD4iYRwhBFqc4AgP9z3rNRNWB78e2M7QRv2sguRhfiIMCzGM8@mrJlX664b8DU@aCuOM7symoXoOo3N9PgJplmzlvIB@Q7rwb6tKftX@UqnN83p4HmfI7O5Q/8r52BAnnf@byfiZ88PpHsm467fbfgM)

**Code explanation:**

```java
(m,i)->{                 // Method with int-matrix and int parameters and int-matrix return
  for(int t[][],         //  Temp int-matrix as replacement
          a,b,           //  Temp integers used for the dimensions
          j;             //  Temp integer for the inner loop
      i-->0;             //  Loop the input `i` amount of times:
      m=t)               //    After every iteration: replace the input-matrix `m` with `t`
    for(t=new int[b=m[0].length][a=m.length],
                         //   Create a new temp-matrix `t` with dimensions `b` by `a`,
                         //   where `b` & `a` are the amount of columns & rows of matrix `m`
        j=a*b;           //   Set `j` to the product of these dimensions
        j-->0;)          //   And inner loop in the range [`j`, 0):
      t                  //  Replace the value in `t` at position:
       [j%b]             //   `j%b` (let's call this row A),
            [j/b]        //   `j/b` (let's call this column B)
        =m               //  And replace it with the value in `m` at position:
          [a-j/b-1]      //   `a-j/b-1` (which is the reversed column B as row,
                         //     so it both transposes and reverses at the same time),
                   [j%b];//   `j%b` (which is row A as column)
  return m;}             //  And finally return the new int-matrix
```

**To save bytes**, the inner loop is a single loop and uses `j/a` and `j%a` as cell positions. So a loop like this:

```java
for(r=a;r-->0;)for(c=b;c-->0;)t[c][r]=m[b-r-1][c];
```

Has been golfed to this:

```java
for(j=a*b;j-->0;)t[j%b][j/b]=m[a-j/b-1][j%b];
```

to save 5 bytes.

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZLPT@swDMfv/BXWpCe1zC0pbI83qiJx5AAc4Fb1kHaBl9JmU@PyQ1X514ebblxgo4fKib@2P3ZcyhcZlMvnTVFJa@FGatMdAWhDqnmUhYLb4egu0izNoPB2Vo1sgfZj9vdH/LMkSRdwCwYS2Hjs94PL7nHVDCHgglBijhbLWAfBpYjrhPzBT4lRr65EntSpyMJKmSf6n6UyqXc2lok8zuPSBfqUln/yLLVJeZJnHCOnHzZzd3GjqG0M1HG/iQesdZtXjLWle1npJdTcpXdPjTZP3Ij0xxZJWfJ2IAzbdRGe4SmeiR6d4NvXzXCB5xjtF/zFfzjH03nfI8zdqH6sM7gjIfYL5gLZwTR7KwHMMFjMBJ4fkDCOEAIdTnSAh/teDJoZq6NvL@xm6KK@dkHyMN8Qxo0Yx3n/bknV4aqlcM2Tpsp4k2uzbslewGSqpxOQZslWyRsYtqSr8Kpp5LsNl0qtH1bj83hjZn@L@lPOu5Y46cWvmUxYeF@c/oGM2377zSc)

Comment: Explanation of the above: I restarted it from scratch trying to use simply `new int[m[0].length][m.length]`. It seemed to have worked. The rest is basically your code. So in the end the golf came from moving the variable allocation where needed most.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I was quite proud of this one, but had the feeling it could still be golfed. ;) Btw, 1 more byte can be saved by removing that temp variable `s` and use `a-j/b-1` instead of  `a+~s` again.

Comment: Indeed, that's a one more saved byte. I hadn't passed the code again under full review ;) But to be honest, you did the bigger job with your first answer.

Comment: I've removed that general explanation, since it's now the same as the code, haha. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
r=function(x,i){o=x;n=0;while(n<i){o=t(apply(o,2,rev));n=n+1};o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNCsIwFIT3PcVbvoezSFqrlphbeIFaKgZqUkLtD9Kzx@pCcDPwzTdMTCna29M3gwueZzh5BTsbb5WZ7q5r2Z@/1cB133cLB@SI7SiyTfxOryasabSPeohu5oY1qADlWypktAdVoCNIf@gAOoHKTZeCAtclhsleJIs8opTs96Kh/6VWStIb)

Not really efficient...

Uses rotation approach proposed by [Matthew Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496210/rotate-a-matrix-in-r)

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to R golfing! I like this approach. There are still a bunch of golfs available, e.g., [this](https://tio.run/##VYzNCsIwEAbveYqlp134hK41/kHewpt40EJhD6YQ0hqfPsaL4GVgGJhUawrTEsdsc@QCk86mjg2JM5drTPOLi5wVN4FtVFCkruF5z8kKj6ygAbRt7OFoBzqBDiD92h50BPmWvWDA491e4SIu8Qov7ndR6H/Uvpf6AQ) for 48 bytes. Feel free to join the [R golf chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81960/golfr) to ask any golfing questions you might have, and read [these tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r). Happy golfing!

Comment: To speed it up, you can do something like `i%%4` in the stop condition.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
~!→¡oT↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f6/aoqfF/neKjtkmHFuaHPGqb8v///2gNU53oaEMdYx0jHWODWJ1oEx1LHXMdQxDTTMdCx1THyDQ2VlNHw9DAAKQQwgbrMTUA6QJr0bU0MdAxh2gxACoEaYkFAA) I've always found it odd that the only real way to iterate a function a set number of times in Husk is to index into the infinite list of that function's iterates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 37 bytes

```
f(m,n)=for(i=1,n,m=Mat(Vecrev(m~)));m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3PCoMwDIdfJXhqIULjdJuIe4Nddyk9BNEhWFeKDHbZq3fpHDvkz4@PLwkc5/IeUpqUx1X30yOquSdc0fdX3tRtHOL4VP6tte584hCWl2IoLxDivG6KLTkoEApgW8mWSQEDL4uaEFhrBGstIRwQKummgxqhRTghkIQjwhmhEdg4mVI2vyWdscnRUmN2/auWbS3xtJvGmF2iv/n71Tq5UAsn53T6AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
~{-1%zip}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65a11C1KrOgVuv//@hoQwVjBSMFY4NYhWgTBUsFcwVDENNMwULBVMHINDZWwRQA)

```
~{      }*   # Repeat i times
  -1%        # Reverse the array
     zip     # Zip
```

When the program finishes, only the elements of the matrix are displayed. To see how it actually was outputted, use [this](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65a11C1KrOgVivh///oaEMFYwUjBWODWIVoEwVLBXMFQxDTTMFCwVTByDQ2VsEUAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>8</s> 7 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
Ç├Úe↑Î(
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Ji57LkBALjw=&input=W1sxIDMgOV1dIFtOXSA0MDAwMQpbWzFdXSBbTl0gMTAwCltbMTUwIDMgMl0gWzQgXzk0MCA3XSBbNiA4MDAwIDVdXSBbTl0gMTU=&flags=ZQ==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `&.{.@@.<`
ELABORATE HERE

```
&. Mutate N times
  { Block, key of `_`
        _ Implied variable
      .@ Transposed
    @ Binded map
      .< Reverse
  } End block; implied
```

Input is two lines, the first being an array and the second a number. `&.` supports both 2 separate inputs and one as an array, and as `_` is automatically the STDIN separated on newlines and parsed, this code is valid.

Answer (score -1):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
a = {{3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13}};

Nest[Reverse /@ Transpose[#] &, a, i]
```