# DON'T... do NOT lowercase UPPERCASE this!

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

Write a program that outputs its input unchanged. However:

- If all uppercase characters are removed from the program, it lowercases all uppercase letters.
- If all lowercase characters are removed from the program, it uppercases all lowercase letters.

Transforming characters beyond the basic Latin `[A-Za-z]` range is optional, but any character with [both uppercase and lowercase counterparts within Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt) (`Ñ`/`ñ`, `Ω`/`ω`, etc.) qualifies for "removal" from your program.

In your answer, please specify the character encoding used along with the language name if it might be ambiguous.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The less bytes, the better.

---

Here's an example in a hypothetical programming language, with input `"Hello, world!"`:

```
DONT_do_NOT_lowercase_UPPERCASE_this(_MY_input_STRING_)
```

→ `Hello, world!`

With uppercase characters removed:

```
_do__lowercase__this(__input__)
```

→ `hello, world!`

With lowercase characters removed:

```
DONT__NOT__UPPERCASE_(_MY__STRING_)
```

→ `HELLO, WORLD!`

---

To be complete, here are the characters/Unicode codepoints that can be removed:

#### Uppercase Characters

```
ABCDEFGHIIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZµÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŉŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŻŽſƁƂƄƆƇƉƊƋƎƏƐƑƓƔƖƗƘƜƝƟƠƢƤƦƧƩƬƮƯƱƲƳƵƷƸƼǄǅǇǈǊǋǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǞǠǢǤǦǨǪǬǮǰǱǲǴǶǷǸǺǼǾȀȂȄȆȈȊȌȎȐȒȔȖȘȚȜȞȠȢȤȦȨȪȬȮȰȲȺȻȽȾɁɃɄɅɆɈɊɌɎͅͰͲͶͿΆΈΉΊΌΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫΰςϏϐϑϕϖϘϚϜϞϠϢϤϦϨϪϬϮϰϱϴϵϷϹϺϽϾϿЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯѠѢѤѦѨѪѬѮѰѲѴѶѸѺѼѾҀҊҌҎҐҒҔҖҘҚҜҞҠҢҤҦҨҪҬҮҰҲҴҶҸҺҼҾӀӁӃӅӇӉӋӍӐӒӔӖӘӚӜӞӠӢӤӦӨӪӬӮӰӲӴӶӸӺӼӾԀԂԄԆԈԊԌԎԐԒԔԖԘԚԜԞԠԢԤԦԨԪԬԮԱԲԳԴԵԶԷԸԹԺԻԼԽԾԿՀՁՂՃՄՅՆՇՈՉՊՋՌՍՎՏՐՑՒՓՔՕՖևႠႡႢႣႤႥႦႧႨႩႪႫႬႭႮႯႰႱႲႳႴႵႶႷႸႹႺႻႼႽႾႿჀჁჂჃჄჅჇჍᏸᏹᏺᏻᏼᏽᲀᲁᲂᲃᲄᲅᲆᲇᲈᲐᲑᲒᲓᲔᲕᲖᲗᲘᲙᲚᲛᲜᲝᲞᲟᲠᲡᲢᲣᲤᲥᲦᲧᲨᲩᲪᲫᲬᲭᲮᲯᲰᲱᲲᲳᲴᲵᲶᲷᲸᲹᲺᲽᲾᲿḀḂḄḆḈḊḌḎḐḒḔḖḘḚḜḞḠḢḤḦḨḪḬḮḰḲḴḶḸḺḼḾṀṂṄṆṈṊṌṎṐṒṔṖṘṚṜṞṠṢṤṦṨṪṬṮṰṲṴṶṸṺṼṾẀẂẄẆẈẊẌẎẐẒẔẖẗẘẙẚẛẞẞẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼẾỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸỺỼỾἈἉἊἋἌἍἎἏἘἙἚἛἜἝἨἩἪἫἬἭἮἯἸἹἺἻἼἽἾἿὈὉὊὋὌὍὐὒὔὖὙὛὝὟὨὩὪὫὬὭὮὯᾀᾁᾂᾃᾄᾅᾆᾇᾈᾈᾉᾉᾊᾊᾋᾋᾌᾌᾍᾍᾎᾎᾏᾏᾐᾑᾒᾓᾔᾕᾖᾗᾘᾘᾙᾙᾚᾚᾛᾛᾜᾜᾝᾝᾞᾞᾟᾟᾠᾡᾢᾣᾤᾥᾦᾧᾨᾨᾩᾩᾪᾪᾫᾫᾬᾬᾭᾭᾮᾮᾯᾯᾲᾳᾴᾶᾷᾸᾹᾺΆᾼᾼιῂῃῄῆῇῈΈῊΉῌῌῒΐῖῗῘῙῚΊῢΰῤῦῧῨῩῪΎῬῲῳῴῶῷῸΌῺΏῼῼΩKÅℲⅠⅡⅢⅣⅤⅥⅦⅧⅨⅩⅪⅫⅬⅭⅮⅯↃⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏⰀⰁⰂⰃⰄⰅⰆⰇⰈⰉⰊⰋⰌⰍⰎⰏⰐⰑⰒⰓⰔⰕⰖⰗⰘⰙⰚⰛⰜⰝⰞⰟⰠⰡⰢⰣⰤⰥⰦⰧⰨⰩⰪⰫⰬⰭⰮⱠⱢⱣⱤⱧⱩⱫⱭⱮⱯⱰⱲⱵⱾⱿⲀⲂⲄⲆⲈⲊⲌⲎⲐⲒⲔⲖⲘⲚⲜⲞⲠⲢⲤⲦⲨⲪⲬⲮⲰⲲⲴⲶⲸⲺⲼⲾⳀⳂⳄⳆⳈⳊⳌⳎⳐⳒⳔⳖⳘⳚⳜⳞⳠⳢⳫⳭⳲ
```

#### Lowercase Characters

```
abcdefghiıjklmnopqrstuvwxyzμàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþssāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįi̇iĳĵķĺļľŀłńņňʼnŋōŏőœŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷÿźżžsɓƃƅɔƈɖɗƌǝəɛƒɠɣɩɨƙɯɲɵơƣƥʀƨʃƭʈưʊʋƴƶʒƹƽǆǆǉǉǌǌǎǐǒǔǖǘǚǜǟǡǣǥǧǩǫǭǯǰǳǳǵƕƿǹǻǽǿȁȃȅȇȉȋȍȏȑȓȕȗșțȝȟƞȣȥȧȩȫȭȯȱȳⱥȼƚⱦɂƀʉʌɇɉɋɍɏιͱͳͷϳάέήίόύώΐαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωϊϋΰσϗβθφπϙϛϝϟϡϣϥϧϩϫϭϯκρθεϸϲϻͻͼͽѐёђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѡѣѥѧѩѫѭѯѱѳѵѷѹѻѽѿҁҋҍҏґғҕҗҙқҝҟҡңҥҧҩҫҭүұҳҵҷҹһҽҿӏӂӄӆӈӊӌӎӑӓӕӗәӛӝӟӡӣӥӧөӫӭӯӱӳӵӷӹӻӽӿԁԃԅԇԉԋԍԏԑԓԕԗԙԛԝԟԡԣԥԧԩԫԭԯաբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆեւⴀⴁⴂⴃⴄⴅⴆⴇⴈⴉⴊⴋⴌⴍⴎⴏⴐⴑⴒⴓⴔⴕⴖⴗⴘⴙⴚⴛⴜⴝⴞⴟⴠⴡⴢⴣⴤⴥⴧⴭᏰᏱᏲᏳᏴᏵвдосттъѣꙋაბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰჱჲჳჴჵჶჷჸჹჺჽჾჿḁḃḅḇḉḋḍḏḑḓḕḗḙḛḝḟḡḣḥḧḩḫḭḯḱḳḵḷḹḻḽḿṁṃṅṇṉṋṍṏṑṓṕṗṙṛṝṟṡṣṥṧṩṫṭṯṱṳṵṷṹṻṽṿẁẃẅẇẉẋẍẏẑẓẕẖẗẘẙaʾṡssßạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽếềểễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừửữựỳỵỷỹỻỽỿἀἁἂἃἄἅἆἇἐἑἒἓἔἕἠἡἢἣἤἥἦἧἰἱἲἳἴἵἶἷὀὁὂὃὄὅὐὒὔὖὑὓὕὗὠὡὢὣὤὥὦὧἀιἁιἂιἃιἄιἅιἆιἇιἀιᾀἁιᾁἂιᾂἃιᾃἄιᾄἅιᾅἆιᾆἇιᾇἠιἡιἢιἣιἤιἥιἦιἧιἠιᾐἡιᾑἢιᾒἣιᾓἤιᾔἥιᾕἦιᾖἧιᾗὠιὡιὢιὣιὤιὥιὦιὧιὠιᾠὡιᾡὢιᾢὣιᾣὤιᾤὥιᾥὦιᾦὧιᾧὰιαιάιᾶᾶιᾰᾱὰάαιᾳιὴιηιήιῆῆιὲέὴήηιῃῒΐῖῗῐῑὶίῢΰῤῦῧῠῡὺύῥὼιωιώιῶῶιὸόὼώωιῳωkåⅎⅰⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽⅾⅿↄⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⓩⰰⰱⰲⰳⰴⰵⰶⰷⰸⰹⰺⰻⰼⰽⰾⰿⱀⱁⱂⱃⱄⱅⱆⱇⱈⱉⱊⱋⱌⱍⱎⱏⱐⱑⱒⱓⱔⱕⱖⱗⱘⱙⱚⱛⱜⱝⱞⱡɫᵽɽⱨⱪⱬɑɱɐɒⱳⱶȿɀⲁⲃⲅⲇⲉⲋⲍⲏⲑⲓⲕⲗⲙⲛⲝⲟⲡⲣⲥⲧⲩⲫⲭⲯⲱⲳⲵⲷⲹⲻⲽⲿⳁⳃⳅⳇⳉⳋⳍⳏⳑⳓⳕⳗⳙⳛⳝⳟⳡⳣⳬⳮⳳ
```

#### Uppercase Codepoints

```
0041, 0042, 0043, 0044, 0045, 0046, 0047, 0048, 0049, 0049, 004A, 004B, 004C, 004D, 004E, 004F, 0050, 0051, 0052, 0053, 0054, 0055, 0056, 0057, 0058, 0059, 005A, 00B5, 00C0, 00C1, 00C2, 00C3, 00C4, 00C5, 00C6, 00C7, 00C8, 00C9, 00CA, 00CB, 00CC, 00CD, 00CE, 00CF, 00D0, 00D1, 00D2, 00D3, 00D4, 00D5, 00D6, 00D8, 00D9, 00DA, 00DB, 00DC, 00DD, 00DE, 00DF, 0100, 0102, 0104, 0106, 0108, 010A, 010C, 010E, 0110, 0112, 0114, 0116, 0118, 011A, 011C, 011E, 0120, 0122, 0124, 0126, 0128, 012A, 012C, 012E, 0130, 0130, 0132, 0134, 0136, 0139, 013B, 013D, 013F, 0141, 0143, 0145, 0147, 0149, 014A, 014C, 014E, 0150, 0152, 0154, 0156, 0158, 015A, 015C, 015E, 0160, 0162, 0164, 0166, 0168, 016A, 016C, 016E, 0170, 0172, 0174, 0176, 0178, 0179, 017B, 017D, 017F, 0181, 0182, 0184, 0186, 0187, 0189, 018A, 018B, 018E, 018F, 0190, 0191, 0193, 0194, 0196, 0197, 0198, 019C, 019D, 019F, 01A0, 01A2, 01A4, 01A6, 01A7, 01A9, 01AC, 01AE, 01AF, 01B1, 01B2, 01B3, 01B5, 01B7, 01B8, 01BC, 01C4, 01C5, 01C7, 01C8, 01CA, 01CB, 01CD, 01CF, 01D1, 01D3, 01D5, 01D7, 01D9, 01DB, 01DE, 01E0, 01E2, 01E4, 01E6, 01E8, 01EA, 01EC, 01EE, 01F0, 01F1, 01F2, 01F4, 01F6, 01F7, 01F8, 01FA, 01FC, 01FE, 0200, 0202, 0204, 0206, 0208, 020A, 020C, 020E, 0210, 0212, 0214, 0216, 0218, 021A, 021C, 021E, 0220, 0222, 0224, 0226, 0228, 022A, 022C, 022E, 0230, 0232, 023A, 023B, 023D, 023E, 0241, 0243, 0244, 0245, 0246, 0248, 024A, 024C, 024E, 0345, 0370, 0372, 0376, 037F, 0386, 0388, 0389, 038A, 038C, 038E, 038F, 0390, 0391, 0392, 0393, 0394, 0395, 0396, 0397, 0398, 0399, 039A, 039B, 039C, 039D, 039E, 039F, 03A0, 03A1, 03A3, 03A4, 03A5, 03A6, 03A7, 03A8, 03A9, 03AA, 03AB, 03B0, 03C2, 03CF, 03D0, 03D1, 03D5, 03D6, 03D8, 03DA, 03DC, 03DE, 03E0, 03E2, 03E4, 03E6, 03E8, 03EA, 03EC, 03EE, 03F0, 03F1, 03F4, 03F5, 03F7, 03F9, 03FA, 03FD, 03FE, 03FF, 0400, 0401, 0402, 0403, 0404, 0405, 0406, 0407, 0408, 0409, 040A, 040B, 040C, 040D, 040E, 040F, 0410, 0411, 0412, 0413, 0414, 0415, 0416, 0417, 0418, 0419, 041A, 041B, 041C, 041D, 041E, 041F, 0420, 0421, 0422, 0423, 0424, 0425, 0426, 0427, 0428, 0429, 042A, 042B, 042C, 042D, 042E, 042F, 0460, 0462, 0464, 0466, 0468, 046A, 046C, 046E, 0470, 0472, 0474, 0476, 0478, 047A, 047C, 047E, 0480, 048A, 048C, 048E, 0490, 0492, 0494, 0496, 0498, 049A, 049C, 049E, 04A0, 04A2, 04A4, 04A6, 04A8, 04AA, 04AC, 04AE, 04B0, 04B2, 04B4, 04B6, 04B8, 04BA, 04BC, 04BE, 04C0, 04C1, 04C3, 04C5, 04C7, 04C9, 04CB, 04CD, 04D0, 04D2, 04D4, 04D6, 04D8, 04DA, 04DC, 04DE, 04E0, 04E2, 04E4, 04E6, 04E8, 04EA, 04EC, 04EE, 04F0, 04F2, 04F4, 04F6, 04F8, 04FA, 04FC, 04FE, 0500, 0502, 0504, 0506, 0508, 050A, 050C, 050E, 0510, 0512, 0514, 0516, 0518, 051A, 051C, 051E, 0520, 0522, 0524, 0526, 0528, 052A, 052C, 052E, 0531, 0532, 0533, 0534, 0535, 0536, 0537, 0538, 0539, 053A, 053B, 053C, 053D, 053E, 053F, 0540, 0541, 0542, 0543, 0544, 0545, 0546, 0547, 0548, 0549, 054A, 054B, 054C, 054D, 054E, 054F, 0550, 0551, 0552, 0553, 0554, 0555, 0556, 0587, 10A0, 10A1, 10A2, 10A3, 10A4, 10A5, 10A6, 10A7, 10A8, 10A9, 10AA, 10AB, 10AC, 10AD, 10AE, 10AF, 10B0, 10B1, 10B2, 10B3, 10B4, 10B5, 10B6, 10B7, 10B8, 10B9, 10BA, 10BB, 10BC, 10BD, 10BE, 10BF, 10C0, 10C1, 10C2, 10C3, 10C4, 10C5, 10C7, 10CD, 13F8, 13F9, 13FA, 13FB, 13FC, 13FD, 1C80, 1C81, 1C82, 1C83, 1C84, 1C85, 1C86, 1C87, 1C88, 1C90, 1C91, 1C92, 1C93, 1C94, 1C95, 1C96, 1C97, 1C98, 1C99, 1C9A, 1C9B, 1C9C, 1C9D, 1C9E, 1C9F, 1CA0, 1CA1, 1CA2, 1CA3, 1CA4, 1CA5, 1CA6, 1CA7, 1CA8, 1CA9, 1CAA, 1CAB, 1CAC, 1CAD, 1CAE, 1CAF, 1CB0, 1CB1, 1CB2, 1CB3, 1CB4, 1CB5, 1CB6, 1CB7, 1CB8, 1CB9, 1CBA, 1CBD, 1CBE, 1CBF, 1E00, 1E02, 1E04, 1E06, 1E08, 1E0A, 1E0C, 1E0E, 1E10, 1E12, 1E14, 1E16, 1E18, 1E1A, 1E1C, 1E1E, 1E20, 1E22, 1E24, 1E26, 1E28, 1E2A, 1E2C, 1E2E, 1E30, 1E32, 1E34, 1E36, 1E38, 1E3A, 1E3C, 1E3E, 1E40, 1E42, 1E44, 1E46, 1E48, 1E4A, 1E4C, 1E4E, 1E50, 1E52, 1E54, 1E56, 1E58, 1E5A, 1E5C, 1E5E, 1E60, 1E62, 1E64, 1E66, 1E68, 1E6A, 1E6C, 1E6E, 1E70, 1E72, 1E74, 1E76, 1E78, 1E7A, 1E7C, 1E7E, 1E80, 1E82, 1E84, 1E86, 1E88, 1E8A, 1E8C, 1E8E, 1E90, 1E92, 1E94, 1E96, 1E97, 1E98, 1E99, 1E9A, 1E9B, 1E9E, 1E9E, 1EA0, 1EA2, 1EA4, 1EA6, 1EA8, 1EAA, 1EAC, 1EAE, 1EB0, 1EB2, 1EB4, 1EB6, 1EB8, 1EBA, 1EBC, 1EBE, 1EC0, 1EC2, 1EC4, 1EC6, 1EC8, 1ECA, 1ECC, 1ECE, 1ED0, 1ED2, 1ED4, 1ED6, 1ED8, 1EDA, 1EDC, 1EDE, 1EE0, 1EE2, 1EE4, 1EE6, 1EE8, 1EEA, 1EEC, 1EEE, 1EF0, 1EF2, 1EF4, 1EF6, 1EF8, 1EFA, 1EFC, 1EFE, 1F08, 1F09, 1F0A, 1F0B, 1F0C, 1F0D, 1F0E, 1F0F, 1F18, 1F19, 1F1A, 1F1B, 1F1C, 1F1D, 1F28, 1F29, 1F2A, 1F2B, 1F2C, 1F2D, 1F2E, 1F2F, 1F38, 1F39, 1F3A, 1F3B, 1F3C, 1F3D, 1F3E, 1F3F, 1F48, 1F49, 1F4A, 1F4B, 1F4C, 1F4D, 1F50, 1F52, 1F54, 1F56, 1F59, 1F5B, 1F5D, 1F5F, 1F68, 1F69, 1F6A, 1F6B, 1F6C, 1F6D, 1F6E, 1F6F, 1F80, 1F81, 1F82, 1F83, 1F84, 1F85, 1F86, 1F87, 1F88, 1F88, 1F89, 1F89, 1F8A, 1F8A, 1F8B, 1F8B, 1F8C, 1F8C, 1F8D, 1F8D, 1F8E, 1F8E, 1F8F, 1F8F, 1F90, 1F91, 1F92, 1F93, 1F94, 1F95, 1F96, 1F97, 1F98, 1F98, 1F99, 1F99, 1F9A, 1F9A, 1F9B, 1F9B, 1F9C, 1F9C, 1F9D, 1F9D, 1F9E, 1F9E, 1F9F, 1F9F, 1FA0, 1FA1, 1FA2, 1FA3, 1FA4, 1FA5, 1FA6, 1FA7, 1FA8, 1FA8, 1FA9, 1FA9, 1FAA, 1FAA, 1FAB, 1FAB, 1FAC, 1FAC, 1FAD, 1FAD, 1FAE, 1FAE, 1FAF, 1FAF, 1FB2, 1FB3, 1FB4, 1FB6, 1FB7, 1FB8, 1FB9, 1FBA, 1FBB, 1FBC, 1FBC, 1FBE, 1FC2, 1FC3, 1FC4, 1FC6, 1FC7, 1FC8, 1FC9, 1FCA, 1FCB, 1FCC, 1FCC, 1FD2, 1FD3, 1FD6, 1FD7, 1FD8, 1FD9, 1FDA, 1FDB, 1FE2, 1FE3, 1FE4, 1FE6, 1FE7, 1FE8, 1FE9, 1FEA, 1FEB, 1FEC, 1FF2, 1FF3, 1FF4, 1FF6, 1FF7, 1FF8, 1FF9, 1FFA, 1FFB, 1FFC, 1FFC, 2126, 212A, 212B, 2132, 2160, 2161, 2162, 2163, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2168, 2169, 216A, 216B, 216C, 216D, 216E, 216F, 2183, 24B6, 24B7, 24B8, 24B9, 24BA, 24BB, 24BC, 24BD, 24BE, 24BF, 24C0, 24C1, 24C2, 24C3, 24C4, 24C5, 24C6, 24C7, 24C8, 24C9, 24CA, 24CB, 24CC, 24CD, 24CE, 24CF, 2C00, 2C01, 2C02, 2C03, 2C04, 2C05, 2C06, 2C07, 2C08, 2C09, 2C0A, 2C0B, 2C0C, 2C0D, 2C0E, 2C0F, 2C10, 2C11, 2C12, 2C13, 2C14, 2C15, 2C16, 2C17, 2C18, 2C19, 2C1A, 2C1B, 2C1C, 2C1D, 2C1E, 2C1F, 2C20, 2C21, 2C22, 2C23, 2C24, 2C25, 2C26, 2C27, 2C28, 2C29, 2C2A, 2C2B, 2C2C, 2C2D, 2C2E, 2C60, 2C62, 2C63, 2C64, 2C67, 2C69, 2C6B, 2C6D, 2C6E, 2C6F, 2C70, 2C72, 2C75, 2C7E, 2C7F, 2C80, 2C82, 2C84, 2C86, 2C88, 2C8A, 2C8C, 2C8E, 2C90, 2C92, 2C94, 2C96, 2C98, 2C9A, 2C9C, 2C9E, 2CA0, 2CA2, 2CA4, 2CA6, 2CA8, 2CAA, 2CAC, 2CAE, 2CB0, 2CB2, 2CB4, 2CB6, 2CB8, 2CBA, 2CBC, 2CBE, 2CC0, 2CC2, 2CC4, 2CC6, 2CC8, 2CCA, 2CCC, 2CCE, 2CD0, 2CD2, 2CD4, 2CD6, 2CD8, 2CDA, 2CDC, 2CDE, 2CE0, 2CE2, 2CEB, 2CED, 2CF2, 10400, 10401, 10402, 10403, 10404, 10405, 10406, 10407, 10408, 10409, 1040A, 1040B, 1040C, 1040D, 1040E, 1040F, 10410, 10411, 10412, 10413, 10414, 10415, 10416, 10417, 10418, 10419, 1041A, 1041B, 1041C, 1041D, 1041E, 1041F, 10420, 10421, 10422, 10423, 10424, 10425, 10426, 10427, 104B0, 104B1, 104B2, 104B3, 104B4, 104B5, 104B6, 104B7, 104B8, 104B9, 104BA, 104BB, 104BC, 104BD, 104BE, 104BF, 104C0, 104C1, 104C2, 104C3, 104C4, 104C5, 104C6, 104C7, 104C8, 104C9, 104CA, 104CB, 104CC, 104CD, 104CE, 104CF, 104D0, 104D1, 104D2, 104D3, 10C80, 10C81, 10C82, 10C83, 10C84, 10C85, 10C86, 10C87, 10C88, 10C89, 10C8A, 10C8B, 10C8C, 10C8D, 10C8E, 10C8F, 10C90, 10C91, 10C92, 10C93, 10C94, 10C95, 10C96, 10C97, 10C98, 10C99, 10C9A, 10C9B, 10C9C, 10C9D, 10C9E, 10C9F, 10CA0, 10CA1, 10CA2, 10CA3, 10CA4, 10CA5, 10CA6, 10CA7, 10CA8, 10CA9, 10CAA, 10CAB, 10CAC, 10CAD, 10CAE, 10CAF, 10CB0, 10CB1, 10CB2, 118A0, 118A1, 118A2, 118A3, 118A4, 118A5, 118A6, 118A7, 118A8, 118A9, 118AA, 118AB, 118AC, 118AD, 118AE, 118AF, 118B0, 118B1, 118B2, 118B3, 118B4, 118B5, 118B6, 118B7, 118B8, 118B9, 118BA, 118BB, 118BC, 118BD, 118BE, 118BF, 16E40, 16E41, 16E42, 16E43, 16E44, 16E45, 16E46, 16E47, 16E48, 16E49, 16E4A, 16E4B, 16E4C, 16E4D, 16E4E, 16E4F, 16E50, 16E51, 16E52, 16E53, 16E54, 16E55, 16E56, 16E57, 16E58, 16E59, 16E5A, 16E5B, 16E5C, 16E5D, 16E5E, 16E5F, 1E900, 1E901, 1E902, 1E903, 1E904, 1E905, 1E906, 1E907, 1E908, 1E909, 1E90A, 1E90B, 1E90C, 1E90D, 1E90E, 1E90F, 1E910, 1E911, 1E912, 1E913, 1E914, 1E915, 1E916, 1E917, 1E918, 1E919, 1E91A, 1E91B, 1E91C, 1E91D, 1E91E, 1E91F, 1E920, 1E921
```

#### Lowercase Codepoints

```
0061, 0062, 0063, 0064, 0065, 0066, 0067, 0068, 0069, 0131, 006A, 006B, 006C, 006D, 006E, 006F, 0070, 0071, 0072, 0073, 0074, 0075, 0076, 0077, 0078, 0079, 007A, 03BC, 00E0, 00E1, 00E2, 00E3, 00E4, 00E5, 00E6, 00E7, 00E8, 00E9, 00EA, 00EB, 00EC, 00ED, 00EE, 00EF, 00F0, 00F1, 00F2, 00F3, 00F4, 00F5, 00F6, 00F8, 00F9, 00FA, 00FB, 00FC, 00FD, 00FE, 0073 0073, 0101, 0103, 0105, 0107, 0109, 010B, 010D, 010F, 0111, 0113, 0115, 0117, 0119, 011B, 011D, 011F, 0121, 0123, 0125, 0127, 0129, 012B, 012D, 012F, 0069 0307, 0069, 0133, 0135, 0137, 013A, 013C, 013E, 0140, 0142, 0144, 0146, 0148, 02BC 006E, 014B, 014D, 014F, 0151, 0153, 0155, 0157, 0159, 015B, 015D, 015F, 0161, 0163, 0165, 0167, 0169, 016B, 016D, 016F, 0171, 0173, 0175, 0177, 00FF, 017A, 017C, 017E, 0073, 0253, 0183, 0185, 0254, 0188, 0256, 0257, 018C, 01DD, 0259, 025B, 0192, 0260, 0263, 0269, 0268, 0199, 026F, 0272, 0275, 01A1, 01A3, 01A5, 0280, 01A8, 0283, 01AD, 0288, 01B0, 028A, 028B, 01B4, 01B6, 0292, 01B9, 01BD, 01C6, 01C6, 01C9, 01C9, 01CC, 01CC, 01CE, 01D0, 01D2, 01D4, 01D6, 01D8, 01DA, 01DC, 01DF, 01E1, 01E3, 01E5, 01E7, 01E9, 01EB, 01ED, 01EF, 006A 030C, 01F3, 01F3, 01F5, 0195, 01BF, 01F9, 01FB, 01FD, 01FF, 0201, 0203, 0205, 0207, 0209, 020B, 020D, 020F, 0211, 0213, 0215, 0217, 0219, 021B, 021D, 021F, 019E, 0223, 0225, 0227, 0229, 022B, 022D, 022F, 0231, 0233, 2C65, 023C, 019A, 2C66, 0242, 0180, 0289, 028C, 0247, 0249, 024B, 024D, 024F, 03B9, 0371, 0373, 0377, 03F3, 03AC, 03AD, 03AE, 03AF, 03CC, 03CD, 03CE, 03B9 0308 0301, 03B1, 03B2, 03B3, 03B4, 03B5, 03B6, 03B7, 03B8, 03B9, 03BA, 03BB, 03BC, 03BD, 03BE, 03BF, 03C0, 03C1, 03C3, 03C4, 03C5, 03C6, 03C7, 03C8, 03C9, 03CA, 03CB, 03C5 0308 0301, 03C3, 03D7, 03B2, 03B8, 03C6, 03C0, 03D9, 03DB, 03DD, 03DF, 03E1, 03E3, 03E5, 03E7, 03E9, 03EB, 03ED, 03EF, 03BA, 03C1, 03B8, 03B5, 03F8, 03F2, 03FB, 037B, 037C, 037D, 0450, 0451, 0452, 0453, 0454, 0455, 0456, 0457, 0458, 0459, 045A, 045B, 045C, 045D, 045E, 045F, 0430, 0431, 0432, 0433, 0434, 0435, 0436, 0437, 0438, 0439, 043A, 043B, 043C, 043D, 043E, 043F, 0440, 0441, 0442, 0443, 0444, 0445, 0446, 0447, 0448, 0449, 044A, 044B, 044C, 044D, 044E, 044F, 0461, 0463, 0465, 0467, 0469, 046B, 046D, 046F, 0471, 0473, 0475, 0477, 0479, 047B, 047D, 047F, 0481, 048B, 048D, 048F, 0491, 0493, 0495, 0497, 0499, 049B, 049D, 049F, 04A1, 04A3, 04A5, 04A7, 04A9, 04AB, 04AD, 04AF, 04B1, 04B3, 04B5, 04B7, 04B9, 04BB, 04BD, 04BF, 04CF, 04C2, 04C4, 04C6, 04C8, 04CA, 04CC, 04CE, 04D1, 04D3, 04D5, 04D7, 04D9, 04DB, 04DD, 04DF, 04E1, 04E3, 04E5, 04E7, 04E9, 04EB, 04ED, 04EF, 04F1, 04F3, 04F5, 04F7, 04F9, 04FB, 04FD, 04FF, 0501, 0503, 0505, 0507, 0509, 050B, 050D, 050F, 0511, 0513, 0515, 0517, 0519, 051B, 051D, 051F, 0521, 0523, 0525, 0527, 0529, 052B, 052D, 052F, 0561, 0562, 0563, 0564, 0565, 0566, 0567, 0568, 0569, 056A, 056B, 056C, 056D, 056E, 056F, 0570, 0571, 0572, 0573, 0574, 0575, 0576, 0577, 0578, 0579, 057A, 057B, 057C, 057D, 057E, 057F, 0580, 0581, 0582, 0583, 0584, 0585, 0586, 0565 0582, 2D00, 2D01, 2D02, 2D03, 2D04, 2D05, 2D06, 2D07, 2D08, 2D09, 2D0A, 2D0B, 2D0C, 2D0D, 2D0E, 2D0F, 2D10, 2D11, 2D12, 2D13, 2D14, 2D15, 2D16, 2D17, 2D18, 2D19, 2D1A, 2D1B, 2D1C, 2D1D, 2D1E, 2D1F, 2D20, 2D21, 2D22, 2D23, 2D24, 2D25, 2D27, 2D2D, 13F0, 13F1, 13F2, 13F3, 13F4, 13F5, 0432, 0434, 043E, 0441, 0442, 0442, 044A, 0463, A64B, 10D0, 10D1, 10D2, 10D3, 10D4, 10D5, 10D6, 10D7, 10D8, 10D9, 10DA, 10DB, 10DC, 10DD, 10DE, 10DF, 10E0, 10E1, 10E2, 10E3, 10E4, 10E5, 10E6, 10E7, 10E8, 10E9, 10EA, 10EB, 10EC, 10ED, 10EE, 10EF, 10F0, 10F1, 10F2, 10F3, 10F4, 10F5, 10F6, 10F7, 10F8, 10F9, 10FA, 10FD, 10FE, 10FF, 1E01, 1E03, 1E05, 1E07, 1E09, 1E0B, 1E0D, 1E0F, 1E11, 1E13, 1E15, 1E17, 1E19, 1E1B, 1E1D, 1E1F, 1E21, 1E23, 1E25, 1E27, 1E29, 1E2B, 1E2D, 1E2F, 1E31, 1E33, 1E35, 1E37, 1E39, 1E3B, 1E3D, 1E3F, 1E41, 1E43, 1E45, 1E47, 1E49, 1E4B, 1E4D, 1E4F, 1E51, 1E53, 1E55, 1E57, 1E59, 1E5B, 1E5D, 1E5F, 1E61, 1E63, 1E65, 1E67, 1E69, 1E6B, 1E6D, 1E6F, 1E71, 1E73, 1E75, 1E77, 1E79, 1E7B, 1E7D, 1E7F, 1E81, 1E83, 1E85, 1E87, 1E89, 1E8B, 1E8D, 1E8F, 1E91, 1E93, 1E95, 0068 0331, 0074 0308, 0077 030A, 0079 030A, 0061 02BE, 1E61, 0073 0073, 00DF, 1EA1, 1EA3, 1EA5, 1EA7, 1EA9, 1EAB, 1EAD, 1EAF, 1EB1, 1EB3, 1EB5, 1EB7, 1EB9, 1EBB, 1EBD, 1EBF, 1EC1, 1EC3, 1EC5, 1EC7, 1EC9, 1ECB, 1ECD, 1ECF, 1ED1, 1ED3, 1ED5, 1ED7, 1ED9, 1EDB, 1EDD, 1EDF, 1EE1, 1EE3, 1EE5, 1EE7, 1EE9, 1EEB, 1EED, 1EEF, 1EF1, 1EF3, 1EF5, 1EF7, 1EF9, 1EFB, 1EFD, 1EFF, 1F00, 1F01, 1F02, 1F03, 1F04, 1F05, 1F06, 1F07, 1F10, 1F11, 1F12, 1F13, 1F14, 1F15, 1F20, 1F21, 1F22, 1F23, 1F24, 1F25, 1F26, 1F27, 1F30, 1F31, 1F32, 1F33, 1F34, 1F35, 1F36, 1F37, 1F40, 1F41, 1F42, 1F43, 1F44, 1F45, 03C5 0313, 03C5 0313 0300, 03C5 0313 0301, 03C5 0313 0342, 1F51, 1F53, 1F55, 1F57, 1F60, 1F61, 1F62, 1F63, 1F64, 1F65, 1F66, 1F67, 1F00 03B9, 1F01 03B9, 1F02 03B9, 1F03 03B9, 1F04 03B9, 1F05 03B9, 1F06 03B9, 1F07 03B9, 1F00 03B9, 1F80, 1F01 03B9, 1F81, 1F02 03B9, 1F82, 1F03 03B9, 1F83, 1F04 03B9, 1F84, 1F05 03B9, 1F85, 1F06 03B9, 1F86, 1F07 03B9, 1F87, 1F20 03B9, 1F21 03B9, 1F22 03B9, 1F23 03B9, 1F24 03B9, 1F25 03B9, 1F26 03B9, 1F27 03B9, 1F20 03B9, 1F90, 1F21 03B9, 1F91, 1F22 03B9, 1F92, 1F23 03B9, 1F93, 1F24 03B9, 1F94, 1F25 03B9, 1F95, 1F26 03B9, 1F96, 1F27 03B9, 1F97, 1F60 03B9, 1F61 03B9, 1F62 03B9, 1F63 03B9, 1F64 03B9, 1F65 03B9, 1F66 03B9, 1F67 03B9, 1F60 03B9, 1FA0, 1F61 03B9, 1FA1, 1F62 03B9, 1FA2, 1F63 03B9, 1FA3, 1F64 03B9, 1FA4, 1F65 03B9, 1FA5, 1F66 03B9, 1FA6, 1F67 03B9, 1FA7, 1F70 03B9, 03B1 03B9, 03AC 03B9, 03B1 0342, 03B1 0342 03B9, 1FB0, 1FB1, 1F70, 1F71, 03B1 03B9, 1FB3, 03B9, 1F74 03B9, 03B7 03B9, 03AE 03B9, 03B7 0342, 03B7 0342 03B9, 1F72, 1F73, 1F74, 1F75, 03B7 03B9, 1FC3, 03B9 0308 0300, 03B9 0308 0301, 03B9 0342, 03B9 0308 0342, 1FD0, 1FD1, 1F76, 1F77, 03C5 0308 0300, 03C5 0308 0301, 03C1 0313, 03C5 0342, 03C5 0308 0342, 1FE0, 1FE1, 1F7A, 1F7B, 1FE5, 1F7C 03B9, 03C9 03B9, 03CE 03B9, 03C9 0342, 03C9 0342 03B9, 1F78, 1F79, 1F7C, 1F7D, 03C9 03B9, 1FF3, 03C9, 006B, 00E5, 214E, 2170, 2171, 2172, 2173, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 217A, 217B, 217C, 217D, 217E, 217F, 2184, 24D0, 24D1, 24D2, 24D3, 24D4, 24D5, 24D6, 24D7, 24D8, 24D9, 24DA, 24DB, 24DC, 24DD, 24DE, 24DF, 24E0, 24E1, 24E2, 24E3, 24E4, 24E5, 24E6, 24E7, 24E8, 24E9, 2C30, 2C31, 2C32, 2C33, 2C34, 2C35, 2C36, 2C37, 2C38, 2C39, 2C3A, 2C3B, 2C3C, 2C3D, 2C3E, 2C3F, 2C40, 2C41, 2C42, 2C43, 2C44, 2C45, 2C46, 2C47, 2C48, 2C49, 2C4A, 2C4B, 2C4C, 2C4D, 2C4E, 2C4F, 2C50, 2C51, 2C52, 2C53, 2C54, 2C55, 2C56, 2C57, 2C58, 2C59, 2C5A, 2C5B, 2C5C, 2C5D, 2C5E, 2C61, 026B, 1D7D, 027D, 2C68, 2C6A, 2C6C, 0251, 0271, 0250, 0252, 2C73, 2C76, 023F, 0240, 2C81, 2C83, 2C85, 2C87, 2C89, 2C8B, 2C8D, 2C8F, 2C91, 2C93, 2C95, 2C97, 2C99, 2C9B, 2C9D, 2C9F, 2CA1, 2CA3, 2CA5, 2CA7, 2CA9, 2CAB, 2CAD, 2CAF, 2CB1, 2CB3, 2CB5, 2CB7, 2CB9, 2CBB, 2CBD, 2CBF, 2CC1, 2CC3, 2CC5, 2CC7, 2CC9, 2CCB, 2CCD, 2CCF, 2CD1, 2CD3, 2CD5, 2CD7, 2CD9, 2CDB, 2CDD, 2CDF, 2CE1, 2CE3, 2CEC, 2CEE, 2CF3, 10428, 10429, 1042A, 1042B, 1042C, 1042D, 1042E, 1042F, 10430, 10431, 10432, 10433, 10434, 10435, 10436, 10437, 10438, 10439, 1043A, 1043B, 1043C, 1043D, 1043E, 1043F, 10440, 10441, 10442, 10443, 10444, 10445, 10446, 10447, 10448, 10449, 1044A, 1044B, 1044C, 1044D, 1044E, 1044F, 104D8, 104D9, 104DA, 104DB, 104DC, 104DD, 104DE, 104DF, 104E0, 104E1, 104E2, 104E3, 104E4, 104E5, 104E6, 104E7, 104E8, 104E9, 104EA, 104EB, 104EC, 104ED, 104EE, 104EF, 104F0, 104F1, 104F2, 104F3, 104F4, 104F5, 104F6, 104F7, 104F8, 104F9, 104FA, 104FB, 10CC0, 10CC1, 10CC2, 10CC3, 10CC4, 10CC5, 10CC6, 10CC7, 10CC8, 10CC9, 10CCA, 10CCB, 10CCC, 10CCD, 10CCE, 10CCF, 10CD0, 10CD1, 10CD2, 10CD3, 10CD4, 10CD5, 10CD6, 10CD7, 10CD8, 10CD9, 10CDA, 10CDB, 10CDC, 10CDD, 10CDE, 10CDF, 10CE0, 10CE1, 10CE2, 10CE3, 10CE4, 10CE5, 10CE6, 10CE7, 10CE8, 10CE9, 10CEA, 10CEB, 10CEC, 10CED, 10CEE, 10CEF, 10CF0, 10CF1, 10CF2, 118C0, 118C1, 118C2, 118C3, 118C4, 118C5, 118C6, 118C7, 118C8, 118C9, 118CA, 118CB, 118CC, 118CD, 118CE, 118CF, 118D0, 118D1, 118D2, 118D3, 118D4, 118D5, 118D6, 118D7, 118D8, 118D9, 118DA, 118DB, 118DC, 118DD, 118DE, 118DF, 16E60, 16E61, 16E62, 16E63, 16E64, 16E65, 16E66, 16E67, 16E68, 16E69, 16E6A, 16E6B, 16E6C, 16E6D, 16E6E, 16E6F, 16E70, 16E71, 16E72, 16E73, 16E74, 16E75, 16E76, 16E77, 16E78, 16E79, 16E7A, 16E7B, 16E7C, 16E7D, 16E7E, 16E7F, 1E922, 1E923, 1E924, 1E925, 1E926, 1E927, 1E928, 1E929, 1E92A, 1E92B, 1E92C, 1E92D, 1E92E, 1E92F, 1E930, 1E931, 1E932, 1E933, 1E934, 1E935, 1E936, 1E937, 1E938, 1E939, 1E93A, 1E93B, 1E93C, 1E93D, 1E93E, 1E93F, 1E940, 1E941, 1E942, 1E943
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Your program's encoding doesn't necessarily have to map to ASCII/Unicode one-to-one to determine which characters to remove, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Would it help to have answers specify their encodings, and different encodings in the same language compete separately?

Comment: What happens if the program doesn't contain uppercase character?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Then there would be no way to know whether to lowercase the output or leave it unchanged.

Comment: @darrylyeo I think you need to make it a little more clear that there are three cases.

Comment: Google traslate thought that this question is in Vietnamese.

Comment: Really interesting challenge. It basically boils down to: 1) write a program with no uppercase letters that lowercases; 2) write a program with no lowercase letters that uppercases; 3) combine those two. I'm not sure if 1 and 2 are possible in JavaScript. I can write a function write iterates over a string and does something depending on the case of each letter, but I can't yet think of how to actually convert a 'c' into a 'C' without using a function like `toUpperCase()` etc.

Comment: It may be a good idea to allow functions as well, since a lot of languages are unable to print or read input without using letters (also there are already a few answers which use functions instead of programs).

Comment: IMO, When someone try to design a programming language, using any features based on lower / upper case letters is [a bad idea](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5763).

Comment: Now claim `壹` is uppercase of `一`

Comment: What characters do we have to handle in the input? Just letters? Or is anything fair game?

Comment: @dfeuer You must transform the basic Latin characters `[A-Za-z]`. Any characters beyond that range is optional.

Comment: So it would be okay to transform "$#47" into "zxpq", or error out?

Comment: is `,.` in brainfuck a valid solution?

Comment: @dfeuer Can you clarify what you mean? By default, the program should output its input unchanged.

Comment: The question is whether we're required to handle input other than upper and lower case ASCII.

Comment: @dfeuer Input characters without uppercase/lowercase counterparts should be left unchanged in the output. So `$#47` should transform into `$#47` in all three cases as none of those characters have uppercase/lowercase counterparts.

Answer (score 20):

## perl -p, 37 bytes

```
goto Aa_;A_:$_="\U$_";a_:$_=lc$_;Aa_:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z89vyRfwTEx3tox3kol3lYpJlQlXsk6EczJSVYBigPZ//97pObk5OsolOcX5aT8yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA)

Removing all lowercase letters leaves:

```
 A_;A_:$_="\U$_";_:$_=$_;A_:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/BMd7aMd5KJd5WKSZUJV7JGsxWAQv@/@@RmpOTr6NQnl@Uk/Ivv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA)

Removing the upper case letters leaves:

```
goto a_;_:$_="\$_";a_:$_=lc$_;a_:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z89vyRfITHeOt5KJd5WKUYlXsk6EczOSVaJBzH///dIzcnJ11Eozy/KSfmXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

How it works? With nothing removed, control jumps to the end, leaving the input unmodified.

With the lowercase letters removed, we have the string `A_` in void context (nothing happens), and then at label `A_`, we upper case the string, at label `_`, we have a no-op (assigning `$_` to itself), and an empty statement at label `A_`. Finally, the result is printed.

With the upper case letters removed, we jump to label `a_`, which lower cases the string, and the result is printed.

Answer (score 16):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 20 bytes

```perl
$_=0xE0?$_:lc"\lU$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagwtXAXiXeKidZKSYnVCVe6f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwUxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

[With all uppercase removed.](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagwsBeJd4qJ1kpJkclXun/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFMV/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

[With all lowercase removed.](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbA1cBeJd5KKSZUJV7p/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBTFf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

### Explanation

Because we're using the `-p` flag, the input is placed in`$_` implicitly and `$_` is printed implicitly when the program terminates.

In the unmodified program, this checks `0xE0`, which is `224`, for truthiness and sets `$_` to itself.

When all uppercase characters are removed `0xE0` becomes `0x0` which is `0` and the else block is reached which sets `$_` to `lc"\l$_"`. `lc` is Perl's lowercase function and converts the string to lowercase. `\l` is a string modifier that changes the immediately following character to lowercase, but this is irrelevant since it'll be lowered by the function call anyway.

When all lowercase characters are removed, `0xE0` becomes `0E0` which is `0` again, hitting the else block. Here we set `$_` to `"\U$_"`. `\U` is a strong modifier that makes the following part of the string uppercase.

Comment: Do you need the `lc` call? Seems like the `\l` handles that anyway.

Comment: @Neil Unfortunately `\L` lowercases the whole string, `\l` only does the character immediately to the right: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCkmJ8Q1OETp/38A "Perl 5 – Try It Online").

Comment: Ah, so the `l` is just a placeholder basically, so that there's still something after the `\\`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I tried to avoid having anything there but couldn't see a nice way to do it...

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Unmodified function:

```apl
'AAb'≢⍛⊃⊂,⍨⌊⍮⌈
```

Leaves argument untouched: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X93RMUn9UeeiR72zH3U1P@pq0nnUu@JRT9ej3nWPejr@pz1qm/Cotw8k1bvmUe@WQ@uNH7VNfNQ3NTjIGUiGeHgG/09TUPdIzcnJ11Eozy/KSVFUBwA)

Without lowercase letters:

```apl
'AA'≢⍛⊃⊂,⍨⌊⍮⌈
```

Uppercase argument: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X93RUf1R56JHvbMfdTU/6mrSedS74lFP16PedY96Ov6nPWqb8Ki3DyTVu@ZR75ZD640ftU181Dc1OMgZSIZ4eAb/T1NQ90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUVQHAA)

Without uppercase letters:

```apl
'b'≢⍛⊃⊂,⍨⌊⍮⌈
```

Lowercases letters: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/Xz1J/VHnoke9sx91NT/qatJ51LviUU/Xo951j3o6/qc9apvwqLcPJNW75lHvlkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv9PU1D3SM3JyddRKM8vyklRVAcA)

---

`⌈` the uppercased argument; `"HELLO, WORLD!"`

`⍮` pair to:

`⌊` the lowercased argument; `[hello, world!","HELLO, WORLD!"]`

`,⍨` append:

`⊂` the entire argument; `[hello, world!","HELLO, WORLD!","Hello, world!"]`

`⊃` pick element number:

`≢⍛` the length of:

`'AAb'`/`'AA'`/`'b'` these three strings, i.e. number 3/2/1

Answer (score 11):

### Javascript 192 characters (without `\123` literals)

```
$=>'Aa'[1]?$:'a'?$['to\u004cower\u0043ase']():
z/A/g&&([,A,,S,E,,O,,,,C]=!1+{},[T,R]=!0+$,[U,N,,,,I]=1[0]+$,$[T+O+'U'+1199331[T+O+'S'+T+R+I+N+($[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R]+$)[14]](36)+'C'+A+S+E]())
```

### Javascript 197 characters (without `\123` literals)

```
$=>'Aa'[1]?$:'a'?$['to\u004cower\u0043ase']():
z/A/g&&([,O,,,E,C]={}+$,[,A,,S]=!1+$,[T,R]=!0+$,[U,N,,,,I]=1[0]+$,$[T+O+'U'+1199331[T+O+'S'+T+R+I+N+($[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R]+$)[14]](36)+'C'+A+S+E]())
```

### Javascript 204 <s>208</s> <s>226</s> <s>234</s> characters (without `\123` numeric literals)

```
$=>'Aa'[1]?$:'a'?$['to\u004cower\u0043ase']():
a/A/g&&([,O,,,E,C]=JSON+$,[,A,,S]=!1+$,[T,R]=!0+$,[U,N,,,,I]=1[0]+$,P=25[T+O+'S'+T+R+I+N+($[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R]+$)[14]](36),$[T+O+'U'+P+P+E+R+'C'+A+S+E]())
```

```js
r=
$=>'Aa'[1]?$:'a'?$['to\u004cower\u0043ase']():z/A/g&&([,A,,S,E,,O,,,,C]=!1+{},[T,R]=!0+$,[U,N,,,,I]=1[0]+$,$[T+O+'U'+1199331[T+O+'S'+T+R+I+N+($[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R]+$)[14]](36)+'C'+A+S+E]())


console.log(eval(String(r))('Sentence Case'));
console.log(eval(String(r).replace(/[A-Z]/g, ''))('Lower Case'));
console.log(eval(String(r).replace(/[a-z]/g, ''))('Upper Case'));
```

I didn't realise that you could make arbitrary characters with `\123`. It's a much more interesting challenge without :)

A couple of comments:

- Some of the concepts are inspired by JSFuck, although the constraints are different. There is fortunately one global object whose name is entirely upper case letters, JSON, so we can directly harvest quite a few letters from `[object JSON]`
- Other letters come from `true`, `false` and `undefined`. We take the letters we need to write `constructor`, which then means we can find the string representation of a random string's constructor, which starts `function String() {...`
- That `g` is the last ingredient we need to then form the method name `toString()`, which in base 36 lets us turn any number into an equivalent lowercase letter.

The only other thing of note here is that once we remove all the uppercase letters from this branch path, it's not syntactically correct. So we turn it all into a `//` comment with a regex `/A/g` which turns into a comment. We end up with three completely different syntaxes for the three modes:

- No removals: `a/A/g&&(...` one undefined variable divided by another by another.
- Remove lower case: `/A/&&(...` a regex (always truthy) and the rest of the expression
- Remove upper case: `a//g&&...` an undefined variable and a comment.

### Javascript 272 characters

```
$=>'Aa'=='\u0041\u0061'?$:'a'=='\u0061'?eval('$.to\u0055pper\u0043ase()'):(
[,O,,,E,C]=JSON+'',
[,A,,S]=(''+!1),
[T,R]=(''+!0),
[U,N,,,,I]=(''+1[0]),
Ka=Ca+Oa+Na+Sa+Ta+Ra+Ua+Ca+Ta+Oa+Ra,
Ga=(''[Ka]+'')[14],
$[Ta+Oa+'L'+Oa+(32)[Ta+Oa+'S'+Ta+Ra+Ia+Na+Ga](36)+Ea+Ra+'C'+Aa+Sa+Ea]())
```

(Linebreaks inserted for readability)

Room to golf, but pretty excited that it even works. Took a lot of inspiration from JSFuck.

Whoops, I realised I got the functionality backwards: when you remove uppercase letters it uppercases, etc.

Comment: Can you write `pper` together?

Comment: how do you mean? P,E and R are three different variables..

Comment: I mean `$[T+O+'U'+697947..toString(30)+'C'+A+S+E]`

Comment: Also why use `JSON` rather than `{}`?

Comment: Also claiming `(without \123 numeric literals` seems random assumption, does it work on strict mode?

Comment: Good point @l4m2

Comment: Also thanks, now I get what you mean about PPER - that helps!

Comment: Also - yeah, the without \123 literals is a totally arbitrary constraint, that came about because I didn't know about them. And the challenge is just so much more interesting this way. Probably I should not use the `\u0099` literals either, to be slightly less arbitrary.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Byte-count more than halved (-11) thanks to *@Dorian*!

Full program:

```
lIq.•L•.V
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/x7NQ71HDIh8g1gv7/98jNScnX0ehPL8oJ0URAA)

With uppercase characters removed; outputting in lowercase:

```
lq.••.
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/p1DvUcMiINL7/98jNScnX0ehPL8oJ0URAA)

With lowercase characters removed; outputting in uppercase:

```
I.•L•.V
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fU@9RwyIfINYL@//fIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFEQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
          # Full program:
l         #  Lowercase the (implicit) input
 I        #  Push the input again
  q       #  Stop the program, after which the top of the stack is output implicitly
   .•L•.V #  No-ops

          # Program with uppercase characters removed:
l         #  Lowercase the (implicit) input
 q        #  Stop the program, after which the top of the stack is output implicitly
  .••.    #  No-ops

          # Program with lowercase characters removed:
I         #  Push the input
 .•L•     #  Push compressed string "u"
     .V   #  Evaluate/execute it as 05AB1E code; uppercase the (implicit) input
          #  (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•L•` is `"u"`.

Comment: Why do you push the compressed string "chr" when you could simply push the compressed String "l" (lowercase L)? `uIq.•C•.V`

Comment: I think the question is asking for the opposite way around: when lowercase characters are removed the output should be uppercased, not lowercased, and vice versa. I believe `lIq.•L•.V` should do that for you

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, 107 characters

```bash
cC=echoECHO
cC=${cC,,}
cC=${cC::4}
[ c ]||cC+=(${@^^})
[ C ]||cC+=(${@,,})
[[ cC = ?? ]]&&cC+=($@)
${cC[@]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY8/b8IwFMR3f4orijBRk06dorhEspDYGDp0iIwUHLeJZHDkGDpAPntq6J80qJXa7fneu7ufN0Vb9bJweICx9Uu9K/RdWyFN6WL1SHvJmZKVWfDlivg5OEoeRd3nmCT3HckhIU4nyW/ZLDhm63UXeo1/17zFa/6Qg2E@hxDT6fsuC8k5KM9E1/tCQs5toHEcM5Z/EaGVtm4cEuz9yymrSgjG/BUlG/@BEfokyCZXOfumUVYWrYJWzttbWLU1B5/ybM0WrlJDgzS7g7KuhTPQ5vXDN2pLZ3AWcQmaJ5foRFCkI4jwJ4wh7n8YA/6vGJfoP2BQ0vdLpbWJ8GSsLm/eAA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 106 bytes

**Full version:**

```ruby
$_=[*$<]*''
$.=0
o_=97
O_=65
@_=->{$_[__=''<<$.+_]?$_[__]=''<<$.+(_^32):$.+=1;$.<27&&@_[]}
_&&=@_[]
$><<$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeNlpLxSZWS12dS0XP1oArP97W0pzLP97WzJTLId5W165aJT46Pt5WXd3GRkVPOz7WHsyPhQloxMcZG2laAVm2htYqejZG5mpqDvHRsbVc8WpqtiAWl4odUGX8//8eqTk5@ToK5flFOSmKXKF5OZm5mSWpKQoB/uGuQQA)

**Uppercase:**

```ruby
$_=[*$<]*''
$.=0
_=97
O_=65
@_=->{$_[__=''<<$.+_]?$_[__]=''<<$.+(_^32):$.+=1;$.<27&&@_[]}
_&&=@_[]
$><<$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeNlpLxSZWS12dS0XP1oAr3tbSnMs/3tbMlMsh3lbXrlolPjo@3lZd3cZGRU87PtYezI@FCWjExxkbaVoBWbaG1ip6NkbmamoO8dGxtVzxamq2IBaXih1QZfz//x6pOTn5Ogrl@UU5KYpcoXk5mbmZJakpCgH@4a5BAA)

**Lowercase:**

```ruby
$_=[*$<]*''
$.=0
o_=97
_=65
@_=->{$_[__=''<<$.+_]?$_[__]=''<<$.+(_^32):$.+=1;$.<27&&@_[]}
_&&=@_[]
$><<$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeNlpLxSZWS12dS0XP1oArP97W0pwr3tbMlMsh3lbXrlolPjo@3lZd3cZGRU87PtYezI@FCWjExxkbaVoBWbaG1ip6NkbmamoO8dGxtVzxamq2IBaXih1QZfz//x6pOTn5Ogrl@UU5KYpcoXk5mbmZJakpCgH@4a5BAA)

**Explanation:**

The verbose part here is all about the no-lower-case version. Avoiding lower-case characters means the string replacement needs to use the syntax `str[from] = to`, wrapped in a loop via a lambda that calls itself. The lambda is the variable `@_` defined using `@_=->`, and it's called via `@_[]`.

Stepping through...

`$_=[*$<]*''` : Read multiline input into the variable `$_`. (Depending on your interpretation of the spec, this could just be `$_,=*$<` for single-line input or even happen implicitly via the `-p` flag).

`$.=0`: Initialize the variable we'll be using to iterate over the letters of the alphabet.

`o_=97`: This initializes a variable that we never use. But if `o`, the only lower-case character in the program, is deleted, it's instead initializing `_`.

`O_=65`: Same but for upper-case.

`@_=->{`: Start the loop definition.

`$_[__=''<<$.+_]`: Check for the presence of a specific letter in the string (starting with "a".)

`?$_[__]=''<<$.+(_^32)`: If it's there, swap its case.

`:$.+=1`: Otherwise, move on to the next letter.

`$.<27&&@_[]}`: Either way, repeat the loop as long as we haven't reached the end of the alphabet.

`_&&=@_[]`: If `_` has been defined, run the loop. If it was defined as 97, we'll be caseswapping letters starting with 'a' (character code 97). If it was defined as 65, we'll start with 'A'.

`$><<$_`: Output.

Comment: The loop is genius. I like the workaround to avoid `-p` too.

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 68 bytes

```c
__(_,$){$="";_[""-$]&&__(_+1,_[""-$]^=_[""-$]-('Aa'^32u)<26U?32:0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDRCoIwFIbvfYrTENtIoRS6aEl01wtEF6JjrChhabjtSnz2paRFpNC5@s/Hz8fhiOAqhLWMYea7pHZjhChLEArc1PM6ulj5/Z7FfQjwfM/nWRQasg3Xx10UbpaENpaZUYmZlHSOL4XD5KhCTik@Z7wVeaHhzvMCE6gdaEdprnMB4sYrUEkKMaDDRcoSTmUlzzNEf1r6r5aZbLV/U4TCw2jVhRczWA9MD0xiM7A2OI19Ag)

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 66 bytes

```c
__(_,$){$="";""[$=_-$]&&__(_+1,""[$]^=""[$]-('Aa'^32u)<26U?32:0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDRCoIwFIbvfYrTGLqRQil00RrRXS8QXYiOYVHC0tDtSnz2pYVFpNC5OT8fPx@HkwWZksXFWiGI8DFtMEeIIRRjLgKcuG7P50u/J0nKnysg3k56aRQauglXh20UrheUtVaYCYUZVfSGL4Ej1IRAjQk@J7wFeaHhJvOCUGgc6KbWUucZZFdZQR0nwAHtz0qVcCwrdZoh9tPSf7XMZKv7V00Z3I2u@/BihuiB6YEpYgbWBae1Dw)

Thank @G.Sliepen for fixing code for tio and pointing that the optimize work on clang!

Comment: Tried on duck.ac with extra `__attribute__((optimize("-O0")))`, works fine

Comment: Very nice trick with `""-$` to get around the need for `char*`!

Comment: @G.Sliepen `$-'a'<26` is signed

Comment: @G.Sliepen If uppercase removed `26U` turns into `26`

Comment: Ah, never mind! I forgot about that.

Comment: can you please explain this one? I have no idea how this answer works

Comment: Some of the tricks used: in `_[""-$2]`, the only pointer is `""`, `$2` is an `int` but has the same value as the address of `""`, so they cancel each other and `""-$2` is basically `(char *)0`. Then, `_[""-$2]` is equivalent to `(""-$2)[_]`, so basically `(char *)0 + _`, which means we get character at address `_`. Then to check whether to change case, `'Aa'^32` is `'a'` for the upper case, `'A'` for the lower case variant, or >255 otherwise. `$-('Aa'^32u)<26U` subtracts the previous value from the current character, makes it unsigned, and if <26 it is a candidate for case change.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Why don't `""[_-$]` work same?

Comment: @l4m2 It works the same... when compiling with Clang. I think the main issue is that there is no guarantee that all four occurences of `""` point to the same memory location, and with GCC and `""[_-$]` that indeed isn't the case.

Comment: -2 bytes if you rename the function from `__` to `€`

Answer (score 8):

## perl -p, 19 bytes

```
$A_=lc$_;$a_="\U$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FMd42J1kl3lolMd5WKSZUJV7p/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinJR/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

A completely different solution than my earlier one. The program reads a line from the input (in the variable `$_`), does zero or more modifications, and prints that line (due to the `-p` flag). That is, it prints whatever ends up in `$_`.

As is, the input line isn't modified; its lower case variant is assigned to `$A_`, and its upper case variant to `$a_`, but both variables are otherwise ignored.

Removing the upper case letters gives us:

```
$_=lc$_;$a_="\$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYnWSXeWiUx3lYpRiVe6f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opyUf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Now, `$_` is set to the lower case variant of itself. The variable `$a_` is set to the literal string `$_`, but otherwise ignored.

If we remove the lowercase letters instead, we end up with:

```
$A_=$_;$_="\U$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FMd5WJd5aJd5WKSZUJV7p/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinJR/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Now we assign `$A_` the input line, and ignore this variable. `$_` is set to the uppercase variant of itself by using the special interpolation symbol `\U`, which upper cases the rest of the string, until it encounters `\E`, or the end of the string.

Comment: Very nice! ....

Comment: Just realised you could use `lcA` instead of`lc$_` for -1.

Answer (score 8):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 10 bytes

```
JZZzz#RjHD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fKyqqqko5KMvD5f9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA)

This was a very fun one to puzzle out.

Explanation:

```
J            # Duplicate the input
 ZZ          # Uppercase it
   zz        # Lowercase it
     #R      # Rotate the stack right
       j     # Swap the top two elements in the stack (back to the original order)
        HD   # Hide the top (modified) element, returning the original input
```

Removing the lowercase letters gives us:

```
JZZ#RHD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fKypKOcjD5f9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA)

Explanation:

```
J             # Duplicate the input
 ZZ           # Uppercase it
   #R         # Rotate the stack to the right
      HD      # Hide the top (unmodified) element, returning the modified input
```

And with uppercase letters removed:

```
zz#j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/qko56/9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA)

Explanation:

```
zz            # Lowercase the input
  #j          # Treats the stack as code to be run. Pops the string from the stack
              # and pushes it straight back in again to be implicitly output
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
uN‹ß⇧:[,]_⇩
```

[Full Program:](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=uN%E2%80%B9%C3%9F%E2%87%A7%3A%5B%2C%5D_%E2%87%A9&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

```
             # Implicit input, e.g. "Hello, World!"
uN‹          # Pushes '-1', negates it, and decrements, evaluating to `0`
   ß⇧        # Pops the top of the stack, and if it's truthy, converts the input to UPPERCASE. The top of the stack is '0', so this isn't executed
     :[,]    # Duplicates the top of the stack, and prints it if it is truthy, which it is
         _   # Discards the top of the stack
          ⇩  # Converts the input to lowercase
             # Implicit output is disabled

Output: Hello, World!
```

---

[UPPERCASE PROGRAM:](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=N%E2%80%B9%C3%9F%E2%87%A7%3A%5B%2C%5D_%E2%87%A9&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

```
            # Implicit input, e.g. "Hello, World!"
N‹          # Swaps the casing of the input and appends '-', evaluating to 'hELLO, wORLD!-'
  ß⇧        # Pops the top of the stack, and if it's truthy, converts the input to UPPERCASE. The top of the stack is a non-empty string, so this is executed
    :[,]    # Duplicates the top of the stack, and prints it if it is truthy, which it is
        _   # Discards the top of the stack
         ⇩  # Converts the input to lowercase
            # Implicit output is disabled

Output: HELLO, WORLD!
```

---

[lowercase program:](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=u%E2%80%B9%E2%87%A7%3A%5B%2C%5D_%E2%87%A9&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

````
           # Implicit input, e.g. "Hello, World!"
u‹         # Pushes '-1' and decrements, evaluating to '-2'
  ⇧        # Performs graded_up() on the top of the stack, evaluating to '0'
   :[,]    # Duplicates the top of the stack, and prints it if it is truthy. '0' is falsey, so it is not executed
       _   # Discards the top of the stack
        ⇩  # Convert the input to lowercase
           # Implicit output

Output: hello, world!
```
````

Answer (score 7):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 5 bytes

```
VgUu$
```

---

[Full Program:](https://tio.run/##K/v/Pyw9tFTl/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

```
V      # Enter Visual Line mode
 gU    # Change all characters to UPPERCASE
   u   # Undo
    $  # Go to end of line
```

---

[UPPERCASE PROGRAM:](https://tio.run/##K/v/PyxU5f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURQA)

```
V    # Enter Visual Line mode
 U   # Convert all characters to UPPERCASE
  $  # Go to end of line
```

---

[lowercase program:](https://tio.run/##K/v/P71U5f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURQA)

```
gu$  # Convert all letters to lowercase from here to end of line
```

Answer (score 5):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>114</s> 96 bytes

```
	OUTput =inPUT :(enD)
Den	OUTPUToutput =REPLACEreplace(INPUTinput,&LCASEucase,&UCASElcase)
END
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NKSgtETBNjMvIDREwUojNc9Fk8slNQ8kARTJLy0BSwe5Bvg4OrsWpRbkJCananj6AeUy84BSOmo@zo7BrqXJicWpOmqhIHYOiK3J5ernwpWal/L/v6OTcwoA)

[T  !](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NETBNgBIWGm4aHK5gPggnm2Qa4CPo7OrhqcfkKuj5uPsGOyqoxYKojS5XP1cuP7/d3RyTgEA)

[ry it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n7OgtETBNjNPwUojNU@TKzWPM7@0BCxWlFqQk5icqpGZB@TqqJUmJxan6qjlgChNLqDClP//HZ2cUwA)

(Ab)uses SNOBOL's case-insensitivity and GOTO labels.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```javascript
_=>_['A'?'slice'||'\164\157U\160\160\145\162C\141\163\145':'to\x4cower\103ase']()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYvdCoIwGIbPu5FvUv4staCwkK6hk5zIWN/EGE6cWIT3viYe1VkHL@/D@/PgIzeib7rBb/UdrcxslZ2qAnI4g1GNQJgmYHSXMJrurw6iRUnqfHtxQB3EcwAHGDR7JUI/sWc0irlBKIlnjyuhW6MVBkrXRBK5BvC87xRHrsjSBD12igskYZH7tzKsN/P8jxf3378v@wE)

Trivial one

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) work if `\123` was an error, 170 bytes

```javascript
$=_=>_['A'?'slice'||(/A/,[,A,,S,,,O,,,E,C]=!1+{},[T,R]=!0+_,[U,N]=_._+_,$[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R](`P='\\${U}0070'`)(),T+O+'U'+P+P+E+R+'C'+A+S+
Ea):'to\Zx4cower\Zx43ase']()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1Pa4NAEMXvfooUhNllxj@lhUKLLSLeShI0XrKKWbZLsIgrKmlpks9u11t6LMMwD@b33vuUJzmqoeknrzMfep7dqI5eawExvMHYNkrD5cKCOCBBMVFORBu7KSVVdHeP5yuJHWVWh1iTKGhdRbVfW@2KBDe4xhx3mGGBib0bzCp22EZQlu65uIbhUwgHzjgtLygAt3ZSi0MCGFurk0r@DJMp99@PynzpYREPctRQMT47jqNMN5pW@605MpdBrrtJd0qvkoXh/OUPoE@yZfk0NJ2FuT/ovpVKs0DE3r4KjrQCa2HwvhT9M0F6PzcJRd/fJMy/)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) strict, <s>186</s> 184 bytes

```javascript
(_,[,A,,S,,,O,,,E,C]=!1+{},[T,R]=!0+_,[U,N]=_._+_)=>0xE0?_:_['A'?(/A/,(_=>_)[C+O+N+S+T+R+U+C+T+O+R]('U',`U[0]='\\${U}0070'`)(U=[]),T+O+'U'+U+U+E+R+'C'+A+S+
Ea):'to\Zx4cower\Zx43ase']()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Ba4MwFMfvfoqsCEnIs2ZsMGhJi4i30UJtLo0hDS6UDlFR15WVfnYXb91xh8f7H37/3@N92ovty@7cDlHdfLhx9tU71A/duRxmS1S5AYVIoJEYUJAA5ACw9ZNBqsXTM7vdQe1h5zNnHpGw0cLMDTNUrPg142uzMAoneE3iJAZixMpQlbIt27Cc7dmOSZb6vWU7TbDEcJSKa4GLIrzJO@dvHB8pkUJpChPlEd@QLPNNnGKWeEuQWbrAQ1Mcrq9l8@26KbzY3mFN6BgEQdnUfVO5edWcSEhw7urB1aVD6cRQuvwDuIutSO7/rz1M551rK1s6EqskOuj4BAj7CsHv06F/Gmz082CQbftgGH8B)

Comment: Ha, well there's a technique that would have saved  me a lot of time and bytes if I'd known about it :)

Comment: Oh, clever idea with the `\\${U}0070`. I thought of something ilke that but couldn't quite figure out how the escaping would work.

Answer (score 5):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 243 bytes

```
{`+^^(_[0...#_]|{[[_,alpha[_2[ascii[33:58],_]]]["Z@"<_∧_<"["],NTS[20363848091226750223144960725905269888206028302]@_2[NTS[6060454347787589083238889994600682623947941084],_]]["z`"<_∧_<"{"]}&_2)}&({[`0,[$,`_3][_@_3=_2]][_3<#_][_,_2,_3+1]}&0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/PSsNAEMZfJa5SWrqEyczuZrekkKMnEfTksJ2E2tJAsFIDgrF338T38kXi6qHXj9/3rx2GdnvYTftstc6msVluNnNhyPP8WuLnyCy67V8PLQty@7btOiZaWR@1xBhZPdWqkp@vb6kUq6jvHh8YgRx54yEUiK60gEiFMcFBiTaARRe89wgO0BNgrFPyn88lxVhDpix9aX0AT0iJDCEYB@A8OqRgymAK8OZ/AKuP5tI/qnieCS7Os/nIDWi@0Y1QZKmF1oKJFqrSqfRIUAsti8TDYro/dS8D71nd7vr@qLP346l/vlIxTr8)

At first, I wasn't sure if it was possible. However, this is in fact possible due to two key factors:

1. We have a lot of symbols at our disposal, including variable names in lambdas being accessible entirely symbolically: `_`, `_2`, etc.
2. We have the `ascii` variable to work with while having access to lowercase letters, and `NTS` (**N**umber **T**o **S**tring) while having access to uppercase letters. The former is simply a string consisting of the ASCII bytes 32 to 126. The latter is a function that takes a number and gives a string representation of it. The first long number corresponds  to the uppercase alphabet, and the second to the lowercase one.

### Explanation

Now, for why this is such a troubling problem in this language. Attache functions are almost exclusively PascalCase, making them unsuitable for either computation. This means we do not have access to basic functions like string lookup, which we have to implement from scratch. This can be found at the end of the code:

```
{[`0,[$,`_3][_@_3=_2]][_3<#_][_,_2,_3+1]}&0
{                                       }&0    function with right parameter = 0
                                               parameters: string, search[, index = 0]
 [  ,                ][_3<#_]                  if index < length(string) then
     [ ,   ][_@_3=_2]                            if string[index] = search then
        `_3                                         yield a fn returning the index
      $                                          else yield this current function
  `0                                           else yield 0
                             [_,_2,_3+1]       call the result with the arguments, and index + 1
```

This snippet exhibits how we do conditional computation and recursion without letters. Thankfully, Attache has the Self reference `$`, which makes this leagues easier than it would be otherwise.

The main attraction takes this helper as a right argument, and is referenced (and passed manually down through scopes) as `_2`. I'll remove the body of the mapped function to explain how the main function works generally:

```
{`+^^(_[0...#_]|{-------}&_2)}&(-------)
                              &(-------)   saving the helper function as _2
{                            }             function taking a string as _
      _[0...#_]                            get characters of input
               |{-------}                  map each character by this function
                         &_2               (passing down _2)
 `+^^(                      )              fold concatenation, returning a string
```

Last, the function which tests each character and makes the conversion. The difference is made when testing for conditions. Two seperate conditions are checked:

1. `"Z@"<_∧_<"["`
2. `"z`"<*∧*<"{"`

Without any intervention, they both return false. We index into a nested array, obtaining `arr[0][0]`, in which is placed the input. So, by default, the input is unchanged.

When removing uppercase letters, the first condition will become true for uppercase letters. When removing lowercase letters, the second condition will become true for lowercase letters. So, we have that `arr[1]` corresponds to the lower-to-upper transformation, and `arr[0][1]` corresponds to the upper-to-lower transformation. This is seen in this structure, where we index by the comparison.

```
[[_,--------]["Z@"<_∧_<"["],--------]["z`"<_∧_<"{"]
```

Both transformations have the form:

```
Desired[_2[Source,Element]]
```

That is, they find the index in the alphabet the mapped element belongs to, then index that into the other alphabet. For upper-to-lower, we can use `alpha` and `ascii[33:58]` to obtain the lowercase and uppercase alphabets, respectively. For lower-to-upper, we can use `NTS` on `20363848091226750223144960725905269888206028302` and `6060454347787589083238889994600682623947941084` to obtain the uppercase and lowercase alphabets, respectively. (These numbers are obtained by inputting the desired string to `STN`).

And with that, the program functions in all three cases.

Answer (score 4):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

Turns out that `⟰` and `⟱` aren't implemented! That surely gives me a headache to implement that myself. (No TIO 'cuz the TIO interpreter has a bug. Use the offline interpreter instead.)

```
AAa!&ø?&¦3(:AZ•[ -]")|2(:za•[ +]")║_™^
```

### Explanation

```
AAa                                    # Push the "magic string"
   !                                   # Find the length
    &                                  # Save the result into the accumulator
     ø                                 # Clear the stack
      ?&                               # Take input, append accumulator value
        ¦3(:AZ•[ -]")|2(:za•[ +]")║_™  # Default condition: directly return the input
                                     ^ # Reverse the stack
```

No lowercase letters:

```
AA!                                 # Here, the length of the "magic string" is 2
   &ø?&                             # Same as above
       ¦3                           # If the length of the stack is 2:
         (                          # Do this for every stack item:
          :AZ•                      # Is this in the A-Z range?
              [ -]                  # If so, lowercase it
                  ")|2(:•[ +]")║_™^ # Same as above
```

No uppercase letters works similarly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 90 bytes

```hs
(<$>)__
__ _'|0XA<1&&_'>'@'&&_'<'['||0xa<1&&_'>'`'&&_'<'{'=([_'..'~']++['?'..])!!32|1<2=_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8NGxU4zPp4rPl4hXr3GIMLRxlBNLV7dTt1BHUTbqEer19QYVCTChBOgwtXqthrR8ep6eup16rHa2tHq9kB2rKaiorFRjaGNkW28@v/cxMw824LSkuCSIp88BRWFNAUlD6C1@ToK4flFOSmKSgr//yWn5SSmF//XTS4oAAA)

Comment: [82 bytes.](https://tio.run/##Fc0xDoJAEEDRnlMME5KRgCRiZ3YROgs7CwskIwFR4woEsIENR3fF6r/uP/L@dVPKVPJiVsKJXGaLGZg0U0Qx@UyCpn92OKPAJEWtU6YswvGKcrUwCGimzPNS2i/OXNvehnojQslk3vmzlmVjAbSf4TR0xxocqAAPy7Px4dx0qrTjZJzQfItK5fferIu2/QE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
≡_¦_a↥Ｓ_A↧θＳ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/7@4PLMkOUNBQyleSVOhmis5sThVQSk@UclKIaAoM69EI7SgILUIJKrhmVdQWhJcAhRN19DU1LSGqXWEq/XJL4eqLQTJp6SmJZbmlMBkUfVbc9X@/@@RmpOTr6NQnl@Uk6LI9V@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≡_
```

Switch on `_`.

```
_a↥Ｓ
```

If it equals `_a` (i.e. never) then print the input uppercased.

```
_A↧θ
```

If it equals `_A` (i.e. never) then print the input lowercased.

```
Ｓ
```

Otherwise print the input unchanged.

With uppercase characters (including `Ｓ`) removed:

```
≡_¦_a↥_↧θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R58L4Q8viEx@1LY1/1Lb83I7//z1Sc3LydRTK84tyUhS5AA) Explanation:

```
≡_
```

Switch on `_`.

```
_a↥_
```

If it equals `_a` (i.e. never) then print `_` uppercased.

```
↧θ
```

Otherwise print the input lowercased.

With lowercase characters (including `θ`) removed:

```
≡_¦_↥Ｓ_A↧Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R58L4Q8viH7Utfb9nc7zjo7blQPr/f4/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFEUuAA) Explanation:

```
≡_
```

Switch on `_`.

```
_↥Ｓ
```

If it equals `_` (i.e. always) then print the input uppercased.

```
_A↧Ｓ
```

If it equals `_A` (i.e. never) then print the input lowercased.

Obviously both programs still work if you only delete ASCII upper/lowercase characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 127 bytes

```r
aA=`\143`("\101-\132","\141-\172")
`\164`=1
`\143\141\164`(`\143\150\141\162\164\162`(aA[T+1],aA[t+1],`\163\143\141\156`(,"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9HRNiHG0MQ4QUMpxtDAUDfG0NhISQfINgGxzY2UNLmA8mYmCbaGXGCFIBmwgAaUa2oAFTICCYPoBI1Ex@gQbcNYHSBdAqJBRhgjdJuaJWjoKClpamr@90jNycnXUQjPL8pJUfwPAA)

This uses the [octal code trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191117/86301) to write most of the code without letters.

In its unaltered version, it is equivalent to

```r
aA=c("A-Z","a-z")
t=1
cat(chartr(aA[T+1],aA[t+1],scan(,"")))
```

Recall that `T` is the boolean `TRUE` and will be coerced to `1`, so we are calling `cat(chartr("a-z","a-z",scan(,"")))` which will leave the input unchanged.

### No lowercase

Remove the lowercase letters and you get code equivalent to

```r
A=c("A-Z","a-z")
t=1
cat(chartr(A[T+1],A[+1],scan(,"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39E2IcbQxDhBQynG0MBQN8bQ2EhJB8g2AbHNjZQ0uYDyZiYJtoZcYIUgGbCABpRragAVMgIJg@gEDcfoEG3DWB3HaBAJ0m@M0GpqlqCho6Skqan53yM1JydfRyE8vygnRfE/AA)

so we are calling `cat(chartr("a-z","A-Z",scan(,"")))`, which will convert to uppercase.

### No uppercase

Remove all uppercase characters and the code becomes equivalent to

```r
a=c("A-Z","a-z")
t=1
cat(chartr(a[+1],a[t+1],scan(,"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2IcbQxDhBQynG0MBQN8bQ2EhJB8g2AbHNjZQ0uYDyZiYJtoZcYIUgGbCABpRragAVMgIJg@gEjcRobcNYncToEhAF0m@M0GpqlqCho6Skqan53yM1JydfRyE8vygnRfE/AA)

This time, we are calling `cat(chartr("A-Z","a-z",scan(,"")))`, which converts to lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 30 bytes

```
:A&&1=$1:l
:a&&1=${(U)1}
<<<$1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhb7rBzV1AxtVQytcrisEsHMao1QTcNaLhsbGxVDiCKo2lXRSo5OzimpaUqxUBEA)

[A T O!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZ7rBzV1AxtVQytuKzAjGqNUE3DWi4bGxsVQ4gSqMpV0UqOTs4pqWlKsVARAA)

[ttempt his nline!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZ7rNTUDG1VDK1yuKwSwcxqDU3DWi4bGxsVQ4gSqMpV0UqOTs4pqWlKsVARAA)

`:` is a command which does nothing and always succeeds, but both `:A` and `:a` don't exist and always fail.

Conveniently, Zsh has two ways to change the case of a string: `${(U)string}`/`${(L)string}`, and `$string:u`/`$string:l`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (224 Bytes)

```
<?=!fPassthru(STDIN)&&0;__HALT_compiler();FUNCTIONfunction fPassthru(){returnRETURN STDIN;};functionFUNCTION __HALT_compiler(){ECHOecho                                                       STRTOUPPERstrtolower(STREAMstream_GETget_CONTENTScontents(Pfopen('php://stdin','r')));}
```

### Uppercase version

```
<?=!P(STDIN)&&0;__HALT_();FUNCTION P(){RETURN STDIN;};FUNCTION __HALT_(){ECHO STRTOUPPER(STREAM_GET_CONTENTS(P('://','')));}
```

### Lowercase version

```
<?=!fassthru()&&0;___compiler();function fassthru(){return ;};function ___compiler(){echo strtolower(stream_get_contents(fopen('php://stdin','r')));}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) [(PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 51 bytes

```
<aaA^:~@#
, >-\:'``\'{^
^ 1>\:'@`\'[>\`**' *+
^ 01>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3SUx0jLOqc1Dm0lGw042xUk9IiFGvjuOKUzC0A/IcgLxou5gELS11BS1toKiBod3//x6pOTn5CuH5RTkpigA)

[Try it online! (Uppercase letter removed)](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3SUyMs6pzUObSUbDTjbFST0iIUa@O44pTMLQD8hyAvGi7mAQtLXUFLW2gqIGh3f//Hqk5OfkK4flFOSmKAA)

[Try it online! (Lowercase letters removed)](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3cYyzqnNQ5tJRsNONsVJPSIhRr47jilMwtAPyHIC8aLuYBC0tdQUtbaCogaHd//8eqTk5@Qrh@UU5KYoA)

### Explanation

Without removing any characters, most of the code is never executed. The code that does get executed is

```
<   ^:~@#
,
^
^   >
```

This reads each character sequentially with `~`, duplicates it with `:`, and then prints the duplicate. Once the input runs out, `~` reflects the instruction pointer and `@` ends the program. A copy of the input string is left on the stack, but it never gets printed, so we don't care about it.

With the uppercase `A` removed, the `^` on the top line moves one space to the left and the third line is executed rather than the second.

```
<  ^:~@#
,
^  >\:'@`\'[>\`**' *+
   1
```

This sequentially reads through the input with `:~@#` as before. Then, it puts a 1 on the stack, followed by two copies of the character. The two duplicates are compared against `'@` and `'[` (64 and 91 respectively) to see whether the character is an uppercase letter. If it is, the product of these checks (1*1=1) is multiplied by 1 and then by the code point of  ​ (space) to get 32, which is then added to the original character to make it lowercase. However, if the character is not uppercase, one of the comparisons will return 0. This 0 gets multiplied by a bunch of things and then added to the original character, and so the character remains unaltered when it is printed.

With the lowercase `a`s removed, the first `^` is now shifted over two spaces to the left, and the second line is executed rather than the fourth.

```
< ^:~@#
, >-\:'``\'{^
^ 1         >\`**' *+
  0
```

This does mostly the same thing, except -1 is pushed onto the stack rather than 1 at the beginning of the loop and the bounds are replaced with 96 and 123 (to see whether it is lowercase). Then, the `^` (we can't use `v` because it's lowercase!) shifts the IP down a line, to execute the same logic as before. If the character is a lowercase letter, 1 is multiplied by the top of the stack (which is now -1 rather than 1) and by 32 to get -32, which is added to the original character to make it uppercase. As before, if the character is not lowercase, 32 is multiplied by 0 and the final `+` does nothing.

In all cases,

```
<
,
^
^
```

is executed at the end of the loop, printing the possibly modified character and rerouting the IP back to the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 22 bytes

```
İḷ|f{;.P∧Ạ{∧Ṇ}ᶻ∋P∧|}ᵐ|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//8iGhzu216RVW@sFPOpY/nDXgmoQtbOt9uG23Y86ukGCNbUPt06o@f9fyTEpWSElVcHN3UPRXul/FAA) [try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7TVp1dZ6jzqWVwNx7cNtux91dANZNbUPt06o@f9fyTEpWSElVcHN3UPRXul/FAA) [TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//8iGmmprvYBHHcsf7lpQDaJ2ttU@3Lb7UUc3SLCm9uHWCTX//ys5JiUrpKQquLl7KNor/Y8CAA)

I had some bizarre errors trying to use subscripted `∋`/`∈`. Takes a string through the input variable and outputs through the output variable, since printing is impossible without lowercase letters.

```
İ                         The input is an integer, but it's not,
 ḷ                        ...
  |                       so maybe...
   f                      its factors, but it doesn't have factors...
    {;.P∧Ạ{∧Ṇ}ᶻ∋P∧|}ᵐ     ...
                     |    so just output it unchanged.

 ḷ                        The input converted to lowercase
  |                       is the output.
  |f{;. ∧ {∧ }ᶻ∋ ∧|}ᵐ|    Hooray, that worked, forget everything else.

İ                         The input is an integer, except it's not,
  | {              }ᵐ     so then instead for each element of the input
     ;.                   that element paired with the output it's mapped to
       P                  is P,
        ∧                 and
         Ạ                the lowercase alphabet
          {∧ }ᶻ           zipped with (I don't actually know why this works!)
            Ṇ             a list of all printable ASCII characters (ABCDEFGHI...)
               ∋P         contains P
                 ∧        (which isn't the output);
                  |       if that's impossible pass the element through unchanged.
                     |    Since that worked, we don't worry about the rest.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>72</s> 49 bytes

```
Zz=0;Yy=z=Z=0;~Xx=@.Xx+('`'<Xx+32Z<'{')*(32Z-32z)
```

[Try all 3 versions online!](https://tio.run/##lY09D4IwEIb3/orKQusHwXYwUWpMnN2RyYupsaQB0oIiGv567SSasDjdk/fuvSdvtIJl6wALHASByzoRb44P0YnMQ5@2Yhel7YyEpzDxk7MsCZ8hnRJPC8466nwLIevr@yuYiMTrJVtRhCqjiloXBCiSN9DkIGuIKjBW@oh@1r3Fry3OS1UM2TchYP71RelaGjJRVpd3ac5g5RzDcAdsxML@0vAfTVNVYxo@ouHjGvcG)

input and output are lists of characters

Answer (score 2):

#### Haskell, 208 bytes or 210 bytes

Note: my original, shorter, solution was buggy. This one seems pretty solid. This challenge is not so easy in Haskell; there's no golfing here, aside from space removal. I imagine it's possible to do better.

```haskell
(!)((/):($))((#):(*))(+)|(+)==(/)=(#)|0<1=(!)($)(*)(+)
(!)_ _(+)=(+)
(&)[(*)]=[]
(&)((*):(+))=(*):(&)(+)
_:(#)=(&)['@'..'[']
_:(%)=(&)['`'..'{']
(+*)|"A"==[]=(!)(#)(%)|"a"==[]=(!)(%)(#)|0<1= \(+)->(+)
(+*)<$>
```

The first seven lines are definitions. The last line is prepended to the input, like

```haskell
(+*)<$>"My name is David."
```

If you don't accept this, you can upgrade to a "function" by enclosing in parentheses, at the cost of two bytes. To make a proper function definition, you'd turn on `NoMonomorphismRestriction` and write, say,

```haskell
(##)=((+*)<$>)
```

#### Explanation

Haskell variables (including function names) generally have to start with a lower-case letter. Infix operators, however, can consist of various symbols, as long as they don't begin with a `:`. So ... all the functions defined and their argument names are written as operators. An operator enclosed in parentheses is treated as a regular old name, so this works. The case restriction prevents us from using any standard functions except infix ones, and also prohibits us from importing any modules. So we can't use `fromEnum`, `toEnum`, `ord`, `chr`, or `unsafeCoerce` to manipulate characters as numbers. Instead we write a function, `(!)`, that looks for a character in a list, and produces the character in the same position in the second list if it's found. These lists are produced rather awkwardly using characters before and after the lower and upper case ASCII ranges and a hand-rolled version of `init` (called `(&)`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 111 bytes

```lua
bB=...aA=io or _G['\112\114\105\110\116'](('')['\117\112\112\101\114'](B))load"print(_G and bB or b:lower())"()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/yclWT08v0dE2M18hv0gh3j1aPcbQ0AiITWIMDUyBtAEQm6nHamioq2uCJc2hCoDYwBCkECjppKmZk5@YolRQlJlXohHvrpCYl6KQ5AQyMskqJ788tUhDU1NJQ5MrCWwdzDbyLEO1C2IVpk1gjznaKlDiJyWQVxScFBSsIIb@///fIzUnJ18hPL8oJwUA)

### Lowercase Version

```lua
b=...a=io or _['\112\114\105\110\116'](('')['\117\112\112\101\114']())load"print(_ and b or b:lower())"()
```

### Uppercase Version

```lua
B=...A=  _G['\112\114\105\110\116'](('')['\117\112\112\101\114'](B))"(_G  B  :())"()
```

### Explanation

This code takes input as a command line argument, and can effectively be split up into two conditionals.

```lua
aA=io or _G['\112\114\105\110\116'](('')['\117\112\112\101\114'](B))
```

This segment is equivalent to `aA=io or print(B:upper())`, just written in a way to avoid lowercase characters for the print. Normally, this section of code does nothing because `io` is a truthy value. When lowercase letters are removed, `io` and `or` are removed, allowing the print to occur.

```lua
load"print(_G and bB or b:lower())"()
```

This segment is surrounded by a `load` call because without it, Lua will see this part as a syntax error when attempting to run the uppercase version. The uppercase version will throw a runtime error when it encounters this part, however.

The normal version will see `_G` as a truthy value and print the input as-is. The lowercase version will instead see `_` as a falsy value and print the input in lowercase.