# I uppercase the source code, you reverse the input!

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout

*It's one of [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558/i-double-the-source-you-double-the-output) again :D*

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program/function (**without any uppercase letters**) that outputs/returns its string input/argument. The tricky part is that if I convert your source code to uppercase, the output must be reversed.

For simplicity, you can assume that the input is always a single line string containing only ASCII letters (`a-z`), digits (`0-9`), and spaces.

You do not need to handle empty input.

### Example

Let's say your source code is `abc` and its input is `hello`. If I write `ABC` instead and run it, the output must be `olleh`.

Comment: How about switching case instead of just uppercasing it? So `heLLO` would become `HEllo`. Although this question would still be way too hard

Comment: If using a function, may we take and return an array of characters?

Comment: Anyone feel like using [oOo CODE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE)?

Comment: Just a piece of advice: while it's always a good idea to post challenges in the Sandbox (no matter how simple they might seem), it's an *extra* good idea to do so if something similar has been done multiple times before (such as the "I <blank> the source code, you <blank> the input" challenges)

Comment: Are the rules the same for letters in other languages like Φ/ϕ?

Comment: @EthanChapman For non-ASCII characters, no. That could get complicated. As long as the behavior is consistent for each character, it's fine to treat them either as lower/uppercase or as separate, non-letter characters.

Comment: The lowercase rule kicks pip outta this challenge :(

Comment: Can we place any reasonable limit on the input string length?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler What would you consider "reasonable"? If it's bounded by something that is a part of the language, like limited memory or pointer size, then sure. If it's just an arbitrary limit to save bytes, then that isn't really as valid of a reason.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms a sentence, a paragraph, enough to demonstrate reversing a string when uppercased. My code selects string indices which don't exist; it demonstrably works up to the cutoff I chose. If I have to increase to cover 2Gb strings it will become code which works in principle but takes too long to select 2Bn nulls even on 2-char inputs, and is a longer answer - and for nobody's benefit. That's a choice, but one I think is worse. Unless you then say "must run in reasonable time on max length strings" or "must scale performance with string length" which may invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler If it works up to a length you choose, go with something that runs in a reasonable time (for testing purposes), and say that the technique would work with longer strings if you change that number. Interested to see your solution!

Comment: @Razetime I thought so at first, but [it is possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211333/16766). :)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms my answer is below in PowerShell; it indexes chars `[99..0]` which makes a 100-item array first, then looks them all up, internally throwing exceptions for any after the end of the string. Input len 100 is fine, 1000 would be fine but needs `1e3` constant for longer code. 1e6 makes 25 seconds of exceptions. 1e8 runs out of memory for the array. String max is maybe ~2e31. Or `$a=[char[]]$s;[array]::reverse($a);` does 1e8 in 77 seconds but sucks for golf. Handling 2e31 might need custom reverse code. Saying "must be testable on len X input" sets a clear limit we can golf within.

Comment: @Razetime It also keeps 1+ away :(

Answer (score 47):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
r
```

Try it online [lowercase](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/6P//4Pzc1OCSosy8dAA) or [uppercase](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6P//4Pzc1OCSosy8dAA)!

Finally a question which I (a dumb brain) can answer! Thanks for this easy, yet fun challenge! (I do feel great, even though it requires little effort to make an answer in 05AB1E.)

#### Wait, how?

```
r # reverses the stack. (Which literally does not do anything since only the
  # implicit input is in the stack)
R # actually reverses the top string of the stack (Which is the implicit input).
  # at the end, the input is automatically printed.
```

Comment: That's awesome :)

Comment: That's completely unfair! You didn't even put any effort on it and you get 40 upvotes, more than the sum of my answers. (Upvote)

Comment: @null Sorry about that, but I do not have any idea how I got 40+ upvotes. (Honestly, I thought that I will get numerous downvotes)

Comment: You beat me to it. I was thinking the same thing :)

Answer (score 42):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>61 50 49</s>  48 bytes

-1 thanks to benrg!

```python
r=-1;ʳ=1;ᵖʳᵢⁿᵗ(ᵢⁿᵖᵘᵗ()[::r])
```

**[lower-cased](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8hW19D61GZbQ@uHW6ed2vxw66JHjfsfbp2uAWNNe7h1BoivGW1lVRSr@f9/RmpOTj4A) / [upper-cased](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8hW19D61GZbQ@uHW6ed2vxw66JHjfsfbp2uAWNNe7h1BoivGW1lFRSr@f9/RmpOTj4A)**

This works because

1. [PEP-3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) was implemented in Python 3.0; and
2. These are the minimal length Unicode characters with no upper-case version which also normalise under the Normalization Form Compatibility Composition ([NFKC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms)) transformation to the basic latin characters one would normally use - [TIO](https://tio.run/##XZAxa8MwEIX3/IrbJNGmYLLZaCpkCXTwWjIokoyPypK4ypTmz7tyncSRH5q@e0/cu/ib@uAP09RRGGD0qIOxRiUFOMRACXygQTm82l0XCDSgzy@OiYt6B1nYZSglsJYtYFYk9IkzYq9gvZGMif@RdbP7bYzREhdzSm8zepv4tqsFQUIgw7V4oJ8enYVq9Sy@FwlVgVyO6p44igKPGbv7QuUf3ZyR2aG8Wa/A2cfx9J57ue3@ZQ9X9njWhaz6mqZW7quGZNUsgdtRP@u6PYs/).

Note that identifiers, like `r` and the function names `print` and `input`, may be written like this but not keywords, like `def` or `lambda`.

(See the [upper-casing](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzOvoLREQ1OvtKAgtUhDU/P//yJbXUPrU5ttDa0fbp12avPDrYseNe5/uHW6Bow17eHWGSC@ZrSVVVGsJgA) of the code.)

Comment: The more I learn about Python, the weirder it becomes. I really can't understand some design decisions. FYI: ⁱ would look a bit more consistent.

Comment: ...but it would make the code two bytes longer :)

Comment: Time to enter some bugs for various IDEs... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44577

Comment: How did you know about this? Do you read all the PEPs?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No, I don't read all the PEPs I recalled the use of the PEP-3131 trick from some other challege on codegolf.SE, can't recall which - I'll have a dig. Then it was a matter of finding suitable Unicode to replace the original cursive I recalled was used.

Comment: @JonathanAllan you're probably thinking of Print X Without X

Comment: @Lyxal - that's the one!

Comment: @ThomasWeller - [nthistle's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81278/nthistle) [cop submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207563/53748) to Print X Without X employed the fact that we can use Unicode characters for identifiers.

Comment: Nice work! But shouldn't the lower-cased code also reverse the input?

Comment: Can you replace the variable name by i instead of r to lose two more bytes?

Comment: @Reinier No, the ʳ is the slowest ordinal character there, while ᵢ is one byte longer. Using the lowest ordinal available which translates to one of a-z, ª, is also the same byte count as ʳ.

Comment: @whme No, the spec is that the lower-cased code gives the input back as-is.

Comment: @ Thomas Weller this really is just a side-effect of reasonable design-decisions. PEP-3131 specifies that all unicode characters be usable as identifiers, which allows supporting all languages. And it specifies that they should be normalised to NFKC, so visually equivalent representations like Å (U+212B) , Å (U+00C5) and Å (U+0041 U+030A) are considered equivalent, which they really should be.

Comment: @iFreilicht NFC normalization would accomplish that without the weird side effects. It's unclear to me why they picked NFKC. PEP-3131 doesn't explain it.

Comment: `r=-1;ʳ=1;`...`[::r])` saves another byte unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks, @benrg, I did try something like that when making this, but must've just got it backwards!

Comment: @benrg [UAX #15, Figure 6.](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Compatibility_Composite_Figure) has a good example where that would make a difference.

Answer (score 15):

## Python 3, 48 bytes

```python
ᵖʳᵢⁿᵗ(ᵢⁿᵖᵘᵗ()[::b'b'[0]%3-1])
```

[Lower: Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7//@HWaac2P9y66FHj/odbp2vAWNMebp0B4mtGW1klqSepRxvEqhrrGsZq/v@fkZqTk69Qnl@UkwIA)

```python
ᵖʳᵢⁿᵗ(ᵢⁿᵖᵘᵗ()[::B'B'[0]%3-1])
```

[Upper: Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7//@HWaac2P9y66FHj/odbp2vAWNMebp0B4mtGW1k5qTupRxvEqhrrGsZq/v@fkZqTk69Qnl@UkwIA)

You can also verify that the [upper program is truly uppercase](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ@nh1mmnNj/cuuhR4/6HW6drwFjTHm6dAeJrRltZJaknqUcbxKoa6xrGairplRYUpBZpaGr@/w8A).

---

It's unlikely we can write a program for Python 3 just using ASCII - we have no `def`, no `lambda`, and no builtin function calls. Also, all the properties of existing builtin objects are lowercase so we can't access those either. So instead our strategy is to look for Unicode characters that:

- Are not uppercase
- NFKC normalise to the character we want
- NFKC normalise to the character we want even after uppercasing

The following code does exactly that.

```python
from unicodedata import normalize
for c in 'printinput':
  for i in range(0x10ffff):
    if not chr(i).isupper() and normalize('NFKC', chr(i)) == normalize('NFKC', chr(i).upper()) == c:
      print(chr(i))
      break
  else:
    raise Exception('no')
```

Comment: Love the bytes trick!

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṛ
```

**[lower-cased](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztn////PAHLyAQ)  /  [upper-cased](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzln////PAHLyAQ)**

#### How?

```
ṛ - Main Link: list of characters, S
ṛ - right argument (implicitly S)
  - implicitly print

Ṛ - Main Link: list of characters, S
Ṛ - reverse
  - implicitly print
```

Comment: `Ṛ` is an uppercase letter with `ṛ` being its lowercase.

Comment: Totally fixed and now just 1 byte and future-proof.

Comment: A bit late, but `u`/`U` also works: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/0////GUBmPgA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I had that before, but since `u` is still free to be implemented as an atom this one is future-proof.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌽⍣('a'∊⎕a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HP3ke9izXUE9UfdXQ96puaqPk/7VHbhEe9fY@6mh/1rnnUu@XQeuNHbROBcsFBzkAyxMMz@H@agrpHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiOgA)

`⌽⍣(`…`)` apply reverse the following number of times:

`'a'∊⎕a` is "a" a member of the uppercase **a**lphabet? (0)

#### Uppercased

```apl
⌽⍣('A'∊⎕A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HP3ke9izXUHdUfdXQ96pvqqPk/7VHbhEe9fY@6mh/1rnnUu@XQeuNHbROBcsFBzkAyxMMz@H@agrpHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiOgA)

`⌽⍣(`…`)` apply reverse the following number of times:

`'A'∊⎕A` is "a" a member of the uppercase **A**lphabet? (1)

---

In Dyalog APL, `⎕A` is case-insensitive and always refers to the uppercase alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>33</s>, <s>25</s>, 22 bytes

Thank's to @DomHastings who also had the same idea

```perl
m;$_=/.(?{$\=$&.$\})^/
```

uppercase

```perl
M;$_=/.(?{$\=$&.$\})^/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/XWiXeVl9Pw75aJcZWRU1PJaZWM07///@M1Jyc/H/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: This is a nice solution! Can't think of a different approach (this one didn't even jump out at me to be honest!) It's possible to potentially save a couple of bytes if you use `s` instead of `next` and add a `;` to the end. It shouldn't be a problem because the input can only contain letters!

Comment: Also, you can use `\D` as the search pattern to save a few more: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z/YWiXeVj/GRcO@WiXGVkVNTyWmVjNO3/r//4zUnJx8rvL8opyUf/kFJZn5ecX/dQ3Mzc0LAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings, indeed, i also though to `m` instead of `next`, but was looking if there could be a false match

Comment: Also I didn't see your comments, when I modified `[\0-\277]` to `.`, i think we crossed

Comment: Ahh, `m` is even better! Looks good!

Comment: indeed the difficulty with perl was the without lowercase, `reverse`,`s///` subsitution, `//g` global match, `eval`, `sub` function definition, can't be done

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

Takes and returns an array of characters.

#### In lowercase

```javascript
s=>s.map?s:s["\162\145\166\145\162\163\145"]()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdNCoAgEEDhu7RRFw305yKwDlItxKwUc6KJrm8Frb73vL41mdMdVx5xtmlRiVRHsOujp5aGbCxkORZ18yp/35fV19nERTIYCYOFgCtf@AAAbLMhIJsEeHSRMyZEegA)

#### In uppercase

```javascript
S=>S.MAP?S:S["\162\145\166\145\162\163\145"]()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/Y1i5Yz9cxwD7YKjhaKcbQzCjG0MQUSJtBaSDfzBjEVorV0PyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphGtp6ennpGak5OvHqupl5Wfmaehrq6p@R8A)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>74</s>  73 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

Takes and returns a string.

#### In lowercase

```javascript
s=>s.big?s:[...s]["\162\145\166\145\162\163\145"]()["\152\157\151\156"]``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5YLykz3b7YKlpPT684NlopxtDMKMbQxBRIm0FpIN/MGMRWitXQBKkwBYqYmgOxIRCbKcUmJPxPzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI01DPSM3JyVfX1PwPAA)

#### In uppercase

```javascript
S=>S.BIG?S:[...S]["\162\145\166\145\162\163\145"]()["\152\157\151\156"]``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/Y1i5Yz8nT3T7YKlpPTy84NlopxtDMKMbQxBRIm0FpIN/MGMRWitXQBKkwBYqYmgOxIRCbKcUmJPxPzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI01DPSM3JyVfX1PwPAA)

Comment: You could use the logic from your second solution, using `s.big`, in your first solution to save a byte.

Comment: @Shaggy Good idea.

Comment: The problem statement does explicitly say `input is always a single line string`, which I interpret to mean an actual string in JavaScript, rather than an array of characters.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 122 bytes

```r
`\103`=`\162\145\166`
`\151\156\164\124\157\125\164\1468`(c(`\165\164\1468\124\157\111\156\164`(`\163\143\141\156`(,""))))
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyHG0MA4wRZImRnFGJqYAmmzBC4g19QQiM2AXJMYQyMgNjUH0qYQvomZRYJGsgZIE0IEocwQrjUBrMYYKA/CYOEEDR0lJU0g@J@ZV1Ba8h8A)

[TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyHG0MA4wRZImRnFGJqYAmmzBC4g19QQiM2AXJMYQyMgNjUH0qYQvomZRYKGswZIE0IEocwQrjUBrMYYKA/CYOEEDR0lJU0g@J@ZV1Ba8h8A)

Includes only one letter, the lone `c` in the middle. The rest uses octal codes to get the equivalent of

```r
C=rev
intToUtf8(c(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))))
```

With the lowercase `c`, the `c` makes no difference: we convert the input to integers, concatenate it with nothing, and convert back to characters. With an uppercase `C`, the integer vector in the middle gets reversed before being converted back.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <sup><s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>47</s></sup> 46 bytes

*Saved a byte by using a shorter lexicographical comparison taken from [@WheatWizard's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211281/92901).*

#### Lowercase

```python
?a<?_&&(f=->_{/.$/?($_=$`;f[_+=$&]):$_=_})['']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/3z7Rxj5eTU0jzVbXLr5aX09F315DJd5WJcE6LTpe21ZFLVbTCsiPr9WMVleP/f8/IzUnJ/9ffkFJZn5e8X/dAgA)

`?a<?_` tests whether the character `a` is lexicographically less than the character `_`. The test returns `false`, short-circuiting the `&&` operator so that none of the remaining code is actually executed. The input is printed automatically thanks to the `-p` flag.

#### Uppercase

```python
?A<?_&&(F=->_{/.$/?($_=$`;F[_+=$&]):$_=_})['']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/397Rxj5eTU3DzVbXLr5aX09F315DJd5WJcHaLTpe21ZFLVbTCsiPr9WMVleP/f8/IzUnJ/9ffkFJZn5e8X/dAgA)

Now we test whether `A` is lexicographically less than `_`. Here the comparison returns `true` so we proceed past `&&`. The code after `&&` defines and calls a recursive lambda that reverses the input, which (because of `-p`) has been stored in the predefined global variable `$_`:

```python
(F=->_{      # define a lambda F with parameter _
  /.$/?(     # if $_ contains at least one character, match the last one, then
    $_=$`;     # remove that character from $_
    F[_+=$&]   # recursively call F, appending that character to _
  ):$_=_     # else set $_ to _, which now contains the full reversed input
})['']       # call F, initialising _ to the empty string
```

Finally, `$_` (now containing the reversed input) is printed automatically thanks to the `-p` flag.

Comment: Very impressive. This might be the least clear Ruby code I've ever seen.

Comment: @EricDuminil I took much inspiration from [a master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205713/92901).

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
_0(_1:_2)|'a'<'_'=_0 _2++[_1]
_0 _1=_1
```

[Try it online! (lowercase)](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P95AI97QKt5Is0Y9Ud1GPV7dNt5AId5IWzs63jCWC8Q2tI03/J@bmJlnm5lXklqUmFyiohBv8D8xpzglJ/c/AA)

```hs
_0(_1:_2)|'A'<'_'=_0 _2++[_1]
_0 _1=_1
```

[Try it online! (uppercase)](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P95AI97QKt5Is0bdUd1GPV7dNt5AId5IWzs63jCWC8Q2tI03/J@bmJlnm5lXklqUmFyiohBv8D8xpzglJ/c/AA)

Haskell requires that any variable name beginning with a capital letter is constructor of a declared type. This basically means we can't have any identifiers that start with a letter.  (I think the options we actually have are `LT`, `GT`, and `EQ` but I wasn't able to find a use for any of these.)  Luckily it is possible to write haskell programs without letters.  We can start variable names with `_` and we add numbers to the end to make it a valid name (certain symbols would work too).

To detect that which mode we are in we use the fact that strings change and do a comparison between a changing and static string, `'a'<'_'` evaluates to `False` while `'A'<'_'` is true.

Answer (score 5):

### Windows NT Batch + coreutils, 28 bytes

```
@if %os:~9%==t (tac)else cat
```

Explanation: `%OS%` contains `Windows_NT` and the substring starting at position `9` is compared with the letter `t`. If the batch file is uppercased then the comparison succeeds and `tac` is invoked otherwise `cat` is invoked.

Comment: How will invoking `cat` or `tac` with no arguments print the arguments to the batch file backwards?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The question allows you any string input, so I'm assuming the input will be on STDIN. Maybe I should have said that in my answer...

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>21</sup> 14 bytes

```
|.^:({.\:'a_')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a/TirDSq9WKs1BPj1TX/a3KlJmfkK6QpqGek5uTkq3NxpdvqKSAUOQIVcUHUpMPU/AcA)

*-7 bytes thanks to Adam!*

Taking inspiration from [Adam's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211230/15469).

### how

- `|.^:` Reverse the following number of times...
- `:({.\:'a_')` Grade down `\:` the string `a_` and take the first element `{.`.

  - "Grade down" returns a list of indexes for the string, sorted descending.  Thus `\:'abc'` would return `2 1 0`, for example.
  - "Grade down" will thus return `0` for the string `a_`, and `1` for the string `A_`, since `_` is between `a` and `A` in the ascii alphabet.

Comment: `A` is uppercase.

Comment: Thanks.  Needed a new approach but fixed now.

Comment: [`|.^:({.\:'a_')`](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a/TirDSq9WKs1BPj1TX/a3KlJmfkK6QpqGek5uTkq3NxpdvqKSAUOQIVcUHUpMPU/AcA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Very clever.  Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
#[[i=1;i^2;;-i^2;;i^2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCsMgEADQ/T7jhEzp0K4SEEL2QtNJLFzlgkKiog6Fkm83pWu7vOltVB1vVL2ltgzYhNZ@OEv/uEh5@vrBmK4h3CwFDZN1UQm4Zh@qnuP0SplL8THoxajRUSZbORclzL8zx3tKnEcqrH5@178BHa9rxB6QnhZhN@0A)

`I` is the built-in symbol for the imaginary unit \$i\$. Its value cannot be overridden without `Unprotect`ing it first.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
⌽⍣(<×'a')
```

[Try it online (both lower and upper)!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HP3ke9izVsDk9XT1TXROY6qmtypRk@apvwqLfvUVfzofWmj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyDudKMkKRN0KX/pxkqqCcmJasD1UEYAA)

In Extended, `×` (signum) on letters queries the letter case, giving -1 for lowercase and 1 for uppercase. Then `<` has implicit left arg of 0, so it tests if the right arg is positive (1) or not (0). Therefore, `<×'a'` evaluates to 0 and `<×'A'` evaluates to 1.

Comment: Clever use of the Footer!

Answer (score 4):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
væ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v@zwsv//PVJzcvJ1FMrzi3JSFAE)

And uppercased:

```
Væ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P@zwsv//PVJzcvJ1FMrzi3JSFAE)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 76e6                                     v
```

### How?

`v` enters 'visual mode' and begins selecting characters. At first, only 1 character will be selected. Then `æ` reverses every character that is selected. Reversing only 1 character does nothing.

But `V` will select every character on the current line, and then `æ` flips the whole line.

Comment: Isnt `Æ` the uppercase of `æ`

Comment: @Jasen Yes, it is. However, as the comments say *That could get complicated. As long as the behavior is consistent for each character, it's fine to treat them (non-ASCII characters) either as lower/uppercase or as separate, non-letter characters.* so I'm treating `æ` as a non-letter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 61 bytes

```forth
: f 'a 65 = if bounds 1- swap 1- -do i c@ emit 1 -loop then ;
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy9CsIwGEV3n@LYxSlDBzsogqNv4JzmxwZiv5CkiE8f2006He65cLzkOqmX39DaBc9JM5y5ETyjLLMt9Iry0WmjskLA3HHvUOlRUSRRJzdzbaVDj6ZbG/WbHCYfVrObDxej8JQc7fHvaj8) [TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//Wym4Kag7KpiZKtgqeLopOPmH@rkEKxjqKgSHOwaAaF0XfwVPBWcHBVdfzxAFQwVdH3//AIUQD1c/Bev/xUoKiUnJSgppCslFXEAOguWRmpOTrxCeX5SToggR/Q8A)

A challenge where the case insensitivity of Forth has a use ... except that you don't have a string reversal built-in, so you have to loop through the string itself in reverse.

Almost all words in Forth are case-insensitive. The only case-sensitive part in the code is `'a` or `'A`, where the char's ASCII code (97 for `a`, 65 for `A`) is pushed to the stack. So we can compare it with a (trivially case-insensitive) numeric literal `65`. If they're equal, the string is printed in reverse. Otherwise, the string is returned as-is.

Comment: Now to find a place where space separation is useful.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
ṡ↔|
```

and

```
Ṡ↔|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/XDnwkdtU2pqH@7qVANyFsA4/6ES//8rpeXnJyUWKQEA)

```
ṡ↔
ṡ   if input is a square matrix,
Ṡ   if input is a string,
 ↔   it is reversed
  | otherwise return input unaltered
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell 7+, <strike>56</strike>, 35 bytes

```
-join"$args"['a'[0]-97?99..0:0..99]


# save as golf.ps1 and call .\golf.ps1 "string"
# e.g. (running in anonymous function &{} for demo):

PS C:\> &{-join"$args"['a'[0]-97?99..0:0..99]} '123 Alice'
123 Alice
PS C:\> &{-JOIN"$ARGS"['A'[0]-97?99..0:0..99]} '123 Alice'
ecilA 321
```

With golfing suggestions from [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy).

Assuming the string is <= 100 characters. Change both the 99s to 1e5 notation for +2 bytes, much longer inputs, and much much slower code.

#### old 56 byte version

```
&{$a="$args";(gv a).name[0]-97?-join$a[$a.length..0]:$a}

e.g.

PS C:\> &{$a="$args";(gv a).name[0]-97?-join$a[$a.length..0]:$a} "123 Alice"
123 Alice

PS C:\> &{$A="$ARGS";(GV A).NAME[0]-97?-join$A[$A.LENGTH..0]:$A} "123 Alice"
ecilA 321
```

The parameters to the anonymous function `{}` appear in the automatic variable `$args` and get stored in variable `$a`. String quotes `"$args"` cast to a single string. PowerShell is indifferent about the case of variable names, command names, property names, operator names, etc. so all the code runs in either case. `gv` is `get-variable` which looks for the `a` variable, finds its `.Name` (`a` or `A` depending on the case of the script - case is preserved), gets character [0] which is `a` or `A` again but this time as a `[char]` type, subtracts 97 (lowercase `a` value in ASCII), and `? :` ternary operators whether that hit zero or non-zero, and either prints the original or reverse-indexes the characters and joins them into a reversed string. Printing is implicit. `&{}` runs the anonymous function.

NB. TIO.Run only has PowerShell 5 or 6 at the time of writing, and ternary ?: is not in that version.

Comment: `gv` is nice. you can save some bytes wuth `param($a)` instead `$a="$args";`. You can omit `&{}` also because CodeGolf requires a Complete program. the complete Powershell program is a text in a ps1-script.

Comment: `gv` is nice and too heavy. The `[char]'a'-97` is sufficient :)

Comment: @mazzy good ideas! Can push them a bit further and do away with `param()` and `[char]` and `.Length`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
[r_]@1
```

This is a function solution. Since it relies on the recently added unary `R` operator, it doesn't work on TIO, but a similar 7-byte version does:

```
[rv_]@2
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@K/xP7qoLD7Wwei/kkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqKS5n8A) or [TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@K/xPzooLD7Wwei/kkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqKS5n8A)

#### Explanation

Lowercase:

```
[  ]    Make a list containing
 r       A random number between 0 and 1;
  _      The identity function
    @1  Get the item at index 1 (the identity function)
```

Uppercase:

```
[  ]    Make a list containing
 R_      A function that reverses its argument
    @1  Get the item at index 1, with cyclical indexing (the function)
```

The TIO version is the same idea, but uses the `RV` operator for reverse. It therefore has three items in the lowercase list (including `v`, which is -1) and gets the function using index 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <strike>46</strike> <strike>44</strike> then by tch: 37 bytes

```javascript
$=([o,...a])=>o?o.sub?o+$(a):$(a)+o:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxDsIwEAT7vMKyUpwVuBoFmRS8gQoh5TAXCHI4yzb@viE9otliNLNPKpRcnEPell11cmNl1VhbC2fZICJdjD3IIJje10G6Fsj063TSUx0xx3kBs28aLuRBT1arTq0vX@bklcQzernDBPrB3os2v2TMcgqB45ESg/mT1g8)

Thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) for saving 7 bytes!.

Recursive function `$` takes a string and destructures it into the first character `o` and an array `a` of the remaining characters.

If lower case, `o` has  a property `sub` it returns the forward string `o+$(a)`.
Otherwise, `O` has no property `SUB` and it returns the reverse string `$(A)+O`.

The final iteration happens when `$` is called with and empty array so there is no `o`. Here it returns `a`, an empty array `[]` which acts as and empty string `""` in string addition.

Comment: [`$=([o,...a])=>o?o.sub?o+$(a):$(a)+o:a`](https://tio.run/##fYuxCsIwEED3fkUpGe6o3iyV2MFvcBKhZzy0knohifn9aEcXlwcP3nty4eTiHPK27KrTm7S2naqxcNYNEfEF7UFHpfS@jtobYBxW9DpwnSjHeQHcN40U9rDuX3H6SuqFvN7BQPcQ77XDn4qynkKQeOQkgH@e@gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 0X0, 68 bytes

*Works in both 000 and 010*

### Lower case

```
"a`"1+-+?@      \
/!?:    (0)?/!?:<@?
>$:?!\?>:?!\\(  /
\   (/ \  )/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/18pMUHJUFtX295BAQxiuPQV7a1ALA0DTXsQ28bBnstOxcpeMcbeDkTGaCgo6HPFgFToKwApTf3////rJv83MDD4n1ickpudCwA)

### Upper case

```
"A`"1+-+?@      \
/!?:    (0)?/!?:<@?
>$:?!\?>:?!\\(  /
\   (/ \  )/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/1/JMUHJUFtX295BAQxiuPQV7a1ALA0DTXsQ28bBnstOxcpeMcbeDkTGaCgo6HPFgFToKwApTf3////rJv83MDD4n1ickpudCwA)

---

Most of this is just a program that reverses the input, which is not exactly easy in Klein.

```
>:?!\?)0(    :?!\?@
\  (//!?:<?/!?:$<
     \)  / \(   /
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/9/Oyl4xxl7TQEMBCMBsB64YBQUNfX1FeysbexCpYsMFklSI0VRQ0FeIAanU////v27yfwMDg/@JxSm52bkA)

To do the condition we have the very simple

```
"a`"1+-+?@
```

Which is an expression that is exactly zero, but becomes something else when `a` is capitalized.  This is pretty much the exact method used by every other answer.  The `?@` means that when it is zero it halts immediately (a cat program).  Otherwise we continue execution to the reverse program bit.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 28 bytes

```
{.?"{'flip'~^'    '}"()||$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Ws9eqVo9LSezQL0uTl0BCNRrlTQ0a2pU4mvBitIVbBUgitx8PAMwFVkrFCdWKqjEa6hnpObk5CuU5xflpKhrKqTlFwFt0AEaYP0fAA)

- `$_` is the input to the function.  Method calls lacking an explicit invocant are called on it.
- `flip` is the method to reverse a string.
- `$obj."name"()` is the syntax to call a method where the name is a string.  The double quotes can contain interpolated values as usual.
- `$obj.?method` means to call `method` on `$obj` if that method is defined for it, and otherwise return `Nil`.
- `~^` is the stringy exclusive-or operator, which exclusive-ors the corresponding characters of its operands.

Putting it all together, the uncapitalized program xors `flip` and a string containing four spaces, producing `FLIP`.  That method is not defined for strings, so the `.?` method call returns `Nil`.  Then `Nil || $_` evaluates to the original string.  When the source code is uppercased, `flip` becomes `FLIP`, which when xor-ed with the spaces becomes `flip`, which when called on the input string, reverses it.

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 61 bytes

```
	&lcase 'a'	:f(r)
	output =input
r	output =reverse(input)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n1MtJzmxOFVBPVGd0ypNo0iTizO/tKSgtETBNjMPSHEVwflFqWWpRcWpGmBxTa7UvJT//wE)

SNOBOL by default case-folds identifiers and labels (unless `&CASE` is set to `0` or the flag `-CASE 0` is used at the start of the program), so the only thing that really changes is the `'a' -> 'A'`, as SNOBOL uses case-sensitive pattern matching. Since `'A'` is not lowercase, it jumps to the label `R`, which reverses.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) -v, 24 bytes

```
ternaryless"a""_"reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/78ktSgvsagyJ7W4WClRSSleqSi1LLWoOPX/f2eYGt0yAA) In upper case:

```
TERNARYLESS"A""_"REVERSE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z/ENcjPMSjSxzU4WMlRSSleKcg1zDUo2PX/f2eYGt0yAA) Explanation: If `a` or `A` as appropriate is less than `_`, the ternary then reverses the implicit input, otherwise just takes implicit input. The result is then implicitly printed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

### Lowercase

```
ô
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9A&input=ImFiY2RlZiI)

Partitions the input at falsey characters, but there's no such thing as a falsey character in JavaScript.

### Uppercase

```
Ô
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1A&input=ImFiY2RlZiI)

The shortcut for `w<space>`, Japt's built-in for reversing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```
_->_[::('a'>'_')*2-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzP17XLj7aykpDPVHdTj1eXVPLSNcw9r96RmpOTr66Qo2dQhqIKCjKzCv5DwA)

[Try it uppercased!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzP17XLj7aykpD3VHdTj1eXVPLSNcw9r96RmpOTr66Qo2dQhqIKCjKzCv5DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 9 bytes

```
?r\{9-=[^
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fviim2lLXNjru/3/HpGQA)
[TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fviim2lLXNjru/3/HpGQA)

Somehow, by making the answer valid, I saved bytes.

Comment: I love how it looks like your `Try it online!` gets angry and demands me to `TRY IT ONLINE!`.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms try it online or die ;P

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 19 bytes

```
%|11a{%%0~}<%0/>[;]
```

[try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%7C11a%7B%25%250%7E%7D%3C%250%2F%3E%5B%3B%5D&input=Hello) or [TRY IT!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%7C11A%7B%25%250%7E%7D%3C%250%2F%3E%5B%3B%5D&input=Hello)

MAWP ignores lowercase letters, so this answer uses a conditional to check if subtraction has happened or not, and reverses based on it.

Answer (score 2):

## [oK](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/oK), 13 bytes

```
.:9+23*7!"!g"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81Kz8pS28hYy1xRSTFdicsNme@uxMWlkaaUWpGYW5CTqsSl4KbkGuHoG@DjqqT5/z8A)

Explanation:

```
         "!g" /magic string
  9+23*7!     /9 + 23 * (ascii value mod 7)
.:            /eval ascii values as a string
```

When the input is `"!g"` it becomes `"||"` which is evaluated as reversing twice.
When the input is `"!G"` it becomes `"| "` which is evaluated as reversing once.

### [oK repl](https://johnearnest.github.io/ok), 10 bytes

I'm going to say that this one doesn't count, because it relies on the fact that the oK repl works in mysterious ways.

```
.:4*54!"u"
```

[Try it in repl!](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%20f%3A.%3A4%2a54%21%22u%22%3BF%3A.%3A4%2a54%21%22U%22%3B%28f%22example%22%3BF%22EXAMPLE%22%29)

When the input is `"u"` it becomes `"$"` which evaluates as "string of expression". In the repl it is a noop when applied to strings.
When the input is `"U"` it becomes `"|"` which evaluates as reversing.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 58 bytes

Lowercase:

```
sub r(s)
if asc("a")=65then s=strreverse(s)
[a1]=s
end sub
```

Uppercase:

```
SUB R(S)
IF ASC("A")=65THEN S=STRREVERSE(S)
[A1]=S
END SUB
```

Output is to the cell `A1` of the currently active sheet (if this is in a module) or the parent sheet (if this is in a sheet object). I'm a little concerned this doesn't comply with the spec, though, because VBA auto-formats much of the code once it's input:

```
Sub r(s)
If Asc("a") = 65 Then s = StrReverse(s)
[a1] = s
End Sub
```

Of course, the standard has been to not consider the extra formatting in the byte count so I presume we can also ignore the capitalization. Really, I'm more worried about the answer being too straightforward to be interesting rather than that technicality.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 45 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$s+=$_;$r=$_+$r};($s,$r)['a'[0]-ne97]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9XyWxKL24RrVapVjbViXeWqUISGqrFNVaa6gU66gUaUarJ6pHG8Tq5qVamsf@r@XiUgkuKcrMSwdqVjI0MlZwzMlMTlXiUgMa5wCVAQJlheKCnMSSEiD3/38A). Outputs `123 Alice`.

```powershell
$ARGS|%{$S+=$_;$R=$_+$R};($S,$R)['A'[0]-NE97]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9X8UxyD24RrVaJVjbViXeWiUISGqrBNVaa6gE66gEaUarO6pHG8Tq@rlamsf@r@XiUgkuKcrMSwdqVjI0MlZwzMlMTlXiUgMa5wCVAQJlheKCnMSSEiD3/38A). Outputs `ecilA 321`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 46 bytes

```hs
_f[]=[]
_f _s|'a'>'_'=_s|_x:_r<-_s=_f _r++[_x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Pz4tOtY2OpYrPk0hvrhGPVHdTj1e3RbIjK@wii@y0Y0vtgVJFWlrR8dXxP7PTczMU7BVyMwrSS1KTC5RiE/7n5iUnJIKAA)

```hs
_F[]=[]
_F _S|'A'>'_'=_S|_X:_R<-_S=_F _R++[_X]
```

[TRY IT ONLINE!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P94tOtY2OpYr3k0hPrhG3VHdTj1e3RbIjI@wig@y0Y0PtgVJBWlrR8dHxP7PTczMU7BVyMwrSS1KTC5RiHf7n5iUnJIKAA)

---

Regular identifiers in Haskell may not start with an upper-case letter, though starting with an underscore is fine. We cannot use the built-in `reverse` function, so we implement our own.

```hs
f [] = []
f s | 'a'>'_' = s            -- if we are lower-case, just return the string s
    | x:r <- s = f r ++ [x]  -- otherwise, split of the first char x, recursively reverse 
                             -- the remainder r and concatenate it to x
```

Comment: I used a nearly identical method but came up [8 bytes shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211281/). Although I did not see your answer prior.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript 75 bytes

```js
_=>'a'<'['?[..._]['\162\145\166\145\162\163\145']()['\152\157\151\156']``:_
```

Seems the straightforward way to do it:

- test if 'a' has become 'A' by now having a lower ascii value than '['
- if so, break the input into an array, then call `.reverse().join('')` on it, using octal to avoid spelling out the names of the functions
- otherwise return the string

Would be a lot shorter if the reversing happened on the lowercase version :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte with non-ASCII case-change thanks to Razetime*

```
?↔o↔↔→ḋ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/5R25R8IAajSQ93dBv9//@/JCOzWAGISjJSFTLzCkpLAA)

If (`?`) last element (`→`) of binary `ḋ`igits of `2` is falsy (it's zero, so it is!), reverse the reverse of the input (`o↔↔`) - so, output the input unchanged.

**Uppercased:**

```
?↔O↔↔→Ḋ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/5R2xR/IAajSQ93dBn9//@/JCOzWAGISjJSFTLzCkpLAA)

If (`?`) last element (`→`) of `Ḋ`ivisors of `2` is truthy (it's 2, so it is!), reverse input (`↔`).

---

As an alternative that uses the approach of *not* uppercasing non-ASCII characters, there is also:

```
?↔+ø→d10
```

also for **8 bytes** ([try it](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/5R2xTtwzsetU1yMTT4//9/SUZmsQIQlWSkKmTmFZSWAAA))...

Comment: looks like there's an uppercase for ø: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98#:~:text=It%20can%20also%20be%20typed,page%201252%20as%20system%20default.

Comment: Ah, yes!  Thanks (and now noted)!  ...but close inspection of the rules indicates that non-ASCII characters could be considered here as non-letters...

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/5R25R8IAajSQ93dBv9//@/JCOzWAGISjJSFTLzCkpLAA "Husk – Try It Online") [-1(uppercase)](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/5R2xR/IAajSQ93dBn9//@/JCOzWAGISjJSFTLzCkpLAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: That's cool!  Now both situations are covered (=changing case of non-ASCII letters, as well as not-changing case of non-ASCII letters).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, <s>87</s> 75

Input is in A1.

Lower:
A2: `=len(a1`

Output: `=arrayformula(if(code("a")-65,a1,join(,mid(a1,sequence(a2,1,a2,-1),1`

Upper:
A2: `=LEN(A1`

Output: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(CODE("A")-65,A1,JOIN(,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(A2,1,A2,-1),1`

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine code, 18 bytes

dst=EDI, src=ESI, byte count = ECX.  Copies src to dst either forward or reversed.

The only ASCII upper-case byte in the machine code is the `0x71` `'q'`, the opcode for `jno`, which is always taken (because it follows an xor-zeroing).  When lowercased, it becomes `0x51 'Q'`, a `push ecx`, which is balanced by a `pop ecx` in the fall-through path before reaching the loop.

http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x71 is a useful opcode map.
Conveniently, most of the `jcc` conditional branch opcodes are in the upper-case range.

```
rev:
    xor   edx, edx
%if 1
    jno   .loop                 ; 71 08  lower case: straight copy
%else
    db 0x51, 0x08               ; JNO becomes 0x51 push ecx, leaving the displacement as an opcode
%endif
    db 0xd1                ; ModRM for the uppercase case, where 08 is an OR opcode
.fallthrough:
    db 0x59                      ;pop  ecx (or RCX in 64-bit mode on TIO)

;    nop                         ; jump displacement needs to be 8, not 7 POP ES which will fault
;    add   edi, ecx
;    dec   edi                   ; so might as well use a longer single instruction
    lea   edi, [edi + ecx - 1]  ; point to *last* byte of destination
    mov   dl, 2
.loop:
    movsb                       ; *edi++ = *esi++
    sub   edi, edx              ; 0 for copy forwards, 2 for copy backwards
    loop  .loop

    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTfb9MwEH7PX3FMTNrWrmq6ASMVD4B4AGl0GjxMQgg58SXx5tjB5/QH/3w5O7Qr7RB@cKKz833ffXcXQYRNrlfnRlCzXjucZwnwWlrHO8rlMGzJsSphHA/ujeV9pK1t4WBNQdsFOigEYQbknVBV7aGw7So5Rk0YIWQO4@WLdMj7@OoA4dPnGeRY2AYpXoO2oxqwYCUaxVyZCnyNIBW1WhTYoPEgCIQB2xZWIhMZqcpHJpkeyry28vYaSk4yYHVtiy5ojsKHsKjRIbA2FXFntxvoUSm09rWzXVVnO7m8hifXtA0msXQ4Yabb93egDLy8PM@Vh4bxwBr4@nF2miTTcN08ZelW8n3XtH9nbRAlgbdsF1wN@XMPr@BmdgMfvnAKqqhhobSGUnTa9wxCylhVNQyq@pjEoo89yUoWmlhDtniBjNaxS4LLbCquM3E1NHJWXOqu8MqaaArXaUPzLQAPogfnkH4PkK1VLJ5ln2lB/gzylWcnShZCXhmxRWnsPMjTQ5gksd@yTZjyf7p0xnyDAbzhF@KX@AV1@TZrudz/YhzbILRoeFkIJ4kZH4O5KB5itE8t9n2Uk8SAQ7@utM2Fhh/khfNJ/8gec4jMknzelTtB4iC5YicSWpwjI1K/@kEpuNuYYJ7sXBJ86XI/h4tJ7Km37z7CwroH2u8zVZa97egISo7y@cUE@Jx2oHOGTvf0HMiWOyK3/IMoaQq45JHn8pvK16HCRY3FQz9m/CvQYXYr4XJR9fmFPuDxuRof1nHhlMeTdCOg52Tg030v0v8h4VL5JCGM7QmjnCjpMTO2ljspHU8ud86dlcKLhOmyP/N9VHPf22Csls@OmLH/EfYO4M8OnnNrbyoZ7t@FdbThZ9@JgdkNiZ5ZYlfFv5jl2RJmFQeAkvVv) with a `_start` that passes buffers and write()s the result.

The code in the fall-through path is 1 byte longer than it needs to be on its own: that makes the jump displacement `08` instead of `07`, because opcode `07` is `pop es`.  That segfaults on many values we could push.

And `07` is not valid in 64-bit mode (illegal instruction), otherwise we could possibly arrange a jump that turns into a `push` of the just-zeroed register, allowing us to pop the null selector into ES.  Setting ES to 0 in 32-bit user-space will fault, or lead to `movsb` faulting. (Even under a 64-bit kernel where 64-bit user-space does run with ds=es=0 null selectors.)

Disassembly of the uppercased version:

```
08049000 <rev>:
 8049000:       31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
 8049002:       51                      push   ecx
 8049003:       08 d1                   or     cl,dl        # c |= 0  leaves ECX unchanged

08049005 <rev.fallthrough>:
 8049005:       59                      pop    ecx
 8049006:       8d 7c 0f ff             lea    edi,[edi+ecx*1-0x1]
 804900a:       b2 02                   mov    dl,0x2

0804900c <rev.loop>:
 804900c:       a4                      movs   BYTE PTR es:[edi],BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
 804900d:       29 d7                   sub    edi,edx
 804900f:       e2 fb                   loop   804900c <rev.loop>
 8049011:       c3                      ret
```

(lower-case ASCII ranges from `'a'` 0x61 to `'z'` (`0x7a`).  The 7C ModRM for the LEA is just beyond that.  `59` pop ecx is already upper case.  If there was a case-flip instead of just upper-case version of this challenge, we could make it 0x79.  That byte isn't executed in the upper-case version: `jno` jumps over it.

The lower-case version is:

```
08049000 <rev>:
 8049000:       31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
 8049002:       71 08                   jno    804900c <rev.loop>
 8049004:       d1                      .byte 0xd1

08049005 <rev.fallthrough>:        # having this label here syncs disassembly after the stray byte above
 8049005:       59                      pop    ecx
 8049006:       8d 7c 0f ff             lea    edi,[edi+ecx*1-0x1]
 804900a:       b2 02                   mov    dl,0x2

0804900c <rev.loop>:
 804900c:       a4                      movs   BYTE PTR es:[edi],BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
 804900d:       29 d7                   sub    edi,edx
 804900f:       e2 fb                   loop   804900c <rev.loop>
 8049011:       c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 128 bytes

The procedure just prints each character recursively, but switches the printing to after the recursive call if in uppercase mode to reverse the output.

```pascal
procedure f;var c:char;begin if eof then exit;read(c);if byte('a')-97<0 then begin f;write(c);end else begin write(c);f;end;end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvBDoIwEATQO1@xN@CA8Wa0/syyTGmTWpqlon49FjAe9rDzZhLPwqGzSdak06j8IOEZSX3MZosEw1NB1iysJDdxrKbH6CN5S5gsZYdIePtsFDw00poC/Sejqbluu@vlfj46x8qal/qCpYc4EMKMn/xzu8l@6y4VlVVV/tPqEML0BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), 52 bytes

`␀` represents the literal null byte `\x00`

```
-[<->---]<[[-]<[<]>----------------[>]]>,[␀>,]<[.<]u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/XzfaRtdOV1c31iY6GkTYxIJ4KCDaLjbWTieawU4HKK9nE1v6/39Gak5OPgMA)

On the interpreter the input has a null byte at the end

EOF is `\x00`