# Sum the array times n, except the last

Tags: code-golf, array, arithmetic

I've been posting relatively hard challenges recently, so here goes an easy one.

### Task

Given an array \$A\$ and a number \$n\$, calculate the sum of all numbers of \$A\$ multiplied by \$n\$, except the last one. All numbers (the elements of \$A\$ and the value of \$n\$) are positive integers, and \$A\$ is non-empty. Shortest code in bytes wins.

I have a 3-byte J solution. Can you find it (or beat it in a different language)?

### Test cases

```
A           N   Ans   Explanation
3 1 4 1 5   10  95    (3+1+4+1)*10+5
3 1 4 1 5   1   14    (3+1+4+1)*1+5
1           999 1     1
```

Comment: Can we take the list in reverse?

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' No.

Comment: I wonder if your J solution used mixed base conversion

Comment: Can we take the input as numbers instead of a single array?

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Yes, that's fine.

Comment: @xnor Unfortunately no. See xash's solution for explanation.

Answer (score 33):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

That was fun to find.

```
&+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1bT1/2v@VzA0UEhTMFYwVDABYlMuBSCJzLe0tATyDQE)

#### How it works

`10 (&+/) 3 1 4 1 5` will bind `10` as an argument of `+` as `10&+`, one verb that gets inserted between the elements of the list by `/`. So we have: `3 (10&+) 1 (10&+) 4 (10&+) 1 (10&+) 5`. Now `x n&v y` means that `y` gets applied to `n&v` for `x` times. With J's right to left evaluation we get: to 5 add 1 times 10, add 4 times 10, add 1 times 10, add 3 times 10. A challenge made for J's stranger parts. :-) And because `+` is commutative, `+&/` would also be a valid solution.

Comment: Perfect, you nailed it!

Answer (score 28):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>28</s>  23 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Mukundan314*

Expects `(A)(n)`.

```javascript
A=>n=>eval(A.join`*n+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@9/R1i7P1i61LDFHw1EvKz8zL0ErTztB839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSxjqGOCRCbxmpqGBpoanLhk8eUNgQKW1paamr@BwA)

#### How?

We simply join the input array with `"*n+"`, so that `[1,2,3]` is turned into `"1*n+2*n+3"` and evaluate the resulting string.

Comment: I'm simultaneously amazed and disgusted. Good work!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
foldr1.((+).).(*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/J6XIUE9DQ1tTT1NPQ0vzv4aqpm1aTmaBQhpXbmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCdLSxjoKhjoIJmDSNVVBVMDTQUcAiChQ0BDEsLS1j//9LTstJTC/@r5tcUAAA)

It turns out this this was close to a port of the [intended J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206979/20260). The pointfree function `((+).).(*)` takes the argument `n` to the map `\a b->a*n+b`, that is, to add `n` times the left value to the right value. This creates the same "verb" as J used, and the `foldr1` does the same a J's automatic right to left evaluation. It starts with the rightmost value in the list, which never gets multiplied by `n`, and applies it right-to-left, effectively increasing the sum so far with `n` times to the new element.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:a.pop()+sum(a)*n
```

Port of my Japt solution to python

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoMwDET3fIW3xm2EGgFDkPiStoMrimoJTETSga9Pk8JQSx7u7vnst/hepE4j9HBPE83PgYCMdFT5xWu8hM@sCc@SePbLGiFsQalxWWFieQFLMaoQB5ZOQR4yIAZIQi4sSBX8xFGj2tPs3liiJkYoLcSlgw7qZE74@IGSwcLJcejXokZd6hH6PcxfEFNtrGnytmCv4Fr1p8E2yoJzDuwX)

Comment: Snap! Just wrote the exact same code without looking at any answers!

Comment: +1 for 2 min earlier

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
#2Tr@Most@#+Last@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X9kopMjBN7@4xEFZ2ycRRKn9DyjKzCtRcEiPrjbWMdQxAWLTWh1Dg1gu7BLI4oa1OpaWlrH//wMA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:a.pop()+sum(a)*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3PcXs2tFqrEBMSfAiwKIqRBIpTVsWhnD2WurClbOYv@/l5Zm3f046C33VhJcabw8FiutSHc1kGO7dPDKFOx1857yDChiBWIzVGQfBIU@9aOM4IQdZIP8riFzkPy7iT0qJiRAkdnOfaTOfL/mdcviuIqNI@smC5x0MGlKOMnlscXq285guYwftWU8Xv8LhCotbYbF11FTQtSvF8AE)

Answer (score 5):

### [Clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/) 41 bytes

`#(+(last %1)(* %2(apply +(butlast %1))))`

Unfortunately, `+` does have to be `apply`ed.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1lDWyMnsbhEQdVQU0NLQdVII7GgIKdSQVsjqbQEJgEE/zW5uDQKijLzSnLyFDTSFKKNFQwVTIDYNFbB0EBTE7ckupxhrIKlpSXQRAA)

Comment: Welcome to the community! Why not add a [Try-It-Online](https://tio.run/#clojure) link for your code so users can try it out :)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by writing just `%` instead of `%1`, it is always recognized as the first argument, even when there are more.

Comment: And another one by swapping the order of operands: https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1lDWyMnsbhEQVVTQ0sjsaAgp1JBWyOptAQqqKlqpKn5X5OLS6OgKDOvJCdPQSNNIdpYwVDBBIhNYxUMDTQ1cUuiyxnGKlhaWgJNBAA

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen.

```
*`²÷O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fK@HQpsPb/f//jzbWMdQxAWLTWC5DAwA)

### Explanation

```
*     Multiply list by second operand
 `    Dump
   ÷  Divide the last item by
  ²   the second operand
    O Sum the stack
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
„²*ý.VO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8Q5u0Du/VC/P//z/aWMdQxwSITWO5DA0A)

### Explanation

```
„       2-char string
 ²*     (Which does when evaluated) Multiply by the second input
   ý    Join the input list by this
    .V  Evaluate
      O Sum the resulting stack
```

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fK@HQpsPb/f//jzbWMdQxAWLTWC5DAwA).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit infix function. Takes \$A\$ as left argument and \$n\$ as right argument.

```apl
⊢/+.×+×∘~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXIn1tvcPTtQ9Pf9Qxo@5/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/GysYKpgAsalCmoKhARcKl8sQSFpaWgIA)

`×∘~` \$A×(1-n)\$

`+.×+` \$\big(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i×n\big)+\$

`⊢/` rightmost element (lit. right-argument reduction)

So this effectively implements: $$
\Bigg(\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i×n\bigg)+A×(1-n)\Bigg)_N\\
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i×n\bigg)+A_N×(1-n)\\
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i×n\bigg)+A_N-n×A_N\\
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} A_i×n\bigg)+A_N
$$

Comment: @Bubbler Ugh, thanks, that'll be much harder to explain. Also, it isn't really related to my solution at all. You should self-answer with that, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
+⍣⎕/⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b/2o97Fj/qm6gMxSOA/ZxqXsYKhggkQm3IZGnCh8kFcQy5LS0sA)

A full program, which pretty much works like the [3-byte J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206979/78410). Takes two lines of input, \$A\$ first and \$n\$ second.

#### How it works

```apl
+⍣⎕/⎕
    ⎕  ⍝ Take the input A
   /   ⍝ Reduce by...
+      ⍝   Add the left argument
 ⍣⎕    ⍝   n times

For n=10 and A = 3 1 4 1 5, this becomes:
+⍣10/3 1 4 1 5
3 (+⍣10) 1 (+⍣10) 4 (+⍣10) 1 (+⍣10) 5
3 added 10 times to
         1 added 10 times to
                  4 added 10 times to
                           1 added 10 times to
                                    5
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 8 bytes

```apl
1¨⍛,⊥0,⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/3/DQike9s3UedS01ABKL/6c9apvwqLfvUVfzo941j3q3HFpv/Kht4qO@qcFBzkAyxMMz@L@xgqGCCRCbKqQpGBpwoXC5DIGkpaUlAA)

A longer but more interesting one. A tacit dyadic function that takes \$A\$ on its left and \$n\$ on the right.

Uses mixed base conversion `⊥`, which does the following:

```apl
Base:        1  1  1  ... 1    n
Digit value: n  n  n  ... n    1
Array value: 0  a1 a2 ... ax-1 ax
Total: a1n + a2n + ... + ax-1n + ax
```

#### How the code works

```apl
1¨⍛,⊥0,⊣  ⍝ Input: left=A, right=n
1¨        ⍝ An array of ones as long as A
  ⍛,      ⍝ Append n, which becomes the base
     0,⊣  ⍝ A prepended with single zero, which becomes the values
    ⊥     ⍝ Mixed base conversion as described above
```

Comment: Another interesting method could be `(⎕⊥,)/⎕`, but I don't think you can get rid of the brackets

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

-2 bytes with help from Giuseppe

```r
function(l,n)rev(l)%*%n^(seq(!l)>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jRydPsyi1TCNHU1VLNS9Oozi1UEMxR9POUPN/mkayhrGOoY4JEJtq6igYGmhyYYiBhAx1FCwtLUEsIzjLAML6DwA)

Reverse the vector, and perform dot product with the vector \$(n^0, n^1, n^1, \ldots,n^1) = (1, n, n,\ldots, n)\$.

I just discovered this behaviour of `seq`, which gains 1 byte on item 4 of [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138046/86301): `seq(!l)` is equivalent to `seq(along.with = l)` (giving the vector `1 2 3 ... length(l)`) in all situations, even if `l` is of length 1. That is because `!l` is a logical, not an integer, and so we avoid the call to `seq.int` when `l` is a (length 1) integer.

Comment: If the list were guaranteed to be at least length 2, [this](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jRydPsyi1TCNHU1VLNS9OQ1GxOLVQI9E2R1PXUPN/mkayhrGOoY4JEJtq6igYGmhyYYiBhAx1FCwtLTX/AwA) would be a byte shorter, but as it is, it's longer by one instead.

Comment: @Giuseppe Good old `seq_along`! I parlayed it into [a 36-byter](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jRydPsyi1TCNHU1VLNS9Oozi1UCPRNkfTzlDzf5pGsoaxjqGOCRCbauooGBpocmGIgYQMdRQsLS01/wMA). Thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe `seq(!l)` works and is equivalent to `seq(a=l)`, even if `l` is of length 1!

Comment: Wow, it's been a while since I saw such a neat and applicable golfing trick! That's probably more due to my lack of participation here than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{*|x+/y*-1_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/6fZlWtVVOhrV@ppWsYX1H7P01PXUPDWMFQwQSITa0NDTStkblAno6htaWlpabm//8A)

**Explanation:**

Couldn't figure out a smart way of solving this.

```
{*|x+/y*-1_x} / the solution
{           } / lambda taking implicity x, y
        -1_x  / drop (_) 1 element from end of x
      y*      / multiply by y
   x+/        / sum up with x as accumulator
 *|           / take last (reverse, first)
```

**Notes:**

- **-1 byte** thanks to coltim - thanks!

Comment: You can trim a byte by doing `{*|x+/y*-1_x}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 407 bytes

```
     ^      ^
    /l\    /+\
   /oop\  ^---^
  ^-----^ -  /x\
 / \   / \   ---
/arg\ /set\
-----^-----^
    /2\   /+\
    ---  ^---^
        ^-  /1\
       ^-   ---
      ^-
     /]\
    ^---^
   / \ /2\
  /set\---
 ^-----^
/x\   ^- 
---  /]\
    ^---^ 
   ^-  /#\
  / \  ---^
 /set\   / \
^-----^ /arg\
-    /+\-----^
    ^---^   /2\
   /*\  -   ---
  ^---^
 ^-  /#\
/x\ ^---
---/ \
  /arg\
 ^-----
/1\
---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLDoJADEX3/Yom7jSTER9/M5IQJWoigYAL/fra284AktAHbU9vGb5j0z1vYbo@2q4VYTw1uyPY@Ermdglp7PtB8zqEgDK8Rhy08tGGyGh2qwWKzXhPHKf2nchb3Tr5kBYw2hduFgBslWiVGrWkHsSLd8yzWK9sDW2xTZS9qtJJZPv@ZpnKzo0N4wpnGsfJVE620yjkf7M6y1mcJXDcAjMrzyrLGujBJ8gBnTM3Cyacr15Eqr0cpZKTvucf)

Takes input through command arguments, with `n` as the first argument. This basically implements the algorithm:

```
i = 2
x = 0
o = 0
while args[i]:
  o += x*args[1]
  x = args[i]
  i += 1

print(o + x)
```

But with more nesting and some shortcuts, like using the variable `2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pa -MList::Util+sum`, 19 bytes

```perl
$_=pop(@F)+<>*sum@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYgv0DDwU1T28ZOq7g018Ht/39jBUMFEyA25TI04ELiAKGlpeW//IKSzPy84v@6BYk5/3V9fTKLS6ysQksyc7SB@gE)

Comment: Did you mean `-MList::Util=sum`?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know `=` would work there. I've always used `+` for places where spaces can't be used without quotes or to help precedence (e.g. `/\d+\D/,say+($1)x$&`). Looks like a bunch of things work though. Good to know, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
o +V*Ux
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P19BO0wrtOL//2hjHQVDHQUTMGkay2VoAAA)

### Explanation

```
o +V*Ux
o         // Pop and return last element of first input
  +       // plus
   V*     // second input times
     Ux   // Sum of first input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 31 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1(?=.*,1*;(1*)|1*$)
$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi8tQw95WT0vHUMtaw1BLs8ZQS0WTS8WQy/D/f2MdQx0TIDa1NjTgQuJwGVpbWloCAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1(?=.*,1*;(1*)|1*$)
$1
```

Multiply all but the last element of `A` by `n` and delete `A`.

```
1
```

Take the sum and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
+*sPQEe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1urOCDQNfX//2hjHQVDHQUTMGkay2Vo8C@/oCQzP6/4v24KAA)

### Explanation

```
+*sPQEe
    Q    # First input
   P     # Remove the last element
  s      # Sum elements
 *   E   # Multiply by the second input
+     e  # Add the last element of the first input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html) with [dash](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/tree/732d92eac56023a4fb4a5dc3d9d4e274ebf44bf9#-sum-list) library: <s>38</s> 51 bytes

```
(lambda(n A)(+(car(last A))(* n(-sum(butlast A)))))
```

(38 bytes was the function body' size only.)

Comment: You forgot to add the last back in.

Comment: My bad, unfortunately the answer is now much longer.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, 18 bytes

```
33 DB       XOR  BX, BX         ; clear running sum
49          DEC  CX             ; decrement array length
74 09       JZ   ADD_LAST       ; handle array length of 1 case
        LOOP_SUM:
AD          LODSW               ; load next value into AX
03 D8       ADD  BX, AX         ; BX = BX + AX
E2 FB       LOOP LOOP_SUM       ; keep looping
93          XCHG AX, BX         ; move sum into AX
F7 E2       MUL  DX             ; DX:AX = AX * DX
93          XCHG AX, BX         ; move result back to BX
        ADD_LAST:
AD          LODSW               ; load last value into AX
03 C3       ADD  AX, BX         ; AX = AX + BX
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

As a callable function: `[SI]` to input array, `CX` array length, `DX` = `N`.  Output to `AX`.

Rather than make an elaborate test program, here's it being run using DOS DEBUG, entering the input array into memory and setting registers as they would be called:

[image]

Explanation of above:

Enter input array into memory address `DS:200` as 16-bit, little-endian words:

```
-e 200 3 0 1 0 4 0 1 0 5 0
```

Point `SI` to this input array:

```
-r SI
:200
```

Set `CX` to array's length:

```
-r CX
:5
```

Set `N` to `10` (`0xA` in hex):

```
-r DX
:A
```

Execute and stop before last instruction (`RET` will "return to DOS" and clobber registers):

```
-g 111
```

Result is `AX=005F` or `95` in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/), 13 bytes

```
~:i;-1%{i*+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84q01rXULU6U0u7Vuv//2hjBUMFEyA2jVUwNAAA)

**Explanation:**
`~` to convert string input to array and integer on stack. `:i;` assigns \$n\$ to `i` and pops value. `-1%` reverses the array and `{i*+}*` folds the array with `(a, b) -> a*n + b`

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84qUz@2WrtWK1Pr/39jBUMFEyA2VTA0AAA "GolfScript – Try It Online"), if you take input in a different format

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), <s>7747</s> <s>3668</s> <s>1985</s> <s>1732</s> 1619 bytes

### Edits

- -4079 bytes by giving the variables shorter names...
- -1638 bytes by doing some more manual optimisation
- -253 bytes by using more 0-height trees
- -113 bytes because out can output the final result directly

```
    ^  ^        ^       ^        ^  ^        ^        ^        ^
   / \ -^      / \     / \      / \ -^      / \      / \      / \
  /set\ -^    / do\   /set\    /   \ -^    /set\    /   \    /out\
 ^-----^ -^  ^-----^ ^-----^  / set \ -^  ^-----^  /     \   -----^
/l\   / \ -^/c\   ^-/n\   ^- ^-------^ -^/i\   ^- / loop  \      /+\
---  /arg\^----  ^- ---  ^- /N\     /#\^----  ^- ^---------^    ^---^
    ^------^    / \     /-\ ---    ^----^    ^- / \       / \  /s\ /#\
   / \    ^-   ^---^   ^---^      / \  ^-   ^- /<=>\     ^---^ --- ---^
  /99 \  ^-   / \ / \ /n\ /1\    /arg\^-   ^- ^-----^   / \ / \      / \
  ----- ^-   ^---/   \--- ---   ^------^  ^- /i\   /0\ ^---/set\    /arg\
       ^-   / \  -----^        /n\    ^- /-\ ---   ---/ \ ^-----^   -----^
      ^-   ^---      / \       ---   ^- ^---^        ^---/s\   / \      /-\
     ^-   / \       /set\           ^- /n\ /1\      / \  ---  / + \    ^---^
    ^-   /set\     ^-----^         / \ --- ---     ^---      ^-----^  /n\ /1\
   ^-   ^-----^   /c\   /!\       /set\           / \       /s\   /*\ --- ---
   -^  /n\   /+\  ---  ^---      ^-----^         /set\      ---  ^---^
   / \ ---  ^---^     /=\       /s\   /0\       ^-----^         /#\ /N\
  /set\    /n\ /1\   ^---^      ---   ---      /i\   /-\       ^--- ---
 ^-----^   --- ---  / \ /l\                    ---  ^---^     / \
/n\   /0\          /arg\---                        /i\ /1\   /arg\
---   ---         ^-----                           --- ---  ^-----
                 /n\                                       /i\
                 ---                                       ---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbagIxEH3PV6T4Vgmz0vahUPsJ/YIQEJVW8IZrH/r1aTK3zO4qGGozzJycOXPR899lddhtQr/@2R62OftyEv7RSaP7ZtAYrvwDH31gV7XtfTM4MAoD9NuroMBvTjVIPnR4pRg5q3H6vRaKFOpJCBNb7gIuz5jDOD1zkMfBPqpcWFc7BTjSzc8oA@zYCX5/Op291jKPrkCKsbp8R3yBMLnhi1szM0EhDlRgQiliiVebGiKxcZiftHaSBX2sSVx7mYJwm1vCHPTwsfwkHkLUTCwH3t8VWd/gp/QGFjQEKti2KhmkmTTGmhwcI@cZ1FzlYJuhi4TUyddcTtZPBPnWLAQdpezWMkwXjTyeu2FK3FyzoKrMto3F93GwyoFlNVF@sLNNs2ldk1@tuYyrbcGAIQ3LpG3V9tkC2p5TLmdr5PHgksPTPaG2BEQ@a7LKJuS4@F62fJJ/Sq7I9uOhHsIuR4m76O@wzmL9Wjn7y6C9NQPTDeBntFrB0lJZg@2QqRTCvW2MnrHusuLckc7gcWM19/RUNaSYdnskVsv294@KJaSb5jhG/9gpatztQh86BZlzfsmL/Fo@b3nR/QM)

### Explanation

```cs
(set nil (arg 99)) // Make nil

// Count the number of input arguments - n
(set nargin 0)
(do
    cond
    (
        (set nargin (+ nargin 1))
        (set cond (! (= (arg nargin) nil)))
    )
)
(set nargin (- nargin 1))

(set N (# (arg nargin))) // N - the number all but last of the array elements is getting multiplied by

// Add all but last elements of A
(set sum 0)
(set i (- nargin 1))
(loop
    (<=> i 0)
    (
        (set i (- i 1))
        (set sum (+ sum (* (# (arg i)) N))) // A[i] multiplied by N
    )
)
(set sum (+ sum (# (arg (- nargin 1))))) // Add the last element of A
(out sum) // Print
```

Comment: Some golfing for [1042 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVPbSgMxEH3fr4j4poS4qA8F648YF0pbtGDZ0vXFr49nZk6SWTSwzWTu58z08nPdnU@HuOw/j@djKQFnCvVMq7vrnWXATwqZzyrZ3fWQv2i5zwhJy/G7eh5m9VVN10MzzxeRpxgjysgFgQqReDe9JJODILzTbR6sqLSR9pYqRPWLfLVskiEtWUvhBy6760dWydzYB18Op3kHQVWTmUSKxPqe9ZVetq8dK2usCZyilwXdH7xIGY2SkDYbeiPOUQq8N/i2mZZsxAdiH5iCfTYCNQUpBR2nir/TruPurSqpUqrm0OZjYO70hibusnEw5sGFhpYaZZQmP/qKnXPF3WIb8wKuYegrYPPC8HUBahBzT87N6tomiIeBCA5kA4UtalNZUSIvv/JDG7nyLVYZcf8ToCaIMJmWtgQeeZ1xVbIzv2K8XaSx7FpYHxIN27DSM@@/B7ZSymMZyxO@5zI@/AI). There's more you can do though (especially with that first `do` loop)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), <strike>46</strike> 19 bytes

```
->a,n{eval a*"*n+"}
```

Courtesy of [petStorm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96495/petstorm).

**Old answer:**

```
n,*A,l=gets.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
p A.sum*n+l
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ686tSwxRyFRS0krT1up9n@BQlp0tLGOoY4JEJvG6hgaxHJxYQjCxAxjdSwtLWP/AwA), as an anonymous function

Comment: I should use anonymous functions more. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 26 bytes

```
%@_2A<\:.>2M3A[1A~M~]%\WM:
```

Now it works properly on the testcases. Works on MAWP 1.1's integer input.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%40_2A%3C%5C%3A.%3E2M3A%5B1A%7EM%7E%5D%25%5CWM%3A&input=1%202%203%204)

Comment: The new program works now. Only took 6 days!

Comment: +1 for persistence!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ṫṭ×S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlUPd649PD34/@Hl@o@a1kT@/x8dbaxjqGMCxKaxOoYGsTqoAiA@kLC0tIwFAA)

```
Ṫ       Pop the last element of the left argument,
 ṭ      append it to
  ×     the right argument times what's left of the left argument,
   S    and sum.
```

A more fun solution, which borrows Jonathan Allan's base conversion trick:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
S,¥/ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Y59BS/Yc7Wv8fXq7/qGlN5P//0dHGOoY6JkBsGqtjaBCrgyoA4gMJS0vLWAA)

```
   /     Reduce the left argument by
 ,       pair right with
S ¥      the sum of left,
    ḅ    and convert from base right.
```

Bonus: `Ä-.ịḅ’}` is a whole 7 bytes, and doesn't even work if the left argument only has one element, but it's just kind of funny.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
j&10p#v&\10g*\4
_\.@  >+\:#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz///PUjM0KFAuU4sxNEjXijHhio/Rc1BQsNOOsVL@/9/QQMFYwVDBBIhNFQA) Input is first `N`, then `A`. Note that there has to be a trailing space.

Animation of the code:

[image]

<sup>The pilcrow (¶) represents a newline (value 10) in the grid.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
fn($a,$n)=>array_pop($a)+array_sum($a)*$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw/C8IwEMX3@xRvuKHRUCzqUGJ1EhwEu5dSQmnI0jY0dRDxs8f4Z3CQ4x3v9457zrqwOzjriNgUwQwJa8mDKPZ6mvStcaOLiVh@yF/7Fy14CIp47vzsUaAioIqzlpncRG1riWyFuP8dfvK3z/McNYhqKCIzTp1uLRJ827WPDgL3@NK1dgSbJE1TnoVEeSqb4@Ws6IHwBA)

Just trying to use all the built-ins!

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 20 bytes

```raku
{@^a.pop+$^b*@a.sum}
```

By using twigils, `@^a` matches the first arg (the array), and `$^b` the second (the multiplier).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9ohLlGvIL9AWyUuScshUa@4NLf2vzUXF1CBgyNQgWNRUWKlXl5quYaxjqGOCRCbauoQFDXUtAab4AQ0wdBAR8FQR8HSEmhqcWKlQppGjUq8pkJafhHIhiigIuv/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṪṭSƊḅ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of numbers on the left and a number on the right which yields a number.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlUPd64NPtb1cEfr////o411FAx1FEzApGnsf0MDAA)**

```
ṪṭSƊḅ - Link: list of numbers, A; number n
   Ɗ  - last three links as a monad - f(A):
Ṫ     -   remove the tail (of A) and yield its value
  S   -   sum (the remaining elements in A)
 ṭ    -   tack -> [sum_of_remaining, tail]
    ḅ  - convert from base (n) -> n×sum_of_remaining+1×tail
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Q'Nial](https://github.com/danlm/QNial7), 33 bytes (20 bytes without operator definition)

```
s is op n a{+link[n*front,last]a}   %full operator definition

+link[n*front,last]a                %simple function
```

Explanation:

```
+                                   sum, reduce by +
 link                               list of the items of the argument
     [                              atlas (argument of link operation), point-free notation
      n*                            n *
        front                       all elements but the last of the argument
             ,
              last                  last element of the argument
                  ]                 end atlas
                   a                array a (argument of atlas)
```

Intermediate results, for `n=10` and `a=3 1 4 1 5`

```
         10 s 3 1 4 1 5
or
         s 10 (3 1 4 1 5)

or
         +link[10*front,last]3 1 4 1 5

         [n*front,last] a
+-------------+-+
|+--+--+--+--+|5|
||30|10|40|10|| |
|+--+--+--+--+| |
+-------------+-+

         link[n*front,last] a
+--+--+--+--+-+
|30|10|40|10|5|
+--+--+--+--+-+

         +link[n*front,last]a
95
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
a@v+b*$+Ha
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboVS7IKlpSVpuharEh3KtJO0VLQ9EiECUPFN0UrRxtaG1iZAbBqrpGNoANMBAA)

-2 from DLosc.

Comment: `@RVa` can be `a@v`; also, `@<` can be `H` if you use Pip 1.0: [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboVS7IKlpSVpuharEh3KtJO0VLQ9EiECUPFN0UrRxtaG1iZAbBqrpGNoANMBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```julia
A$n=pop!(A)+sum(A)n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwEEX3OcW3dJFgFgbroosKPUctIm0KKTUNbQr1HuLK03mRGlMLIvphZmB48@fXQ6NOYpymNNSJac2KpmzdD2c39GRlb3skyAicaLblEByR77vcjQ1Dske8438ACA@IaAEEPpTzOI5ngOSEVG0HSlOuGa8ZlIZ/7w@ro3IxitZcXK5Q@52q5nWCmiyOplPaNpoGj/sVAYd3ez1wJPOUbHr5C7994xzBwVI5GllYWSKsWfB20CVxNT0B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 9 bytes

```
-_{1+0+00_?+0+?*?
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyItX3sxKzArMFxuMFxuXz8rMCs_Kj8iLCJbMTAsWzMsMSw0LDEsNV1dIiwwXQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 58 bytes

```
(load library
(d S(q((A N)(i(t A)(a(*(h A)N)(S(t A)N))(h A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcotDoAwFANgzykq@1AsgJjcBTA7wQiCJQs/A8Ppx4MEh2jSfukZlyvFYyuFaQ0TUhxzyFfFCZ476TAII084YWDNWYuKf2UQeaDQQ78tDDpNLwLTSPWj@NTostZKuQE)

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>78</s> 65 bytes

```
(d S(q((A N)(i(t A)(i(h A)(a(S(c(s(h A)1)(t A))N)N)(S(t A)N))(h A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRSFYo1BDw1HBT1MjU6NEwRFEZYCoRI1gjWSNYjDHUBMspekHhEBhENtPUxMk9V8jWAFogLGCoYIJEJtqaioYGmhyYRFVgIkaAnmWlpaa/wE)

Solution without using `library`, which is only for `*`.

-13 bytes thanks to DLosc

Comment: The non-library version can be [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRSFYo1BDw1HBT1MjU6NEwRFEZYCoRI1gjWSNYjDHUBMspekHhEBhENtPUxMk9V8jWAFogLGCoYIJEJtqaioYGmhyYRFVgIkaAnmWlpaa/wE) if you make the multiplication algorithm part of the main function.

Comment: @DLosc that's incredibly clever. I have a lot of practice to do!

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 56 bytes

```
s,i;f(v,l,f)int*v;{for(i=0;i<l-1;s+=v[i++]);return s*f;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VY1RC4IwEICf2684hGDTk7TsaflLREKWF4M1YzMfEn/7WmBg93b38X2n8rtSIXjUkviEBkloO6aTnGlwXNeF1BeTl9Jn9dToLGuFdP34chZ8SnJh7NFpywWbGawTdeica1qoYS4RjggnhArhvEi2W@nV9DZy7vW7H@h7EXDYrk0RP7G/KHVqHFy0qg14uoiIJ/tbgkA8mvjr42qIGFpYCB8)

`f` takes a vector (`v`), the length of the vector (`l`) and the factor to multiply the vector with (`f`) as arguments. It sums up the values in the vector, except for the last one (in `s`) and returns the sum multiplied by the factor.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `s`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
×Ẹ¹÷
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrFS7IKlpSVpuhYrD09_uGvHoZ2Hty8pTkouhoouWGOsY6hjAsSmXIYGEDEA)

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
µʋ¹×+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKw9tPdV9aOfh6dpLipOSi6GiC9YY6xjqmACxKZehAUQMAA)

Suggested by @noodleman.

##### Explanation

```python
×Ẹ¹÷  # Implicit input
×     # Multiply each item in the list by the number
 Ẹ    # Dump onto stack, last item on top
  ¹÷  # Divide this number by the second input
      # Implicit output of summed stack
```

```python
µʋ¹×+ # Implicit input
µʋ    # Right-reduce the input list by:
  ¹×  #  Multiply by the second input
    + #  And add this to the cumulative total
      # Implicit output
```

Comment: 5 bytes flagless [`µʋ¹×+`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faEm0klLsgqWlJWm6FisPbT3VfWjn4enaS4qTkouhogvWGOsY6pgAsSmXoQFEDAA)

Comment: @noodleman thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 17 bytes

```
Input N
Nsum(Ans)-(N-1)Ans(dim(Ans
```

Takes input of \$A\$ in `Ans`.

Alternatives that are also 17 bytes:

```
Input N
sum(Ansmax(1,N(N>cumSum(1 or Ans
```

```
Input N
sum(AnsNaugment(1 or ΔList(Ans),{N⁻¹
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Ｉ⁺⊟θ×η↨θ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyCntFgjIL9Ao1BTRyEkMze1WCNDR8EpsThVo1BHwVATBKz//4@ONgbydBRMwKRpLJAyiP2vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Presumably Charcoal has the same problem as IO when it comes to summing empty lists. Edit: saved 1 byte by converting from base 1 instead. Explanation:

```
   θ        `A`
  ⊟         Remove last element
 ⁺          Added to
       θ    Remaining elements of `A`
      ↨ ¹   Take the sum by converting from base 1
    ×       Multiplied by
     η      `n`
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
a___~f~b_=+a#+b&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8xPj6@Lq0uKd5WO1FZO0ntf0BRZl5JdLWycq2uXVq0srJRrINyrJqDg0M1V7WhgY6xjqGOCRCb1uoA@ahcS0tLHcNartr//wE)

This one doesn't need a strange-looking input.

Takes input as `f[A][n]`.

---

**older, 17 bytes**

```
#//.a_@b_:>a#2+b&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfXy8x3iEp3souUdlIO0ntf0BRZl5JtLKuXbqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtbGDoYMJEJvqGBrU6qDwQVxDHUtLy1qu2v//AQ)

Takes a singly linked list as input: if `X` is a value and `L` is a list, `X` is the single-element list with element `X`, and  `X[L]` is the list with element `X`, followed by the elements of `L`. For example, `3@1@4@1@5=3[1[4[1[5]]]]` is the list with `3, 1, 4, 1, 5`.

Per [this discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16548/81203), we can take the first element with `Head`, and the tail with `Last`.

Comment: is `{3@1@4@1@5,10}` a valid input?   If it is, nice job! I tried something similar but the best I could do was 24 bytes `#/.{a__,b_}:>Tr@{a}#2+b&`

Comment: @J42161217 a flat input can get down to 18 byes by taking it in `Dot` or a `Flat` two-byte operator (`a_.b_` is `Times[Optional[a_],b_]` rather than `Dot[a_,b_]`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfXy8xXkEvKd7KLkk7UdlI7X9AUWZeSbSyrl26g4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V7Wxgp6CIRCbQGlTHUODWh2s4iBhl/ySaMNYHUtLy1qu2v//AQ) For a list, you can get 20: `#/.{a__,b_}:>+a#2+b&`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

```sh
n=`<&0`
<<<$[0${@/#/*n+}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxP882wUbNIIHLxsZGJdpApdpBX1lfK0@7Nva/JhdXmoKxgqGCCRCbKgAVKBgaYAoBRQzBLEtLy/8A)

Takes the list as arguments and N on stdin. Inspired by [the JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206976/86147). Prefix each element with `*n+` and `$[evaluate arithmetically]`. We have to add a `0` to the start as well. This is one byte shorter than using the join flag `<<<$[${(j:*n+:)@}]`

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-P`, 24 bytes

```sh
a=(0 \*`<&0`+$@)
<<<$[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgG8DFlaahqfE/0VbDQCFGK8FGzSBBW8VBk8vGxkYlOjH2vyZQgYKxgqGCCRCbKgCFFQwNMIWAIoZglqWl5X8A)

Alternate solution using the -P flag, which enables RC_EXPAND_PARAM to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

## Vimscript 36 Bytes

[Disgusted to report that Arnauld's solution also works for vimscript.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206976/64736)

```
let F={a,n->eval(join(a,"*".n."+"))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 40 bytes

I am using a table instead of an array, sql doesn't have arrays

The test uses a temporary table instead of a real table, because of lack of permissions to create a table.

```sql
SELECT sum(a*@-i/@@rowcount*a*~-@)FROM t
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1262451/sum-the-array-times-n-except-the-last)**

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, 81 bytes

It's fairly chunky :/
Mostly due to limitations in my language...

```
{@eachargv.0}{@ifloop.last is equal0}{@set*_ _,argv.1}{@/}{@incby_ R}{@/}{@echoR}
```

Takes a string of numbers or an array as the first argument, and the `n` as the 2nd argument.

You can try this on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c7290781560c876ff1e72e5d1680ed7b98861a3

---

**Ungolfed:**

The code above is a little weird to read...

Here's a more readable version:

```
{@set result 0}
{@each argv.0 as number}
    {@if loop.last is equal to false}
        {@set* number number, argv.1}
    {@/}
    {@inc by number result}
{@/}
{@echo result}
```

Notes:

- `{@set result 0}` is optional, as `{@inc}` will create the variable, if it doesn't exist
- `{@each argv.0 as number}` doesn't need need the `as number`, defaulting to the variable `_` to store values
- `{@if loop.last is equal to false}` uses the special variable `loop` to know if it is the last item in the `{@each}` Also, `false` is the same as `0`.
- `{@set* number number, argv.1}` multiplies `number` with `argv.1` and stores it inside `number`. If `number` was an array, it would multiply with all the values.
- `{@inc by number result}` will increment the variable `result` by `number` (effectivelly, `result = result + number`)
- `{@/}` is usually optional, but, with this code, they are all required.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://perldoc.perl.org/) + `-pi`, 19 bytes

```
s/,/*$^I+/g;$_=eval
```

For example, for multiplicand 10, `perl -pi10 -e's/,/*$^I+/g;$_=eval`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0dfSyXOU1s/3Vol3ja1LDHn/39jHUMdEyA2/ZdfUJKZn1f8X7cg09AAAA) Idea stolen from [this J answer](/a/206979/1976). Accuracy improved by Dom Hastings in comments on this answer (many thanks!).

Comment: You need to take `n` from input too, it's not always 10! :)

Comment: You can get the same byte-count using non-standard input for `n` (`-i`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0dfSyXOU1s/3Vol3ja1LDHn/39jHUMdEyA2/ZdfUJKZn1f8X7fgv26moQEA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 21 bytes

`ss0[+z2<o]dso0rx*ls+p`

Examples:

```
dc -e '10 3 1 4 1 5 ss0[+z2<o]dso0rx*ls+p'
95
dc -e '1 3 1 4 1 5 ss0[+z2<o]dso0rx*ls+p'
14
dc -e '999 1 ss0[+z2<o]dso0rx*ls+p'
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
{*.join("*$_+").EVAL}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pLLys/M09DSUslXltJU881zNGn9r81V3FipUKahqGBpoaNsYKhggkQm9ppwsWxC1taWmpqRBvGalr/BwA)

This works the same as the [Perl 5 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207098/76162) and also works with non-mutable lists, unlike the [existing Raku answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207027/76162), which is only one byte smaller than this.

Note: My [previous answer](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo6KFpNQ0tbJS7p8HQtzdhYBYf42v/FiZUKaRqGBjoKNsYKhgomQGxqp2nNBRXHLmxpaamjEG0Yq2n9HwA) of the same size does not work for singleton lists, which I've lodged [an issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3794) about.

Answer (score 1):

### excel, 25 bytes

Enter A followed by n in one column, followed by this formula

`=SUM(R1:R[-3])*R[-1]+R[-2]`

Comment: Note: R1C1 Reference Style option must be checked.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 58 bytes

```lua
r,t=0,{...}for i=2,#t-1 do
r=r+t[i]end print(r*t[1]+t[#t])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/SKfE1kCnWk9PrzYtv0gh09ZIR7lE11AhJZ@ryLZIuyQ6MzY1L0WhoCgzr0SjSKsk2jAWKKhcEqv5//9/S0vL/4YGAA)

Having almost no array functions, Lua doesn't do too well in this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 22 bytes

```
a=>a.last+_*a.init.sum
```

This returns a `List[Int] => Int => Int`

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DsR6KBZITjC2l6kCoV28jg)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
*1G0)0Z(s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8vQ3UDTIEqj@P//aEMFIwXjWC7T/wA)

### Explanation

```
*1G0)0Z(s
*          % Multiply the inputs and push it onto the stack
 1G        % Push first input onto the stack
   0)      % Replace top stack element with its last element
     0Z(   % Set last element of multiplied inputs to top element in stack
        s  % Replace top stack element with its sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 45 bytes

```
|a,n|a.pop().unwrap()+a.iter().sum::<i64>()*n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lY1BDoIwEEX3PcXAwrRaiUQ0AQlLjuDGuGhIiU2kktLKAjh7neIBjJv/Zyb/zTdusL7V0AmlKYOJAFg5WOpnwfUskv7VU5Y4PRqBw04kykqDl8F1RVGqc1ZRttUegF3IQgh@CnhZV7QtoGZkfEgj8WmNm6abzlm4ymYFOaAy2FfBSWjujdL2qSMaT0vMof3m37KJbkcOKYds1dMd7cCw8T/kJ5FiKs/zkFv8Bw)

The expected argument types are `a: &mut Vec<i64>` and `n: i64`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ç+Ux*V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=xytVeCpW&input=WzMsIDEsIDQsIDEsIDVdCjEw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 29 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a-join"*$b+"|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP2/ILEoMVdDJVFHJUlTJVE3Kz8zT0lLJUlbqSYzteJ/LReXGlChg4axjqGOCRCbaioYGmARgwoZaipYWlr@BwA)

^ inspired by Arnauld's solution

My original one

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 75 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)(($a[($l=$a.Length-1)]+$b*($a[0..($l-1)]-join'+'|iex)),$a)[!$l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP2/ILEoMVdDJVFHJUlTA0hHa6jk2Kok6vmk5qWXZOgaasZqqyRpgSQM9PSAciAR3az8zDx1bfWazNQKTU0dlUTNaEWVnNj/tVxcakBjHTSMdQx1TIDYVFPB0ACLGFTIUFPB0tLyPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╡÷E@
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b5f64540&i=10,%5B3,1,4,1,5%5D%0A1,%5B3,1,4,1,5%5D%0A1,%5B999%5D&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 23 bytes

```
[ dup pop -rot Σ * + ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XckrDgIxFEZh31X8GsKE8hAFgyMYDAFDEE3nEiYztOX2VhAyq2E/bKk8JOKY75ytk8Blv9ts1wtcrVyq7BsXakJL7KlDolsm7yj9LiKTyD1y4wVLpfQYhwem0Jh9mqNX@h@MMV/S6MsRdY6IIWLEQfB6YoAhTmUi3KxQJbiOLJc3)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
*ṫ⁰/J
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=*%E1%B9%AB%E2%81%B0%2FJ&inputs=%5B3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5%5D%0A10&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 30 bytes (on-calc) / 37 bytes (as text)

Assumes list variable `L₁` contains the array and variable `N` contains n.

```
dim(L₁
Nsum(L₁,1,Ans-1)+L₁(Ans
```

### Explanation

- `dim(L₁`: Get the size of L₁, to be used in the next line as `Ans`.
- `Nsum(L₁,1,Ans-1)+L₁(Ans`: The `sum(` function has optional arguments to specify the beginning and end of a region of the list to be summed. The sum is implicitly multiplied by N, then added to the last element of the list, and implicitly printed.

Closing parentheses can be left out at the end of lines in TI-BASIC.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 18 bytes

```
&n&spp&+>l<s>l*+u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tT624oEBN2y7HptguR0u71Pr/f2MuQy4TIDblMjQAAA)

```
&n                 - read all the numbers into the stack
  &s               - save the entire stack to the backup cell
    pp             - delete top two entries on the stack
      &+           - sum the stack
        >l         - switch to clean stack, load original input
          <s       - switch back, save summary to backup cell
            >l     - switch stacks, load save sum of 2nd to N entries
              *    - multiple top two entries on stack
               +   - add top two stack entries
                u  - print top of stack as a number
                 ; - exit the code to avoid printing the rest of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 28 bytes

```arturo
$[a,n][+last a n*sum chop a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?EBdq4V)

```
$[a,n][           ; a function taking args a and n
  +last a         ; add the last elt in a to
  n*sum chop a    ; n times the sum of a without its last elt
]                 ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
n=>a=>a.reduceRight((x,c)=>x+c*n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZCxTsMwEIb3PMVhdTiDiZpAoRFKJQYYO5SVocaxSyTXDk4itYryJCwVgofqo7Dh1KWCk63T2d__n8_vn8YWcveh8q-2UZfT_ZnJZ9yv2MmiFXJRrl4bxA0TNJ9tLsS5oUfwW1hTWy1jbVdI5jDEvXN8CyEWsm51Q-hdpKwDHOgGdGkkWAVOvrWlk0hUTahvxYvHUsunrRE4ZkB8h6k_rytdNkieDaEUugggmBjIYd6uX6TDwS-udSnkoJtQeoK4h_7c3pzcmDde8wqDg39eUPxOshx1B1nFiwdTYHJLexh1Cg1FTvul5_vwAbt9mhwGvWIJu_Z7EiXj_3WWZb5OjjllaRqkPw)

Not as short as the `eval` solution but uses a very similar method.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 46 bytes

```swift
{a,n in a.dropLast().reduce(a.last!){$0+n*$1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQZqWgEe2ZVxKrowAkNRV07UC0gu3/6kSdPIXMPIVEvZSi/AKfxOISDU29otSU0uRUjUS9HCBfUbNaxUA7T0vFsLb2f0FRZl6JRppGtLGOgqGOggmYNAWaamigqcmFWxZZ0hAoYGlpqan5HwA)

Type signature: `<C: BidirectionalCollection where C.Element: Numeric>(C, C.Element) -> C.Element`. (That syntax isn't quite legal Swift for lack of generic lambdas, but you know what I mean.)

For each element (`$1`) in `a` except the last one, add `n*$1` to the running total. The total starts at `a.last` instead of zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 65 bytes

```
s/<(!*)><(!*)>$/%\2%\1/
s/><//g
:a
s/!>%(!*)%/>%\1%\1/
ta
s/.*%//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WN9GQ1FL0w5CquirxhipxhjqcxXr29no66dzWSUCmYp2qiBpVX07oBxYugQkrKelqq///7@NoqKinQ0IITPArH/5BSWZ@XnF/3VdAQ)

Input is a list exclamation marks surrounded by `<>`. `n` is given as the last element of the list. Output is just exclamation marks.

Example where `A = [3,1,4,1,5]` and `n = 1`:

`<!!!><!><!!!!><!><!!!!!><!>` => `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 40 bytes

```c
f(*a,l,n){return--l?*a*n+f(a+1,l,n):*a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LasMwELzrKwYHg@RHSWhzcJwmH@L6IPxoF9R1sJ1ejL/dXSmUtiB2lt3ZmVGTN87y@7b1OrGZy9gsYzffR85zd01swmmvbXoIm1Niy3XbETfu3nY4T3NLw9PHRamvgVo1d9OsiWeIEDy6jh8NG7UohJZKJV0/jNCEV@xLEM6eWSJNycgOuI3C7HUUT3EbiQKuEIhOiCpBW1FtgsoPr0bcIr9IfWMhiKlkzh72bIS7KiVM9WmJtY/6G8dWtaRY8JzhkOEl1CPWIB/@IzpHme5F5f/kzwCpP5NXFIV3274B)

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 18 bytes

```
(add-last)*$n+last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8n5lXUFqikFisoJJX818jMSVFNyexuERTSyVPG8T4/z/aWMdQxwSITWO5DA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 24 bytes

```
j&0#v&:61p+2
g+.@>'.-*61
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz///PUjNQLlOzMjMs0DbiStfWc7BT19PVMjP8/9/QQMFYwVDBBIhNFQA)

Ended up converging on a similar layout to [ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206969/76167), though with a different strategy:

#### Explanation:

```
 &0          Read numeric input (n) and push a zero on top as sum
   #         Skip into the main loop
     &:61p+  Read a number in, save a copy in (6,1) and add it to the sum
j          2 Jump over the initialisation and continue the loop
    v&       When we're out of input, go to the next line

At this point, our stack looks like `n sum`

    >'.-     Retrieve our saved last value and subtract it from the sum
        *    Multiply by n
g+       61  Retrieve our saved value and add it back to the sum
  .@         Print and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles)

```
/@+*_
```

```
/@+*_       # full program
/@+*_$@     # with implicit args added;
/           # fold from right over
 @          # arg2
            # with function:
  +         #   add
   *        #   the product of
    _       #     arg1
     $      #     and the left-hand element
      @     #   to the right-hand element
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/+⍜↘×¯1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAgLyvijZzihpjDl8KvMQoKZiBbMyAxIDQgMSA1XSAxMApmIFszIDEgNCAxIDVdIDEKZiBbMV0gOTk5Cg==)

```
/+⍜↘×¯1
     ¯1  # push negative one
  ⍜↘×    # multiply all but last element by input
/+       # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
f(a,n)=na.total-(n-1)a[a.count]
```

[Try it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bpwbsam1yb)

-1 byte thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow).

Comment: This is a relatively recent update as a result of the creation of the Desmos Geometry Tool but `a.length` can be replaced with `a.count`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 31 bytes

Saves a byte over the 32 byte solution. But it's boring.

```
method(a,N,a sum*N-a pop*(N-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0UjUcdPJ1GhuDRXy083UaEgv0BLw0/XUFPzf5pGTmZxiYaxjoKhjoIJmDTVBFIGmgoFRZl5JTl5XLiUYKgwBIpaWlrCxf8DAA)

### Explanation

```
method(a, N,
    a sum * N         // Sum the input, multiply by N
  - a pop * (N - 1)   // Minus the last item, multiplied by N - 1
)
```

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 32 bytes

Just as comparison

```
method(a,N,a push(a pop/N)sum*N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0UjUcdPJ1GhoLQ4QwNI5Rfo@2kWl@Zq@Wn@T9PIySwu0TDWUTDUUTABk6aaQMpAU6GgKDOvJCePC5cSDBWGQFFLS0u4@H8A)

### Explanation

```
method(a, N,
           a pop           // Extract the last item from the input list
                /N         // Divide it by N
    a push(       )        // And then put it back into the original list
                   sum     // Sum the list
                      *N   // Multiply the value by N
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
s;f(a,n)int*a,n;{for(s=0;a[1];s+=*a++);return*a+s*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwEETv@oohEJBspYlpcjDCH9BvSHOQbdn44HWQ5NLW@NvdVVJoYdnRwMxbNYe@abYtmE5aTWqgmLGapZu8DNXJ2GtxMyGvMpvnyngXZ0/8DhmZdTse8Ub3OcJ6b78CxjlE1A7fzk@H6Pw4kI2ufRHiYxpa9JLxYD6S0lM@FRYB3D2bTu72rdy36p12GulHIKU5YsQqxGgHks90KtrrDRUWvGoUGufHvmicNFbDkT61C3blRf15nvPDJkL9Syj@t2pulCXn0tHtBw)

Comment: n is implicit `int` in C89, so you don't need to specify it's type.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 29 bytes

```perl6
->$a,$b {$a.pop+([+] $a)*$b};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoFakYPtf104lUUclSaFaJVGvIL9AWyNaO1ZBJVFTSyWp1vq/NVdxYqWCUpFGtLGOgqGOggmYNI0FUgaaCrYKSjpAU7BK4tGpqYBHJ5JGQyDf0tISqBwB4Bphktb/AQ)

Comment: You can use `$^a` and `$^b` instead, as well as `.sum`, and the semi-colon is not needed, which ends up being the same as a [previous Raku answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207027/76162)

Comment: @JoKing Oh, my bad! Thanks for the tip, though - I'm still learning Raku.