# US Tax Due Dates

Tags: code-golf, date

## Introduction

In a standard* (e.g. not 2020) tax year, estimated payments are due quarterly according to the schedule outlined in [Publication 505](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p505.pdf).

| Payment Period | Due Date |
| --- | --- |
| January 1 – March 31 | April 15 |
| April 1 – May 31 | June 15 |
| June 1 – August 31 | September 15 |
| September 1 – December 31 | January 15 |

* Saturday, Sunday, holiday rule, fiscal year taxpayers, and January payment exceptions can be ignored for the purpose of this question; use the standard table provided.

## Challenge

Input:

A date/timestamp, either provided as input to your solution (function parameter or stdin) as a string (at a minimum specifying a specific year, month, an day of month) or native `Date` object (or equivalent) or the current (dynamically updated) date/time based on the clock of the executing machine.

Output:

The most specific payment period, one of `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, or `Q4` as a string, either printed to stdout/console or programmatically returned from the function, to which a timely payment made on the input date would be applied.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| January 16 - April 15 | Q1 |
| April 16 - June 15 | Q2 |
| June 16 - September 15 | Q3 |
| September 16 - January 15 | Q4 |

A day shall commence at 00:00 (midnight) and cover time periods up to but not including 00:00 (midnight) of the following day.  The last moment of a given day, to a ms granularity is `23:59:59.999`.

Comment: can it take day of the year, as in the last day of the year is day 365?

Comment: @smarnav How would you handle leap years?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Publication 505 is **48 pages**.  Mind stating which page you got your table from so I don't have to pour over 48 pages to find the specific reference you're using for your tables?

Comment: ALSO, this is for **estimated taxes** not general tax payments.  Update your question to be specific about that, because **estimated** taxes don't actually fall within that fiscal quarter.  I'm not sure you can golf this based on that.

Comment: @smarnav nope but it can be calculated; leap years would typically number up to 366 though that might make the solution more complicated than less (I considered solving this problem that way and, perhaps, have decided against it since leap years are complicated :P)

Comment: @ThomasWard Page 26, but the relevant bit is copied into the problem. It's an exercise in golfing, not tax code, hence ignoring the edge cases.  The publication is just for flavor :)

Comment: Coule we take three arguments day, month and year?

Comment: @RecursiveCo. I think separate arguments would make the problem easier vs existing solutions (which must either parse the date or extract the necessary parts from a Date object)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Expects a string in `"DD-MM-YYYY"` format.

```javascript
s=>"Q"+"4243131"[[d,m]=s.split`-`,(m*24|d>15)*9%23%7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/RaoMwFIbv@xRHoZrUKE3UjdHp3R5g9FKEBqOrQ40koTC27tVdTDvY3S6S/Pn5z3fOeecXrhvVzyaepGiXrlh0UfqvfuRnLEtpSv2qEmSsC53oeejNKT4RNO5Y9iVKmuPd05al28d66aRCs2ovUEAYEhjlZM5W08NdPlvN7p8owvC5AahyAnQ9DwRYXieW8cKbMxL8A4rSRQAEN60FWS8x8mhUP70hnMxcHA1XBjECewwRhHFob4f/J8f2jIYHx1attugOrT3wzfI8t0UA7vEK@N3KZjEEATRy0nJok0Fa/q3mr@XGtW3gu4R1orVsTV3x5rr8AA)

---

#### 39 bytes

If we can just take the month and the day.

```javascript
m=>d=>"Q"+"4243131"[(m*24|d>15)*9%23%7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8xb4MwEIX3/IoDKWAHgrCBVFVqT@3SoVXVMcpgYZOkAhwBSlW16V@nh0WkDj6/O7/36fyhLqovu9N5WLdWm7ESYyOkFtJ/8yM/53nGMubvSLPi@Y@WrKCr@yXPlnf7sbIdOXfmAgLCMIbGtsMRNdvO8gE1n5soovC9ANgVMbDpbGLgxT5BxpMqj0SrLxDSWQC0GgyCWvMJjygJTzm78deAEt00Gezz@@sLoUlfn0pDUoSmdOsAnekxXxEXoRN8fvA8t3AA7vIE3D6ACQpBAKVte1ubpLYHMmf@j9xmEYTwK7FELja5rnRxHf8A)

---

#### 35 bytes

As suggested by [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), using a larger lookup table with a much simpler formula is actually shorter.

```javascript
m=>d=>"Q"+"_4111223334444"[m+=d>15]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/Ba4MwFMbv/SueHjQhVkysu7TJabv0sDJ2LGUEE9cWNUWlY5TuX7fPYGGBl3wv@b4fL2d91X3ZnS7DsnXGjpUcG6mMVOFHyMKvFedciDzPV7jCfcOkUbw4jJXryKWzV5AQxwk0rh2OqPl6lhvUYm4Yo3BbAOyLBPhULwmI4pAi402XR2L0L0jlLQBGDxZBrf2BV5REZII/@UtAiW6aDm77uXsnNO3rU2lJhtCMrj2gsz3mK@IjdILPD0HgB47AH4GE5wcwQSGKoHRt72qb1u6bzJn/V34yBjH8KdyYj02uO13cxwc)

Comment: Can you explain the thought process that goes around making formulas like these? Is it mainly brute force? what is the starting point? I am always amazed by how people find "magic formulas" for things

Comment: @EliteDaMyth That's mainly brute force on several hard-coded templates and with hard-coded ranges for each variable. I was actually pretty sure that a more standard formula would work for that one, but I couldn't find any that was shorter than the hash.

Comment: Does [this](https://tio.run/##TY/Ba4MwFMbv/SueHjQhVkysu7TJabv0sDJ2LGUEE9cWNUWlY5TuX7fPYGGBl3wv@b4fL2d91X3ZnS7DsnXGjpUcG6mMVOFHyMKvFedciDzPV7jCfcOIUbygh7FyHbl09goS4jiBxrXDETVfz3KDWswNYxRuC4B9kQCf6iUBURxSZLzp8kiM/gWpvAXA6MEiqLU/8IqSiEzwJ38JKNFN08FtP3fvhKZ9fSotyRCa0bUHdLbHfEV8hE7w@SEI/MAR@COQ8PwAJihEEZSu7V1t09p9kznz/8pPxiCGP4Ub87HJdaeL@/gA) work? It produces the same output for your extensive test-suite.

Comment: @ovs I think that works indeed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>72</s> 63 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1+-(1{1,5}(1)*)-1{1,15}(1)*
11$3$2$1
(111)*1+
Q$#1
0|5
4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@9CgIxEATgfl/DFLmLgUz@7u4x7G0ELWwsxE599mjQZAJbzH4MC3u/PK63UynHsxE1C4zVeGKf3hrTPNma8VsEUEF5BdHAd4eRg9pB3CtJLMU7D@vqSItIwpz/0VfusWmgBmocTkRyYjlR81DO5IXlhbpSV@o2nNg6w/VyjU1B5XvgezXmDw) Link includes test cases. Takes input in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1+-(1{1,5}(1)*)-1{1,15}(1)*
11$3$2$1
```

Add 2, 3 or 4 to the month depending on whether the month is greater than 5 or the day is greater than 15 or not.

```
(111)*1+
Q$#1
```

Subtract 1 from the month, then integer divide it by 3 and prefix Q to the result. (This is to avoid zero width matches.)

```
0|5
4
```

Change `Q0` and `Q5` to `Q4`.

Comment: @Arnauld Bah, I'd totally misread the table...

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```r
function(d)paste0("Q",1+sum(c(3,5,8)<el(format(d-15,"%m"):1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCsIwEEDRvccYEGYwKZlog5W68wIeIbQJCKYtTXr@VOk2Wf//1uyf2W/TkD7zhCMtNianEN4g@BK3gANeRSvu1Lsv@nkNNuEouRVwDkAPJqLs0cbmZZND0EqzVLffAESnUjDFYGrC1ERXE11RaKm4KI7wF3kH)

Expects input in R's native Date class. Subtract 15 days from the input, extract the month (as a string such as `"04"`), and convert to numeric with `el(...:1)` (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12837/86301)). We then get the result by adding 1 for each of the values 3, 5, and 8 which are smaller than the result.

Comment: I like the lexicographic comparison, but I think numeric can be [shorter](https://tio.run/##dctBCsMgEEDRfY8xUBipFrWNNNDseoEeYTARutCEODm/tXSrf/t5ewlTCUfy/FkTzmKjzItGeIM0l3xE9HiTg3yIZ/aUkKew7pEYZ2UGCecIolYCUr6@iBcEq61R@l53XafWcM3hesL1xNgTY1NYpU1T/MdPlC8).

Comment: Ha!  You edited while I was typing, and yours is better!  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ-θ§12344÷⁻§θ¹⁺›¹⁶⊟θ›⁶⊟θ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxBCoMwEAXQfU8RspqAARPFjStpobgoCJ4gaLCBEDUZpbdPp4u2m/nw@H@mp4nTanzOXUpuCXA1CWHcvEPow3bgiNGFBUTBuOSCYhftZSBD6LAPs30BV7qqa16wPuDNnW628HDhSL/CXjBFy8GT3aM1aCOohmDdYP/8/OLfCCu6os1Zl1rJspGqyfL0bw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ-θ
```

Input the date, split it on `-` and cast to integer.

```
§12344÷⁻§θ¹⁺›¹⁶⊟θ›⁶⊟θ³
```

Take the month, subtract 1 each if the day is less than 16 or the month is less than 6, divide by 3, then cyclically index into the string `12344`, thus casting `-1` and `4` to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 109 bytes

```python
lambda n,i=int:'Q'+['?111223334444'[i(k:=(S:=n.split('-'))[1])],'1234'[i(k)//3-1]][k in'1469'and(i(S[0])<16)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BjsIwDEWv4p0dUSiOAUFFNWcYsQxZBJVCBKRVyIbTd0KrkcALy3r@39/9K127INs@Dm19HO7ucWochMLXPqQKf3Fm8IeZtRaRVS40nm5VTYeqDotnf/eJcI5KGbbKFshaJokqS5mzteYGPiCvNjt0oSFPB7O0as8bZQfTx5xCLT1TpMa9FMwgH8sd3uTRhXSd2FoLjhO0XYS34tNS/oPJoUbROOdsiC5czsQFsEybbPviovMvfw)

Way too long.

The OP has confirmed very kindly that this is the only solution of mine which is valid.

Comment: You're allowed to ignore useless arguments -there's a meta post about it.