# Minimum difference between cartesian product of 3 elements that add up to a certain number

Tags: code-golf, number, array, permutations

Let's say I've got a list (or array) of:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to get the third Cartesian power of the above list, where we take every possible triple of elements from `l`.

Then I want to filter and only keep the sublists where the sum of that sublist equal to the maximum value of the list.

Then I only want one sublist, which is the sublist where the difference of the three numbers that add up to the maximum value is the smallest.

The algorithm to see the smallest difference could be something like (in Python):

```
max(v1,v2,v3) - min(v1,v2,v3)
```

So the expected output for this case would be:

```
(3, 3, 4)
```

The order of the elements within the output could be in any order.

### Test cases:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
-> (3, 3, 4)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-> (1, 2, 2)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
-> (33, 33, 34)

l = [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 10, 6]
-> (3, 3, 4)

l = [1, 4, 8, 12, 13, 16, 20, 24, 27]
-> (1, 13, 13)
```

This is tagged with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

There will always be an output, never would be a case where no 3 elements would add up to the maximum value.

Comment: suggest `[1, 3, 6, 7, 13]` -> `(3, 3, 7)`

Comment: So this is some kind of an approximation to "1/3 * max number"?

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 83 bytes

```
[ dup supremum swap 3 selections [ Σ = ] with filter [ minmax - abs ] infimum-by ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5LTsMwEN3nFO8AtIrdpi0g1ogNG8QqysJxJ62F7RiPoxJQT8N9uFJwSVnNvN/M65ROfZxeX56eH@/gVDoude9a41WmjWYcyFNU1nyqZHrPeKPoyc7OqPyBGEzvA3mdtz928Eb3e5oBp5zjdLl0wQiRUhpDND7hvihEiVrctE1RXaco/5kvCKxRQWKFW@ywRTZvcL4KOwgJsYLYQJaQa8gtzlON/RDAQ37jBgc@qZDjTJb0XL/Gzzce0OBkcpvO2EQxk854pz6wgGo5i8Z3JucX7YhmquBVCHbEkqEtqTj9Ag)

### Explanation

```
                            ! { 1 2 3 4 5 }
dup                         ! { 1 2 3 4 5 } { 1 2 3 4 5 }
supremum                    ! { 1 2 3 4 5 } 5
swap                        ! 5 { 1 2 3 4 5 }
3 selections                ! 5 { { 1 1 1 } { 1 1 2 } ... }
[ Σ = ] with filter         ! { { 1 1 3 } { 1 2 2 } ... }
[ minmax - abs ] infimum-by ! { 1 2 2 }
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>39</s> 55 bytes

```
l#&@@SortBy[l~Tuples~3,Abs[Max@l-Tr@#]|Max@#-Min@#&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNCoJAAEb3XmPA1Sc4M/61KKb2QqQ7cTGJlqAWOkFheohu0Ak7wqQk7R7fe3y1VOe8lqrMpC7Wuvq83sQUIrq0avdIqjG@Xau8Gzm2xy4J5V1UVtwKkj5nJlZYNoKYqd63ZaMSYm2KyZljlMlm7I2DbE65oDYWcmH0FA5cMHCsEMDHZL1h2QNQBspBPTAbzAHzf4rDm1M@4P9pG4P@Ag)

Slow for larger input lists.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>105</s> 96 bytes

(or 89 bytes in [R](https://www.r-project.org/)≥4.1 by using `\` for `function`)

*Edit: -9 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(l,a=expand.grid(l,l,l),b=apply(a[rowSums(a)==max(l),],1,sort))b[,order(b[3,]-b[1,])[1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY27CsMwDAD3fokEaonJFvBXdDQe5DgNgfiBbNP0611vpdx03HDSg1/zXLkV3V8trvVIEU5ivV2Zo3/scvjhAySnOefzA2wkvZ8tFGDUOvAFI1pSVJJURGcoid8EnJnJ3p1RZNEoa38vUIua8PbvE/Yv)

Comment: [Try expand.grid without rep!](https://tio.run/##VY27CsMwDAD3fokEaonJFvBXdDQe5DgNgfiBbNP0611vpdx03HDSg1/zXLkV3V8trvVIEU5ivV2Zo3/scvjhAySnOefzA2wkvZ8tFGDUOvAFI1pSVJJURGcoid8EnJnJ3p1RZNEoa38vUIua8PbvE/Yv "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - I saw it in your answer, and was just editing it in, but it seemed sneaky...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Wow! First R answer here! Thanks.

Comment: I've deleted my longer straightforward boring answer after seeing yours.

Comment: @pajonk Ah, didn't see it

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You should add in your answer that you could use the new R function assignment with ```\``` backslash, to save 7 bytes.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Mentioned here [Tips for golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226269)

Comment: @U12-Forward - I'll edit to mention it.  Generally, though, I don't use it where it doesn't achieve better than the trivial 7-byte saving (especially because it's convenient to be able to directly compare answers on 'Try it online', which doesn't support R version 4.1).

Comment: @U12-Forward - (it's a bit similar to using ```scan()``` for input: it usually saves a trivial 2 bytes compared to defining a function - [like this](https://tio.run/##DcpLCsIwEADQvaeY5QRGMdYvJadwOWQxMUWEtAkTS@vpY3nbp60lV18yoenFDWuRKR7e@omYaGP64KSU9ENhzctzHiuKcW6UFZMhT5Zq1u/WmLLGQTFwR34f2JI3bL1vFk7QwRkucIUb3OEB9gi79gc) - but it isn't always very clever or interesting...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Ah, that's cool, never knew `scan()`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/), <s>130</s> <s>115</s> <s>99</s> <s>85</s> 80 bytes:

<sup>-14 Thanks to @tsh</sup>
<sup>-5 Thanks again to @tsh</sup>

```
lambda l:max([((z:=max(l)-x-y)in l,x<=y<=z,x-z,x,y,z)for x in l for y in l])[3:]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##HdDLisMwDIXhV9EyAQXqux2aJ8lkkWEoU0gvlC6SvHz6uwuBQB@ydZ7b@/9xd/n5Oi7Dz7HMt9@/WZb@Nq/N2DR7P9Ruabu129rrXRZdz8N2HnZdO0o33dvL4yWr1KHUdvu2Uzu6fjqer@v93Vya0ahYFafiVYJKVEkqWaWomBPF3AAMwkAMxoAMysAMzuJs3YOzOIuzOIuzOIuzOIdzOFcfxDmcwzmcwzmcw3mcx3mcrz/DeZzHeZzHeVzABVzABVyoJ@ACLuACLuAiLuIiLuIiLtZbcREXcRGXcAmXcAmXcAmXaii4hEu4jMu4jMu4jMu4jMs1PVzGFVzBFVzBFVzBFVzBlRrzN@fT1LbHBw)

Get's the Cartesian Product by looping the list 3 times, and summing it up.

Comment: 85: `lambda l:min([(x>y,y>z,x+y+z!=max(l),z-x,x,y,z)for x in l for y in l for z in l])[4:]`

Comment: @tsh Woo, why didn't I think of that! Edited my answer.

Comment: 80: `lambda l:max([((z:=max(l)-x-y)in l,x<=y<=z,x-z,x,y,z)for x in l for y in l])[3:]`

Comment: @tsh Edited, wow!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
3ÞẊ'∑?G=;µ÷Ȯε^ε+;h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIzw57huoon4oiRP0c9O8K1w7fIrs61Xs61KztoIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdIl0=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
3ÞẊ'∑?G=;µ₌Gg-;h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIzw57huoon4oiRP0c9O8K14oKMR2ctO2giLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTBdIl0=)

-2 thanks to Bubbler's insight.

```
3ÞẊ              # Combinations of input of length 3
   '    ;        # Filter by...
    ∑  =         # Sum equals
     ?G          # Maximum of input
         µ    ;h # Minimum by...
          ₌Gg-   # Difference of min + max
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)

```
◄§-▼▲fo=▲¹Σπ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0lkPLdR9N2/No2qa0fFsgeWjnucXnG4z///8fbahjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY2gQCwA)

#### Explanation

```
◄§-▼▲fo=▲¹Σπ3
           π3     cartesian product of 3 * input
     fo          filter by composed function
       =▲¹Σ      max of input equals sum
◄§               min by composed binary function
  -▼▲            max - min
```

Comment: -1 byte by changing ```ΠR3``` (cartesian product of 3 copies of input) to ```π3``` (cartesian power of 3 of input)

Comment: Unfortunately, Jonathan's trick [fails](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9odXNr///ilrpPZm894paywrnOo8@AM////1sxLDIsNSw3LDExXQ) for `[1,2,5,7,11]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly (fork)](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage), 11 bytes

```
ṗ3SƘṀṀ_ṂƊÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzunGwY8a9xxaeqz94c4GIIp/uLPpWNfheQ93LPr//3@0oY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CqY6CmY6CuY6ChY6CpY6CoUEsAA) (this is the equivalent in normal Jelly)

This uses my fork of Jelly which includes the `Ƙ` (keep-like) quick to replace the commonly used `<link>⁼¥Ƈ` pattern. You can see this in the TIO link.

### How it works

```
ṗ3SƘṀṀ_ṂƊÞḢ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
ṗ3          - Cartesian Cube
    Ṁ       - Maximum of L
   Ƙ        - Keep triples whose     is like the maximum
  S         -                    sum
        ƊÞ  - Sort the remaining triples by:
     Ṁ      -   maximum
      _     -   minus
       Ṃ    -   minimum
          Ḣ - Take the first
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 53 bytes

Prompts for list

```
↑((⌊/m)=m←(⌈/¨l)-⌊/¨l)/l←((⌈/i)=+/¨l)/l←,i∘.,,i∘.,i←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##TcxNCoJAGMbx/ZziWSppOqP5sfAAQdEZxDAGRgxcdQGTqKhF0BHad4OOMheZ3imhVvPnNw9vuVX@eleqduNXquw6WRl9vi0Xur9EjGq@ouJMD/va6P7qOPp4CBq3aIiph@D1UK5v0UagLH9cusXkZ57Uw33qjY8koduGrjJTMw6BCDFmSJAiQw4esj@m1qcnD79od/Yjp2VKSyQjZ@ACPAJPIEKIGCJlbw)

Answer (score 2):

## Python/NumPy, 77 bytes

```
lambda l:min(l[argwhere(sum(ix_(l,l,l))==max(l))],key=ptp)
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddJvatswGMdx2EufQi_loUJlyfoT8G6wE2RheNRZTO3EuM7asKPsTWFsd9pOs69ip4R1wxiM9NEj6fn528_hNO0O--fv2-rDj-O0vQm_3nd1_-muFt2qb_eyW9fj58ddMzby4djL9umj7BRPnldVXz9JPjbqvjlVwzTk2XY89GJ_7IeTaPvhME5vl6L1467tGqFXmWjVoWq-1J1s98NxkvnarDa5ejWSiWFs95N8oEpzJ7eyHsf6JNs87bwMHnLYsmje6Pn3m6-dqMRaK1EoYZSwSpRKOCW8EkGJqIS-3WQ374Q083yeZa9XzGIeKv4p_q7Jy7wGaISGaIwGaZSGaVyBK1KdVBdX4ApcgStwBa7AGZzBmbRhOijO4AzO4AzO4CzO4izOppPhLM7iLM7iLK7ElbgSV-LKdAVciStxJa7EOZzDOZzDOZxLd8U5nMM5nMd5nMd5nMd5nE9NwXmcxwVcwAVcwAVcwAVcSN3DBVzERVzERVzERVzERVxMbT73-RKeuTTmKp05lzmjeI7Gz9G4_yVuz-olNbcklFLxL__AecpcrTKX8LW5LuyXn_AP)

Takes and returns numpy arrays. Approach is straightforward. `ix_(l,l,l)` is essentially the cartesian product. This is then summed over coordinates and compared to the maximum. `argwhere` extracts the coordinates where the comparison succeeds and these are used to index back into `l`. It remains to select a triplet that minimises the spread (difference between `min` and `max`). Rather conveniently, numpy has a function for the spread: `ptp`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>73 72 68</s> 61 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.product(l,l).min_by{|x|[(l.max-x.sum)**2,x.max-x.min]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkevoCg/pTS5RCNHJ0dTLzczLz6psrqmoiZaI0cvN7FCt0KvuDRXU0vLSKcCygeqia2t/V@gkBYdbahjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY2gQG/sfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
3Z^!tsGX>=Z)ttX<-X>&S1)Z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XdG7TgMxEIXhPk8xNESRvJDx@CpBaJDoaKBYbbQISiSo2CJvv/zOBgQpXFjzyZdzPt@mj/lV3mUaHuVODlcyymzDy8X09dDvbofNNPU3Xb@7fNLNsJll3XXdWvp7GQ7yPM57deKdmJPgJDpJTrKT4qQ60e24@j8/3597FnMFKEIhilGQohSmOI/z7Rycx3mcx3mcx3mcxxnOcNYuxBnOcIYznOEMF3ABF3ChvQwXcAEXcAEXcBEXcREXcbF9ARdxERdxEZdwCZdwCZdwqf0Vl3AJl3AZl3EZl3EZl3G5hYLLuIwruIIruIIruIIruNLSwxVcxVVcxVVcxVVcxVVcbTEfcz4Vs1Sw1FGPLeSlhfQ7L3/qSKfoW9x5EfbToNq42l5vvwE)

```
3Z^     % Third Cartesian power 

!ts     % Sum of each sublist

GX> =   % See which ones' sums equal input's maximum

Z)      % Filter to keep only those

ttX<-   % Subtract from each sublist its Minimum  

X>      % Maximum of each. Effectively this is (Max - Min)

&S      % Get the indices that would sort this result

1)      % Get the first index of those i.e. the argmin

Z)      % Extract the sublist at that index
```

([Equivalently](https://tio.run/##XdG7TgMxEIXhPk8xNESRvBB77LEtQWiQ6GigWC1aBCUSVGwRnn75nQ0IUriw5pMv53y8Tu/zi7zJNNzLjewvZJRZh@ez6fOu310Pm6nfffVX3fmD3wybWdZd162lv5VhL4/j/OSdBCfqJDpJTsxJdlKcVCd@O67@z0/3p57F3AM8wkM8xoM8ysM8LuBCOwcXcAEXcAEXcAEXcIpTnLYLcYpTnOIUpzjFRVzERVxsL8NFXMRFXMRFXMIlXMIlXGpfwCVcwiVcwhnOcIYznOGs/RVnOMMZLuMyLuMyLuMyLrdQcBmXcQVXcAVXcAVXcAVXWnq4gqu4iqu4iqu4iqu4iqst5kPOx2KWCpY66qGFvLRgv/Pypw47Rt/izovQnwa9jqvt5fYb), perhaps slightly more clearly, `3Z^!tsGX>=Z)tX>yX<-&S1)Z)` - instead of "effectively" doing `max - min`, just explicitly does `max - min`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＦθＦθＦθ⊞υ⟦ικλ⟧≔Φυ⁼Σι⌈θυ≔Ｅυ⁻⌈ι⌊ιθＩ§υ⌕θ⌊θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BC4JAEIXv/Yo5zsIGaVGBJ4mEDoLQUTwsajm0rq3rhv9@241C6PCY92bex9SdGOtBSOduwwioGfzPwpoOLYeSODw4yIolq9QYuivMSE7tGI5nbYU0eLU9EuOQi5l67zVjPtmFyMUz1HNS1uCv9SFIfX0gtCeKkdSEJ2EmTKeLato5kBmpBvXSDx8YS5wry4jDjsORQxR7bb32HOKNl1/Hh6py65d8Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦθＦθＦθ⊞υ⟦ικλ⟧
```

Create the Cartesian product of three copies of the list.

```
≔Φυ⁼Σι⌈θυ
```

Extract those triples that sum to the maximum of the original list.

```
≔Ｅυ⁻⌈ι⌊ιθ
```

For each triple, find the difference between its largest and smallest entries.

```
Ｉ§υ⌕θ⌊θ
```

Output the first triple with the smallest difference.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>280</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>211</s></sup> 210 bytes

```cpp
#import<regex>
#define S(v)std::sort(&v[0],&*end(v))
using V=std::vector<int>;int f(V&v){V r=v,x;S(v);int m=v.back(),n=m,t;for(int a:r)for(int b:r)for(int c:r)x={a,b,c},S(x),t=x[2]-x[0],v=t<m&a+b+c==n?m=t,x:v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1dTdbtowFAfwe57iiEooKQaVfIcQejHtCSpxQ7kIwbCoJUGJyaKhvPrY/zgwkNpq14sUZOyf7eNjO@nhMNql6fn8kO0PRalmpdzJZt572Mhtlkt6MWqzUpvptEKjMaiXTysxeJT5BvVm71hl@Y4WsRa1TFVRzrJczSP80NZYDGrztKAyrkUT8Ui6fh/X43WSvhmmyOO9UNG2KA1uSKaleS2v78opyk18SsRapK14MRpTqLhZWqtRw@HUsZrtB8lwPUzjOH/ex0o00zpqsaQ8fT9uJM2yolKlTPbzryPu6dCSLDfMU4/wpEVeYe4fSfmIX5m@yXK5ophO/dfmu/XahN/wun1B9//tfhvp3vfjL@akZKUq7nyaCLIFeYJ8QRO7FcQ1liC3q5ncasAcXd/hQFAI8PQB/LMHD4vX4gnxgkxgJkATnhJsAmfBWTwOnAVnwVlwFpwFZ8FZcDaczavgCeFsOBvOhrPhbDgbzoFz4Bw4hyODc@AcOAfOgXPgXDgXzuUkwLm8BDgXzoVz4Vw4D86D8@A8TiGcx2uF8@A8OA/Oh/PhfDgfzofzObucFDgfzocL4AK4AC6AC@ACuAAu4OzBBXAhXAgXwoVwIVwIF8KFcCGnWef5ujXdHnT7Eept8Ltt8G4guNsQ75J8Trjffn6AZHNAWW70GbL10P5lNPdyBrpa53YcLF1rX7fpo9Gz29cZcd1I37cs38gGEz1Fl@KsO7/jKvslDTOi4VDXm9TdFH4WpNBDs6VuXEV/2/RS0uKoaDaj/rJ/a9FTdhctOapiQJkqaUrqfuQPIxgDVnFMg0c1XssdX1l6pn4fPfk6moxAbtO0X4SyotGc7sMxlPlfhH0Xy4IkEn89Hp/nXn@75XVSQXLMH3Dzbq3roninQ1LxN0pykOqLPFy/hGxXOprX/BJN22vPv9Pte7KrzqOffwA)

*Saved <s>3</s> 4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs a vector of integers.
Replaces the input vector with the cartesian product of 3 elements of the input vector that add up to the maximum of the input vector and that have the minimum difference between the smallest and the largest element from all of the cartesian products.

Comment: See att's comment on Jonathan's (now deleted) answer: [1,2,5,7,11] should output [1,5,5] (difference 4), not [2,7,7] (difference 5).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Reverted back to my original solution - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```scala
a=>(for{x<-a;y<-a;z<-a if x+y+z==a.max}yield Seq(x,y,z)).minBy(l=>l.max-l.min).sorted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBBa4MwGL37K94x0q@2ibbWbQrbbbDbLoPSQ1YVHKk6DUMt/e0uUbZD2dgS8hG@vPe@99IepZJj9fqWHTVekHU6K9MW93WNswN8SIX85jl73z@W@hAn37dRxgnLq@bc3S3lbW/LYAqKHN2iXwxxLL2T7C59kakUhsY66mlwXe9UlA89U3GiLGCpbMP12qrRWToCdVOUWpUMOZtonCAIPiEgbAhbQkjYESICX7uwG1itLMKCnD8UvhjXyyjMOHGlwDh0ZUatXU9XT0Wrf@bPHqwJe36xMUeYzURTitCmMKn@GySYWNxIcAPi5jeEoQvTFuGsMQeZXn3nMo57TgFtSJBPEe0oJDNve/gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) List::Util, 140 bytes

```perl
sub{$"=',';my$m;($d=max(@$_)-min@$_)<($m//9e9)and($m,@r)=($d,@$_)for grep max(@_)==sum(@$_),map[split$"],glob"{@_},{@_},{@_}";sort{$a-$b}@r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBfb5swFMXf@RRHnjtAumkDJKWEeeO90/rSPWUoShYHoYU/BaK1ivLZ2bXRqm2qZgkb33N@vsdudXdcjqde43PZD6vV16E84umnV5U1qu0z@lPlp448qLE/7c5SKJfctHqRVerJvWKHl8mNP2O7WT94srq5SXTib@s9/1PW@YqNZMRD06HodAtLbXyl@HCLU7Vt1317LAcpciqOzU6cs82FXieR9k03nOV2JneXrLuMqcOneQ6wxjoghISIsCAsCbeEmHBHSAjBPAegPmIdTY4cOb1BGde/w1CTKbTUO0tdXwfz@Vv2P6jINDPf3@2meFPTxCaMTUJO/L@QC@sMGAtYC/h2ISMhl8M4/x3SSpHl/DOj1YsnS5LaV/y8qS1khXovD/zcpW8KbVfWw0Fc9UBZt6dBXc3CiDfQz63@Pug9F2KzLxrW@m@1MJEAkRUC@olXqQU@wW1@uFjB/fLwiId7l4xQCpp0svbUuTjjyDEXtKSQIkrojmLim9/mvwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f x=head$sortOn(\t->m t-minimum t)$filter((==m x).sum)$sequence[x,x,x]
m=maximum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYuxCoMwEEB3v@KGDApREKGd0qljoR9gHQ6b1KO5mJoT8vVNLW95PHgLprf1vhTiuG4CVxTsbpSkcpDNYvGp0tHvoX5Ie2GQlikQ74c1ypEXu9W1MQy56dLOjUr2s9sw2zHrg6liw5j/Q2GkAAbiRkFAgYOx1zBoOGk4a@iHqXxn5/GVSjvH@AM)

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYvBCgIhFEX38xV3oEWBRsNAbbJVy6APsFnIoCX5zNQBF317ZtzN4RzuQ6Wndq5WS@EVM84qq@3FptwZFJGauvr1LfMTIXOy3tLSaCPjJx550u9F@1nLwtomllqLQhDK1Pe7jgSp8j9UUtZDIETrM1YwkAPDyLBnODAM41S/s3HqniqfQ/gB "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYqxCoNAEAX7fMUrLAyshQixcb/kuOJITnLoLslehCv894uCTDXMvENe4rrWOqNw1lcjSZNs4lqBdZfAyO67TV2O3y3qM7pCB57y2ZgFxd@EJZTzrhKSgvGxpD80mOF6wkB4EEZCP/j6Bw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: a Wizard you are indeed. I knew my solution was clunky, I didn't know it was _that_ clunky

Comment: The main issue is just the import really.  If you weren't burdened by it all 3 versions would be roughly comparable.