# Decide Contiguous Binary Tree

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, binary-tree

## Objective

Given an unlabelled binary tree, decide whether it is contiguous in indices.

## Indices

This challenge gives one-indexing on binary trees. The exact definition expresses all indices in binary numeral:

- The root is indexed `1`.
- For every node, to get the index of its left child, replace the most significant `1` by `10`.
- For every node, to get the index of its right child, replace the most significant `1` by `11`.

For illustration:
[image: Binary tree indexing]

A binary tree is **contiguous in indices** iff the indices of its nodes have no gaps.

Note that every binary tree with contiguous indices is balanced.

## I/O Format

Flexible.

## Examples

`L` indicates a leaf. `[ , ]` indicates a branch.

### Truthy

```
L
[L,L]
[[L,L],L]
[[L,L],[L,L]]
[[[L,L],L],[L,L]]
[[[L,L],L],[[L,L],L]]
```

### Falsy

```
[L,[L,L]]
[[[L,L],L],L]
[[[L,L],[L,L]],[L,L]]
[[[L,L],L],[L,[L,L]]]
```

Comment: Assuming solutions have to handle unbalanced trees, it would help to have one in the falsy test cases.

Comment: @alephalpha Nodes are branches; leaves don't count as nodes.

Comment: The test cases do not include any nodes with one child, like: [L,] or [[L,],[L,L]]  Note that this could break some parsers based on the existing test cases.

Comment: @DavidG. *Nodes are branches; leaves don't count as nodes.*

Comment: @DannyuNDos But a binary tree can have 2 entries in it.  In a binary tree, there is normally an entry in each leaf and each branch node.

Comment: @DavidG. You've misunderstood. Leaves are nullptr here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ŒṪ’UḄṬP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7Vz1qmBn6cEfLw51rAv4fbteM/P9fIycxNyklUcHHKpqLy0eHK9pHxycWSEFoJCaYBHPhUtiEYKxYsFFYVPggcaHS2I2GiMZyccVqahhqAgA)

*-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan--funny that I used `ŒṪ` earlier, but never tried removing `Ż` with it*

<s>Very</s> *Embarrassingly* naive solution, using `ŒṪ` "generate multidimensional truthy indices" to directly produce the indices, then `Ṭ` "untruth" to lay them out... if I was sure it works at all, since this doesn't actually produce the stated labeling scheme or represent non-leaf nodes at all. I actually thought it didn't work for a bit, but then I realized my counterexample wasn't a binary tree to begin with.

Requires that the leaf value is truthy.

```
ŒJ         Generate multidimensional 1-indices of truthy values.
  ’        Decrement to 0-indices,
   U       and reverse, so the deepest index is most significant
    Ḅ      when they're converted from binary.
     Ṭ     Generate the shortest array of 1s and 0s that has 1s at exactly those indices,
      P    and check that it doesn't contain any 0s.
```

Since there's no leading 1, this identifies every non-leaf node with its leftmost descendant, but this seems not to matter.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Length[l=If[0>##,0,#+2#0@##2]&@@@#~Position~_List]l&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98nNS@9JCM6x9YzLdrATllZx0BHWdtI2cBBWdkoVs3BwUG5LiC/OLMkMz@vLt4ns7gk9v2ELTlq/wOKMvNKopUVdO0UAkszU0ui06KVY2NjFdQU9B24FKp9dLgUQKSCTy2YBWWicyE0VAxJDR4JBKcWZgdOxT5oYjCF@O2FStbW/gcA)

Comment: [57](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98nNS@9JCM6x9YzLdrATllZx1BHWddQ20jZwEFZ2ShWzcHBQbkuIL84syQzP68u3iezuCT2/YStOWr/A4oy80qilRV07RQCSzNTS6LTopVjY2MV1BT0HbgUqn10uBRApIJPLZgFZaJzITRUDEkNHgkEpxZmB07FPmhiMIX47YVK1tb@BwA)

Comment: [55](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98nNS@9JCM6x9YzLdrATllZx0BHWdtI2cBBWdkoVs3BwUG5LiC/OLMkMz@vLt4ns7gk9v2ELTlq/wOKMvNKopUVdO0UAkszU0ui06KVY2NjFdQU9B24FKp9dLgUQKSCTy2YBWWicyE0VAxJDR4JBKcWZgdOxT5oYjCF@O2FStbW/gcA) (`\[VectorGreaterEqual]` -> `\[VectorGreater]`)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

Expects a nested list of `1`'s. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>!((m=F=(a,v,q)=>+a||a.map(b=>F(b,v+=q,q*2),m|=1<<v))(a,1,1),m&m+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LDoIwEEX3/oUbaaWSlDXDki9ghywGBB@hlJdNTPj3WiEkPlDZTCbnnjtpL6iwTZtz1e1Kech0DhrBXxMiIACCTLGagm9j36MjsCIJ@AFJmLKhZvXWpUz0wD1PUWpkzrgBG2G7VKeybGWROYU8EisKm2t3usUWXT3znHD6TiJzJP6kA/6RDHMunYpLjGl7WC@atS@jAIt25gem8/8y/56O5WXvHyVj6Ts)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => !(         // a[] = input array
  ( m =         // m = bit mask to store node indices
    F = (       // F is a recursive function taking:
      a,        //   a[] = current node
      v,        //   v = node index
      q         //   q = highest power of 2 such that q ≤ v
    ) =>        //
    +a ||       // stop if this is a leaf
    a.map(b =>  // otherwise, for each child node b[]:
      F(        //   do a recursive call:
        b,      //     pass the child node
        v += q, //     add q to v
        q * 2   //     double q
      ),        //   end of recursive call
      m |=      //   update the bit mask m ...
        1 << v  //   ... so that the current node index is marked
    )           // end of map()
  )(a, 1, 1),   // initial call to F with a[] = input and v = q = 1
  m & m + 2     // test whether m has any bit in common with m + 2
)               // (if not, the only 0 in m is the trailing 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>37</s> 34 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ€`}\NÝ"€"×€"Dÿƶ˜s"J.V\)ø<í2δβ>{āQ
```

Port of [*@UnrelatedString*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260694/52210), but unfortunately 05AB1E lacks a multi-dimensional indices builtin, so we'll have to do that manually at the cost of 26 bytes.. :/

Uses `1` as leaves.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRHTWsSamP8Ds9VArKUDk8HkS6H9x/bdnpOsZKXXliM5uEdNofXGp3bcm6TXfWRxsD//6Ojow11DGNBCM6KBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWiy/9zUx41rUmojfE7PFcJyFI6PB1Euhzef2zb6TnFSl56YTGah3fYHF5rdG7LuU121UcaA//r/I9W8lHSUQCTQBwLZCLYGAJwFlgYTSF@SVR@LNRKvHpg1mO1n7BTECpiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ€`}\N         # Determine the depth-1 of the (implicit) multi-dimensional input-list:
Δ              #  Loop until the result no longer changes:
 €`            #   Flatten it one level down
   }\          #  After the loop: discard the resulting flattened list
     N         #  And push the last (0-based) index of the loop instead
Ý              # Pop and push a list in the range [0,depth-1]
 "€"×          # Map each to that many "€" as string
     €         # Then map each string to:
      "Dÿƶ˜s"  #  String "Dÿƶ˜s", where `ÿ` is replaced with the "€"-string
             J # Join this list of strings together
.V             # Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code:
       D       #  Duplicate the multi-dimensional list of 1s
        €      #  Zero or more `€`: map to a certain depth:
         ƶ     #   Multiply each value by its 1-based index
          ˜    #  Flatten the multi-dimensional list
           s   #  Swap, so the multi-dimensional list of 1s is at the top again
  \            # Discard the last multi-dimensional list of 1s
   )           # Wrap all flattened lists on the stack into a list
    ø          # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     <         # Decrease everything from 1-based to 0-based indices
í              # Reverse each inner list of multi-dimensional indices
  δ            # Map over each list:
 2 β           #  Convert it from a base-2 list to an integer
    >          # Increase each 0-based value by 1 to a 1-based value
     {         # Sort it
      ā        # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list)
       Q       # Check if the two lists are the same, in which case there are no gaps
               # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Determining the depth of a ragged-list (`` Δ€`}\N ``) I've done before in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240671/52210).
Determining the multi-dimensional indices of a ragged-list (`` Δ€`}\NÝ"€"×€"Dÿƶ˜s"J.V\)ø< ``) I've done before in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249515/52210).

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｆ№⭆¹θ1⊞υ∨¬ιＥ²§υ⊘⁻ικ⁼θ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw9C8IwFEV3f8Wj0ws8h7g6iQg6VAOOkiG01QZD0nwV/31MerjDhXO5w6zC4JQp5e0C4Nllm/CZgrafXi3ICTwj6HjHGIgcZ8wEj4B3l1BX0TYHglO62XH6NXlVZp1G7LXNETXBl20cd6J@Jrz4rExETyDcgrmZUl4VTly2bEXKsl/NHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list using `1` for leaves (note that Charcoal takes a list of inputs, so there's an extra set of `[]`s) and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for contiguous, nothing if not. Explanation: Port of my Retina 0.8.2 answer.

```
Ｆ№⭆¹θ1
```

Count the number of leaves.

```
⊞υ∨¬ιＥ²§υ⊘⁻ικ
```

Generate the balanced tree with that number of leaves.

```
⁼θ⊟υ
```

Compare it to the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 48 bytes

```
$
¶$`
T`[,]`_`^.+
+`(L+)(\1L?)
[$2,$1]
^(.+)¶\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX4Xr0DaVBK6QhGid2IT4hDg9bS7tBA0fbU2NGEMfe02uaBUjHRXDWK44DT1tzUPbYgxV/v/34Yr20fGJ5YoGU0gsMAniwSSwicBYsSBTMOV9EDyIJHZTIYKxAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Pretty sure this works, but I don't know how to prove it.

```
$
¶$`
```

Duplicate the input.

```
T`[,]`_`^.+
```

Flatten one copy.

```
+`(L+)(\1L?)
[$2,$1]
```

Turn into a balanced tree.

```
^(.+)¶\1$
```

Check whether this equals the original tree.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
data T=T T T|L
h L=[0]
h(T l r)=[1+d|d<-h l,h r==[d]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyWxJFEhxDZEAQhrfLgyFHxsow1iuTI0QhRyFIo0baMNtVNqUmx0MxRydDIUimxto1NiY//nJmbm2RYUZeaVqGSohADV@ij4aIIpKFvzPwA)

Comment: What are the truthy/falsey outputs you're using?

Comment: `(>[])` is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 232 bytes:

```py
def b(x,c,r,d):
 if isinstance(x,list):d[c]=d.get(c,[])+[r];b(x[0],c+1,'10'+r[1:],d);b(x[1],c+1,'11'+r[1:],d)
def f(t):d={};b(t,0,'1',d);K=sorted([int(i,2)for j in d for i in d[j]]);return all(K[j]+1==K[j+1]for j in range(len(K)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVDBTsQgED3LV5BeAMs2xb2YbvoFbfwB5FBbWNkQ2gAajfHbK7Tprok9eWHezJt5vJnpM7yO9vg4uXkepIIv@IP21NGBVABqBbXX1ofO9jISRvtAqoH3oh6Kswy4p1yQnDtxinO8FLTPGUWsRLnjrBJRZSHYRrAbAdJvCie9@us7tgVaxg6UZprajy7IAXNtA9b0gajRwQvUFg4wQb1AfhGCnJwMb87CzhjcxErO6jrGnInrjOvsWWIjLW7IgREye1jDLMtAC3hLWwH4En6h5U3ZRuxVNiRA0rraUtoE6fDTaCX1hZ@MDhg9W0TiRe8mlzZSWL53BuvCycl08bSoRRSirM1iFyEArG3ogO6PJdmXTgtEB399tbdsJfe3WYsiqvzL4/wD)

Answer (score 1):

## [julia](https://julialang.org/), 47 bytes

Expects a nested list of `0`s.

Truthy output: `true` or a positive integer of the total number of leaves

Falsy output: a negative integer

```
c(t)=t==0||(0<=-(c.(t)...)<2)*(+(c.(t)...,1))-1
```

The criterion is that a tree is truthy if, for each neighbouring pair of subtrees \$T_1, T_2\$ with the same parent node, the number of leaves in \$T_1\$ must be equal to or exactly one more then the number of leaves in \$T_2\$

The function `c` returns `true` on a leaf. Otherwise, we compute recursively `-(c.(t)...)` (which is equivalent to `c(t[1]) - c(t[2])`).
This will be either 0 or 1 if `t` is truthy or sometimes if both `t[1]` and `t[2]` are falsy.

In any case, if the condition holds, we return `+(c.(t)...,1)-1` (equivalent to `c(t[1]) + c(t[2])`), which is the total number of leaves if `t` is truthy and negative otherwise. If the condition fails, we return `-1`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6Fjf1kzVKNG1LbG0Namo0DGxsdTWS9YAienp6mjZGmloa2nC-jqGmpq4hRNstxhU-CrYKBlxcyRo-mgo1dgoFRZl5JTl5CliBskJJUWkqUG20j45PLH71ygpGIIVglXgVKysYIxSCSRyKlRVMwAphRuJUrKxgiqYQxkJTrKxgxgXxDT57IUbqGqKaictLaCohBmM1H9NMuEOwqIREGCy-AQ)