# Is it a properly tiered list?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, ragged-list

A ragged list is a (finite depth) list where each element is either a positive integer or a ragged list.

A ragged list is *properly tiered* if it contains either all positive integers or all properly tiered ragged lists.

For example `[1,2,3,6]` is properly tiered because it is a list of only positive integers.  `[[1,2],[[1]],[[6],[[]]]]` is also properly tiered, because it has 3 elements which are all properly tiered lists themselves.  Note that all the lists don't have to be the same depth.

The list `[[1,2],[[6],4]]` is *not* properly tiered because one of it's elements is a ragged list which contains a mixture of lists and positive integers.

### Task

Take a ragged list via any natural format and determine if it is a properly tiered list.  You should output one of two consistent values, the first if the input is a properly tiered list and the second if it is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so your goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[] -> Yes
[1,2,3,6] -> Yes
[[1,2],[[1]],[[6],[[]]]] -> Yes
[[]] -> Yes
[1,[2]] -> No
[[1,2],[[6],4]] -> No
[[1,[2]],[[3],4]] -> No
[1,[]] -> No
```

Comment: How is `[[1,[2]],[[3],4]]` properly tiered? Both lists contain both lists and numbers.

Comment: @Steffan It's not.  Sorry that test cases was suggested and I thought the yeses and nos were the other way when I added it.

Comment: May we error as truthy/falsey value (like the top Python answer currently does)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It seems like it was generally accepted by the community -- see [Functions may return a boolean value via the presence or absence of an error/exception](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/113573).

Comment: @Adam I know, but this challenge doesn't ask for a truthy/falsey result, but specifically "_You should output one of two consistent values_", overwriting the defaults defined in the meta. Hence my question. :) (I've linked that same post as you did in a comment below my 05AB1E when someone mentioned it earlier today.)

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@emanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)*

Returns *false* for valid, *true* for invalid.

```javascript
a=>/\d,\[|],\d/.test(JSON.stringify(a))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY31RNt7fRjUnRiomtidWJS9PVKUotLNLyC_f30ikuKMvPSM9MqNRI1NSHKbzH6JOfnFefnpOrl5KdrpGlExypgBZqaCvr6CpGpxVxo6g11jHSMdczQteFUD9IQqwOkYkGkGYiIBQLc6mOxugiPe6KNsGiBqPfLx-UcoENMkLThUQ4yHqjBGFkDTDkkUBcsgNAA)

Or **23 bytes** if we simply take a string as input:

```javascript
a=>/\d,\[|],\d/.test(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhbbE23t9GNSdGKia2J1YlL09UpSi0s0EjUhsrcYo5Lz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0lKJjlRSwAk1NBX19hcjUYi50HYY6RjrGOmYYGnHrAGmJ1QFSsSDSDETEAoESHh2x2N2Fz1XRRtg0QXT45eN0FNA5Jsga8WkAWQHUYoyiBaYBEsQLFkBoAA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

Returns *false* for valid, *true* for invalid.

```javascript
f=(a,q)=>a.some(b=>q-(q=!b.at)||!q&&f(b))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3NdNsNRJ1CjVt7RL1ivNzUzWSbO0KdTUKbRWT9BJLNGtqFAvV1NI0kjQ1IRpuMfok5-cV5-ek6uXkp2ukaUTHKmAFmpoK-voKkanFXGjqDXWMdIx1zNC14VQP0hCrA6RiQaQZiIgFAtzqY7G6CI97oo2waIGo98vH5RygQ0yQtOFRDjIeqMEYWQNMOSRQFyyA0AA)

Or:

```javascript
f=(a,q)=>a.some(b=>q-(q=!b.at)|f(q?[]:b))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3NdNsNRJ1CjVt7RL1ivNzUzWSbO0KdTUKbRWT9BJLNGvSNArto2OtkjQ1IRpuMfok5-cV5-ek6uXkp2ukaUTHKmAFmpoK-voKkanFXGjqDXWMdIx1zNC14VQP0hCrA6RiQaQZiIgFAtzqY7G6CI97oo2waIGo98vH5RygQ0yQtOFRDjIeqMEYWQNMOSRQFyyA0AA)

Comment: You can get away with not escaping one bracket in your regex.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>61</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```py
f=lambda l:l*-1or[l.sort(key=f)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBSsQwEIbx2qfILa2kxd2VRRYq7EUQZBH2JCGH2k4xmG1Cksr2KXwAL73oO61PY7KxtIWdw4T55v8zmXz9qM6-yabvv1tbp3cnVOeiOLxWBRIbcZ0upKYiM1Lb-B26vE5Y0P1e3fCDchiZzkRRLTUSvAHEGw8yYyvebCLkwoKxZWGAIDgqKC1UKD9rnUhzFSeZUYLbGKP0HuFk5nFK-ChEPNRJFNq6C3f70GBaYZ2ynsiGZlHathCuiV_A4DOGYwnKXvBj0FpqfMG7kzgMVpo3Nqb4Yfv4hAnCz9v9HjM6Lpb_uxiZ7B0mJOHj-tMnZX5V96CILsiSrMh6BJ4w4g7m89on5mLss6mZLkO5k6PTeW5n1IscX824w0MR3vUH)

Errors if the list is not properly tiered, otherwise returns `[]`.

---

-1 byte from @Mukundan314
-5 bytes from @loopy walt for various cleverness
-3 bytes from @Mukundan314

Comment: [35 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBLasMwEKVbn0LQhewgh3xKKAEXsikUSihkVYwWrjOmoootJLnEp-gBuvGmvVN6mo6iGNuQWYyY95mPvn9VY9-rsm1_alvE96fbIpHZ4W2fEbmWk3heaWIqbWEfSvYBTVJEk5mX_t3MxEEhR0xjgqBApRQlEFE6YGrsXpTrgGBYMDbPDDACRwU5NiPJWYsiLVQYTY2SwoaUxA-ERiMPKuEzk2FXR4GndeN7u9BgamlRWQxkHZnlts4kkvQVDD3DcMxB2St-ClpXml7xbivqBystShum9HHz9EwZoS-b3Y7ytD8subg4G9ztJ0T-49rTV8rdqbhQkM7Zgi3Zqgccwhk-3OWVSxyj5_nQnC58ua16J3ruRqgTIb4c4Qh3hd_rHw)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBSsQwEIbx2qfILa2kxd2VRRYq7EUQZBH2JCGH2k4xmG1Cksr2KXwAL73oO61PY7KxtIWdw4T55v8zmXz9qM6-yabvv1tbp3cnVOeiOLxWBRIbcZ0upKYiM1Lb-B26vE5Y0P1e3fCDchiZzkRRLTUSvAHEGw8yYyvebCLkwoKxZWGAIDgqKC1UKD9rnUhzFSeZUYLbGKP0HuFk5nFK-ChEPNRJFNq6C3f70GBaYZ2ynsiGZlHathCuiV_A4DOGYwnKXvBj0FpqfMG7kzgMVpo3Nqb4Yfv4hAnCz9v9HjM6Lpb_uxiZ7B0mJOHj-tMnZX5V96CILsiSrMh6BJ4w4g7m89on5mLss6mZLkO5k6PTeW5n1IscX824w0MR3vUH)

Answer (score 8):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Thanks to DLosc for -2 bytes!

```
{1<≡?∧´¨;≡}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHsxPOKJofCdlak/4oinwrTwnZWKwqjwnZWpO+KJofCdlal9CgpGwqjin6gK4p+o4p+pCuKfqDEsMiwzLDbin6kK4p+o4p+oMSwy4p+pLOKfqOKfqDHin6nin6ks4p+o4p+oNuKfqSzin6jin6jin6nin6nin6nin6kK4p+o4p+o4p+p4p+pCuKfqDEs4p+oMuKfqeKfqQrin6jin6gxLDLin6ks4p+o4p+oNuKfqSw04p+p4p+pCuKfqOKfqDEs4p+oMuKfqeKfqSzin6jin6gz4p+pLDTin6nin6kK4p+p)

`≡` gives the nesting depth of a list:

`1<≡?` If the depth is larger than 1 ( contains at least one list):
    `∧´¨` Are all the elements in the list properly tiered?
Else, if  is either an integer or a list of integers:
    `≡` Return the depth (1 for a list, 0 for an integer)

Comment: @DLosc indeed, thank you ()

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ℕᵐ|ċᵐ↰ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HL1IdbJ9Qc6QaSj9o2AMn//6OjDXWMYnWAVCyINAMRsUAAAA)

#### Explanation

```
ℕᵐ        The input is a list of only integers
  |       Or
   ċᵐ     The input is a list of only lists
     ↰ᵐ   Recursive call on each sub-list
```

Comment: Worth noting there's [*almost* a 6-byter](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f9QytSZZDagUxPkfHR2roxBtqGOkY6xjBmKC2LE6QCoWRJqBiFggAMnEQpRGG8UiKwQqMYEJgKWio41hQkARoF4A).

Answer (score 7):

## [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), 19 bytes

```typescript
type A=number[]|A[]
```

[Try it online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggvAOwK4FsBGEBOBtAugHxjwChiAbCYKAQwC5Yo4oTrHmBGAGgCZOBmTgDZcxVk2zYu3XJwntcMicNl4FIsc1Wi2k2dPU7d0lcoAsC7eN3Z9KvjPMHxXVUA)

Type system shows an error whenever the typed variable doesn't conform to the requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 (or 2..) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
d"Ð1åi˜Që®δ.V"©.Vß_
```

Outputs `0` for truthy and `1` for falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//2Qiw5Axw6Vpy5xRw6vCrs60LlYiwqkuVsOfX///WzEsWzJdXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/FKXDEwwPL808PSfw8OpD685t0QtTOrRSL@zw/Pj/Ov@jo2N1FKINdYx0jHXMQEwQO1YHSMWCSDMQEQsEIJlYiNJoo1hkhUAlJjABsFR0tDFMCCgC1AsA).

If the challenge would have used the default truthy/falsey definition instead of overwriting the meta, it could have been **2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead [by erroring](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/11908#11908):

```
¸P
```

Gives an error† as falsey value, or not as truthy value.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0I6A//@jDXWijWJjAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f9DOwL@6xzaZs8FEuYqz8jMSVUoSk1MUcjM40rJ51JQ0M8vKNGH6IZSaAbaKKiA1eal/o@O5Yo21DHSMdYxA7JAzFgdIBULIs1ARCwQcIEokLpoo1gkVUB5EygfJAEUMYaKAAWAFAA) (somewhat.. the falsey test cases contain rubbish output and lack trailing newline. Not sure how to properly try-catch the inner Elixir errors in 05AB1E.)

**Explanation:**

```python
d            # Convert each value in the (implicit) input-list to a 1
             # (with a >=0 check)
 "..."       # Push the recursive string defined below
      ©      # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
       .V    # Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code
         ß   # Pop and push the flattened minimum
             # (0 for falsey; 1 or "" for truthy)
          _  # Check that this value is equal to 0 (1 if 0; 0 otherwise)
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
Ð            #  Triplicate the current list
 1åi         #  If it contains a 1 as item:
    ˜Q       #   Check if the list is unchanged when flattened (thus all are 1s,
             #   without inner lists)
   ë         #  Else:
     δ       #   Map over each inner list:
    ® .V     #    And do a recursive call to `®`

¸            # Wrap the (implicit) input-list into a list
 P           # Take the product of each inner-most list,
             # which will error if an inner list contains both integers and lists
             # (implicitly output the result if it didn't error)
```

† The (Elixir) error is either an `ArithmeticError: bad argument in arithmetic expression` or an `UndefinedError: protocol Enumerable not implemented for int.` depending on how deep the integer causing the error is.

Comment: *"You should output one of two consistent values"*. Not only do I think errors are not outputs in that context, but you say that the error can be one of two different values.

Comment: @Fatalize Ugh.. And that's why I hate challenged that overwrite the default truthy/falsey meta definition.. :/ [Since error as falsey and no error as truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/52210) is perfectly acceptable if the defaults would have been used.. I'll delete for now and see if I can find a way to do this challenge in 05AB1E. I tried it earlier today to have a program actually outputting truthy/falsey instead of erroring as extra, but couldn't really figure it out. Will try again later.. -_-

Comment: @Fatalize Fixed.. at the cost of 17 bytes, because 05AB1E sucks with both ragged lists and recursive challenges.

Comment: Based on that meta post, I think it would be fine if the error was consistently the same. Maybe other people have different opinions on the matter. (Personally, I disagree with the meta-post: erroring should not be considered a valid output)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
λÞjṅ[Þj|vxA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwizrvDnmrhuYVbw55qfHZ4QSIsIiIsIltdXG5bMSwyLDMsNl1cbltbMSwyXSxbWzFdXSxbWzZdLFtbXV1dXVxuW1tdXVxuWzEsWzJdXVxuW1sxLDJdLFtbNl0sNF1dXG5bWzEsWzJdXSxbWzNdLDRdXVxuWzEsW11dIl0=)

Comment: Can Vyxal distinguish between "12" and 12?

Comment: @Sandra Yes. Why?

Comment: I don't understand Vyxal yet but I was working on this in a other language and what took a loot of bytes was rejecting ["12"] but accepting [12]

Comment: @Sandra you shouldn't need to though, because the challenge gives you input containing lists of numbers, and by our meta defaults,  input will always be valid

Comment: But the challenge is to determine if a ragged list is a "a list of only positive integers": do I need to check polarity and type? @WheatWizard please chime in

Comment: @Sandra pinging him here won't notify him, because he isn't in this comment section. ask in the comments of the main question, please

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 21 bytes

```
*/^9 56?4/'6!3':`j@^:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LSj7NUMDWzN9FXN1M0VrdKyHKIs+LiSlNIyLJXio5VgrEMdYx0jHXMEAIgkVgdIBULIs1ARCwQIORjkTVHG8ViagVqMkEVBikDShijSgDFQTwuLn2u6FgFXTuFyNRiLriL4AI4XISQj0XWDLIKxPXL50JzEJIointg4mDnQDgAXLpSqw==)

Uses a similar idea to Arnauld and Neil's regex approach, but without regex.

```
*/^9 56?4/'6!3':`j@^:   Input: a ragged list
                   ^:   change all numbers to zeros
                `j@     JSON stringify (which contains only `[]0,`)
             3':        get all length-3 contiguous substrings
           6!    each charcode mod 6 (`[]0,` -> 1 3 0 2)
        4/'      base 4 each
  ^9 56?         test if each number is not one of 9 or 56 (which can only appear if
                 the substring "0,[" or "],0" appear in the string respectively)
*/               1 if all true (or empty), 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
Min[0#/.{0...}->1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zczL9pAWV@v2kBPT69W184wVu1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoNyrFpdcHJiXl01V3WtDle1oY6RjrGOGYgJYtfqAKlaEGkGImqBACQDIkFqq41qkVUC1ZjABMBS1dXGYCGu2v8A)

Returns `1` if the list is properly tiered, or `0` otherwise.

Checks that integers are only present in non-nested lists.

```
    0#              zero integers
      /.{0...}->1   turn lists of 0s into 1
Min[             ]  0s remaining?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ß€ŒḊ⁺Ḋ$?P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EdNa45Oerij61HjLiCpYh/w/3C7ZuT//9GxOgrRhjpGOsY6ZiAmiB2rA6RiQaQZiIgFApBMLERptFEsskKgEhOYAFgqOtoYJgQUiY0FAA)

Port of [ovs's BQN solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251421/85334).

```
  ŒḊ         The depth of the argument (0 if integer)
       ?     unless
    ⁺        the depth of the argument
     Ḋ       is greater than 1 (range [2 .. depth] is nonempty)
ß            in which case recur
 €           on each element
        P    and take the product of the results.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

```
f=lambda x:x*0==0 or all((y*0==x[0]*0)&f(y)for y in x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zdJscxJzk1ISFSqsKrQMbG0NFPKLFBJzcjQ0KkHcimiDWC0DTbU0jUrNNKBMpUJmnkKFJlT30RAFW4VoLgWF6FgdEGmoY6RjrGMG4YB4sTpAKhZEmoGIWCCAyMXGcsVycbnBtBvqRBvFomoDajBBCIGlo6ONEYJAMYghIGdVgJwVYgUULyjKzCvRSNOo0NTkgrCVdIFASROhzg1NHcQzsCABAA)

We can get it a little shorter with Whython, because iterating through a number is an error:

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 46 bytes

```
f=lambda x:all((y*0==x[0]*0)&f(y)for y in x)?1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728PKOyJCM_b8GCpaUlaboWN_XSbHMSc5NSEhUqrBJzcjQ0KrUMbG0rog1itQw01dI0KjXT8osUKhUy8xQqNO0NobqOhijYKkRzKShEx-qASEMdIx1jHTMIB8SL1QFSsSDSDETEAgFELjaWK5aLyw2m3VAn2igWVRtQgwlCCCwdHW2MEASKQQwBOawC5LAQK6B4QVFmXolGmkaFpiYXhK2kCwRKmgh1bmjqIJ6BBQUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 56 bytes

```
f=\(x)`if`(all(y<-Map(is.list,x)),all(Map(f,x)),!any(y))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3LdJsYzQqNBMy0xI0EnNyNCptdH0TCzQyi_VyMotLdCo0NXVAwiCxNDBPMTGvUqNSUxOi_xajcJoGSKWGpqaygq6dQmRqMRdUxFDHSMdYxwxTAiarqYPE1UTmmSFzNEEAqxlYxA0hGo1gUn75-GwF2mOCUyXMICT1xljVQ5UiJCBhs2ABhAYA)

Checks whether all elements are lists. If so, recurses, otherwise none of the elements may be a list.

Utilises the [fact](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242180/55372) that `all` and `any` work on depth-1 lists so we may use `Map` over `sapply`.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, <del>147</del> <del>131</del> 123 bytes

-18 bytes thanks to @alephaalpha for reminding me `matches!` exists

-8 bytes thanks to @bubbler for reminding me `Vec` impelments `Deref<Target=[T]>` and @alephaalpha for reminding me you can use `if` in `matches!`.

```rs
enum E{a(u8),b(Vec<E>)}fn f(e:&[E])->bool{e.iter().all(|m|matches!(m,E::a(_)))|e.iter().all(|m|matches!(m,E::b(k)if f(k)))}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5946618338e3c51fab2c91121e712b4c)

Comment: `if let E::a(_)=m{true}else{false}` -> `matches!(m, E::a(_))`, and `false` -> `1<0`.

Comment: You can change `f(e:&Vec<E>)` to `f(e:&[E])`. Also `if let E::b(k)=m{f(k)}else{1<0}` -> `match m{E::b(k)=>f(k),_=>1<0}`

Comment: `if let E::b(k)=m{f(k)}else{1<0}` -> `matches!(m,E::b(k)if f(k))`.

Comment: @alephalpha That second tip is really smart thanks, no idea you could do that

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>21</s> 16 bytes

```ruby
p !/\],\d|\d,\[/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBUT8mVicmpSYmRScmWv///@hYrmhDHSMdYx0zIAvEjNUBUrEg0gxExAIBF4gCqYs2ikVSBZQ3gfJBEkARY7DIv/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

- Thanks to @Dom Hastings for saving 6.
- Fixed output to be of two consistent values.

Using Regexp.

Takes a string array literal and return *true* if list is tiered, *false* otherwise.

**Or 50 bytes**

Checking recursively.

```ruby
f=->l{l.all?{|e|e*0==0}||l.all?{|e|e*0==[]&&f[e]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6nOkcvMSfHvromtSZVy8DW1qC2pgZNKDpWTS0tOjW2tvZ/gUKaXjJQUiM6VlNBWUHXTiEytZgLLqoQbahjpGOsY4ZDFiQdqwOkYkGkGYiIBQIcimNx2hFtBJfzy8dmAdBoE9xKQNqBioxRFf0HAA)

Comment: Nice approach! Also, -6 for Ruby + `-n`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOPyZWJyalJiZFJyZa////6FiuaEMdIx1jHTMgC8SM1QFSsSDSDETEAgEXiAKpizaKRVIFlDeB8kESQBFjsMi//IKSzPy84v@6eQA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Although I personally think it's pretty stupid, the challenge asks for "_two consistent values_", which the `index` isn't. :/

Comment: @KevinCruijssen right, i didn't pay attention , that's fine

Comment: You can save one more byte dropping `(`...`)` and replacing with just a space (just enough so it's not parsed as `!~` I guess?)

Comment: @Dom Hastings yes! And _!_ is enough so I got rid of _~_

Comment: Nice, didn't consider `!` as the regexp executor!

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `json`,  <sup><s>58 38</s></sup>  37 bytes

```factor
[ >json R/ ],\d|\d,\[/ re-contains? ]
```

`>json` postdates the Factor builds on TIO and ATO, so have a picture of running this in Factor's REPL:

[image]

If we're allowed to take input as a string, `>json` can be removed for -6 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a.some?.(v=>v.at!=a[0].at|f(v))
```

Return `false` for valid, `true` for invalid.

```js
f=a=>a.some?.(v=>v.at!=a[0].at|f(v))

update = () => { try { output.value = input.value.trim().split('\n').map(x => [JSON.parse(x.split('->')[0]), x.split('->')[1].trim() !== 'Yes']).map(([i, e]) => f(i) + ' ' + e).join('\n'); } catch {} }

update();
input.oninput = update;
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
<textarea id=input style="flex: 0 0 50%; font: inherit; padding: 10px;">[] -> Yes
[1,2,3,6] -> Yes
[[1,2],[[1]],[[6],[[]]]] -> Yes
[[]] -> Yes
[1,[2]] -> No
[[1,2],[[6],4]] -> No
[[1,[2]],[[3],4]] -> No
[1,[]] -> No</textarea>
<output id=output style="flex: 1 1 0; white-space: pre; padding: 15px;"></output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 35 bytes

```
[..|map(type)?|unique|length]|max<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aT68mN7FAo6SyIFXTvqY0L7OwNLUmJzUvvSQjFihTYWMEVBTLFW2oY6RjrGMGZIGYsTpAKhZEmoGIWCDgAlEgddFGsUiqgPImUD5IAihiDBUBCsTGAgA)

Below, "E" indicates where `map(type)` produces an error. This is supressed with `?`.

```
input:        [1,[2,3]]
[..]:         [[1,[2,3]],          1, [2,3],                2, 3]
[|map(type)]: [["number","array"], E, ["number", "number"], E, E]
[|unique]:    [["number","array"],    ["number"]]
[|length]:    [2,                     1]
|max<2:       false
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 12 bytes

```
1`\d,\[|],\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3zAhJkUnJromVicm5f//6FiuaEMdIx1jHTMgC8SM1QFSsSDSDETEAgEXiAKpizaKRVIFlDeB8kESQBFjsAgA) Link includes test cases. Outputs `0` for a properly tiered list. Explanation: Same approach as @Arnauld, just check for an integer next to a list. Would cost 3 bytes to output `1` for a properly tiered list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
⊞υθＦυＦι⊞υ⁺⟦⟧κ⬤υΦ²⬤ι⁼μ⁼ν⁺⟦⟧ν
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxDsIwDER3vsKjI5mBwtaJAebsloeoAjXCpGpS8/uGgkDccqd7d8OY6jAldY/WRjSCOfSb61QBLcDbc4Avi2oNWQhu4bWKNZcFj6orOmddLhU7grXIBKfZkja8/1L5@5fwUe/OzDviToSY90IHEfHtQ58) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υθＦυＦι⊞υ⁺⟦⟧κ
```

Enumerate the ragged list and all of its elements but replacing integers with empty lists (which are always properly tiered).

```
⬤υΦ²⬤ι⁼μ⁼ν⁺⟦⟧ν
```

Check that all lists contain either only integers or only sublists (or both, in the case of empty lists).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
FreeQ[a_/;!SameQ@@Head/@a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7360oNTUwOjFe31oxODE3NdDBwSM1MUXfITH2f0BRZl5JtLKCrp1CWrRybKyCmoK@A5dCdXWtDpeCQrWhjoKRjoKxjoIZhA8WqNUBMWrBlBmYrAUCiHwtXF@1US26HpBiEyRRsBIg0xhJHCQMNO0/AA)

Checks if the input contains any list whose elements do not have the same head (`List` or `Integer`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40 36</s> 29 bytes

```ruby
f=->l{l*0!=0&&!l.uniq(&f)[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6nOkfLQNHWQE1NMUevNC@zUEMtTTPaMLb2f4FCWnS0oY6RjnFsLBecEw3kQblAVTrRYGlUAbCS2P8A)

#### Why?

First check if l is a list (`l*0!=0`)

Then map f on l and check that the result is the same for all elements. By applying `uniq` directly on the list, instead of `l.map(&f).uniq` we can just check if there is a second element (`uniq` returns elements of the list instead of `true` or `false`). If we map the function first, we must check that the size is 2, because if we check the second element, it could be `false`, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 38 bytes

```
f(a)=(#a>#b=[f(x)|x<-a,#x'==#x])*#b||b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN9XSNBI1bTWUE-2Uk2yj0zQqNGsqbHQTdZQr1G1tlStiNbWUk2pqkqCq2xILCnIqNRIVdO0UCooy80qATCUQR0kBZI6mjkJ0dCyQMNQx0jHWMQMxQexYHSAVCyLNQEQsEIBVQpRGG8UiKwQqMYEJgKWio41hQkARoF5NiGtgfgAA)

Returns `0` for valid, `1` for invalid.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 40 bytes

```
f(a)=[#x'==#x|x<-a]&&[x'===0||f(x)|x<-a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNzXSNBI1baOVK9RtbZUraipsdBNj1dSiQVxbg5qaNI0KTYggVH1bYkFBTqVGooKunUJBUWZeCZCpBOIoKYBM0tRRiI6OBRKGOkY6xjpmICaIHasDpGJBpBmIiAUCsEqI0mijWGSFQCUmMAGwVHS0MUwIKALUqwlxDcwXAA)

Returns `0` for valid, `1` for invalid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
:w"\d,\[|],\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfiv/N@qXCkmRScmuiZWJybl///oWK5oQx0jHWMdMyALxIzVAVKxINIMRMQCAReIAqmLNopFUgWUN4HyQRJAEWOoCFAgNhYA)

Outputs `False` if list is properly tiered and `True` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```
f=v=>v.every?.(u=>!u.at)|v.every?.(f)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN1XTbMts7cr0UstSiyrt9TRKbe0US_USSzRrEGJpmhDFtxh9kvPzivNzUvVy8tM10jSiYxWwAk1NBX19hcjUYi409YY6RjrGOmbo2nCqB2mI1QFSsSDSDETEAgFu9bFYXYTHPdFGWLRA1Pvl43IO0CEmSNrwKAcZD9RgjKwBphwSqLCYAAA)

Outputs `1` for properly tiered list, `0` for lists that is not properly tiered, or integers (only used for recursive case)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:sum(l)>=0?all(map(f,l))?0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZCxasMwEIbp6mfooKEgGZSQJiWUgBOyBAodCulmNKiOTASyLaRzGz9Lh3opfab0aSpFLlVCb5C4-7__dKf3r7d9B_um7vvPFsrR_fGmzBSvXnYcqYVtK6LSZTZZcaVIxTUpqUrT1SSw31fXstKNAWQ7myRlY5CStUCy9oWxhZ2sFwlyAcJCwa2gSBy0KEDsUHZiHWSkJunYaiWBYDRaIpyeeRwpXrkiv3maBNl0obcPI2yrwJFlhHlBHAqh4R8QC2Mag08CL6DlyhXdMCQQwyPayBpIjjfrh0dMEX5ab7eY5X9LZIOZ0WjHoUX4pP74kTO_1rNpRZLf0imd0XlU8SVG3cX8OfcHcxEB7MyfT0O-4cpGdme8uxQ86qTZpeSUKA9z_gA)

*Test harness stolen from the one [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan314) contributed to [Adam's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251427/16766)*

#### Explanation

```python
f=                                    # f is
  lambda l:                           # a function that takes one argument l:
           sum(l)                     # Sum the list (errors unless all items are numbers)
                 >=0                  # If that worked, return True
                    ?                 # If that errored,
                         map(f,l)     # Recurse on each item (errors if l is not a list)
                     all(        )    # If that worked, return True if every item returned True
                                  ?   # If that errored (l is not a list),
                                   0  # Return 0 (falsey)
```

The only time the function returns `0` is when it is called on an integer. If it is called on a list, it will always return either `True` or `False`.

Comment: You could do `f=lambda l:~sum(l)?all(map(f,l))?0` and just return truthy or falsey.

Comment: You really should thank @Mukundan314 for the tests

Comment: @Steffan This particular challenge specifies that "You should output one of two consistent values," so I don't think returning any of various negative numbers for truthy would be allowed. :(