# Encrypting Emojis

Tags: string, sequence, code-challenge, encoding, encryption

### Problem

You are tasked with creating a program that performs emoji encryption on a given string of emojis. In this encryption scheme, each emoji is replaced by a unique character (from `a` to `z`). Your program should take an emoji string as input and output the corresponding encrypted string.

The mapping of emojis to characters is up to you and can vary each time the program is run. For example:

```yaml
Input: 
Output 1: aaabbcdce
Output 2: xxxiikbkg
```

Both outputs are valid.

Your task is to write a program that produces encrypted strings for given emoji inputs. Your program will be evaluated based on its **average result value** and size of code (in bytes).

### Value of the Result

Each letter from `a` to `z` has a value from `0` to `25` in ascending order.
ie.

```yaml
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2 
  .
  .
  .
y = 24
z = 25
```

The value of the result is calculated as the summation of the values of all characters in the resulting string. For example:

```yaml
aaabbcdce
0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 4 = 13
```

### Scoring Criteria:

Run the program 10,000 times, each time generating a random 25-emoji string, and calculate the average value of the results. Your score will be determined by this average value in comparison with the size of the code.

The goal is to create a program that, on average, produces encrypted strings with the lowest possible value based on the emoji-to-character mapping chosen for each run (a `run` is considered converting 25 emojis to a string hence there will be 10,000 unique runs considered in your score)

Create and submit a program that generates encrypted strings as described above, and your score will be the average result value obtained from the 10,000 runs and multiply by the size of the code in bytes. A lower Score is better.

$${\text{average value of results over }10,000\text{ runs}}\times {\text{size of code in bytes}}
$$
**LOWER SCORE IS BETTER**

### Notes:

**Ignore decryption**

This problem emphasizes randomness and the ability to produce low-value results on average, so figuring out which emoji has been repeated the most in the input and giving it the character `a` will improve the program's result.

##### Input restrictions

- Input Emoji string will contain **25** emojis without any spaces.
- There will only be **10** unique emojis in the Input at maximum.
- The 10 valid emojis in the Input are

some example inputs:

```yaml
Invalid input: ♿️⛷5️⃣⏏ (it has more than 10 unique emojis)
                ♿️⛷  5️⃣⏏ (invalid for including spaces)

Valid input:  ( Valid since it has only 9 unique emojis (<= 10) and no spaces)
Valid output to this Input: abccdaefeagaaaefehcccaief
```

#### example random Input generators

##### Python

```py
import random

input_string = ''.join(random.choice("") for _ in range(25))

print("Emoji String:", input_string)
```

Comment: Should glyphs consisting of multiple characters, like flags or skin tone modifiers, be considered one or multiple emojis? Or can we assume those won't be in the input?

Comment: they are considered different, but also it doesn't matter @mousetail as generating the input is not part of the code so you could just choose a random set of 10 emojis that do not include the human ones. Because the only restriction really is that the distribution should be uniform and I don't really know if the skin tones are considered different or similar in your random function.

Comment: I might just give the 10 random emoji's in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You said the input is given though, so I don't understand how it does not matter. You need to specify what possible inputs can be

Comment: @mousetail yea, sorry for the confusion. I've added the 10 valid emojis to the question now. The input should be a random 25 length Emoji string of these 10 Emojis ONLY.

Comment: dividing byte the size of the code insentiences longer programs (with no lower bound on the score), did you mean "multiply by the size of the source-code"?

Comment: @bsoelch dividing by smaller code size will increase the Score and ``higher is better`` I'll add it to the question. also, your answer has an error.

Comment: wait i just realized the problem. yea I should change it to multiply

Comment: How is this a [tag:decision-problem]? Also, to what extent is randomness actually required?

Comment: @UnrelatedString sorry I'll remove that if it isn't related. and the input should just be a uniform distribution. ie. probability of any of the 10 Emojis appearing should be the same.

Comment: For a given input, the "minimum" value is known deterministically. From there, it seems it should be possible to compute the average minimum value for a random 10K sample. I think this question could be improved by including this average minimum value, so that looking at the average value of an answer, one has an indication on whether the answer is close to the minimum, or not.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I mean looking at the answers it's pretty clear that the best average is 72-73. I feel adding it to the question might just add more text noise since in no way you are expected to write the code with the lowest average heck, even the 3rd best submission has an avg. value of 287 and still beats everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 516.3704 (73.7672 * 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands))

```
ÙΣ¢}RA‡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Mxziw8tqg1yfNSw8P//D/OnT/4wf2b/h/mTp0PwpN0QscntH@bPWgShQfwJnRAahpHlJ81A6AdhkPyMVTA1AA) or [verify the average score of 10,000 random runs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9yaIOb0of50yd/mD@z/8P8ydM/zJ@0G0i3P1o79cP8CZ1A7owP82es@jC/r1PJyDTv8Fy9IiPTQ4sPr/A6PCHs/@GZ5xZHFh9aVBvk@Khh4X/H4uBsf65aTSXHMNcgR3dXhWBn/yBXKwUle5fDrY46XEqOOTkKxcn5RanFIEH7/wA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù        # Uniquify the emoticon-characters of the (implicit) input-string
 Σ       # Sort it from lowest to highest by:
  ¢      #  The count of the character in the (implicit) input-string
   }R    # After the sort-by: reverse it from highest to lowest count
     A   # Push the lowercase alphabet string
      ‡  # Transliterate the descending sorted unique emoticons to lowercase letters in
         # the (implicit) input-string
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>73.2 * 81 bytes = *5929.2*</s> <s>73.2 * 70 bytes = *5124.4*</s> 73.2 * 64 bytes = *4684.8*

Same method as below for finding most common letters, but two significant improvements suggested in comments by [@pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55372/pajonk):

1. -11 bytes thanks to a much better approach to splitting and concatenating strings using `utf8ToInt()`.
2. -6 bytes pointing out [`chartr()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html) can take a range of characters (e.g. `"a-d"` rather than `"abcd"`).

```r
\(x)chartr(intToUtf8(names(sort(-table(utf8ToInt(x))))),'a-z',x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVLNbtNAEJY47lOMnEN3q3WVhFaNqoK4VFAJCkLOrZK7uGuw2KyNdy2Fn56rXNoqOSRtDw5FXDhxz5O0T-FHwONNCXBmJOvb-fvm2_Fef83n3-Jd_3thY793--SQDln0TuQ2p4m2Qdq3cY9qMZCGmjS31LfijZK0ru4F6b62dTkaXxP-pzU-ZI7n7sHPFrzUEqw0FiJhJImpV5WT06o8G1Xl5XlVjme1P63Ki5E7YwxzVzerHPrjhfPxPJ2sPuxDvoZr4frORh4jLei0368mG2Kk3TBSHtPNLiOJzgob1iHY9SGiBGrzkNHjiJfnDidTh-PF0j91eHXj8GK0zM8czn44rBUQRvYPXvWD8PnewdPgGc7pbpEhYiaMlW1qxCCrl_hbCoc_GzjkMlMikvAIgtf9PcYhSpUSmcGIV9-QREJFhRJWhiZKc4nUcaEjm6SapoVl8Lm5Vy5NoazBtPttxuYmU4nFIo5UrKl7ITJ6tH7E7xs4GPkhFCrVb-kyxMCHDoMvj5sGtEKrxFj6V8wUA8rICSGNrBALcHitPVMfaWenIzc5HNLkXuD_XAry_bMXGuPzJCeMDKTQdKl4pY0xaMH2w41ue2vbPdz53OEv)

The ATO link includes a footer with 10k random test cases.

---

Original approach:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 73.2 * 81 bytes = 5929.2

```r
\(x,p=paste0,`^`=Reduce)chartr(p^names(sort(-table(strsplit(x,"")))),p^letters,x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVLNbhMxEJY4-ilGm4uNvFUSWrVCDbcKkKBAld6qbMx2FlY4u2btlYJoz1UubZUckpZD0iIunLjnSeAp9hGw1ymBnhlp9Xn-vvk86y83xeJrsht-K00S7vx8c0SHXHWU0AabvN_rdw7wuIyRxe9FYQqqepkYoKY6LwwNjXgrkWpTaCVTYzuDgFnjqifRGCw0HzJP_OvBjwa8yhAMagOx0EgSGlTzyVk1Px9V86uLaj6eWX9azS9H_uxiLnd9u845f7z0vjtPJ-vP9Tm-mmvp-85HASMNaDU_rCdrotFsaMRjutlmJM1UaSIbgt0QYkrAWuAYA-7w6sLjZOpxvFz5Zx6vbz1ejlb5mcfZd49WAWHk-f7rw270Ym__afeZm9PeIkOHftFUi4Gym_wjhcPfDRwKVFLECB3oHhzuMQ5xLqVQ2kXszgmJhYxLKQxGOs4LdNRJmcUmzTOal4bB5_peBepSGu3S9_6dLeKOitV1L4Wi_Yd9ftfAQePHSMg8e0dXIQYhtBicPKkbnJWZTLWh_8R0OaCMnBJSy4pcgRtutSv5ibYet3CTwxFN7wT-z6U4vnt7oQkd2iueMjJAkdGV4rU2xqAB24822s2tbf9wFwuPvwE)

*-4 bytes thanks to noticing I was being very foolish by using paste0() twice on the same string*

### How?

Fun question. R code golfers will no doubt be aware of the [advice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91294/115882):

> If you see a challenge involving string manipulation, just press the back button and read the next question. `strsplit` is single handily responsible for ruining R golf

I boldly ignored this, but it was quickly clear that once you've invested all the bytes in splitting the string into a vector, you need a fairly low-scoring mapping of letters to emojis to come in under 10k. I note some of the answers have slightly lower average value of results than my 73.2 (around the 73.1 range). If anyone has a lot of time and compute power, it would be interesting to see how low you could get it by brute forcing the best random seed.

The actual algorithm is not rocket science: simply assigning the most frequent character `a`, the next most frequent `b` etc. Here is an ungolfed version:

```r
f <- function(x, p = paste0, `^` = Reduce) {
    s <- strsplit(x, "")
    m <- sort(-table(s))

    # Ungolfed equivalent to
    # chartr(
    #     Reduce(paste0, names(m)),
    #     Reduce(paste0, letters), x
    # )
    chartr(p^p^names(m), p^p^letters, x)
}
```

The main golfing is using [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171759/115882) trick by @J.Doe:

> Operator abuse gives you `p=paste0;"^"=Reduce;p^p^r` which saves two bytes on the usual `paste0` call.

It also uses [`chartr()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html), basically the equivalent of Python's string `translate()` method, for an (irrelevantly) fast one-to-one replacement of each emoji with the letters of the alphabet. For clarity, the second argument should be `letters[1:10]`, but `chartr()` is fine with the replacement being longer than the pattern to be replaced.

---

Approaches which aim to optimise the number of bytes:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 57 bytes * 90.2775 = *5145.8175*

```r
\(x)chartr(gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)","",x,pe=T),"jihgfedcba",x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVLBbhMxEJU4-iss9zKunKhbWkRRA6cKkKAglN4ibR3Xmy44u2btlYKAc5VLWyWHpOWwoYgLJ-75EviK_QTsdUqAM5as53kz8-bZ8qfPxeJLst_6Wtqkdf_HXg9GVJzywhYwMGUfCLQpPOq0N3u9iBJGCBsxLTtdysjr9HSQyBPR546kQeDnne8b-EUmsZXGYsGNRAmQupqe1dX5uK6uLupqMnfxrK4ux-HsOZ-7vlnnfDxZhtifZ9P19n1er9Fahr7zMaFoA0dbb9aTDTLSto2UJ7CzTVGa6dLGjsL7LSwAYbeIVyTM49VFwOks4GS5is8CXt8EvByv8vOA828BnQNE0dPDl0fd-NnB4ePuEz9nexeNPGpurNwCw4daSfhtheE_GxgupFZcSNzB3VdHB5RhkSvFtfEMcTdEgitRKm5lbEReSC-dlJmwaZ5BXlqK3zf3KqQplTU-bXnfTTS2MFql1hcxL0Wbuudcw_HmMbttYNjItzFXeTaAFUVxC0cUf3jYNPhVZio1Fv7iTDkEij4i1NiKfYEf7rxr9Q6iB5HcYbgH6a3B__koXu-fd4HEfWPnh6Kh5BmsHK-9UYrdZ4nutffu7oaPu1gE_AU)

+7 bytes but still lower scoring than the previous approach below, thanks to the observation in the [comment by Dominic Van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264399/encrypting-emojis/264425?noredirect=1#comment578035_264425) that, as the regex leads to assigning `"a"` to the emoji whose final appearance occurs first, you're more-likely to assign `"a"` to emojis that only appear once.

So if we reverse the replacement string to `"jihgfedcba"` then we end up with a value of 90.3, much lower than 116.9 in the approach below, which despite the increase in bytes leads to a better overall score. Although still not as low as the first method, and neither scores as well as the excellent [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264485/115882) by Dominic Van Essen.

---

*Previous iteration*

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>116.935 * 57 bytes = *6665.295*</s> 116.935 * 50 bytes = *5846.75*

*Again -7 thanks to @pajonk as `"abcdefghij"` became `"a-j"` in `chartr()`*

```r
\(x)chartr(gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)","",x,pe=T),"a-j",x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVJNb9MwGJY4-ldY3uX15FRL2RCgFU4TIMFAqLtVyrzgjICbhNiRigbnqZdtag_txiFliAsn7v0l8CvyE_AbdxQ4Y8l6_H48z_vY8qfP5eJLsht8rWwS3P3RHcCIx69laUs4NtURMOhweNjrbA4GIWeCMTESher1uWAyeOMi7pk_b33foM8zRa0ylsbSKJIAa-rpaVOfjZv68rypJ3MXz5r6YuzPmMPa1fW6hvFk6WM8z6brjTzUa7WWnnc2Zpxs0HDr7XqyIUbZjlHqFWx3OUmzorKRS9HdgMZAqFsMFZlAvDz3OJ15nCxX8anHq2uPF-NVfe5x_s2jc0A4ebL_4qAfPd3bf9R_jHO6O2SEWEhj1RYYOSy0gt9WBP2TIGipCi1jRXu0__Jgjwsa51rLwmCGuRuSWOq40tKqyMR5qVA6qbLYpnkGeWU5PWnvVSpTaWuwbOWRm2hsaQqdWmwSKMXbvmeygMPNQ3FDENSod5HUeXYMqxSnAQ05_fCgJeCqMp0aC3_lTDUETj4S0tqKsAGHO--Ffg_h_VBtCzqA9Mbg_3wU1PvnXSBx_9f54WSoZAYrx2tvnFP3WcI7nXu3d_zHXSw8_gI)

### How?

This was an attempt to do it in as few bytes as possible. Rather than splitting the input string into a vector, this just finds the unique characters with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301806/regex-remove-repeated-characters-from-a-string-by-javascript), and replace them in the order they appear with the letters `"a"` to `"j"`.

Nice to not have to `strsplit()` and `paste()` for once, and be able to do everything in `chartr()`. It's quite a bit shorter. But it's obviously not an optimal approach to the value part of the score, and the overall score is still higher than the original answer.

Comment: damn, this is really cool! I've never really used that much R myself. But the thing about random seed is that the score accounts for more than that. like the [2nd solution of Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264407/119269) which has a horrendous average value of 287 but because it's only 6 bytes is still the 2nd best solution. So it is kind of more about figuring out a sweet spot.

Comment: @3.14 thanks. I just meant the first part of the score was driven by the seed, which you called average value, inem 71.2 in my case. I was struggling to express that. I did try some other approaches in R but I couldn't get a lower overall score because they were all fairly verbose. If we're allowed to take the input and output as a list of characters, or even a list of Unicode integers, rather than a string, I think it could be done. What are your views on the IO rules?

Comment: yea I did actually consider integers at first but then I realized people can just loop ``%10`` to figure out the most repeated digit. and then just replace or swap the digits to make a small and efficient code. That's why I did the whole ascending order and Emoji thing making sure the emojis aren't in any sequence so people can't just subtract the Unicode and stuff.

Comment: [Alternative 81 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHiNBvdpaUlaboWNwNjNCp0EhQTbDPzSkLyQ0vSLDSTMxKLSoo0FBOL9VLyS5NyUjXyEnNTizWK84tKNHRLEkEiQM0WIfmeeSUaFZogoKNoaW5laGSkU6EJNXiOsoJ_XqpCSWpxiUJyYnEqV5qG0of5k9s_zO_r_DB_Zv-H-ZNmAPnTP8yf0Alhg8RAcrMWIeRA_Em7IXwQe_pkBAbpA5kHNms3RF9fp5ImV0ER0DMaSumJKUkZqUkpiZlJGYlpSYnJycmp6SlpmYlKUDcuWAChAQ)

Comment: @3.14 yes the emojis were a nice touch - I tried using `charToRaw()` at first in R which converts to bytes but obviously that gets you into difficulty quite quickly! I edited my answer with a short random encoding - unfortunately overall score is not as good as the longer version.

Comment: @pajonk awesome! I just edited as I realised that I was doing `p^p^letters` when `p^` would have sufficed, so mine is now also 81 bytes. I very much like your method though - I did try several `intToUtf8()` and back approaches but the function names were too long - I couldn't get down to less than about 86 bytes - your approach is very nice.

Comment: @pajonk although yours seems to work [without](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHiNBvdpaUlaboWN91iNCp0EhQTbDPzSkLyQ0vSLDSTMxKLSoo0FPMSc1OLNYrzi0o0dEsSk3JSNYBaLELyPfNKNCo0gUBH0dLcytDISKdCE2raHGUF_7xUhZLU4hKF5MTiVK40DaUP8ye3f5jf1_lh_sz-D_MnzQDyp3-YP6ETwgaJgeRmLULIgfiTdkP4IPb0yQgM0gcyD2zWboi-vk4lTa6CIqAPNJTSE1OSMlKTUhIzkzIS05ISk5OTU9NT0jITlaBuXLAAQgMA) `as.double()` and then it's 70 bytes - unless I'm missing something. Quite an improvement and a bit of a departure - do you want to post it as a separate answer?

Comment: Ah, right - for some reason I thought it won't work. No, you can use it if you like - I wouldn't have taken up the challenge without your post.

Comment: Some byte-saves by remembering that `chartr` can take simple range of chars as input: `\(x)chartr(intToUtf8(names(sort(-table(utf8ToInt(x))))),'a-z',x)` (64), `\(x)chartr(Reduce(paste0,names(sort(-table(strsplit(x,""))))),'a-z',x)` (70), `\(x)chartr(gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)","",x,pe=T),"a-j",x)` (50)

Comment: @pajonk wow I didn't know that - although now I read the docs again I can see that although the explanation of the parameters doesn't mention it explicitly, the capability is used in some examples. That's awesome, I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Note that in the regex answer doesn't actually assign ```a```-```j``` to characters in the order they appear; it assigns them in the order of their *last* appearance.  If it was indeed in the order they appear the output score would be about 103, not 117 (but the overall score would still be 5150, so worse than the output-optimized versions...).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I did realise that that was the order but I didn't think it much mattered. I don't understand why it should make a difference to the score - whether `"a"` is assigned to the first emoji that appears, or the emoji whose final character appears first, it's just assigned randomly isn't it? Just seen your answer btw - very nice!

Comment: By assigning in order of last appearance, you're more-likely to assign ```a``` to emojis that only appear once, since those that appear several times will likely have a last appearance that is later.  As a result, multiply-appearing emojis will be biased to receive higher-valued letters.  I think...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks! I hadn't thought about it like that but of course that makes sense - so we just need to reverse the replacement string to `"jihgfedcba"` to get a much better score. I've updated the answer as that was a real revelation to me but I'd better stop as my answer seems to be taking up half the page - and yet none of the approaches can compete with yours!

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score 90.24 * 13 bytes = 1173.12

```
⭆θ§β⌕Φθ⁼μ⌕θλι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBTqKDiWeOalpFZoJOkouGXmpWi4ZeaUpBaBZFwLSxNzijVyoRJAkRxNTU0dhUwgqWn9//@H@dMnf5g/s//D/MnTIXjSbojY5PYP82ctgtAg/oROCA3DyPKTZiD0gzBIfsYqmJr/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FrcYjRyLizPT8zQMdBQyNK250vKLFDRCMnNTizUMgUKGBgYGmpoK1VycUGXBJUWZeem-iQUaRqY6CkGJeSn5uRpKH-ZPn_xh_sz-D_MnT_8wf9JuIN3-Yf6sRR_mT-gE8md8mD9j1Yf5fZ1Kmpo6CoVAa2DGuWXmlKQWaRTqKLgWlibmFGvk6Ci4ZealgESyNUGqq5BUIywHSjuWeOalpFZoJEF1VMF0gM0HKoJoCspMzyjRCMgpLdZRCC7N1YDqBmtJgmkB-byWKwBoeomGc2JxiYZLZllmSqpGho4CelhoalovKU5KLoYG4PJoJd2yHKVYKBcA) Link is to test suite for `10000` random iterations. Explanation: Outputs the letter corresponding to the first time this emoji was found in the input. Note that the code is too slow for the test suite so it had to be optimised slightly.

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score 287 * 6 bytes = 1722

```
⭆θ§β℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBTqKDiWeOalpFZoJOko@BelZOYl5mhkagKB9f//H@ZPn/xh/sz@D/MnT4fgSbshYpPbP8yftQhCg/gTOiE0DCPLT5qB0A/CIPkZq2Bq/uuW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FrcYWRyLizPT8zQMdBQyNK250vKLFDRCMnNTizUMgUKGBgYGmpoK1VycUGXBJUWZeem-iQUaRqY6CkGJeSn5uRpKH-ZPn_xh_sz-D_MnT_8wf9JuIN3-Yf6sRR_mT-gE8md8mD9j1Yf5fZ1Kmpo6CoVAazCNK9RRcCzxzEtJrdBI0lHwL0rJzEvM0cjWhOsAKoJoCspMzyjRCMgpLdZRCC7N1YDqdsvMSwFphWgB-aWWKwBoeomGc2JxiYZLZllmSqpGho4Cuu80Na2XFCclF0ODZHm0km5ZjlIslAsA) Link is to test suite for `10000` random iterations. Explanation: Outputs the letter corresponding to the emoji's ordinal modulo `26`.

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score 73.275 * 25 bytes = 1831.875

```
Ｗ⁻⪪θ¹υ⊞υ⊟⌈Ｅι⟦№ικκ⟧⭆θ§β⌕υι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDNzOvtFgjuCAns0SjUEfBUFNHoVRTUyGgtDhDo1RHISC/QMM3sSIztzQXSBdoZOooRDvnl@aVgFjZQMXZsZpAYM0VUJQJFAwuAVLpIIVAsxxLPPNSUis0knQU3DLzUkDGZYIV////Yf70yR/mz@z/MH/ydAietBsiNrn9w/xZiyA0iD@hE0LDMLL8pBkI/SAMkp@xCqbmv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBSgMxEIbx2D5F2NMEUtgKgtBTqQgeCkvrrfSw7W67odlsd5PUgniWXlTsodUeUkRRfAXfxKfIIziLqwcxl-SfzPzfz-zexklYjLNQ7PcvRk8ax58HUVspPpXgM5LQVn2SFQTOeRoraGKp6fs-peSyXqva-rrgctoN53B4xEgvlFGWgufsZu3sw62z642z9x94Xzv7-OTs3Qr11tntu7M3K49SRnLE1C4SLmICXS6Ngv5ccA054vDbIC8wKgHDSJDNoRsueWpSKJkzRgadzEhdvgQ2iyHF0_onHrq19ZmM4iWMGDnlMioNZ_Q3QTUxGJZI1Dj0XerxaaIhEEYx0q_AeWUx-rEod3VVD5CmoRMqDSd8waMYEkb-bg_zPavRWFUrfx14jYXwhpX8Ag) Link is to test suite for `10000` random iterations. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻⪪θ¹υ⊞υ⊟⌈Ｅι⟦№ικκ⟧
```

Sort the characters by frequency in descending order.

```
⭆θ§β⌕υι
```

Map them to lowercase letters.

Comment: The modulo attempt is nifty! Drastically reducing programming size at the cost of a slightly higher average value pays off pretty well. I wonder if a programming language exists in which the algorithm could be implemented in only 1 or 2 bytes, which would put the program's score in the vicinity of the current bests, despite a 3x average value.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Best I could do in 05AB1E is 4 bytes: `ÇAsè`, so its score would be worse.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 112.5 * 34 bytes = 3825

```r
\(x)letters[utf8ToInt(x)%%430%%11]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHa1LzkosqCktTc_KxM26WlJWm6FjeVYjQqNHNSS0pSi4qjgUIWIfmeeSVAMVVVE2MDVVVDw1iIyluMIsj6NZQ-zJ8--cP8mf0f5k-e_mH-pN1Auv3D_FmLPsyf0Ankz_gwf8aqD_P7OpU0uUrySxJzbA24ihLzUopLijLz0m1jNDQLEotLUg00ihNzC3JSNVJzNIBSxQU5mSUkmK2jpKSpqWNkqlOUWpCTmJxqGxIU6qqpk5yfk5NYUJxqC5TmSssv0shUyMxTMLQyNAACTYhzwKR2cWku0AUFBTmVGijeQzhVA2gBPGA0dS3NNa3BWvXBhkECZ8ECCA0A)

Output is a vector of characters in the range `"a"` to `"j"`.

Developed independently of, but uses similar approach to [Arnauld's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264464/95126).

The aim here is to maximally golf the code-size, while keeping the encrypted letters in the range `a`-`j` (but ignoring their abundances in the input).
We find the modulo values to map the emoji character codes to `1:10` using:

```
x=utf8ToInt("")
for(i in 1:max(x))for(j in 1:99){y=unique(x%%i%%j);if(min(y)==1&&max(y)==10&&length(y)==10)print(c(i,j))}
```

which pretty quickly outputs `430 11` and nothing else.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 112.5 * 39 bytes = 4387.5

```r
\(x)intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(x)%%430%%11+96)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHa1LzkosqCktTc_KxM26WlJWm6FjfVYzQqNDPzSkLyQ0vSLDSAghYh-Z55JUBRVVUTYwNVVUNDbUszTYjyW4xyyIZoKH2YP33yh_kz-z_Mnzz9w_xJu4F0-4f5sxZ9mD-hE8if8WH-jFUf5vdB2QispMlVkl-SmGNrwFWUmJdSXFKUmZduG6OhWZBYXJJqoFGcmFuQk6qRmqMBlCouyMksId4uJR0lJU1NHSNTnaLUgpzE5FTbkKBQV02d5PycnMSC4lRboDRXWn6RRqZCZp6CoZWhARBoQpwDJrWLS3ORQgLFxwjXamhqaupammtag_Xog03hggTTggUQGgA)

As above, but outputs as a single string (same as [SamR's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264425/95126)).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 73.2 * 61 bytes = 4465.2

```r
\(x)intToUtf8(rank(-table(y<-el(strsplit(x,""))),,"f")[y]+96)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZCxTsMwEIbFmodAlaez6ogUCUiBjAysqJ2AwQQHGZzYsl2peQLEAogOLTA4ILEg8QQ8CTyFHwErQWrZOMn327Luv-_u-UU3H6zKda0sK-Ulz94mtojTr-wEpphXdiTHtkhB0-oKYkvPBIN6P2YCjNVGCW5hShDCGBOCCoSP69P-cBt3Jt9r66vWgLybz7x7vPNuNvfu4TPotXdPr97d34T3wrvFu3e3v_flQTiy0lKRJVEAOQ-teXURCLGixrIEDC1VAFul-ncv1OKTzS2imRI0Z9noaHyASS6FoMqwLHxHhdTAe7zqDXYHSQjc4bS5byYlhHnTkTysLPyZeEkLYUXxcAfvtTUbrUvUralpOv0B)

Minimizing the output string value at the expense of code-size doesn't seem to pay-off.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 90.0438 * 31 bytes = 2,791.3578

```ruby
->s{s.tr s.chars.uniq*'','a-z'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboW-3XtiquL9UqKFIr1kjMSi4r1SvMyC7XU1XXUE3Wr1Gshqm4xhhaUlhQrpEUrfZg_ffKH-TP7P8yfPB2CJ-2GiE1u_zB_1iIIDeJP6ITQMIwsP2kGQj8Ig-RnrIKpUYrl4krNzc_KVLBVQLMQZBnMIJAFIINAGvs6lSDu5wI7VMNQT8_QAAg09YpLc6sVajJrFLgUilKLS3NKgIamRYMUGJlq6uUmFlSDrdIrTswtyEmt1cvKz8yL5VIIDnFxDQrSA5umlJlXlpiTmaKQn6dQVJqnoFydWWsFJCHm1SopZKbBza5T0I-OAwZdrD7MPr2kypLUYrA74g11Lc1ruWr1wW7TM4CE7oIFEBoA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73.1206 * 53 bytes = 3,875.3918

```ruby
->s{s.tr s.chars.uniq.sort_by{-s.count(_1)}*'','a-z'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLTsMwEBXbnGIUFmkRmTZIFR-prOACBVYhVAkkwlWTlNhGKqnZom4ANYsWWKTis-EKnAROkSMQxwogLD2PPJ_3nufpNeHeePkSdI_fOAvMrc-OuUtTiiwBiqfnbkKRR-QCaZywvjdOzTIb84g1-lZTrBnGuuGaV4ZQw18rRyPOKAS2XuTzrMgf7oo8myvMPlQuuynyx2cV5ft-qmKNv_XZ4ndeQtYX73WP7miaH8YDAl34JyjFaiIpIInk4O1UV7_SKqMNC9Fql6eJlIcpTMgENEh8yoesJA1s2bDRaWLojtJKCqkbjoa-wEFMIkeDg8O9_V4PKzadRJfukJxBHEHCI1hNidgpb8UndCDBD_c1tOyTcnVOq9ZDb8x8WvnoW-b2ptBEq_KGbbXd5VLFbw)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES5), score: 112.346 * 62 bytes = 6965.433

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/../g,e=>(e.charCodeAt(1)%576%11+9).toString(36))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVO9btswEB666Q26nQUnJuOathM4_ZWBIGi2ooOBLoZbKxJlM5BJg6ITJ4ayFlnSIh6StoONoF36Cn2S9in8CCVFKXEigDjx7uN3H--OP35yEdLlbeT9mqio9uJve-q1p0TScewHFNUJqQ-eUa-NKAmGvtzX4D2Fmnij9Xx3o9msvsREiY6SjA_Qzi7GluXfk6eB4ImIKYnFAEXIXS2u56vFty-rxfzarqs_1jf_vFp8v7XW7L9eWFus9fjVzf15s0z85neBcTF2nLFIEnYY07cjccQS8KBLCOH0BDpUPZZhJBT0Jq2hN3SXFy7uOU5MFSSBkFSzNJxISEDGxcz2tTZvoNnQn_6tVjHMHADGxxOlwybfnpT-KdpuYRKxOEYNTEb-GH3y2g8Vds_P0TtfDYn0eShGCG81G7iHyZFgHFUqWLNKmkxiQxuhLIG-JYCpr9aSfPBjFupYqWRhOosKhqj-sevXznrVch3D5mYhzPNysrUG6_4CMr3F4LWzamXgXjdHMh7S6fvIQnpGD4sAlfLMGNRQihPoM36cKdG6jqlMmOAQSTECtzzL-FIXlDA7S5u6fXOLu6IKW1Shi7rd0raoKOQdqN4pXxtDgaEGFb-y7msYhamTOo6tUKDdHXZmehjdjyomMeUDNXTWx7SfpXoF5RmySeu2wWbED9iUhmgHp7Cl4wVpCoenipope3xGwwrQg-P9_IUsl9b-Bw) A simple hashing method; optimized for the specific emoji specified in the challenge.

## JavaScript (ES6), score: 73.152 * 109 bytes = 7973.590

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/./gu,e=>"abcdefghij"[[...new Set(x)].sort((a,b,c=e=>x.split(e).length)=>c(b)-c(a)).indexOf(e)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVPNbtNAED5w8xtwm1hRM9skm7SoEgIcqUJwQxwicYkCcex1vJXjjdabNm3kXlEvgJpDCxwSVXDhFXgSeIo8ArveuCSNtJrs_HzftzPj7z9SEbLVXeT9nKqo-fTPeOZ1ZlSySeIHDFu0NZo2mNdx_WEQsmgU8xO316OUpuwMukzhjPRpJqRC9BvDRuAxU55NEq6QEZqwdKRi4nUCHJJmgD4hlKchm72NdLhPLOnfR48DkWYiYTQRI4zQXS9vFuvl18_r5eLGnuvf1rf4uF5-u7PW3L9cWVue7fj17f96c0z89leZ4xLiOBORZXyYsFdjccIz8GD7bQ9kGAklvKE18Abu05VL-o6TMAVZICTTKG0nEhLQuLi5PtfmBRy09U__rdcJzB0Ank6mSocN37GU_jkeHhEa8STBNqFjf4IfvM6uwt7lJb7xVUyln4ZijGT_oK37SE8ET7FWIxpVsmyaGNgICwL9SgDTX60le-cnPNSxSsWmaRYVxNh63_ObF_16tUVgb68U5nkbsJ19aAAGsS8JeJ2iW0Vyv7fJLKdbpPSNHh4BVjbMBFQsxRkMeHpaKNG6TpnMuEghkmIMbnVe4OUuKGFuFjZ3B-YV900VtqlCN_XwSNuyo7CZQP1eudHxUq_4sUJBoAk1v7btaxuFuZM7ju1QoN1dfmFmGFElukrydITlIjvbazooqJ5BdY6WtGUHTHTdaz5jIT4hOezreAmaw_BcMbNlD2t0Wpm0Uz7YfCGrlbX_AA) A more generic approach, which sorts the input's unique characters (code points) to minimize the value per run.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), score 103.6078*101 bytes = 10464,3878

assigns the characters in alphabetical order

```python
lambda l:''.join(chr(97+[x for(x,_)in groupby(sorted(l))].index(c))for c in l)
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRSsMwFIbxNk9x6M0St9UqiDrok8xRujbtIm1T0lS6J5DdqKzIJl60IPNC8Al8Er30CfYIJqbDscDhkHPOn_Plf3nL53LGs_Y1cq83pYyGl1808dNp6EMy6vXsG84yHMwEvrrojyuIuMDVwCMsg1jwMp_OccGFpCFOCJnYLAtphQNC1BwEoKYSgiLBU2CSCsl5UgBLc6U4Nsu-j7xcsEziCFvbZlVvm-eHbVOvTCw_Ta2--_l40slcHxcm72KvvVz_q3Xo9vq9G7EIQcisB-FnIU-Rf0uFH1PXQZrY08SqE1PsDE4ddcgIgSrmpfQKqUBjcGHninnCDmacBfQQX6N3XBpXc2mO-4VF4GDV2bniAuCldCO8v0tXO8C-W5QpHnMRKneHOll-99KfzUo8IchY2UlOzAeMz21r8i8)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), score 73.2 * 136 bytes = 9955,2

*-21 bytes, thanks to @Value Ink*

always produces a string with the lowest possible average byte value

```python
lambda l:''.join(chr(97+[x for(_,x)in sorted([(-len([*n]),c)for(c,n)in groupby(sorted(l))])].index(c))for c in l)
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRSsMwFIbxNk8RerNk6-YURB30SWopXZp2lTYpaSrbE-huVDZkEy82GHoh-AQ-iV76BHsEc0yHY4HDIef8J-fL__JWTvRIivUm8a5ea510L77u8qgYxhHOB61W71pmgrCRIpfnHX-ME6lI6I5pJnAlleYx8Uk354L4bRFQl1EQMFeAIFWyLocT0ghzSgMa9DIR8zFhFJSYYaPLKUqULHCmudJS5hXOitLMtC3P91FYqkxokhBnu1rMt6vnh-1qvrAx-7S1-e3PxxMke32c2ryLvfZs-T8NAe3leyNxKEXIrscqErEsUHTDVZRyr4-AOARi00k56bsnfXPoAGFTLGsdVtqAptjDO-PsEz02khnjh_iA3nABLnABx_3Uofhg1emZ4cJY1tpLyP4uqDaAHa-qC-JLFRt3u5CcqHnpz2YzHFBkrWxGju0HrM_rtc2_)

Comment: Theres an error in the output (check 9th character) it should be `b` not `e`

Comment: The character ⭕️ in the input consist of two Unicode code-points ('⭕' 11093 and '️' 65039), handling this case will be difficult, I suggest replacing that character with a single code-point character

Comment: oh Thanks! I'll change it to 

Comment: It seems like ⭕ is a single character but for some reason the string contained a "variant-selector character" after it.

Comment: after changing that your code works perfectly! with the score 12435.1379

Comment: Second answer [136 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDRSsMwFIbxNk8RerNk6-YURB30SWopXZp2lTYpaSrbE-huVDZkEy82GHoh-AQ-iV76BHsEc0yHY4HDIef8J-fL__JWTvRIivUm8a5ea510L77u8qgYxhHOB61W71pmgrCRIpfnHX-ME6lI6I5pJnAlleYx8Uk354L4bRFQl1EQMFeAIFWyLocT0ghzSgMa9DIR8zFhFJSYYaPLKUqULHCmudJS5hXOitLMtC3P91FYqkxokhBnu1rMt6vnh-1qvrAx-7S1-e3PxxMke32c2ryLvfZs-T8NAe3leyNxKEXIrscqErEsUHTDVZRyr4-AOARi00k56bsnfXPoAGFTLGsdVtqAptjDO-PsEz02khnjh_iA3nABLnABx_3Uofhg1emZ4cJY1tpLyP4uqDaAHa-qC-JLFRt3u5CcqHnpz2YzHFBkrWxGju0HrM_rtc2_) by reversing each element of the list comp to eliminate the `key` argument

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 89.8656 * 30 bytes = 2695.968

```
dup""uniq $abc","zip >M swap :
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Uses a very simple index-based mapping.

For testing purposes:

```
10000=$n.
""=$e.
$W ( ; S>c 97- +/ ) map $n tk +/ $n / n>o
$W ( $e "."/?& :r ) map 25tk dup >o " => ">o ; dup n>o
dup""uniq $abc","zip >M swap :
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
dup () uniq $abc \, zip >M swap :
```

- `dup () uniq` get unique emojis
- `$abc \, zip` pair emoji with alphabet to create translation map
- `swap :` translate emojis to alphabet

---

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 73.147 * 50 bytes = 3657.35

```
""Q""group"len _"sort $abc"0.: dip ,"zip >M swap :
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Uses frequency-based mapping.

For testing purposes:

```
10000=$n.
""=$e.
$W ( ; S>c 97- +/ ) map $n tk +/ $n / n>o
$W ( $e "."/?& :r ) map 25tk dup >o " => ">o ; dup n>o
""Q""group"len _"sort $abc"0.: dip ,"zip >M swap :
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
dup () group ( len _ ) sort $abc ( 0.: dip , ) zip >M swap :
```

- `() group` group emojis
- `( len _ ) sort` sort descending by frequency
- `$abc ( 0.: dip , ) zip >M` pair emoji with alphabet to create translation map
- `swap :` translate emojis to alphabet

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 107.3917 * 38 bytes = 4080.8846

```python
lambda x:[97+ord(c)%3203%13for c in x]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBdSgMxEMfxNacIgdqEfrjtImphT1JLifst7mZNs1JPIH1R6SKt-LALRR8ET-BJ9NET7BFMOiuWBoY_ycz855d5ectuVSTSahM456-5CnqnX4dXPLnwOJ6PxmcnHSE96rKWPbTs1sAOhMQujlM8n0D198F1JuNU0YCSulwVdfn8UJfFCmL5CW_F3c_HkxG4Pi5A_2InvVz_d5sw6fV7U0IYQyhOMiEVljz1RIL4jS956DsWMmhTg6YzoU-t7sDSh40Q1o9ZrqYzpUFD7OB2u38p4pSCRd-NROz6-_gGveEyuIbLcNwvCMN7o4bHmgtjkSuHELBOeEbdSHYDujubbesa5I4zyxM6hv32jBDeeG83rO0mDMFym5Yj-BJsvqpAfwE)

Outputs as a list of codepoints. Scoring script taken from bsoelch's answer.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 101.9159 * 61 bytes = 6216.870

```python
lambda x:x.translate(dict(zip(map(ord,set(x)),"abcdefghij")))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBSsQwFIZxm1OEbibBTq2CIAM5iUrJpEmbYdqUNpXqBWQ2KlNkRly0ILoQPIEn0aUn6BFMSMVhAo-fvJf3vy_v-a241qnK-xdBLl5rLaZnX2RJs3lMYTNrAl3SvFpSzVEsmUY3skAZLZAqY7_iGjUY-x6ds5iLJJULD2PsTL4PoqKUuUYCeUO3aYfu6X7o2o2L9afLtbc_H49W3PVh5fQvdsrr7X-3DVvevo9PzFgAZFaoUkPDG6sM0Cte0oSTEAhVwgjK3FYSjkL_ODQHzwA0yaLWUaUNaAIJnEyChZI5chYBS5VkfB_foo9cFtdyWY67lYfh3qiTU8MFoao1EWh3ls2OgIekqjN0bvaJGJ5a8ejoxKyTab7EwK1ybDlyH3B77nunvw)

Outputs as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 112.5 * 24 bytes = 2700

Expects and returns a list of code points.

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>n%430%11+96)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/NSsNAEIDveYqhULJr6jTxD6QmUHoWBI@lyJLmryS7YXcRRD1LLyr20Oql4NFX8KX6BnE27uGbZWb225mVuBcm1VVrj6VaZl0edyJOBDaiZTJO5PDsNBxGUXB5wbtUSWMhLYWGGAaH/XYzPuw/3wibLeHj191eCF/fhPe1y@0Iux/C63qApq0ry/yxzyeelyvN6syCJFk4oXAFkYtBwOHRA3A1Q7U5Ik61Fg/s5Jwv@sHuIE76OebXwpaohVyqhnE46pNYZ7KwJTxBuOC4UpVkvs9HpHRHZ06aM6c1/7q012FK@99Qt51axjmNCOA2VnWGtSqYGcGt1ZUsMNeqmdFHM3rASENK1/7c/QE)

This version uses a fixed mapping of the smileys to `abcdefghij`.

The theoretical average score is:

$$\frac{25}{10}\sum_{n=0}^9 n=112.5$$

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), ~90 * 50 bytes = ~4500

```javascript
s=>s.replace(e=/../g,c=>Buffer([e[c]||=i++]),i=97)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVHRSsMwFMXXfsVlIEtsl9aBzDEzmD77BaNIydKt0jUl7UCxPsteVNzDpj5sDH3xF_wS_Yp9gjeNiHk4uTk395zcm9e3TI3kZhvz91kZt46_2gXvF0zLPI2EJJL7jPljT_D-6SyOpSZDORRhVfHEdUPqJbzbobbye-9KqKwoQUwiDRwau_Vy4e_Wzw8IiyXC06eJ7hBetgiPc8OtEFYfCPfzBivyNClJ02_SnpPKEkpVRilqBT3HiZUmhsvqM24ncBjgwtB1Kdw4ACZdYHrIGBtoHV2T9hEN2TTKyQXwfv2y4XlUTpiOspGaEgoHKAIVBCFllyrJSNNYWyUtjVZMij-mEErLX33MhgijGU6J5B4IahxycEEw43OGYx2U6NCCbseDoBax_bjcKhkmg_26DagqMONTqWSpGpPCM_6evYi1t87_rNXx7QBoz37AZmP3Hw)

This version uses a dynamic mapping of the smileys to `abcdefghij`, according to their order of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 89.9 * 67 bytes = 6022.9

```
=LET(c,MID(A2,ROW(1:25)*2-1,2),CONCAT(CHAR(96+MATCH(c,UNIQUE(c),0))))
```

This does not optimize for the lowest character sum because doing so in Excel takes so many bytes that the overall score ends up higher. The formula is written for the input (the 25 random emojis) to be in the cell `A2`. To simulate 10,000 runs, I wrote a formula to generate those random string, copied it down for 10,000 rows, then copy / pasted values. The encrypted results are on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/cpBsczfP) and the end result in Excel look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Note: When I copy / pasted down the formula from `B2`, I changed the row reference to be absolute (`$1:$25`) so it would work on all the rows below the original formula.

---

Explanation:

- `LET(c,MID(A2,ROW(1:25)*2-1,2)` defines the variable `c` to be an array with one emoji per row. It's a little tricky to pull out only because Excel sees these emojis as being 2 characters long so need to pull out strings of length 2.
- `CONCAT(CHAR(96+MATCH(c,UNIQUE(c),0)))`

  - `UNIQUE(c)` filters for just the unique emojis
  - `MATCH(c,UNIQUE(c),0)` finds the first instance of each emoji within that unique list
  - `CHAR(96+MATCH(~))` converts that match value into a character in the range `a-j`
  - `CONCAT(CHAR(~))` combines all those characters into one string

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), score 73.2 * 110 bytes = 8052.0

```haskell
import Data.List
j(Just x)=x
f s=map(toEnum.(97+).j.(`elemIndex`(map head$sortOn((0-).length)$group$sort s)))s
```

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), score 90.1 * 72 bytes = 6487.2

```haskell
import Data.List
j(Just x)=x
f s=map(toEnum.(97+).j.(`elemIndex`nub s))s
```