# Output the happy primes

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, primes

**Input:** n

**Output:** A list of length n, with each element being the nth happy prime.

Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number either equals 1, or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. A happy number is a number for which this process ends in 1.

A happy prime is a number that is both happy and prime.

For example, if the input is 5, the output should be the list

[7, 13, 19, 23, 31]

Shortest answer wins!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The challenge should include a definition of "happy prime" in the text, and optionally a link

Comment: Happy number/prime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Happy_prime. I think the challenge should include that information.

Comment: I have edited appropriately :)

Comment: This just combines a [primality test](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/194) with [testing for happy numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2245/194). I won't cast a supervote, but IMO it is a duplicate of the second question, since primality testing is standard and often offered as a builtin.

Comment: I voted to close as a dupe of the happy number challenges. Besides the dupe issue, challenges to check for the AND of two unrelated conditions usually split into checking each condition separately, which feels like two separate challenges.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I agree with the close vote for the reasons xnor stated (but won't use the mod hammer either). But please don't be disheartened by that. Writing good challenges is hard and knowing what has already been done by the community also is. You can post challenge ideas [in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) where you can get feedback from experienced users and iron out the details before the challenge goes live. I hope you'll stick around! :)

Comment: Don't we close questions as subset? But this case is a superset..

Comment: @LeakyNun I think it's more of a case of whether the subset or the superset makes more sense

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try not to be too brokenhearted over this one :P. The sandbox sounds very useful, I'll use that in the future.